# Draw a BCD Binary clock

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, date

Create a BCD [binary clock](http://www.thinkgeek.com/homeoffice/lights/59e0/)
in ASCII. As implied, it shall display time in six columns of dots:

[image: Binary Clock]
<sub>(source: [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Binary_clock.svg))</sub>

Each column is a binary-coded digit, reading hours, minutes and seconds 
from left to right. Hours are given in 24-hour format.

The time to display is read from the command-line or from stdin (whichever 
fits better). If empty, the current time should be used instead.

Output size is a little constrained here and we can only fit two lines of 
text. So you are required to put the dots into only two lines. The 
characters `.`, `:` and `'` come in handy here.

**Input**

The time to display in ISO-8601 format, i.e. `HH:MM:SS` without fractional 
seconds. Mandatory 24-hour format. Input can be empty in which case the 
current time will be used.

**Output**

Two lines with represent the BCD binary clock as in the image above. Each 
line is exactly six characters long and the only allowed characters are 
space, period, colon and apostrophe.

**Winner**

Shortest code by byte count wins. In a tie, the solution posted first wins.

**Sample input 1**

*(empty)*

**Sample output 1**

```
     .
''. ::
```

**Sample input 2**

```
17:59:20
```

**Sample output 2**

```
 ..'  
.:..'
```

**Sample input 3**

```
01:08:01
```

**Sample output 3**

```
   '  
 .   .
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Golfscript (+ruby/date) - 46 chars

```
"#{`date`}"10>+9<" .':":S-.{4/12-S=}%n@{4%S=}%
```

You can replace `` `date` `` with `Time.now` if necessary (+2 chars).

Comment: I knew it was hopeless to even try Golfscripting ;-)

Answer (score 5):

### Ruby, <del>107 103 99 94</del> 90 characters

```
$><<[$/,(gets||Time.now.to_s[11,8]).tr(z=" .':","").bytes.map{|a|$><<z[a/4-12];z[a%4]}]*""
```

Note that the input shouldn't contain a linebreak, so to test the solution use something like `echo -n "01:08:01" | ruby1.9 bcd.rb`.

To test the default behavior, run it with `ruby1.9 bcd.rb` and enter `^D` (i.e. a literal EOF).

Comment: There's no such thing as a literal EOF! :-)

Comment: You can shave off 4 characters with `Time.now.to_s[11,8]`.

Answer (score 3):

### Windows PowerShell, 81

Since I did not create an implementation when writing the task I feel myself eligible to golf it from the start, too :-)

```
-join" .':
"[(($d="$(date)$args"[-8..-1]-ne58)|%{($_-band12)/4})+,4+($d|%{$_%4})]
```

History:

- 2011-02-26 23:50 **(119)** First attempt.
- 2011-02-26 23:55 **(108)** Inlining fun.
- 2011-02-27 00:03 **(102)** Optimized selecting the first line. `[Math]::Floor` is waaaayy too long. I hate that.
- 2011-02-27 02:22 **(101)** I don't need `:` for the first line.
- 2011-02-27 02:53   **(95)** Optimized getting input or current time.
- 2011-03-04 20:36   **(88)** Only a single join remains. Indexing every character needed (including the line break) from a single string.
- 2011-03-04 20:39   **(83)** Using `58` instead of `:` which auto-casts to integer as well – no more need to enclose `$_` in quotes :-)
- 2011-03-04 20:42   **(81)** The parentheses after the `-join` are no longer necessary.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 21 bytes

```
o7ŒT¤fØDV€d4Zị“.': ”Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATIAzf9qZWxsef//bzfFklTCpGbDmERW4oKsZDRa4buL4oCcLic6IOKAnVn///8xNzo1OToyMA)

For the empty input, you can use either an empty string or no argument at all.

### Explanation

```
o7ŒT¤fØDV€d4Zị“.': ”Y   Main monadic or niladic link
o                       Logical or (Python-like)
 7ŒT¤                     Current time in hh:mm:ss format
     f                  Filter
      ØD                  Digits
         €              Each
        V                 Evaluate
          d             Divmod
           4              4
            Z           Zip
             ị          Index into [1-indexed, auto-maps]
              “.': ”      ".': "
                    Y   Join with newlines
```

Comment: Didn't know jelly had a time function. Too bad there's none in Husk.

Answer (score 2):

## C#

#### 236 characters

```
using System;using System.Linq;class X{static void Main(){var d=Console.In.ReadToEnd().Replace(":","");for(int i=0;i<2;i++)Console.WriteLine(string.Join("",(d==""?DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss"):d).Select(c=>" .':"[i<1?c/4-12:c%4])));}}
```

Readable:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
class X
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var d = Console.In.ReadToEnd().Replace(":", "");
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("",
                (d == "" ? DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss") : d)
                .Select(c => " .':"[i < 1 ? c / 4 - 12 : c % 4])));
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need to do `- 48` when you are doing `% 4`, as `48 % 4 == 0`

Comment: @Dogbert: Brilliant, thank you! That also gave me the idea that `c/4-12` is shorter than `(c-48)/4`... :)

Comment: You can delete a lot of spaces and tabs too which would get rid of a lot of characters, also think about using the new top level code feature of c#

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby - 124 chars

```
t=*((i=gets)=="
"? Time.now.strftime('%H%M%S'):i).tr(':
','').bytes
puts (0..1).map{|i|t.map{|_|" .':"[i<1? _/4-12:_%4]}*''}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Golfscript (+ Ruby), 63

```
."#{Time.now.strftime'%T'}"if':'-:|{4/12-" .':":@\=}%n|{4%@\=}%
```

Still a beginner with Golfscript. Don't hit me.

Comment: There's a few things to shorten (see my answer). Specific to what you have at the moment that isn't in my answer -- brackets can be omitted from ruby function calls, `""` coerces to false so you can remove ``,\``.

Comment: @Nabb: Thanks. Well, Ventero already told me he had it down to 63, though I couldn't bring him to tell me how ;-). Still, dragging Ruby into this through the string interpolation feels like cheating, somehow. I think I'll stay with my preferred language below and just try to beat Ruby :-)

Comment: well since the question required access to the current time, it's not really possible without resorting to ruby anyway

Comment: @gnibbler: I know. Still, it's the only really unportable feature of Golfscript and I don't particularly like using it due to that ;-)

Answer (score 2):

### Perl (84)

```
#!perl -pl
$_||=localtime;y/://d;/\d{6}/;$_=$&;y/0-9/    ....''/;$_.="\n$&";y/0-9/ .': .': ./
```

Comment: You can save one character by changing `"\n$&"` to `$/.$&` — common Perl-golf trick :)

Comment: @Timwi I could use a real newline there :)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 136 chars

```
import time
d=input()
for i in(0,1):print(''.join([" .':"[[c>>2,c&3][i]]for c in map(int,d.replace(':','')or time.strftime('%H%M%S'))]))
```

Comment: I get 137 when I do a `wc -c`. Good work tho. +1

Answer (score 2):

### VimScript, 143 characters

```
if getline(1)==''
norm"=strftime("%T")^Mp
en
nm- "ax"=@a/4^MgP
nm, "ax"=@a%4^MgP
norm0YP--x--x--xP^M,,x,,x,,xP
%s/0/ /g
%s/1/./g
%s/2/'/g
%s/3/:/g
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <sup><s>45</s></sup> 42 bytes

```apl
' .'':'[4 4⊤{×≢⍵:⍎¨⍵~':'⋄,⍉0 10⊤3↑3↓⎕TS}⍞]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qG@qp/@jtgkGXI862tP@qyvoqatbqUebKJg86lpSfXj6o85Fj3q3Wj3q7Tu0AsioA0o@6m7RedTbaaBgaABUY/yobSIQTwYaFBJc@6h3Xux/oEn/07gMza1MLa2MgAb3TQVaoK7OlcZlYGhlYGFlYIgsxgUA)

A full program submission.

-3 bytes from Bubbler.

Very barely edges out Golfscript (Thanks, Bubbler!).

### Explanation

```apl
' .'':'[4 4⊤⍎¨{×≢⍵:⍵~':'⋄,⍉ 0 10⊤3↑3↓⎕TS}⍞]
                                        ⍞    string input
              {×≢⍵:                          if length is nonzero:
                   ⍵~':'                     remove ':'s from it
                        ⋄            ⎕TS     otherwise get current time array
                                 3↑3↓        remove yymmdd and take hhmmss
                         ,⍉ 0 10⊤            convert to base 10 digits and transpose, then flatten
                                             (pads with a zero)
            ⍎¨                               convert each character to digit
        4 4⊤                                 encode into base 4 matrix
' .'':'[                                   ] index into string " .':"
```

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, <s>232</s> 165 characters

```js
t=>(a=t.match(/\d/g).map(x=>(+x).toString(2)).flatMap(x=>x.padStart(4).match(/..?/g)).map(x=>" .':"[x%4])).filter((_,i)=>~i&1).join``+`
`+a.filter((_,i)=>i%2).join``
```

## Snippet

(modified because i dont count console.log() and the function assignment/call in the byte count)

```js
f=

// 215
t=>(a=t.match(/\d/g).map(x=>(+x).toString(2)).flatMap(x=>x.padStart(4).match(/..?/g)).map(x=>" .':"[x%4])).filter((_,i)=>~i&1).join``+`
`+a.filter((_,i)=>i%2).join``

console.log(f('17:59:20'))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <strike>192</strike> <strike>180</strike> <strike>174</strike> 166 bytes

-21 characters thanks to @Laikoni

```hs
import Data.Time
main=getCurrentTime>>=interact.(\x y->unlines[map(!!i)[mapM(pure" .':")"__"!!(fromEnum e-48)|e<-take 8$y++formatTime undefined"%T"x,e<':']|i<-[0,1]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY1BC4IwGEDv/Yo5ChWdZBTZUC/VsZs3Exn5WUM3ZW6g4H@37PZ4h/c@bGigbZeFi75TGt2YZkHGBWwE4zJ5g74apUDq1aVpwqUGxV46cJ4jmkhqZMslDLlgvWNZ3F3h4fRGAUaBTbGLyxJbllOrTtylEQjIMXJniIlmDaBoO3le3SnB/gNkZAX1L1jhXYZHH2Kb2sXMY5Lv/bAo3GUJz/R0oYfwCw)

Comment: @Laikoni thank you! i noticed the transpose+unlines can be made shorter too

Comment: Even shorter transpose: `(\x y->(++).(++"\n").map(!!0)<*>map(!!1)$[ ... ])` can be `(\x y->unlines[map(!!i)[ ... ]|i<-[0,1]])`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY1BC4IwGEDv/Yo5ChWdZBTZUC/VsZs3Exn5WUM3ZW6g4H@37PZ4h/c@bGigbZeFi75TGt2YZkHGBWwE4zJ5g74apUDq1aVpwqUGxV46cJ4jmkhqZMslDLlgvWNZ3F3h4fRGAUaBTbGLyxJbllOrTtylEQjIMXJniIlmDaBoO3le3SnB/gNkZAX1L1jhXYZHH2Kb2sXMY5Lv/bAo3GUJz/R0oYfwCw "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

### Python - <strike>201</strike> 172 characters

```
from time import*
t=raw_input()
if not t:t=strftime('%H:%M:%S')
t=t.replace(':','')
for i in(0,2):print''.join(" .':"[int(bin(int(d))[2:].rjust(4,'0')[i:i+2],2)]for d in t)
```

Comment: How about: `t=raw_input().replace(':','')` / `if not t:t=strftime('%H%M%S')` — saves you 5 characters :)

Answer (score 1):

**Lua - <strike>163</strike> 160 Chars**

```
s=io.read():match"(%S+)"or os.date("%X",os.time())t=" .':"w=io.write for l=1,2 do for k in s:gmatch"(%d)"do y=1+select(l,(k-k%4)/4,k%4)w(t:sub(y,y))end w"\n"end
```

Answer (score 1):

## VBA (Excel), <s>150</s> <s>148</s> 132 bytes

Using Immediate Window and Cell `[A1]` as input.

```
a=Format(IIf([a1]="",Now,[a1]),"hhmmss"):b=Split(" ,.,',:",","):For c=1To Len(a):d=Mid(a,c,1):e=e &b(d\4):f=f &b(d Mod 4):Next:?e:?f
```

Comment: The time is given either from the command-line or from stdin. Neither seems to work here.

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: It's an older task with a fairly stringent input restriction and VBA probably cannot handle input like specified. In terms of the task given, this answer does not solve it as it chooses to ignore part of the requirements.

Comment: @Joey, VBA, excel and several other spreadsheeting applications do not have an official STDIN or STDOUT, and as such the community has decided to allow it some leeway in how to take input. I took quite a bit of input in actually [writing these down in March of 2017](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/114126/61846). Under the rules we set down then, I see no reason why this answer would be invalid, as it takes input in ISO-8601 formart

Comment: @remoel, You can improve this answer by bringing the `If` statement into the `[..]` notation, and using a non-breaking space instead of a regular space in the split statement (Alt+255), and then by using string addition instead of the string concatenation. Should look like `a=Format([IF(A1,A1,NOW())],"hhmmss"):b=Split("  . ' :"):For c=1To Len(a):d=Mid(a,c,1):e=e+b(d\4):f=f+b(d Mod 4):Next:?e:?f`, where the first character in the split statement is the nonbreaking space

Comment: cool tricks of non-breaking space for `split` function. Learned new things again XD Nice! And Thanks! :D

Comment: @TaylorScott: Okay, it's been too long that I've been active here. Usually on my tasks (back when I was active) I rigidly defined input and output to be able to provide a script that checks a solution for correctness (which can't be done if everyone can just use whatever they want). This was not one of those tasks, though. However, thinking back, I think I'd rather have fewer languages that can compete, but an objective way of checking correctness automatically. I think the thing about test scripts never really caught on, sadly.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 35 bytes

```
{-1_'" .':"@2/+0 2_2\.'(x^":"),"9"}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJwNzDEOwjAMBdDdpyhGwokaGjsSgv4OdPUdIlKWsjMgJARnp+8Ab8XnaE24GwQ8l9xrV1qpg4T3jcEx8chfokxkZ5xGFCU16AVqVIkc1nw+/IJfk3CulaOE3d6hWO7Px6uzSLQoJCTesoyUpQ9JPFVs/bSKx4n+S4Ybnw==)

Answer (score 0):

#### Scala, 222:

```
object C{def main(a:Array[String]){
val t=if(a.length==0)new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss").format(new java.util.Date)else a(0).replaceAll(":","")
t.map(c=>print(" ,'"(c/4%4)));println;t.map(c=>print(" ,':"(c%4)))}}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Dash](https://wiki.debian.org/Shell) ([SUSv2](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/index.html)-compatible?), <s>202</s> <s>200</s> <s>193</s> <s>169</s> <s>138</s> 137 bytes

Usage.

- Requires input from positional argument.
- Outputs to stdout, without trailing line.

I think I should change the language for golfing off.

Notes about 138 and 137 bytes:

- May not SUSv2-compatible because it gives floating value to second argument for `substr()` in AWK.
- It ran successfully on GAWK.

```sh
s='for(;++i<7;){D=substr($0,i,1);printf substr(" .'\'':",(h?D%4:D/4)+1,1)}i=h++'
echo ${1-`date +%H%M%S`}|tr -d :|awk "{$s;$s}"|fold -w 6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7RSsMwGEbv8xQ/JSUNabWRzWliEWkFhcrG5oWCsFXb0KA0I6ms0PbZa5Hdnu/Ad8rC1VPVHY1tYbPePb/l7/t0vd0@pq8JR@chT/cPeZ6kSAU0mFxClLGBZEzfrSTts8T9frrWBjgOdcipPFrdtArO1IML8kGI8MKgvs/8hcguF5TxWRx1UjNGUPVVG8A9jw5l0VbA/Cf/xd8dxqG1EJUghuL0DV6PncRu9AZlfkqITnA9UTSHQAe6AUKAr8TyVlzFEHMR34iYy9KAAtzJ/wOCyAyaavoD)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 28 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
õQižažbžc)T‰}Sþ4‰ø" .':"sèJ»
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8NbAzKP7Eo/uSzq6L1kz5FHDhtrgw/tMgPThHUoKeupWSsWHV3gd2v3/PwA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFqiW5KZm2qloGRfqcOl5F9aAhQC8nQqXf4f3hqYeXRf4tF9SUf3JWuGPGrYUBt8eJ8JkD68Q0lBT91KqfjwCq9Du//rHNpm/z9aSUlHydDAytjcysQSxDS3MrW0MjIAMg0MrQwsrAwMlWIB).

**Explanation:**

```python
õQi                # If the (implicit) input is empty/absent:
   ža              #  Push the current hours
     žb            #  Push the current minutes
       žc          #  Push the current seconds
         )         #  Wrap all three into a list
          T‰       #  Divmod each by 10 to add leading 0s
  }S               # After the if-statement: convert it to a flattened list of characters
                   # (which will use the implicit input-string if necessary)
    þ              # Only keep all digits to remove potential ":"
     4‰            # Divmod each digit by 4
       ø           # Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
        " .':"sè   # Index each into string " .':'
                J  # Join each row of characters together
                 » # Join the lines by newlines
                   # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```