# How predictable is popular music?

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, music

[The McGill Billboard Project](https://ddmal.music.mcgill.ca/research/The_McGill_Billboard_Project_(Chord_Analysis_Dataset)/) annotates various audio features of songs from a random sample of the Billboard charts. I scraped this data to produce the following file of chord progressions:

[`chords.txt`](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tdxdaoj9e9wgpxm/chords.txt)

Write the shortest code that outputs the above file (or its contents).

**Edit:** Here's a quick description of the notation to get you started:

- `N` denotes no chord.
- `A:min` denotes the A minor triad chord.
- `C#:sus4(b7,9)` and other spicy chords are completely described [here](http://ismir2005.ismir.net/proceedings/1080.pdf).

Comment: That's .... a really long list. Does the output have to be in order?

Comment: are compression/decompression libraries allowed?

Comment: Could you include a brief description of the chord format? Understanding what `C#:sus4(b7,9)` exactly means may help to compress it.

Comment: What prevents us from reading the file and printing it?

Comment: @RGS You can do that. As per the rules described [in this meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4934/58563), your score would be `your_code_size + 802213 + 1`.

Comment: Ha ha, seriously! Clever way to ask us to find the shortest logic in pop music, will we be cited in the academic paper? :D Joke aside, what is `N`? Also I think it would have been better with simpler patterns extracted, or chords used in the songs rather than the whole songs..

Comment: @JoKing - Yes, the output must be in order.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco - Yes, compression/decompression libraries are allowed, but presumably, the best compressions will leverage insights from music theory.

Comment: @DustinG.Mixon I'm hugely interested, being a musician, but quite discouraged by the 125000+ lines of data, I have a work too :D is there a version with songs titles just for info? Another interesting part would be the relative aspect of notes, as the same progression can be transposed, but that's another matter, the way notes are written make this a bit difficult

Comment: @Kaddath - For the record, the file size is [not unprecedented](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/152856/write-moby-dick-approximately) for this community. Song titles (and other interesting information) are available at [The McGill Billboard Project website](https://ddmal.music.mcgill.ca/research/The_McGill_Billboard_Project_(Chord_Analysis_Dataset)/) under "Index."

Comment: This challenge would be more interesting if (like the [Moby Dick challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/152856/86301)) we hade to output something close to the file, with score depending on both code size and number of errors.

Answer (score 4):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), <s>295709</s> 47044 (gzipped file) + 943 (code) + 1 (file) + 67 (imports) = 48055 bytes

Examining the file manually (with some help from notepad++), I found that there were 976 unique entries in the file, formed of 36 unique characters (plus newlines):

`#(),/123456789:ABCDEFGNXabdghijmnsu`

I then looked for common patterns, and created a dictionary as follows (key = value):

> `:maj = ¬`
>   `` :min = ` ``
>   `\r\nA = "`
>   `\r\nB = £`
>   `\r\nC = $`
>   `\r\nD = %`
>   `\r\nE = ^`
>   `\r\nF = &`
>   `\r\nG = *`
>   `\r\nN = _`
>   `\r\nX = -`
>   `:sus = +`
>   `:hdim = =`
>   `:dim = [`
>   `(9) = }`
>   `(#9) = ]`
>   `:7 = {`
>   `:5 = ~`
>   `:aug = ;`
>   `#11 = @`
>   `b7 = '`
>   `maj7 = <`
>   `b13 = >`
>   `:11 = ?`
>   `(11) = \`
>   `b:9 = Z`
>   `¬^¬ = H`
>   `¬%¬ = I`
>   `¬$¬ = J`
>   `¬"¬ = K`
>   `£b¬ = L`
>   `¬*¬ = M`
>   `b¬"b = O`
>   `¬&¬ = P`
>   `b¬^b = Q`
>   `+4(', = R`
>   `¬£ = S`
>   `+4(') = T`
>   `%b¬ = U`
>   `` £`£ = V ``
>   `` `7%`7 = W ``
>   `` 7"` = Y ``
>   `"b{] = c`
>   `` *`7 = e ``
>   `:13^b = f`
>   `` `7$ = k ``
>   `` %` = l ``
>   `` ^` = o ``
>   `` "` = p ``
>   `` b`7^ = q ``
>   `b{% = r`
>   `cc = t`
>   `oo = v`
>   `&#~ = w`
>   `__ = x`
>   `YY = y`
>   `&#¬ = z`

I then find-and-replace using those items in order:

```java
()->{String s = "A LONG STRING THAT I CAN'T PASTE HERE - SEE TIO LINK";
		String[] d=new String[]{"&#¬","z","YY","y","__","x","&#~","w","oo","v","cc","t","b{%","r","b`7^","q","\"`","p","^`","o","%`","l","`7$","k",":13^b","f","*`7","e","\"b{]","c","7\"`","Y","`7%`7","W","£`£","V","%b¬","U","+4(')","T","¬£","S","+4(',","R","b¬^b","Q","¬&¬","P","b¬\"b","O","¬*¬","M","£b¬","L","¬\"¬","K","¬$¬","J","¬%¬","I","¬^¬","H","b:9","Z","(11)","\\",":11","?","b13",">","maj7","<","b7","'","#11","@",":aug",";",":5","~",":7","{","(#9)","]","(9)","}",":dim","[",":hdim","=",":sus","+","\r\nX","-","\r\nN","_","\r\nG","*","\r\nF","&","\r\nE","^","\r\nD","%","\r\nC","$","\r\nB","£","\r\nA","\"",":min","`",":maj","¬"};
		for (int i=0;i<d.length;i+=2){s=s.replace(d[i+1],d[i]);}return s;}
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##7L3rcttIsi76fz/FhAVANuQOhm7EoXt6PD95AZeooWiHW2oIi/vonNjbjEVOrwkNxwjpZfpvP4VfbO/6MrMKhSsBkpLtHpNAVVZWVlYBBAt1ycv//s/7//zhf/@/H//P/1z853//95/G//m//iv5H3/60//6r3/c/fr//ef/vPvTfyD5pz9N//Hr//qv//9Pdy9f/ajSD/9DBf/xp//6009/@j8vX/3wl0Sy/1shXvzHerVyhvnT@/y7N3DH/tAZ3byQYCKYEqLhzYvPv1cTrlbr25tfb/5LhS/mn3@fdc4p9n8KnMRJvNhJOuc69uLO/JSBz7/9fZ7cvLgQypL8@cc4iOZvowvUPk9mLgGXSSTlgpmP@maBEweKOg64XnU@MCly/bliHaCyFoxSbvpqGsTqoPtw6zzKd9w5VXexc@ojcIYU2YhO4B2dCArBiZ@kZYYPjroQnIr6wUM8zCeXnfPVzQ39PDedQ0Gm@arKiQrHKuUPl4rSk@IlXOkcruUKhvT9/Pti4dFvzfGdwnTOQ/XrgGE@Gzg0/ZyeHX2RE6Tdj4BRcMKlOaRC5m48Z5VMU14mrXJ8q5vxlPX5xN/c@6V3EPsjDm9ejFDnwEWQT3QO8cN3uhSeuwNVAoXGquj45gXIBPP59yVouu5gv8zGupH4N1kkdYUakCic9CfuPH7AiX9n9@XhKx2r/y0fv7Q58de3T41Hb/BcPGw63Qv90vZC1vScrHIf/bBV4RYLB6koyYC7l6/hq98LqlM7W6mOHY/@maN6dfDFMx87sae@6k5O59INFVGqj/TiO7wSenbIHSZ1qqXMqzI@//701VLgTW5e/BR05ucSLQL/rf@26l60vo5hkdOEexC8vaJ5TP8Wer/N6P1mvamsJIEn@l1pU4ENzs6hf8F0eGJn7jzRML01XXXHnqs6VZPhwrm/5loz41vgo6tT/Zj6sQ20PW7gD9QTseRw9fm3@B6Bym3McYfiB9dLlVq6Q4nUE7Hfi7NatBOj3e7wkL5j6TLWeL2o70CNhvAPWKozULcvoJeWQQ796d96rz7/lizVaO3q5kXiyigBtF11SSrdOaRASo3VzxDwG6uvXr0DgOr1o15FgJwDxc45SBRGjQGvFOOI3m2BizeTOh2VoeLjUwpu6cWJF5iqlt6Dm1NjTqzX3DUS/359GHpDT/VKGFN4FKprd/rU5GJIJfbLcqr@l@qV/U6d/p5Z7yGMzHBhtVDD4ZqzBOUP@awqksn3J0t13Lpj9cAm9NxS8PTV2DWO1aOMZ@nL1JoGtyr0@mkQje1UZZD@Wp9/m06Pzj7/hhN1cOgdXKlD5X3@/VPnVB2q/1PvTg4jDJcpWKr3Hs5s0cQcOzOgjiTLaGte@2jPDmw45PdipEaQ2cMZZILSo0jjjHzpa2hxgKYQVaVTNiWFAGxTW3ViVDhUbyvPHDqmsEmAzgtnPuEcnZmjrGA7buH2FZVWzr8xjZAwINLnDAsf7iUnAHt4KYVMdymjKRrFbU0c7VwNDwNNVsp5Lj3GD9mPw/@QnwL0KAsEmK2seLrCkOrTAGDRINJxf@XK0EP1eSlIwWLpTIhSFaXSuxT1eKSgBgx2qF6kAf6RsR6DRH01WyqvL8NtnF5PiypGhRrMnMyP/VhN2BYr3K/Qm6h3ddw5x5yCFjgogZ/QwvGsRjUNp390hqLLFYfCro7bZOENSkqu0kKTDN4OZVS4dlRn0OCI5o/OY4NAfZsx3I65irxH/1HNalTin//0krZfVZJOxchVLMBI/U8USw@863NRM5LOozvXecnNCwI//2Zf/Ha3IX@8Oe4cc6CqRiURN8dFi@he/FPVjiVhPfalySIFPPW2AV7fSSlMrsczQA1eVpA14Jbh04BlA7InYPnVN9AQNPwB68lkETTqW9@Rb2B6ySsM@jUErkx3uC8d0YxgwJ3e9mWnU5WgQHfRhpNFXcdp66DPl@8d4I9kh@9i/qo@X/Wp2UDn2d8qOvVeKGdeVaAMX1nrO0yb42BP1byL9YBmwEvFPk8xB8WDfoGBP8RYN0rUC2/h6HXp4gEy4eSbOBNUlMmWxdKVDmjgaZY7aV1jSGsb/kjNl6yTFwLyWKy@fFDDdvfo5OXhq2wq5TbeJzN9jjHA6pyqf/Gkcxr@8APuILa@ZBNsRot1sYVRwVUN0YegqqbiqeeC@Lh4QpoG9/JxBjiWipF7dNY62g8XixE@y720aSnPkjOkFWss92IdCatTk/2Ez523Tfv0YiD6lEilceKZ70VXdkSBr6YCzsEVL979OXcGvJKnCD7@iP0jGs1ec8abHvNPqjjTgPqQQ3sdUNYFaSTf7ZyCE8AA0xLuB4XnzYs3PRB@/u2nAKtpAXO/efEWWJfaBXZvaFmxhmc5N49X0a2J7q1eTaUNS3yxv0hxDjH2B@6QzlwG7Q1yDq3Dula@BlFe9ouPTjonagzKERrUxfwMKI68x07XfTQUmwg3kjmP2GriU0190YfRZrajnhBXnWluHVX0c/RztqrmLcSEW/Wt8@HmatIGDcsJFRs895vITLM3X8e2kfso/zkfuxMDSCOEuH5JasAtYGhwNaKvhm1cOzxGYWmg/q3/LP/YS2OfPuEPJO@HjaA7ylVKL/JxIXAzDZTvOHNz8CfTb/6IZuDqX9nPRFM1sCvDV2VvoG9cbCov2NtlsOypsywsz/kXon/h7Z7eOA73W7xp4f0U26Kxrb/8JGDyHro/BX7iqA46CT//du3E3hXP6u2MaD5VM6BLrPqphIqdNz09@8/SKZIMHRNlWX78yMSXcRiahR71WsGpunUDearvpi00NTAMDUXmvPavGO69/MsrJ@6hGW9U2IvmcS8Mwq66Xz@GNy/UK@7Ny/n568PXp6@wIJ24aDGIKMJuO6XCsAL9lLWbKFt7ig7CoEn9@@fY/IqwssZfGQ3d36/uV@rVk6jjHkuFS2yACmJZlYdR5MAfbcpHV1dNMwSJGpyuzUSHdkarYjk7J8tCGA0LJVQFrYgp71AG4QBpxzYODH5FiKuSVmnG9xsr4TtTe5VN7oL@L@JlweFqtXIhSDmmQRn97rj8VaBwE2/s06arM@b6HaZEKU7REGzciNEQDek6A3xdU9gZrqW8vTeCMcetMyE5NYxtvEk2DjHdQwsSEu2clFN5w8ociTey2Lmi3ZuwU@1manvLfR0tkoUZGHsb@pzrPRBJhARxWE@QyeDVuOl8FDYqlG2DvddyGz2yIKCJRxgQHZ0hLEunWJfleyjZ59gZyF/B7Wvq3TgNsHac@GrA05Sfr4UwWNSQ5bdYFJPWb7gL2QjqC9hn05hc3fytbrn6Ozeu6aloZQ6obqt6rVmh@xPLUD/ceWruekPTFjxmCzVU8ROETek2nS34ULI8cN/rBTyzqTE03wkLtBDU18LI6g81nVvAhDbNfHWDzjIwVnA8/MfGEMhW3fIQW5TuR1rUUd3GYuEImAaExNebpPUOdqsWiEh1aOjnaWctSjqnCjGk3VQ/KW0FvSfUdxEs1Mz3/Z6CwE1@wfHeH9NI1Kd9K4/2pbB75D36Yy2wCbktEkXVAJC4KRMLUq9M3kNX/@vYG0IW@5S1GJiG3obeUF@Nj3QpH7rZB5jJ4VVJY27qPXEn55MQJ34SQk9CU@OER@fpCawfp4SGy1cJdM6pzWdtEiHrKpxLAg@eytFTj1vMoE8kYEmMsRFpp3jMfYxLmx@ZnFIK3f/W0fulRC2akS2fpvLCJN/FEfYpjqD6bZ525yIRGD7X8r27QqWVtKsLE3bedeedy7238Y9Xp0hlr29dXjDMR7TQzAl7HdERyWkd0Gxlm0Ig5MVw/R9WY7oi4djPSo2VEmH@ltuRKrsomqhRKafAZJeAGsBDdNp272E7LrpQg5@f1f@vhw2DJW0RQKjaHQckN/2m9/L49PVfXxkAZDh9lqjeQPH5t59JFnTv3Li9X2k1tDOk9yd92QzqnGDJUMb@J8tS3BJF1XMRpTvfjPBTBOWZ4vjBXh4fv8bu1sF1jnchBv84xDAc2z@RvVqEK0JDpo/Y5bLrByJff5Q27enaqu9Q/o4VKEriTEWbK2sYBxvSrS@mDsv/Vfd98YsF3Px566tDPaa0w9d9efj6@PjVBqgdV4tyEYisyZCXLPKhM3GOzkKIn6o@bA9QRTV74r6xnj1fzvPV9EzVrCsfhG3DdA1sBo0uNb8k3a/qBI8xIPzbkl7UyaysvJoZiUGzgtiWvHnRw4YtFfOdK1ivZ1rrjYGLf9c7YTMtrSxHo5dssHAgm@isfQ8ZJAmOT02Y@Yra@91dCqk/RI/OeBU@hA8YZPX8tyWUnbM7Em4uoQYRnR5vdbHe5yN6jeHObKbzt5Rw529x@9Rw5m2khbEocC/S01dpb87ZbzO5xRytOokZfbAshtgIIgXGFWvUnRYQawcLcVGCNZfYmXixI@tNJo0Jo@YXYgHKG3rjmxe01jSiPNLCG3ROohJWpFisKx9rVhs52aKkevDsHJ2oI@w@qEObX/CGKoFlIMIykAv9@Pi4Mz/1JlhQZKynCzAF/WB3psCdzaB5sVz4PAUzxBM/7qpDUQz1IDj949y8uBxz6IvYruxqBHh8bdiTf/U2ZXmfxL/yExJPfKQ/P0u4a5zKD@uLV2a3hfMpEbRSzz9Wu0lIrDLxQd2G7gNNFv0pHuVoPsbu3jD6SOYhAkfWkztBNhJrIL0vxpmCSFR0iicLmAlf3IyVsWziG3Mnvfp6IIIhQVpls/vaOCFiaouqj0MGPqrxJBgGobMFdeNk54AHgSF9CFf5sUpTGeKLZ1N9SIIMCjUrNSV9r2O7NOMY1tvI2N69udERfnH16yMJpXJnaqdWJIaMMVlsgW3I9TYCJVX/27q@LIHLcZ7G3or@vky0t2WiNU318OgsFpAu4fDlHLPqpAzlHFwH6hV3h/UFFSRhwFIFndMSanWs17f7YKOfdoiCZxiWk9Nf2b4QY3npijpp1fHEd51DmPXAlza@FQ7jjwKugOABKZQXqZebSz/GjE/wj6UNxtIkXjgN6tyliu0aYJPsJyXqpqS9J8EYRwFBhivUf33pj6A4cG8naUjmHp1gGev0NZY0XvdeYRPnkUTrS/AQsmNdX3ekJVHJXFLQObx3IcZKQz8dMFWOclmkYzGiQTnnanqXKyFrFIOq4vcNi1uJcat78k3ht8zSS7EwHND/9Mk/iN2DOIJEB6mj@CRzD3tmNqBIgmgq6vHewdEZTjDwDqbCJVequqivzrV/oSe27oWaajKYQZgNLTW@JsHu12riCd1L9FX4p3fTgCzTsfwnIYIK7AWEROdaqzoQxU8RBefJYai1QXnPxtCBS49mkLyH06OwiykfhsgwuZN4ZESFi6KVOo54gkkViXiQxTUw1@FpraBMxsU0m/xiTZ9P9RWYjWn1Gy@6LL9SAXDiEYvQB@ev6iH812O2bFOIwHBhoqX7vqqqzU1qUc0iEAj/ndEDsdDSTKy@9igXmI3IICBWTTBs1vvCu7arophiv@jiu/0daQU8GeMsQIEW/svutdQHLHO@GZxyZwcxf93xkfC/lajMaEal/uptGr5tUH4hX1ELaaXJNcZVIpNkXFO68uu0L2Hd6gEY4QUGbjC6Uk@ia2nKeu9gWWD3wrhXZ2qSAJVR7Go9qP9oT/qxLuvP7YOGjUx2AgSHrMD3U0AGdbSW3nPUMiAzTammsDt8oAlbNpRZXE0WTfCqaDSl8@gOy2KIxjn0cA4LNU6c9vzaT013aXl5Tru2pDIU0Bfx01E3ZvJDzGBEqQCEWuotNICO1U/pxGzqlUcrcRh2DnkuF81hyDjsnJNkXBEdds6/4rqxqKfbIH/WVL@ZHu5lgHUVZ5hNYTeABaz5n7CB9j77aUq8LGrbMUQJPcLxDxJ1cPrgOmAKQxdhc0ETFwAHrWd7WzhIq64p88qQtx9qKNQhT@Ug@/X14hQN34a@HcJshaFkTd0NZI2I6glzhcptbWEzgb9ugicO8sUMO4lvfaFiwTnb4p098dFfS3pVZEdZhtTXYh3qPvG6ncvCkQxUJ5rQjv1MJbka5c0y/3/ob/Gp2@l@/o3eQrlFhbYta9COMXZatLDseH/BSOuqkzD2Pdm32E@U6t6o/5wHEdQ@TeFjHn3hr@vQYYzq2R3ISP/pty1ZUriCbJ32LKNsV5MjlLWP6OhsSVsmYuG0c8L6ayW4yowynNg0hvRup7sKoFIuQna9RQBDDCvADzRuoNymjL94A1Zsh@HozADO@zDAorRWzL9Hzkdhm0mI0tKXuSO74NxU8IzXas/1CorITxiZDVp7PjpL7e@5Ocg2@GTUyXRKtG0Ytgw5BeRkYRbMuq7U@2DoC3i7hkurqrXZYPUHZFAbkSvGtTEmoK1HSLnKNMtnFUi2VZHisMnkYo9qIyG2RGnPcvUh4H3NPOJJWBUDlcd/eBZaoO4DXyj4j0SKnpT9JczROD@@PHzdexUlZFPbiIea3SqrMI9m5FaHUC0Pf/hBjTIvJ5HWVwxlgDkxGuhqBKlQA1qPvFaDyTtLQ13FNUk/LkPIPoIMsCjqs9VSstFMHSjW7/p4ERGBNtjcj1iBL0X2m1F9TXVxb8/GnAKCSjGpmZjtG9ygKQ2aKs/m1HxYW5iMQx5M8cbj5fUpwzaijBR2gEuJLYR6lWoyG/2pnJBWWbyDJ4s@1WZ@Sk3wOLIRpt5sZLtcjU@Gq5VL@97@cOVOk87pfedwpeZauSQf@@GRR1Zg8NOkKG2Hj8TALUNutIhDSjzSmWCUQwE6lSSdItFvY5Pppag8N/ph6debmlIAWQWPURuygSLIaqKRJXh0H0WWAydU8hYLCkX/fbFw57E6SJsJ/dvtAlh9qm6TrPBQQP5nShm15ZLNFEs/rYJUvDZ1RGTe3lqA0tUvbI2J5qnZ3dIiW5UXQ8NZoKZdT9OK@b4TssH9r6qPGnh9rP@QWS81TUNn/gYSqJ2u9@blqd47Ks2ori@t9w8lz@QO3sUyvxy47GygmEqpSiFeIRk3z9Vei@z69JSUlYZhxHgisf6OiQ2ZgHLHxiBUNj3W7ggexDvLsha6b0jXGCI3T7AYIifeHc9RB7o1iPA9rBAuFl/L9edPamum2el@BEkX0R7zqARkBVs1LY@1OYRsjva9IYYRTjl0R/otmGSrINcaO/FIG5RnQ/Sj0rZvqrECEdl3RM/O1IAU56fOiTqyqQLCSvH4AOO3vrzdK@NPdXW04fMJowUfIwZfhg4bElSyc@LoiISXOof@wcdm5TOJL0ePU36u2ayL2XddxEbCf24d1fEkZRDagCAfURSod3rD0l9Dw8pZdrVkPF5pYdg5UYc37Jypaa2CFoTSWRTDqBF5BrTIMgWcpEg/wMKHw@u0vN6DXZqEUpD5HnIEGT9/mEGlkWOpIl5lv/TCTgM/NjCqeUaiptiFaXuJMiP5l/DFSxgnLjSQwVYnGtGL9oHWcxLdeJ/yZsYrWYrT/gL/0bAp8HII@ttZoEXHZsenfMjMjJaWg0g0cdx@AUG@qqayuVQJ9TdwqUcMnqeaPGK/ZA0Qw7xZerOURvbAjXIRVtP2nW2H/XSoQuIGDPDYgCQMcjn7wGtphbUvVueGsqSpxea3xmlB@bG9E8Q2XJL0yyWoEylgC7R603LcvEhb9uMsxspL3Rc8h/gUidJgy71zvgq04yc7bcMLNZEZkBIHKXSU0rg07dFUXrwUj7cNiJ3h3jiqaG0eB76x984wB1CITdyhwCSy0Ix0LClVREW8wdamDo5c2SaGrwP4U/nnP52DR3VwSh3v4nvetYV7Awtkww1HZz4dWibZf4ykXArtyCGib7mbBv2lqUwZtzbtrIfU8eU6rVsojK46XWiEsvboEyU8UWIik0jfCOdvM9HsfiwenPhB/bHVyOn1X175ifaJd1gMtSfOozO8eed46i@OTlRAWpXzdE2ZwJkH5WntyLYuRdNlDPuyEa0t/oFY031D14AJs7p7mLUcsX24O1pKVdP0bxAWLSfddeVcHmUCvVdurX1vGezASW/dD7Zog1nqJr8uFPiss9srYrJYrScAGwQ4oZ1Vn2vnfys8db5Nk@aSO5Eo9V5qjia3M8WstfQfmziQ1blsigJysnZg/K2xwSYxX1@VSX9dYbEk@1cDCffKjUYoPq@sa9fONk67Y36miytrTubim4RGWFgLx@ZDNSrCuqqP6kit5ebFGNKvRo24PBuN0jx2ZvAsjXgHKYS6RmTvChlDxp0jC5m2oy49wR3QHD0iYw7G15aWlHuQKGLzmwPjz0ssVYpNztoSA5f8s/X1bs9IFrC1i51IG/gUqtJKbGRtRVWsG9UrrVy7A6tQGoy0WO1gSZoFgyIgFt7zGZDSZWMMK5@3RrCO1pSqc7p0Be@y7/U0XdIGdxsuZFsgE8mqYcq2eFllQCmZazbKacpn5utYjrBTyPSxDDx0Yp4csm0Ssx6wJTGWEDgQ7/akwYr/kMjYYPvCTubThSRsPOtzTBZ4TRJO8rYtO2bBfUgc8bbTOfnls9Lk1i@HEP/wbEFaPIr76DmHuTQe@a2bVp/ccM2Nb3YaaNc5a2PhV4wJDzLC7qTrYw44CFMvmg6buh1tzsTKQ8rn829jozqRCtJw2h2UYZ6nlu0wDdpG/Z18MrfXLKRhModzEfhXZMybUv6Vf2XBiYi/QhqjBEqyTJyPZKa4czgLOsHT8CwiJvXECiMymGRpJReyARaOFivY314bYK8FtAUKdy7m0OtZ21@zi46dKjHJD8Mcgf@mx65UfiTrRNfq0PdO9Y5XnRP3JxgKcdUYQO@POXFXdZZksNI7SMQo1VYcyBoc/VauYke@PDz72Yrmgwd14hcJsQ@I3Dv6eCxkpGqgiPAsuBoghlueTPJOf56Eax0NLlQbbK0P7jZ99GR3VHuQF5nHEoQZJPHi3qgdSdvjCVh@W4dlL@kgxi6/eseSUYxvEX7qKuiNzh4d5GVEi3/nOydYxKIfsSCylkq1zz/A3Su5/DaoSEtuZ2/Nl7tlHkQJoD@7J@gZfuJdfgISmF6jx/i0Xmd1TO/v7y2ApT@N/0GoedACSJbKTSXmHklO4alCsTM3FY1iWG6DKJwVTuPOmaKCUv6zV1mdIy162/bYpq5CzoBfCtThkcaIXoucJpEtETctSWtJOspaEotPNeStiotSQC6fsn323zNRsVh8JVEB6PuTyPKa/fjkKIZkRUs2adksnF7qk6EoNp79o7N8LDuak2y8WsHVUecQqxJdn31g7aecbSwJA@Ws8SSfLUSp0WlFc0viiX7xa/e75lswSoiREh5kefPxHTKALvOUxf3yrxaT/kf6WTeA/yGyIo/@o3bJDKepenW4Cr9gY0RJ52zx@bdrSAqzBemElArrcgc5lsU0Cd8dXJMUvTh@wsPIDE4J68eW2zSR6f2DNYltdzxAT41EhgPSeCzgvMl9NP9RHfQeafszlmV@BVc/bnTppTfAzM6s6yvBccazX9jG3MVazN0NyIBldymLO9w6Z9w5E0g32BlzLNYpaXm2p2bn6MjV5Qwg6ugObIzFOMuikqd4OW3KNs9mM98kZZhkGrhuyGkDG7Qps@lk76qMRWZ/e5AtsZ6zujJ5Pr8i3JWdM9dZjM@34olrt3KwJjgQDWuNHUDPmu5oCKer2jCOI1RlWWLAuHlD99bYyptXc/rGsSb0@0bR0dkDTgssSeLkEd@bXmrAbyMJTr2i5lhnHpcay5KlFoh@6IP/9lmMTfglGmkapNenR9mgn8H3zQ6bo40OsWXmRDAWmD9rsixeJahNBZsxSo00Yc8Lq8vBvQaWNy9g6iKTehffN6TjbosNAWwAxXl4KZvm2DyNNoZw64gBUnZMaoFeJsGbG6SFCx85vl6s3kBDtrTEj@iwBXX@nKTDU/mK83ZMqBGrOfVIrD/j2zUHEwDKkkAZIHiVi@I/V/CrrWxj9ubWNKsg57P@FiYkIEfGRkJIeUKlr2E0hIxUWI4GjbtBq0C2@DdAZ2xgPdpfNWOk0ONxr/8YEsShN9Z73lvT62@WDI/ykqnZx672tGunNod@6xIIb73Hf/qPaw3cbstH3YSJuNXN3oDU4e5Eb@vEHjyONoqa0rWM2OVJ0jl8CuZ7qPg5m9T6dwi0Q3H38eYFi5KrGDrnueSm/L0l2QH8NGYBtamsfYgW8O3X0IxsBnse1FrKJ7JUY4WSVew5fKqLFV3PxVYtK91@AsNdsZ90Y6gBo91uBjHKXHc@Ltyg3I2puF8VaDtzwPatB1rCDWN0ltLiQ@tqQNva@KEuINMA0gC8RkoYllprX64UPTLmMnksLobmKJGQoAYY53dRy6lGsjEQOuRY0ku0mfYwxK506lS8jujN8emtIkuMn3D2YqtNwrtzFMug4Ojjr6/Yhtid91H8MN0pSoV2MBj5Y3BItCGuMAw6gTZtz8NsG6HupXcVshRAC1Ia1FrRhMfud0yEES39bLnijSrgRQ7UUsKBKiyhCcX01/rWLVnscvudQ/uMSHa4AWEtzXOUrzr3zLf6hlQGT32FuVPLdtVegTwCGOGxW1PyHjrBM9IJVIeB/R4NLkLnrTdV2dONJKTaEHLI3nDIsYT7U8A9FO/e1nJadA4Z9mN32HXgmQPD0Gnj5skfek3FaPyqhqn4d7vvQ60X/5EM5wCNelb/CharINSn5LQrxAUDEufUJcj9ElkAEvtTOfpCeZt@mxb960OwqQ54e9JOXdQtgmEgc9JKNwW3dOOwbK56qpsbiJXd6HgNZFkGrUoQI/WSWduMi8wrWHAFt7XZzaqZ1F1baY5xuXgr6tD@EJaWxiJrP@Yk7f2NzdmMalxHlKMd@GK1EiY3OwcUnhshZpjuwQ70obGldG/W6Q74dJkkg9OKpXqNdexPoagX8zai2H3KbzNyOLJxtDn/hSodvdNSz1bZNjyKwNgyWUzfEcwLVZ9iBQgDNGOlgCyhH51Bo@LopKyAaClFEMI90VpL7rZ1SU319dnOV0etmZjTZtPP2GIYwctFQvYTZOC6KUW3Ca7HGpTM0XLetC8muWGRwU6TlxKbV1@DuqBdr4pMRhJJEYSpNLXpB0L1Jntzc0OB@5hN5dO5lO6hIShx5V@RkuxhCq3wktsfO3ZaTBKvBNEeZ3m1rYYuCzJle/qKOkiyB0O66Xg1p4RkCibkPuuc9oMXQchGmtXM7f0dTNDjvXbHBmke1cn@m2h@Ga6oDz5CP1cCG@Cqc7aCwHENkNqHyNy9QSaFN2Y2mbu3pF@C04KdK6c0dN8vO4fq2DVeyoDslha9r9Uc0IGy9ZDvJ@12sRVmR9/jczHEXJYvZopIYwaWFpb0y6yCEgTpyOypxtb1iW3vIGOS3ueZS8@VCVwKeJRflUkLAwfXS7yJEH8I0kN9yWurFZCF15SkQQXj1TYcm0epexTS7/4pkP@q3j0tRcOSIt1DvHfp5qqpLZwKCKhyoyv0dX@Dx05s9JTSQyHMSiBzaZUprblhU0pYP1GL7FtknjXM/1k28wp7/IlqZqL63sBJViTpz6Ms9rvwdC3Z7s5sc3vQmfHFw//rE1XsJpYzKdUjQMlofupck7cmPQgxWDAgsckA4pkDzich2/kJBnTq36qgKNHDR1VIbyVbVIE2xfimJx5oZc8SO3NGADfhC0lcNrffrJ6NtSxkLOaiTez8lm1s0ZgqgWugsgsL7BpdbTPFELBlR/VE4grSUfJU1v@25gevWIrjQrONEqMG29Vd7Rzz/Vic9mITrXM2C7LYbIpy1TRzy4LRXDzYupcETJF/mcUlT8w9/EqvuopMoVMNWhJJEiXXgYnUuFVNqtgtAyRf3EEdheQPzau8RdSM9YZ8N6GroOGpOCXXgvGjjrgBVvFITjttC/GImnuGZsBpTI3npyQnRwHGWNoEgX5NgZCcRnT1dgbNUdkewkk5X5yMKecoxmFZJjCVDUTAtl0IeYigywJMbL2Y5/8lZTPxLtfahLtpiqmh4pfQzHTPxV/5DaEUjIu56ZwZReFMOqO9KINJFurwY6KxoyGXITEQkkM/uF6oF4ivZUuwVNbFVCGLgIWiMeOeoyqWUN9ASPMZz/aQZFyoZSL4BynDV2VvoG9cTGtd32KcvnKmiY5l6K7AKbxjN4BKiu6Jy6a4hLQ16l6eZLLr@ynj68ByffApjygjqir8rEwRwHd3VR578ihhJM8pLOSqgxaXaeMqSeF0oyq65EX2lCpPt4GWazGH3p7C6zTYPqC1ibllMcsE3k@BcVj99zkU5J03PewGknYw2ZDtObQ/aIGqkJT7hYJtmWgOJU3@@68JNjBVRRDATD12T8si1aPsvwVfRaBXA@5Z8hv9Zi04dGiiIsZAAtZPKivegHDJsH6lGf1xNuZ83gTmtZKx@jVoAwVsy2AoJGmvJVgmEa8zz1Wb7HDEPml90RLY8AmuqOzrZC5YSx3VfVXz6LRhHlSO/JE/bklo3FKIg0X@6ZckGtOERfKLOlKULZFCYnD43nrskXlu2dEifRqPZwjhjADsWEI4Iw41Xk0dUB5jpWaUkXEQN0/XMhuV3Qh6sayEs/7E2eyBvdtivLkJ4X2MZ5H4jMnhyYXMJf6CXhxonzJlCTUP4qtTwKwQ6gsnC94ZoKTOp27LJWn6zhu2BnwlYs6X/K@p4J6pqe3NaASoumfmIVqzctGa/Yk/dUh@d7Ca8QtOZ/SLBb6LyTkfvMeQT1Q2Uk2G52mK48PwFbmAccWlzK70sM5rx9qooLge1Wh/ypJhJSSpbfzGVVZhdOf4R1YwWLM7paxXgbVo50ZGT5ck5Rj8pAEe0O6rsCq4NjDhtXcDM1srTKzWFRO5aoKNZXTUpKSZtxl5Ex371CE4sM1jgY2o6CenlzPLzjQsNG5f5lKcV@U/t9oS32CdelNV3SWZy@0@cMhifB5sOOHdNguiS/aoWsCRAJIXw/BTNL9K3Y2hPOTi4oC6PgZ9dqpKI@ykWIfFa4YBO/jpbtPiZaW3YChXG102gtU1ma3Dpd7GHC@D6COp07jJmm1Cyb6aypzKdmc9lbHEf@/EPECqJja8ePe1npfYv/X4drnzPjQ38CrC7elHjSJ1iBOzsWw3sJhMLsm4EW1Nd2GkgRVzJaUX3Fl9UOv0y8OnBnYDGdylVCVFigUxKtToEftT4zU@FMxmW@xGvl2trlpb5V/nLchjwwNvz2Ut6v6@IkP1vmkeJCrS97GfOoqMyqy/2q34OniwecTsJSrc2iwjYI/kI@3WiPvw6ShFshAJMNMKPEnTB/CIhZNNZwCBDaAI9vmrCmYOo1ys7e6xc@Vz2alKJyMsfz6uyiORl@NjG8Rj4l5Vs0wxjYuS@muRXa5dO7QkvR3fxTRrxTRvyWBLB3ubJLrrHyTkWbjPh8rFLgBsPUlMdpx2oc5VyG7NtmHTFKm9G0PZ9GGhGHrDttHn31e0zC@eQyjcjKGVoC1rrIsmDRrzJBW3idCC2@8zva9ppre@LRkOiyN4j0fLgCatqFIl34YFZViuDVqRZIUvAgQP@bRGshXz0bLHchjxzU0GQ4mgFtqdQw207LFtiBQggYrdGddDlk3dlfXBIHm1iij80jj6yOLlJPMuVmNtc653zpuk5rMuEvL2OE9mEutzpj7uPPFFMkLkIhLneibqcLm954SmJSpFgXNw7U7xME95x8neeWKFqIQWQxXy12uDvNSTaKr7moU7qF2/ygdeBfXBad1eRu5erITWt46s8jtqSClTal0D0BeGsllb/M0sd0bKlO020o5uaSzQj6bajnUB29c@cackvN0XQW@IUaRWltiTQQYlGdMSRi05lfJoyQIzi3zV@ZboZzD1acLmc2i0HCVVX/4r2BgWZMeedi5jUzEpUl@wlNAr/UILFX8@Du0c3mBoD4XfXYt9dy3WwrUYWxbFnzG1MwphLIpPG@We7oFHRa47zlkHsI7pzw4tYcUfgn1W@SQNCrsPsJ/2oIZU8fGxBq8ESHMVhAlHaeQOstWV1Utz7s6Zo4bWz4WsRNtCb3CskHGtFORdK2VQWmMNiSJ6DDdANHVQs@M3PfXygBiyVn2zgiKH/dVlXEZ9b3Zls@sZ59Dd72od39U6vim1Dn8cOMOVOF7GNtmQ546Md8qx2hdwkVpEyMdLVedK/DQ5I4umsqbn5Vl@rZU1@eMPEmh4qNW0SWSflFN03DnFc3pFW@CBMZtdS/IM@fofwn8oetwCViEhKfVTXsmYwqBK3IsS/dws80jN6ina42vVm7RJOyJxyoM@SC07imFIWIR12Pt85wP1uYOlegzUyX7OqunE1Cn8wWWiKS1@piQDrTRJY4t8ajumcMG44q@0s1klNKpp1/wdSHh/T/4hS@/gp@B@iQnwm@NT2gyAiUPaHKhLQd4VWlA1JIqnEZV4Eq4j9scmVqpMYnM1u1Saj6fWqkH0oyh7rbrRdOSz/wmggfvQ1VstVKNewMYfoT0pq5yJul0/0DpoH2VvtQXDhNt9@IqCLF/tqJwwWGxgBwQ/hoH4miKff@CIzZQ7zlUjALglcJJbEUKJu9o@4frWXvDb@YTr3r0yzJ3mLRJ77LOK7RinSbxyyNJn6OAIXG0LVKfH6Pg@AL8KXBE2yKOoECrZA6P1el3i2qqEtrx4xg6HWKpoHZHZOTLxwPG@@NS2adtKKurKx5ZqvJa0cZNbBALCqIzAOnPI3jIZYWfUlsqDbpLxwi2PfZRPkLSy@rqstsjmnlhcFqItpWnYhdovvzqOQmSx5Xo2cW1yFdmMHZjl015s3OVljBUt8ojUGpKYvdfYCYsfTFpR8w4ObVCrbx5fhIfageKVOtjkXSgSpNwpl2DYSrwTazt488lCnSwYyIYMYcBwj6wUM2lfBUFlOb1jpZ3KJuxgFoPVxLW@JRkwIyUJ8ZRzuzfqiowiIN838MCwLlr9G2DcDVOdTxK/i@@/av4NymOhryVP/Sab0nYRCX7RnlYhivTA0R05cDpG@DwGB14/4rb55sVIe3DGrtIT8SUvUUbQzmcJDtWXkkSewW@gsdTtmrRmWmiRGh6kbVJN6px7152DM96BcsnoQRcZXecawkpTcmv15uX8/PXh69NXvEYkbxDHoGc8aIzmKaGBiPRDqIoZVMOEBZrfvXVkuR8xZu49MXFvvmOWMPF1bNw6WemxCFMdxL19niTRIPKNgRaoZJNi2LJUqCsW5zLUdjZcNia/@DwL2JLumWtvXnXyyxPQpgVwpjYbYfHwoXBOyD/ARM2A8Ha865xl4Sa5aRiu1ABqEq7YpFi7sjrUwotipS1JIZHBnfZJbvATbys3zZRNbsoi2206bfI2VVggtLkS3JRvDhp97/q/d/27dv3aCiXtZJ9pw4XmjEYPivyBIijwYbFkmqXoZwqxt51NhbKnNiIvJk/OVaNkY2C5UkWPzvhB0fDn3@8t9P19BX4pS4G0gK5@x/vOoTOs5VYOZngVGZmchpWUspvmmTHt0ZlonZAJGdE7ECPxeOrQfS/Z82ciI0KsPKtO/KfAQUcjwqNftHz7DBnU3i6DZQ@W70rC8px/IfqXNsZgywLvt3jTwvsptkVjW39l2adKh35KTymbLVBvaGiHLllwA3qfLciXWLEnFeAdztlM3nx3T/f5riDwJRUEnIPHl3951SakfYKAX9K0W5GU4bCwz@jM1kbVjkdF3JK8cdyMkC93Y2j4oeiN3W52GP0E7X@C@6HdBkDxCcY7HDYTz84DsjFtwJCnPfJIMimn8oaVORJvZLFzRbs3YafaHXNbIfxOgr@HOoRo0hzyJjP9cS9jk2Hn7gvfvEBM9uyM0UnjWmKpYpKcGeyOJUcnMTxryQm03iVrmTHXY2x4CIazy@XDKnDfQnCIRAU@BDD2i5NsFF/BMNgi4J5YE5XngmHndKVzbeYslZpyFz5RQntfaZIWHD7/3lv1rEZEV9FHOOVUhF9by@Zv1UHTpgdP8fQgm/t3IMkeEOl2A8F674xRvf3fLzUMrjNYuYp7oh1PAkr/Xvy0nXlbsaXJ4ZLCeFZZfHceA29882J482LspdBe@OZPVsw/0SI/WnRy/5i9MNPoX6rOTOGNx21q08IRg2czlLTSaVBLRumLDWwUsrRcfdonIxmndJxkTFx8@ZaQRQ0KyDATm9jonGhbG21yOCTVfbHhy0ZvVM0z9@KLXG@OD5@u9oTnHNQjRhsJxMAl5PewyKMCG3YPYnU41871J5WBdKIOiCNRhkuAgWmJxNWprfgMMi2xaGlNo3kzr2qaWV1Fw5wGMAWygjd2@nRCN3H5gebzCP3hvTqKGD4ypNms4mEmw56eKrIA1NBN5MWPkah3cB2w6b4EdOVUZO02JWvCKvV8XWcxmsmx@kBSP0Oz9jdkRxMUDvRqRVsaFsstFhzkkcaIlroIs0DNwcSbkG6RqK52xaf5orfoheFDbTbuCcYBlEOAyggWx8fwe@J@HG7KfTLW4UP4oA1PqLv0ANvDuFcPbIRYPVnHxw6NCZeBy4ZpNtA0ZZIjM8CgAYvdCaQR6vxusvDf1mQhbOSHzoAPiG44QzhmILtLLsstGStM@PK/xG1OmjLPkGyZEnNR@IaOXQ@u59bVdqVCJ7WTj6mCbVLUn1tmRp8ia4qxEt/lTeBFC9rnvobOYdoEG/7DtpcEculz@w22vhWPi5bPaBXnXVvdvB0/4GPk0uFZO6Kvz2A2bVLZL@WVExSyfHHirY4UyRBj1bFdO/baCqkRhpejitglPpGEbtMWbXVHSm9A/T1qcA@1r2l6V1@Q@GouAQ/ekhBTPCYdaoOWNkQWNhIn7jHgG1P7bMdZC81O3CvoDOgkl9apYeeUNQsWzkdYp2zYvvDra93WfHn4lIc2VbU5UXD5kUK0teIfmPTn3/obaYxaTAB5H5NgEadU@aYRHzZoG6UuL29hfMcYh/lV24XhgNFMYrAXeYS2@bJuSJdHtyu9Li@td6mMYNdUZI8gqAWsJemlcyILSnNTaHseKc4G9byUZQSiVD3OTSUH8ljJ6kMyWUSHnhcY/BHZkFCab4c0I/jK26j1ruRZ/0f6WTeA/5Hx5qs9@pKiOTYnBrI571E/M/As86n0ByAaUfoTqVXDYafCO1S/pwuxuLW4oA2csi6Uv3p74uqFmezzZHXF3Xm4yb5bVnfq8Ftoa3n7@ddcYG0xUGOvIS0WWgm6Ol7uCdngGIacGhpW4NEpvVcHM9qy/CoAhzEsxqsmjU1zWFsci7tmxwwvUfJNNRWH6Dqp5W2TpwvVoQXZ7UlveimdM32F2FeCJ9CavJosWElTY5ejkzv/4ujk5eGr8M4ouPksytzVY1tRhS7Lc@fXzkfaPcpxw48Fcf0/VuushpVBmr16Ssed01XY9dSQn014/Ghhovk1TDSrPwUU0eHG2Wfh89ISYdfa/fgRhlDJrCZZP8AqtIaGzo/kKBzbJ1A@nc6HtLo3bkFq0dhQVQGShgqN@3oYvSAv5eoMu81Td6Rj7se91cqddM6dAftHHHiPvOU0hlF1du6r6AUMgxJc14e4w@ffe2AW8KAWJiIg1DLgEGpNiiMtVd13TpY9VU4FZ4sF/MirxCKw0e77ytaBkUlsg3MtgwrWG1obYiCVnL4W2WNDBeiB4M28mg55eHCWLIVKRJhxdQKWBWRrkaQE1Dnh3BpeJQ2KUjFCyWdNEFkSp7Gsry27jdk6VTZtuyMQ1Pjh5sUVOUg7OnPHy@NjMtVSn1PCeDemqZk1WcfkSSmbLVV1GbGEeeKQqdc4suaulr3UTWW0aw7kOhcVxQuJb9mwxM2LUYefuUPj@zZYdFlmIEgDLYEQHZ3xYoNWEGDLUpqM9RA6iCE29qYXYTicKeAKtxwbTuUy06QgyEab1HSlh90iS6z@RzwehysGjYZtEaMIoQlZKKCDuDM/dA7e9LyDv5FNErtUxPK4QYEZJ/PZVWmsPqyNKX1jnBLmUIJll6VOAuNGnRYKJ4EzDFcB/CNQWvUWAxdLN0@Vy7aCFmr4NV4G6/UKyiNwaKD6IBvGjQ/ZVFB30Tlfsj/fUxF5Ett7@2tFunHxR7uyle7NsAKJk82vpwG5TiT1SRY1LIbtC5BVd/HKKJQX4oOHOz05Z91ZN4VTR6cUaFPcLOb4d07BD9HVXhpUTslhWZsyzZkX2gQPqA/PEehV09TXbIuwkW3uX63PPimry7aoZrd6jEXwhXzc96nI5UKN/Uxibxlk7dN/6799p0Kgn77KL9JIscX7wGbe2qe/5V9i3LqA8UM0VFNLllw7E9gc8MmjJiwlJAWYXi1zLGiY3EkJpOfPd4qthq7WVUxtxEo1J3SuNrRlJY2@2qohtyUcS1DrdSpQl3JpU6PQHp1pCob0QNUhc5t4v9Lc0xlGCcm@eQfXJGG48uCBSHt19hpQDVlPh0M3NYKVaA41hW3hxzBYsJUkKENphSigrMn4hsxQ7kTYhhOd2pcGiWr6EznH2aSNViPOcoLPv9974/uViSdMKRGwqggbZxeQXGcF@Kbc0iqsgtVsW0dj7Y1mfnT2gAF1fQzBMBZeYxF6BRcwNALqskvGdJVKPYC8/8vAnvhwu6pCMfkV1MYBxkvETJLGXlrLcpd7vrYvfY8uWt6bi8p78vFraETdz1lRCjVJf@mJu43dw03fdvya8fzSrcy3mEen0XvV/aMnK0JDPWASefeGtA3JxBX7YVV8px4KOjFPfW6eTaGxAYyLM1UL1N9e//UVntyXf32FscXfejq6y@VKBGF3fYAHW@szKOy3qUj8C8dhJrO8SHkGMUogGgTxnWKeyr26Y@/Ylxq/t/Y0bmWKVYf2jAOXKRysWgCYQZNV3URDZWfTXPHHmli@WRvBVeG7WDtQe1g9dA7V2V115t1cCudqsRCPMUh6Y2@M68PXQtdSwiecS57hXF7OblIwW6gy1So0g8woJwzEgXHExEfWOZPg4IlKHGtFqRWs5Dbqb0fG@6FGhoG9Z@8nUo8NuzggvVg9RAjSXDbuaqPripSDe66kokgRzaE2yQenOWXhR/nCTrY@sriPtMpNe0EPOFMIAhzeQdz1D0a8taT3rmBKi41OaFbbMKjnaBr5i1NxrluyL6@v/MatC9KVORmXqF8rTxO1om9czAjSwPKsPkI7wQfN@Uqx@msh10XK7bmQq2Jx00aWfnmQWVGDlNFzTnHnuGD7wjRXXoT@cOZfxj7pE9FOiHrjxbxBigXcS3b9y7twMyLVKHW3YFzC0LIHyAaciEfVocrozZVR4Ug9t6fe2NOQFXVwihQYZyjKdyyr9kyF@1QsW3aLKnNc6AaQXETqi7smSezFUROJaZxyyIYhOmf5OPUKq6ckYqJS/SBdGs1RRA@gyfn8e@/l8akM@QQU/7SptYQwvNM7CCVI58ohWe7uA4f8RIfd0AB3NzfqyNORNQecGxvTpLnfVGu5Lary2yKkEWWNrwp3bVT2kllwRF@wXQ/eChR38/E@bss@KWQUNwv0htUmCF9JvTk@rYZr6KSPFYYs4VCX@XP0s/G/25Jv06JlsCqhy61n3Qd1rC0nEN0HXyRo2URYpDsjCx3hAd1MJpoPsRacGa3hzeGtOli8OuKBr414wtpFAgj6eRubkUdMt8L05bZ@/u0RMhLR0UkKqZlFL2KbqwKQ4pN3QOoLiuRNj5tMYBk1rfRBkKL/ySHDrGcRCWdqUGWA7OgM8g8csn7VE1aAkOzLJmwRQ7248AMkLEXPCjINmTWn1GGfpD9wAXQRltw3/j3eHMNWvaWdTTHmS8UDcrnuTuF3/dkqGrKJkmsyPXr7/QY88YXum5c814/yPTqzD/I1xg7HLIsgacB2Ooa@sVcKAXA3WRt2jxUUt/5YJMVp1@zgGmowlbTEKUePRZTKEmm70yDX9NSX2pZ0OzOlQG@RstWWX57vGMr3WaoVGZspv1JZYJT9EkoKr7kriItuIFH55L/sij1oOmN@RTMy8YamXC2Vz1vMXOW/U60FlqyItvu1rLWGRRyQIaXjY/V8qyKdM1qO/HjwkwJJfFpWJ8k4dy6YsllvbVmDjcSwTCifauDn9imI2tCqMdpUn6JyB5ViOhNtTHw7TgPDyDBEiPmPGl1fsRrDlVjVw7b/lexL6dicxrWPCGQZPdiMjJnqcrOBm5fPSvV/f922oMwGZJUnH/o8h@hqqTEGLQr3wsiK5bjs9VKM3C0WJnmcDGCQR@wLGJQg1Dj7n@5jdVxkVU8xaFG7kQKX5SIXq0Jun5f5o4GvDTna8effrlgaPFkS8S4lNthIzO7h8vZH6myCguiCnnzYIqKfXKVJ6z7h/yC6whU5iWYd/gkH6rTWM7phF6tREFUgzS2jOYMxu0zV2Bkl96oH17zOzF1tn3ZEmtGxFm@Am02mcg@uxW@omOYjb/d9o9G/iaoZrwZUUaqFnmCNcGNAJUvQiTO2zzTn3pk4tBG2N14VpcrRO5I@R/AHug3VjZL9r4kPe9cckuanf@XYEDoOmCuGpF3ndLEkZVUIuZHcXn3ukAzof6vsd8vVVmVEuKpzEgbZRAC5hcVCbK9ckjZmSK4TeRe2cyKOnoo0GRKwisxuZza1WDADhFahSftmbV3ln02dNYV0P3@rXW/ClJyr1SFsKbVgxnZgvTg1NVeWHygCR71qsCjq/xRoEAahE1vozcDJy7@8MmITH2NaORVKLqotyKwLdhr06zNiJeUkzSrFV5NXZFVwkXb8vfDh1VwEnFBXFmWjNmXUj3gBWRnoDcfqkagqy@/8TYWJ9iI2APBFbCsALG61sUE3IV0h7L8BGrFypcGloJq2pMDoXXxz02GdNrHgs5lA9CjtsLS6UZPamjLL8rXkUr5iuez17RI@bZf@uHOiIX9IPWYX@g1kAIFYFnAweJue0HBcRfwLd/H7ZhI4vcnqQ6ACmDIgZv4VsnE@SxuI8aTNMc50JxA3mib098aTMSK/d7UpdkHG7sVa0nLetG@Gof1MmsUoLF59DeqCdr0wyKIzkkiKIExFmVJNV2DyPplI6fXUJQGTMXnXhgQ7lEFaRp42/k7LdKdkYYNsB7AHx5Fd0VMm@Br8ydfdTPpxICOgAoeXhLuObtqhx67hGYAZ7JbEo5atSX3X4L/8lSXkJSMmCcl8IOwf5pKb8veWZCGQaUxyICr2xXU9GR64/Rqakc1gewrSPtL4yr3xJMvabbC@1PdoN4j@QfxJcaBwd@wn3RhqwGi3m6GFc9LrzseFG5S7MRX3qwJtZ7JQkG9sNGA68rDCf/KhHsLpTOj/TPbiJ6En0NCTvQ2xI@@N01KOCCDVJFlFDQWz0LiqFdu3GFxvbZTV2KFpWAba1LoJgkxisgndNMjeV7nfVff6OZt/8@Kj2c1iG95rkT2wgnyaAll3m1YGGQIr9enTbUPGnzYwtXnWtWRj8fzV@jQ8ctlhbnVifdus1l2CPlmw0H/wuGcJQ7tzjNQzKDVhfPlX9pIU3HkfY4EUpUI7arb7B@Egpl/WeY8SaVCqjOTISV@yDtsLuxYYdlOKaoWnphzU42FKOZa61H4wTgmN1xRX03Kn5L7p1Zr0DcReja33Uc8RR@opBQ33LIDxWpCeJYJyIfYdEyMrFKifWyKb8/PUsolzMb8G0CyjkXXLgvSWRYNGCcPGLDjVtdfZy33eeHmF1n7MtTfLzQgZ5lRqvkDQN@M3lvYbkTWvkYUx0/SNNCkuzRNant5V5plfslEt/DXX4JZc1x8Vp/c6zQKDGCZT45YXIzLHK1LyrGTABnp52WxclUdLH8fHNsgSBtUsU0zjomTuq8gu164dWpK6r/9EFrWKYQW6PlRjj0KIjVUamiX2ifawY8p2ESSYitGgrsjNi4tW4cyd50PZS6goNK9luTm3dYX7DY1fS/ZP5kngY@Ms4V00E4mzMSwkp6cs96rbvS4pUlfSKu0MjVRRuujXBBZdy7/1Xh@fvpKoinYbKhJsmp8@QRk9ST91R1hFshK@mOnramt@BkFm@uR89juSvSxJPdXVkfw7zjXOJUQg4DpM1QjSYlpk1rIMNyOoOjF/qCJIt38Nz9mGm7tD0TYt5JAHYEteiNObTEtepPJHtk1KtnDqjs2a3ZI3ChQZy/G/i/fERpVxWGluWFpWPRHlFcHZbZH@tlBZ2ZZb85BHYnoWfpDeV4dgzwqr8DShl1fn9tCnL1l5ClHAzkwEU5nQ59fR8J3uvTbrrDdTTZD/4s2rT79N7riYrucl34nZazs64anE0YkokqZJGPc9gSRYEclhPxqoHp33QNLOd/@8tPCb8asRSUq2JftlbMleHfmopzkkNegMp0sHdyR8BO7AmM3tUxtqGrKpofuIR1o8@CIR@dqZxEZeF4IspFFNwhVaRc@5nkF8cJDx7w3B5YQ8cKoUBVCpmML05zQrlpxaNU7I@5lC/nptWyPW7RpwB8suEgfSxyJlKqS5iJEwM9gMgp2go@uVgEcKPqQEZKaimRU55VCNeVnSrO6w67PyWmL2RLRpy8Vq5WcFWPM5t@yLTPsJKy2YJXHfc/5qpaCgnpZYHZ/u8ZCXkTFQJ75sofw6iZAENCTJW97ZxCr/grZrsZnAO9JkzAryUhO2IOsRG@PEK7FyyDcAmQ3r2pWGcHyL05kcY1u7EPBd5PcyvLVzSlvANbe5c74ghwIBXJdJxbgAj60iUE2CMib5cFkieeddqUMF2rWYav8dzVBKMLzm6cRiA1HdooU62bgPXzpZbNgfK1wAt6@CoLKcNvYCP9/XFM3WvpFko1@jeZL@9PExnESqUBST7SRDCHvIOSWILK9BenvLkqrV6JsuyLbbW3ZGcFEfS7B1hZJDcuUbC928uN61oRtbu/W1oCWNW1MTK5Zv12ZVgObouSAznpDtydzsvgmR@otyN@SXjGW2ZDlUL6REdV9DvXa8gH1O8rGtoCk57F2E3phOI5BK2cjBKW59O4cUtCLmEiU1WqKvOgzDVowMFIabz4V@WZs3jGs5xCFZ5FgHZNM0mo9Usxa02RyrG1mbSx4XkQZCAbzOU0Xt5bjlgNCMlMV0KUt3CVh1guTW18Jit7wlbr4Zst05FbgYi0HpHuLn3x/uKLgzIFmfM3fahinQXpbCkGylh91s2pmAyQri0IsPacgeoeJi6LChkWBrxp3TRVeNTLqLl395lYfINVCsLUrEgQ1N5x/JmNYl9YVFWGyKbipuDG@pJyGGU3QWE28CN6OyYbbb4mMdQYNQ1dut4meu7uuCteeXKCP4TW/VGiibbhr72JuOksjUchhZVR5GBt7EIJFysJfVthG7xlYbtr2MXeM93Ou1vGbRbQ5XCx2Zk7YGLJRsLqjnpr9SL4aB6ltzmYUSY2ae2vKm3mvhGQ9jp3fO2yLujocWwR1L08YfgoVKlJKW4XYpK4nA4lRN7Lx13mpjq@lUB0N69c8iv1y1QNDkQLffOd8d@FL893vsq7XfgRqAQ56RNvCjhVeI9jGTQlWxVomd8gJc51BWeQblWLbz9O0wFYClQDbV0LqOp8OOxIDaA70bzmazGduAg1oAaRGe0QrDw0wDxqXRA2R@ePXhZ1PIAEQxw2KKeu3cFAv5pEfowui7KUMe3c/YHIHiwHvqV5ZmX/eba6YmMnmqFZrSKDzS9cz09I9c2y4CN3Fg41oFOk4D7MJnAagBy9eV7y90PF@5bb5yzT/8oJ5F0k2Sv5LW0reR/RJoS0LMBZGTp6xg0KayanTm4AsXPw4Xxm58zs2D2EiG09Qs3jhUDGDrXSYrBPuJGt2/6anjNpqnfE@qE4q0cxruqd6aamRZ2qfq9OAK0kCQXmJR98@/O6hTUrywSr7jDlcYzQmknr0FuJxnVrrDDVVQNZOMzhpJ4ImBDt7GHLgTb2Rn1JPwejxWrbV5uXqoDm9aZrtB9ue8rW9He82aYj7PHdEm8KIF7XNfQ@cwbYIN/2HbC/OWxovjN9f6VjwuWj6jVZx3bXXzdvyAj17LhjepsEkgK7GFBI8A@Cgr2I5buH1FpZWL64joxxUGLaRtvYKsVw8n3M/5b51hIJqlwWLxZ1KLXWCfzWcjhdigeEvRJjI17camHC2nCnnAFXxQ9XswYwZv1qzbXV9r1kaSN8GiTud0tfqzCx0UXEr0HozT/ftg1iXTuur4My@0XLJ/6s78jB4O2sdRtNcBDR4R0ZopBaKnQaYn/gyzvmDhxdpW79uZOxfzY2UZPEHL53g/kv2LyOTMxG4z3rxCA@O/ouh6qZ56DtRoFtIIRzyGDfTgFKO6i6MzMRFvaBpRzjrsRd6MoHUz1fAXKkDl@TJ6n/GC84kYQJaryHOppKEAY3gxISENW@@p9Tu1bff2a2d46hN0Ao/9ZSS8N2Aj4CqHtsfJ@UBj0oi9Ephoone6iYg258EwV7xRBcSIainhQBWW0ITGC4JLcwuR/JB5hp5v0PTD3ZST/UpOhuRNb536@Qs6p0vuQVRA/YbqBHaJvWHAQtR6DVUnJn6S2iWXv3Rdgg30zVJX7TDNoGVvvxgo9s3I4ty3WsNzX4dd11rbSIKxopn/6wUcPLz@yyvCEERW4K/d@TV3Ixeb0LAnRFsj8mKIU1vyJeTu/Me0X6TA@XnWk9VA@JrQDNC8IG3f7aw30/@btXqjKs5eAvN@olwIASL1Zy5mKKT9hyQrw@qdx34tTi1fKq14euS/h@yWkiSnpMRdvIrcaxVgdbOQDakblZ892Ik9EV45um2W36BP1fw@/16SmW1cAZymllSMIN4yug7864CFJ5d@7CqipTsoRbOsdOJqqWnEP1bQZlL3XF2Luu5FLjtfkX9dU82y0NyWF9iuibKwYpvgYtOxHLO69c0LNVB7W5@ZJXu7F06WYufX06iUkw4zuohc/m3xCnJo13jK0Qtf7XmUfWFX64yCaIrgSg3VYdQ/DaDaCm1Y2l7LRl8rG1qKh6HYrxSyzDtt3Alqc2Kda68Mc@f6uxfj716Mv3sx3ujF@HbZc3kBheJsaq@YgDW/GPgQuFfbYXx1W/0x2QlaBjc30AkZePBedfATRr2dQ@dNb/kstcHYduBCXblRk7CpyJ5q8qdzcA2bHWypFCHfPfXuUExIZcW6p5uxT4fZG68rd9D0pn01v@QTEG3LDac4hImLXxITTbbJiSAu9oQs2aRgedT2W82rkuET3Jjtv@vUVxgfasQIe3Oi@No5hfGW@Slrvm6Berd1uSCPQkiW/nHaVBpRUkYIWGc8z3sZVNbFLaqrSZTApZRW4wPLq3dprFXFWb38XS6R5VFWUQERlOXrWrI0tHp4nifKYdPqZf0Ec6AeayTmAbJtUpHXCsDUbJ@8tPdTLU50tuEipvZ@okRhD8pW1QGN984gP72JkoOPFUi9ZMpO6Ton7qATWPBJW7xLsgx7YvbvhqcNa7fPWrxqxENzzX2kbv@od6z2cducKRph8a2jNRpg/v9kU6rXNAmRZjXJ6FGcSTStTOASVNu2bNvSfTV7DzVsrKPdz9g6lSJNbVXfdUZcUTbiosLpSkgEZlPuqcjLaHxS2LD8UUB8U59kuAnuKZDgWTikIZjukvdnaQM@2po42rka3j82WSnnVGqsYvH08@/3/viePAmqJJ2ff199/g2G4Mn1arfTdbJwE6qhM6JdALF8PB3wNoZVVxX3/cCff68h0/dk0XPIv7bqA8hslgpIIbO3Cu4immy65EJzoRBA@rGmhD0K5CiMyvoQUEyKtu7HuJeh5@X1hUJ2DkNJj5adQ3dEriU1NKiupE31qgtxSIW4J4p6iNnTh5hXhUYUEaiJtOQz9uiMztxyqegBqanObXoMF@RyghRcWaAngvOFsc/YfLhcaFthqo/jDTwDtmdVzsfiNGzCqF2Y8jYK1Cv7pIAMMss@PjpHtC5KVuInY0JPZed0Bckj/y0pPjcsQs6OEuN1owT0TbETN2GfAwl7fhQzHsYKOZkN8clfKzl61LFPG2/YZYFRcWQMdD4Z5TBOcBzyo61jS0p2OiW/1zX5G7JJZBZUAqQeuLcoVNvO8kKmsOqrRrwJLyalTmkVDi8J43rlY/YTBx6rgg51TGZKWGTk6Yih4OsMKWS1kc2l87HxXEUWCXIB9qvdy3L8TGUErM2IZGA6GoYElyn/93rqlNLDEpcWdiPTCuiZQPamx3mJsG7SglnVJSh8T3eH3GdmuOSKFRqVbZAukuM4ZeMO1Tel5W1vi5/N1kZsHKOKfHSphxuzyojBbEHOmJdn0v5CmrkN51KuFBXTqS8oGIVRha/0F//eFftdoqBF2h/wd1MRNaHyucoU2lSGgh/k8xQVbHMvtqln13SDe9Dgd3h2EvM@xOJc0a3R/sPVv9QHuyy/4HRGv1jgu9iZxhDTeRdrH0Tq138Pe1RkQ0s1d6jOMXk7JhNqu9K/i9/FduwdXNEhQk4a7U/ZqmMJCaprWWUVRg9R8SFrExDOnr@FpOzxcQGh@0Z2WNdVSAyaSQNPDYenYjuoJldLe0P3CSdyJWtz7XUIvCTs86tvJGakNzfem5fz89fHx5DaxU4Fm33Yex5e8lvfjqe/H1twoSdRrzmMeA1jRPJ@iegOZlMkp6iTZeQZggb0o6cjnzI@FbVhqW7MM8N8CpxY7IziPnmKQcBOWIJPNzeRBdLwnBiwQfKpDe@RF5urcMap4Ww1CyRPROr5NMCETWsPyb5FMbsVMNHGsqfmg2uI2PlTE1h7symNP9F9qGZadIqTj6f4efkQQ6Tp6Q/bpR2r2@bfKtP8vnkuLPxUnAWZuIoQb@dPVYw@VdewY0Ksw97mtf77YlwUkt2D8py@mzUP0LCYiIrzNkck2x14S37h@vv8jf7d2tG8mK3j/W3L99@ynD6@BLGHAK2TI1kwHGtL9ROKeoEMbuyzjVkLkaUpQq5Ztx@xldXckVrJs8fTRSxo4eB96I@8sS/yybuUjoDLBT57D5RIGpjBZbIMR4E58Ma3GcJ6SM9TbsNQzV@wpxBdDo3BMg6LGA49sV@o4zDcvqwzceeTmep8j84w1UzD9Xp7pnWxURLT7oBzJz9heIDoCfOHGrdd1jgbbsFVU/A3ndRgFZ434C7ItG8unUtmll60xWfWp0up9OJ@NZu98eHr8Ib6d6mHKE4D5@A6WBhnuTV5zfhP58Zu8GKxv@o3si1CE2PyLIQNRlIwJosWq1Utwk3C6OeIRtfzmNzm3dzok6xPrsIVFIv9WHZHMgUCq4Sdl8JOBnZM34pZ2NOFWCOY0kHvcH/kw4uwHU61SsUXqLI6R1r0tu2xTV2FnIHZXXek23AIap72sX/UHEUdVAbgcG1GvQ9478EM@DT@wN5b1UQr/ED29nqu9lp7ErFNpj4LhbGzOC1E7ND6OKVrCXsZQldcv6DuDXhJVpVo3Lb9VVkWONeff7Oq/qLtasruS@O1KBPbkvdluFAaQ47aH6j45gWMAGPLuKxQU7pmzNVH7x6qd/9g6Y@x91sKsjmLKhpK5KRVfG1h0gBq5O5yxBbGZoF7bevQUDCTRIPirUoXAdjCcDN8qdli4GBWy5/tIDSoxABiEKFb/HrisxrSVmR6F8/SuTdBHqxG8at2wdvqd6Js3Lx8FYs6Jn92aJeW2KjBBKyL0PRrX5H0z3J/ZjzPm3UfMjG2J0szZmQoLxEj9ak3gRRTUuKpWDaNKUhFNdimgp@aWWBYBaulNrswJnPaE3@YQhuLjhnpxaldeif2ryCUnA8jGG@xInauEavnQu8pyw9GQ7BV4E7nj84jW/R2k84pKRxgIEja5ucaOBQj4FhaFuG8Lsx2qEEeAi@@o8O5Ut89tQwj2N2atic2FKx1RzjuuXCJ2WPdYt@SQa8FyY2dSvnmrHT/NWrMdDv@mVZXX0SzHG3BmazCZK12tYqS@vNnNlaZKVOG2xufrSKYo6c9Gnd@ZeDQnx@d1J01LW5@vV@EsvLO8TPh8FTUmZhT/Qk/BDYyRdBqfSMqMvHt22ztc5KuaNBH@/sxsQVWxZ1zWLZpV0JvNauvWbbbZ/BeHD81a0/NlcnrquAL748Nty3FPgH9gzymCnYPsN/H5x@pbc/5uzS7ij/Kr/HU16H@4tDqfP5w98fz6W7K@vmfc/t2/PH@s9/yP8SxuGntFRICv3lhyZBrkW7UkaiD0wfXAVOkYuOQjdfEBcDBXjHb2SLplX4L5pWhkVqvCtUhSxTBwmdNhilvUJAihEJZmwobMo2B1jac6DQSJ7ELUTrWArDUBgCog90sM2z0CBijwnRYd0uinKsVjxDH/jgFoSJhwQtvjFN7UKqKPXJGFO6HDb7@SDQaRsZRrHiPlk1bxn3qzE8/YaypytCTaIKs56e6CptRrb9vj9Vsj/3gw9Q71G94YkFf@f1Dz6AmVnoiJjTJ2qcuXSyiGaY2N5sVoAuCc1zLbxFp5fmycMWJCw1ksNWJRvSy@CHLsaldeOTNZu6vbDU2xekJ4z8aNqVLm2Pz5HYWiPjJq9nxKR/8mEKw957MRwQszAuEhYILZsEtu8uuRufJSkpuSltFlloRCSbS@mSyLsmB00TM@lVmi@aU7jrJ06wNI/DML5yVx56SYPg1BMNHIiXePMEdjEjdBTD6hj0yea9tQLDhms5p9DTMP6o72rZUHjE16qZi2@JBda0PZDQuTYxIhpsFuQk5RVk2YsP7UilVgWCXsppoc7tM7hbtygWg4kVAdipC@/6P/pzcQs8hooOFUAzSH9l0eOnhEZWnSB41aLGYP@5A7l4qcvpqDxscss3mSORuKnLCb7HNXuq0wM@skWVskKQvfYwLxv6B@gEPpsNCKrRO3WBbhdz@ibWvW3f@6D5qPacoVeKetL6Y/f1o@j6zv4jk1qT5mb1frgqfLXD/avLRHkPR06HDLjmrjkZ08m6YpkVGLM0b01tCoOnV59@uzHukeGg98tt/Zj5GSBqvG9a5RS/5TuYZLIwjVVDkkrHnkYUYkN7Md5bq4xwknTMKsnf5n2Lm7PPvSznvLZjSzmBzjmqCM7C@w70XyYZaXemWVVj55G18B/6tEy@ewXYVq5j6GJxBw7FzhjftnCxhWqnLH5uXvGTHTFLET36xtp5B5rORrZ9Zyq/AOKzgKt3XfA9sReb49V9eKULLVOvtLBUTsAQGypAlEPFl7vSWicm9g8knEx/@vFHQnhWhL@mWBWG@v8@fmDL64nkXjkJ0zO8GOExonWHZ/xDL4dCve6dnvaJs548BDirQkshmNUlBoY@7AfUVZulIaF1SoU6lfxLzjubXNb25I0v8@sCKxHZ1f9tYGwDYvnycVfHtplKC7yrwEnyjDdscl42Kd7wYvUpTPN59mWv8svGmh8OMUkiaZewP/aMzEWcZs2dm6LgNb178qpciSErIF@ks7stkUXCkhRVIDZr0dgfaMMg8@cWnN0Hyy65w2zIQr1Lt/5UcHT0zV3aqXYzJl1PyCwXfr/X5YXnrkVOvlfueHH4J5Azdj7JqSfZ1zpskI6hAIeqc7pNJ6A0X5Xn63EtF@RM2koo3pgzyxQGrN/GGnbOQjeieCWyOxSoI4RKuSFKAF7ClQKu9JndSAvEEFs45j840dLWuYmojVqo5oXO1oS0rafTVVg25LeFYglqvPTNqSbm0qVFoj840BUPS6fpmeBSZwM9qqFEALSJaNOFjJpHDo9OyVPFoSa3OmqWh0qOykllNRXVtmBmHqe/v7iA5byJWhFPcs@hCJMoLQUR@A0UkkWXQZaqSSSwWtBJL5tphAOhncUX4IXCJ4q@v1A9z6uPP6b/ppdtKX0ETXFn1@rs2fkQBhkfbYJx51pAS5Ej3w3lrDFD2rILDglqnn8fq5V7fWsktT4prG@zTkM2wIQ3B4HKAjSN0TrEUAlvQbCF5IyFMAegqxp8kA9YDFaU/Ym2bd2xjZY8c7dtTDJvfDp0E70/Quq@p@F1tBrZnSXG/rLnG411bmzoshrhL7rbWf/IlUxVds55Cc/fpHPv1SXQxcW39y1QrUxLsKXqXwiqXfFVPQtr3chLR@iIFRaajJCgUCW9E8iKLe6HqSDaCpIVemfPdRew34iKW970m5ICjCI9LT3Q8y15VboZCrxkj6Lpyjyk30NIpVQRPzR8ES5zvYvSqf@u9Pj59peOdbssujSLnKecbG/4MTNrdEobD7stAjUjqolSJnyymOrAUNrZSY/xHM6YnJDHerki6mlF3ir1H/tdQ3wr7VUnpYa/0l53b1LVbjdvW@txX2BSnW2bENTCX4O2OOmgjQQqRgc2L2GfDZ3EmyRa8d6lx20rnGyqO9IuVNbk//6ZeRBIuIbSggpHf96fl6AFeqRKMvUEFWaQYL@mfc58qgvfIBPHNi4/cFdzdvLiqxJLoCKR8HEaXoJyDNy/np68PXx8fv@69IllN9QJLVvT/DdT05bSCIrXrrb3BaGcvP7INAAv3LbSxbbtLsF@sne1wz82Vw9TR93JVGbhvbm4cderYhvMx6zhivauGYijrYYWa1pDgXfjQHzcSvEcnVGcmQi2dE@cRFsQnTbiE5G8tH05qLro@WOlJmDuNl7TJVxaql2ttPoU2iRYSCO51nM0t1HevLVL5iT7ppR/Nr8nqeiLj/Q8r8r1@oLCyoAKl7cVLLJ8EdglDf8dzBvVHWX5QA6anYVvDuFi/Pp0hi/geXPtXftKZn2td5FvsOmPKN5s5R1ghpV1oL@565BEnn9DflFYsVs8/Egb4oXs59GKaSyATBuudpBpnAt4275zP3J8ClqFlh2wehAOIsd2C/LeuRTrMVZgLvDi3XOpbkl7R3CyCPTmapCEaQFK8hBVkBL43fpfGf4HKv2a0k65AaYm/ihN30J0fnXjzNy9PXwcQFn8kZ0V2JiEPMySHHGKZQa8KYzWjcxjRvzm5uYnQtWGRI1lD1p7Wf6SfVPD0J/R7MGmFLpDMp5F5ANWZ@NTLcuiMae9EG9agotuwIRMicLTDrf07NdVhsafD2axz6IsjJAx6VQpTYVoO@uGHrSsloyV0o8DNNoRSRM7l8ljIc6hlPTVUGqXZNnRbU6IuEvUMNS8Y4CQXIQz608TRIj/l2CEm4HBfipswkAm5TrNfm4FdLlODxSdfdLANs9LMtdk1wtNM7lNOaBHaToL5CRbdi0gOYXSUDX/q4SaLkO@bF90PFrXh8VIkKdEE6JexpaV4lr7sr9l0JtwSqdtFhy1TE9DAiiok86a1DdnU0H3ExmYqr0Q50@T@z51zzINSgNqMMePB9ZJHToLO0peg2rJwB4HGn2tZmO/KD3XKD2u@r6i6K/tN2bRGkrKeP1r2eOMqvrnJYCgR1EK7c6iByHF159QC6JbszrgeItFJbWsIfqGGpFTgGIBUDOD@rHO@8ieeVpATnbZstCOtJnAmG8NJ3uJI@WmkVT1xzBiQgHDnPNyMEHtccICmAuRj66oMQ0kpbEPYc5@zX6WwnKKnScIw1G4On6/GCgqBKNJeeaqIN1fYoEkFyNja/cM@kSw@PX5QvTwFA92lilB1NqdHhqgGrvbTd/PiKqXXkEKi/ywrV80x/eqGWfa1sY1xq/cyFAhz0cZYNmcOCRxqA9sNS@VB16wrw/n8srcM6AyyaTsVfRw@OMOH1YfjY5yOSfmP6rs7m1XgDrsP9kmuHSlgBmSY@OjE0WGaZlvHTgwDfEcnWAyUHe@4izljDCt93c7JYvHgHJ09OHEYhA/84OMWPkFTrUOWcj7RBz4P4GaAbSqISwcgHI3QGI6cPF11QXGSwZit2XgH2F1j7Xw2bQb1af26gluX01dewl@9OQTYSdi@nE7vRrNfDrvmb5O7RpDaCi39knzEgx3uTtm8hO4Xo6kWx6fJhujOSdLOo15QwnSYly2eoR91ziIWajqLRqRvRKY6VIbEIuXerMJ@6lcFqicyWckFMB04VB0uZOaN8@LUfNj7Bc3twzsK/XL0nf5l7YLpl7mmCpo4MwmtwBV6ZNjDj0N1KLiCyGaRDy7zuj9qDhNdB/51wDPFpR@7kBJzB6Vo9QeWeTRDiH@soM2k7rm6FnXdcw2DfEX@dU01y0JzW15guyZawwB6octcqpdNFTHPnarAjOUwhTYjnqpx9ihmsNcqcGozejEbyoZGL6QExBUL9Q1/672K@iwrSX1JzEsokRag1Mh@M6qvqS62LcROCwOCSjEuw8EuDW7QlAZNNW4UseBKKiU0q4ix3omtKVfSwX5z2J16TOu7kIUmSmwIkylxek6xVHtwxiF78OFb8IyVRXMsOXfVKwl2S6nAqluKXHVd9vD9UxChjtcH8N0jgKuwywAFOFb1X@GswuOE7d@bF296L0mkS8fPee1f8d3@ssgGtOoQY/gk5uqrKR9tS1gJ8pkuiwV6SYWTgIYVePyH36uDGW1ZfhWAg5ooeJMFeWiX5vikWY9Jg5GpjUgKSk0wSJnRSmolx@TpQnV8n@Y@5zSXXLiKVDo1J5tA0oPzlgaxKTash5ry21hP3Dyxa52N4uIlro1J8FRZDGY6bjhIfuHDUoAxuNZoxfIXf/Tlk09N//Uw/yLJkudorXWs@jI752Geg0HfgF1TZk6SIYdrk0SrVGQyHd45J4NsoXrh9POM1bR@72yfgqdpbd8MbbC0dq2Q/kEcYfMI3hfYcmjnnAckTwEjMILS7C@AjXOktjrIXgdr95MRj1GeKFdwtGU5rlC/ydkKkzHdFGkuldxo51pKyOwiwyWamiWiHaIo3bf88ZY3EhOJInJy8uYYN7XrHLC/itNqmsCnh8CEbDBv7zwTWRTbgesXpcFVQUOOVMLUJ6Ls1cp70xMQelblOb39oNtnlKJX@2Gj6NffXQt/dy28hWthJ@556m8WilsfL1GDfzijYlPR5OXHSgV6oTmDKSPQrDjnTU8oUVUGk@f2pmcRZWrU66vUDfgiE0WXR8tNf@u9YgvVsBUlAeS@JYftUlMZQ6RlnWyagTZzvZl0E43VmEY8m9Y74EmZUdCtBR2Wisai3eVTkSJD9z8Do@Zudkym0z69j3U4ouHTaDPR3oo1wZShzGUp5PHpokcRrvb4lFYow@NTMg0K@fpe54yyvYO/QSkGwRhfkLOj7GIMl1X52GeJ/uPTGsAVMdIurRJMwoDblI@LYbZgg5qaMX8itlsyd7YvheE5NSTwxlRKz4jZtnQ0eBe7fb2RoDCw2Uq@u1VcAMmsK8N9LosTYm99E4wESnPJWgNXRKAxUUYVY/OlRyXesdxcPSv7q3nq/MiIiJBCE4kMr2QBUFTfyYemmshM6jI//76gt8qitwwWvejjFc1yetDkSBTNVSbhXrkJ1FC@yQrRtT1bpV8iU5yGOsYmUQpxMvaOznKBx7YkkApS@OOjN/Yh06SDAX9dY@q/7DTla4CMuwp6E33LTXIenSQsPTIJMveUjbcPJ3rTf/6jMYLqai@qnaBooHRTrrHxmohliMqCs61K0YbNz@7PsmPxIbhz1OtVxwx35qdhT1RQ1b80k1Y/j3YWebog42Kq0kVwZ1g5B296Kds9sgruaKlc4wCr8w4Klz1aCjq4Vkdl2Tqc2MD@rk39XZv6m9amJssdbHFUhQTA2eu9CylBlhQkKSMSS33wx2mCDGaPIXdK7y/1R3JFzHVnjqqEeomTNowKBw9kJCvG0hPZKB9oc@QjtlgeFYmi1NjEyBygHslAwhlgJc6VbUxVSs1sD93E1GEOon7WksiQ2GxxqvcWC5AHd95HC46xy5tJpxD9HRB/rCkMV8INiqv4zqmIo/mkKquEGx3l@K@nnTu2RCND0g5Uw9ImCJgghyJj05rLc@2ranMH2pGkvnd47Q2@Za4skB0zlGTsDmbdR4yesKbnq7@EZ9azxn6qUUzM9t@URL5E7uuTd5BJ5tOFJKYx@hzzNEsnVbe/ddkxW6uCFBxbSjwns4hWmpXRsghRYuM51FDOcefcHebSUKjcumn1yQ3X3Phmp8E0tXVF5uWuPTKt8DdZuvKSO@4zSDebMBbcgJzEr0R@RM2mMabmIgkvj5k8n5eBJdPaA/KvOYE62CsYLEDOTyJZFIYxMQo9cUClyoG3RIqsZ59axx1vy6AT0Ls89vvZVEQv0spsedF@DcVdWxWQ7uUd/R5sg03f5c@/d9NAbjHWdAkRVGAvpixejvmb5Fo/NQVh1r6XoQOXHpkX5N@XNcRIRg/CROTjw6NRLxfl3yttbZBddra4BuY6GHmVy6BGW8kv1nQ195crSO2RaZubeuabTo@zGFQN2wNOnM6SCeIcIks0rBHMZeaQeRRCpruFD5G2UYDu6YHOvj/AiUdqCn@kGlFA0qJj1PdHW@TS0sugpPpURxq@VWMSJ56Wg/0udVPlVFhYOKc0e29tSqdaOI35j7ZyccLq7PQ5Stc2swB@@qS3XEROYmyC1E1K53BZC6gJD@@mQZHBQJgWbFOOiu69NfVc2yfsXZ1v0zdUmP2QbhhUiCn2EkHrPiurjLZFoTBcU397aZzE6dQlKRITCS1@al@oiZ8sFhTC/pRo@kLuyU/S7xo@A1iNlmPY2gR9FZ5kFFPpMTwcSQrx3286ZYcnnyKSBW6ayQjOUnGaNnmbKiwQ2lwJbso3B4303xz2VKFz1LXBbFJRP9inTSkLI7HLnptL2bUqn@WyXdWE0EpTllky@sJxCGx/0lNaDs@ClHLjoe3Nq3dhz5EkjIW9d94vg2eo7eNHvfyAY5tGLvPl69v7NcNNqazRQI8CSIQ9pLvstRlkOTtIM8pwPgdx4B5clcO8Sfbyr684/JI1hl0S0xRGDquq9Oryq/Jm3QdS6EnUQy2DVhqk0gYD2z8/uEK5LiaDP3bO17aVfxLq9Q7S8Ju69v3egA33pU2ZpnfxqR63fdXVqsKv49e1g@d9zp/iHnxteU/Fl5xsVLkiWa9v2/79vhY0h@vC5ckICQNxNXeeDxwswkMzESvid/QRra3A5Qee8CxHSSvoaigWZ5J3@vMkXOtoFCJrcLUyuNv00atcticV2XSj3S32cqMOMvYwsuQU@@tayg25zfisQdR94FCvbywWJIgThgYIi6hGeSlRoL@EIsPNnRP1S6rDzXr8UgTDMPRjPy6D1BfdVO5s1Lz27aPgK2pP/n5tvJfypzzI/3215J13EHfOckFRPq@ajvYcyphXFSjDV9b6Tksz7qWad3FqB4Nmx@QgeGoBOh7Tzgmt8PhTA8GS3fIT7AQ1p9bGj2D4RSI1cwYEAeFCxVOKEFSfRjLSGaZfbaNFp2l5gixU0zDCYdPdw9VKXJybPXX3PRnS7t66PwXrDE@Wck@8yWKxCDrnOD1St10GOvAOrlWlPwXmoIYQtMDOiUmhYVvWDUFZ9hEJ09tl9V/jS84mrdrKYM1eLzGPOmLgDG2xE/n0soTmnjzakWXPMxG7aFdi6auDnxdKjXbjUuBnRxnTsJeJ7G9dJO7l0ZneM@BFe71EX5pVU64UR6vI2/CL5pSeiSFhrWJNboDF/y8CBgWxWlnZBreCM1A6J61LqD9yWTXlpQrI5mHquwc/18qZJjqGPWAGp7z4uhEqKbonLpviEtLWKO2HRduGMkaivGHndLEiO1V22o8/LMThqHE9yklsKGqnp5Xg0IFfUvZTmoZ2XRnMrrVt36RmoTqkZ3us@8LlBk4bZtXXkT/yxy0JGTFG9zXSMEmxjZqxSH5RR4rKOub@e@GTOsfkxMu/vIqyUZsyTuxcxGE0J79EYVhZll03bSpMtBexAcgwUAHbCgALYzRa684NjMi/i5E@gqmatPTZ5pzbF9NFAZT8NHVjyinWCtKADG2z5nPjGkcapFLpi0e/FMipRQYwrwmz0Sy5yJ@n4GUFWQNuGT4NWDYgewKWX30DDUHDH7CeTI/Eksx3ILNUWMafagiuPBM1vzGZIhrbqgwP/fOEYnE/2VcV02oIW0rctfVd235jxuSjHVJ2VWbzcEMtlcUmUP87OnugJcSXh6/wjtKQ6gPgEQFmLVnRuNkVtQ09Wonc3Ahznew8uPxbeaHps6geSx8yKV3odnRn3YdMjL2f0owZFlFIuiY2KiPdDKakxFOxbBpT8PU7JZC5oXrHZF2/sP@XBZl0VaFrFuUcswCSJp3hYiFWfdmrGMFUkEM@ashu6yiK8HfzgN/NA343D/hk5gFlFFHmFzySMQc26cm7m4xaCMbaQkXasiawJ351HM1QyrDlejZxbXIV2YwdmOXTnpZ60C4k1mweUaVVILAfE4Q4zCaIS3grTXRibbjBJHwJQwNINlQ4xDAjrxOxd4o98KGyR2fq6AS@Ck58oiIM68cWw9BInJlamdl6L01qklEDhMb4vrw31c@l3rcfYEeTnJR9ING1pUevNfJEoWKdT/tpE1ygEf1LH9kLzO5XrRktSzgNl8xHXHEueEsxbWg1sDDCyeKa3lbevUhEn3cv2JlZkPIfHdhNSKFMYg8Qab77UMQVLfg6GJIDzqNozHfOtk9uzFOPPKJJvgWlzaL0FUZqXLQKjhLx@zn2x7ve21ZXs/kyoo8Vt7z8Nxnu55cf@5PNN4H/yvLswzTm04UsEO9PRdDZH/kjNcu1w6m2//EFqqzOkRa9bXtsU1chZ6B/G3uvX5tf1FAEDQvSoCbZ6cCK@RCaTflMs6eacmkzfSoH3dR4ZjVRNb28msjzGNq7gg1fs5jOumrsQBiOd@EhN8HEarkSH5T@pHOyXHTO8pRC3byQk8Ce7kS9XidqUjDw5Z2NfNGYa9eAdk0VgflgwQbFvOl8iHNBk80kY7mjPtPskrThRKd4w/xEQkvFsAJdH37@bVoIjc@dxD4xWYa8RNvIeqVY0aCuiBputApn7jwfypC9otC8luXm3NYV7jdELaJ5Qv8FPZbE8KpzNguy2GyKcsNw24KRFip3Lwmg6dVlFpc8MffwK73qKrJorqdhOWVo@6w6GtGJ76FpWmQkpllTz0WpNntVZdoA7Ra7V2Shcnt6lnnN7WP1ZRtrtJETb2Ll9rBufzBaSqn@ESsahYwvRTNIIeeVFy7CG4tQIGukHnu2Uh38UJ94G1AILaWqvCEPLBOJBFixJ@hhBTupzLLFbFmHaZRoTFiXEAlHQZP@Zop0UwAPw21brqkjeK1QlUovGXbTtHwNWGQwSuusbEzTDGPPxWG57a6XvPzrK4/M@NB5cO0makAIfU5ygQjYHy9xV5a6TGplphxNTLhoA0Ywe4OFgtR9XsZYm3q4HkLYm3ImFTGeygc6JyvYEH75l1er3oJGWJ2uwiyCxfExLbbD2BVge1gjJ/nJJLN36tyeTf4kQjtgsQ0yyZapPY@pOkvKGted6rfVSonkZkR9XYk34b9kjnkgaVhMa0R@3JU/5MLj0fD/be/L19s2kn3/PvMU@SIAsqF4eLURH51kPHfnekVdkvZ1rIAIZzTn5JgTMp6Mhkf4qJfxv/MUfrFzu7buxkqAImU5sQj0Ul1d3YBIoJeqX6k3I5hOxo1DD9ctiQqqfk43y45vUnrE5VVA6lANdxfL@U6EBEzkhdom6DNqXx/a@XrHYd/tXTSCJUvhqy@7mmJzbuK2CjUpzZOVylltgqteXK1dnohvhjAp@DB5y4gVgsuvSGP/ILa57WIwIo@/9wknfUu@B269etPx93vgNRXg1A6zc7Y@CQNzGKCWLFgv9K@deBmgeTOMOJugQmuV9pHooa0ETxXJkFlRdiGDeBJchilPRkqECJJdX1hqXiJ4cTYqoleIXPpZN@1YvZkbpwsnArXipXqv5p2InfoJtfk5@liROmRo3IblSJyTlKV43Y7hfNPRs9wSHP0Rln5anKNRhZDFzsLcJq8nRnJzH42GvbpX1nbIFNGORoWNl9xUWJltc0TwJxZhN5F2tDJFZ2n64w0pxGV8@KBfXA69AaPybs8vnyQbrGIuiBvFkWgdVw392jUgnHp3//DvVpKYbiuHXwXZG2B0wocy75E3yIgdUhOghzfUHqqJIGYl2/KnijcL0K@y6TLweW0bXpJ2biiZLq5/w6Rn6ePSLeaXDIutZtwIFwqq6N4Ad1qXBmdNNqg@/UZ0Q8jhmSTu/CZ6kripQ/EQJ@5h4RmC/mLxIVSNGhMaoNkV2pGwHYnBx@LzVuI5@7wFD7SWOCBKMBigXuMzF30WYfHxcT41I@TXcCO2r4UV@eBHPCyniVaw3/UHiRwiAsF0setEviy8RYLjm6pag5kVlGFxhb/pMNaAUeLrwNc@sxZ@jLtXgyZak7xZrnGd5hAubYG/lzXOgquxu7SBsnwZL9B@0GKDLxWX1uxDidAt2TaxFkuVhQp1/zt4DvwBLgfBx6NrQ2qSYIf@YKnetUsHoxtQWUUATPznEscC9fAYCnrhdsESrahQ2i75aEeztARr/nySrE/PLL7zCr2oOmOmQyiMslbf0YrQNEI8JXgz8Bx1dEZAqa4d9kzFXcnh1dsOZnH9tm3sR1a8Irt9JCp3oNzTOBHbwiQpn7o1CRbrfWy@PIVVfW0ZOcvLiDejnfVPJO64g/7sDo67FAokdsC4UDC@mepL9u9ShiaW9pZfLGU/GQEN/pnAsHSwKb@JCZIT0tydnYonijHaoeWWeDH6NTvdk1BdHS4cLLEzTdgFbxlTNB3zZqY/44Wih7wt9a7gMRTI3KFxtpR1hdx4I0O1uHG4IaVecwGf/6HIsybBTFP4K@ll7V5X7VZuirduIw8NgNSoCcOw7XR5noO4@eeL14H4a9IEUON65ZPmsoRJBSgR68/aYTeT37d8Qsa0P@X8Xb15oQ//QNwP42KQPtAnsM7JsMYQKZdg@gRrfdKX1ssVZctRhwUx7UXwkjdDhiYhrFOoXu8uWkZMwrLyQDE4MXp/jHzwd0ZJC8w9VRVMaIAD3kOzt@rtofGzA6oa8ote1pnYobPMEjqujMV5Oz/CCTQ5WylJYrBbYeK5unK1DcK66C8wvNM@Echs6sN7VvhBrHxHb13RzO9jlKlDdp7cV9fXztgZEwip@PaBU@upXAq8iIYmV4mwMAHfSbSJHs3o@1nMqr7AacHGjdjuG8mV7WrkeUuaW0VaIU/jDGYxmLANtsMYnAfRwhF58iGdFAKl6Ynijfggiisz9@RFXUt8jQagdGo0ulAf2Tmwtaj1xioj39HWAy4TYeDgUHZchQ4kl5Wwl7QRksjdR/Zvvc190NUhCh4LNYkgxynimmOB27UQnBsKQ2xpnmVwQxVT9Ip1lwEYSfWbqDyVibr4pniUPcMFKLp3znCuqsPpx7@1dDpnr791nV5pIAMpcB9Ni3RdUKzrp@MP76vy4LecBhNtToHHh6MzRL/La56efpZRR0GyvblzcLbDdvraR/QnG2OkLUihzy7yBkXhy0hcLSDK0IjcDOeSqzBuKB68TBBlpUdGG@qGvQ6sDE6XXiQSBHMQLMij7biw5qKlYedsfn88D@4psUqTeY3suhmLJs5BYSsCQD0W62XgvtBL9K/tFX3EQeZFfXDBwkz5pbi3caqX@G3hMNm2pbOcMF4GCPwiWVT@Uq@DZcvqRDgO35LR36Pr2eyFOnDCsvbAJjRaw2TnBY7XDh0eBv9Mnn1iosCS26WkQeoEoBWiVkhcZAzym5LHP2tyqZwJnaFzdNZ30Oh7F6mCZnYkfWM7O76ch2vpgZpZFX4Rtg0do87ovbA//T56tiQPcmDpM0wdfbaf5wP3fgFvDnxskZKlqY9al4IkT2jWYB2yF6HkWZO3c9KR3RYiOKbE9S1ZGnNbfex0eYoNXqZ9hEMJQgJHeQGlKQKQIOezC0Bh07QtCPcRE84s728FaUfvlKhvyM57/1EJnkCfdWCUaGywCJoct5Hb7qispJ2wAuulc0kpRJJ5Pi5KklfJxlnGaC7sqTdJb42RQOwkzeSgulWJurKpUvIkl5y0lIIwKWHb7h2N2MP4@2yIQ9B2NqzND7Hf8wGdjT5kFpf5wELP/YVn5MqrtnE6n8PIBiyQrylqnBIOS4y6YjlEhsdx@UmFSzp9VCG/dkiZbA64Yf2JLR4XcRO1HrS5oXEpi39mQfz26uoWnH@OAAvcDtRUzUeocIkap7cwP7frKj4rmyPkPuJu7yMLlrNvxO0ATOiszIDuxVz@EF7ZQ12ZHiY4icp9HrpHT4d2jWK2LGc18ZDQJmobUqSiyiegc9wVdrq4NQ1up7e6wlE7kSmx7h0lrGxLRFjWuejerZi1tC27vXaxjModqdhUqr@ll1q9I3Ln@/3GoR/BkOiyK4ZefUaFylAoBMNYHrFj3O9vX9cZurPhRP2Ujs4ah3a4Wm0vtCzu92VFahRdXYF/9UR8JjEsiFzReyp8kQ4RnrFN5tLZ0jxO1v9CH9OHpICP4aEg1IEimFVUIj4pkmx887mSjLKjpublYAVgM6PdQc/Y0Dqw/Km@FV1JwPM@Q6ySgIrqnzSoKkHzD589exwdyeUvEKKV3QV7ZIoGuARrDm9XO0YTMIJgQe36fC6vW1jC8UYR927o/l24V@vmttKrNL1VJfYs8LsZ4GYy@l8/qR1pA9kz0difk349mST27Ib2maFrAOCcx9xNbYWkAqeL@jBNR7p26JHpPSUWqEtTi7lXszfmd6buyGPL8Ep/DzUUMISu58QDv7w8w5fgzqcW1ZUYNKipg2FsPurdEbITXMFswPcSItcxoSofvYrsg5gpXU1KwnNOmpe5lzttkQt1gmuINXIIyjHmOD42AWpdRi0vooXWqy8vZdG2cYZ402sEtblyvuUV2YpsKHyiJk3g5v7oDOnitv7eJdBi68kfGQnpc8e54yKyMIXN1xL6q2D7mcGYcXmrJR7@Zs@PQef4L1v@Ue2HDP@yi7@UWOPBBye5Jx4uOXOaodr45EHO0Qkswe8h7VgehADRICKairt7b1plR0wuiIs7CEpsqMi2504@tvQGNhxU0LfrH@oPxnsnuJ56nsqk/7yDDrmMaJzfWmnn4I7mhFdf3jWaH97fNc51XuV2I6WsDHeMRTcdoaJ0Tkm9h@DirhKq7P4vrX56zP8976D3CPPqMM81AJYCD4sUy4cVSnyJ5WPneQ0Ule@7pHKfinwzW3Q0rhLOHdXH4XSiPvqbMJAwCScZjBm8U3lkxUWWChOJXbLCYtWOiDQqHXSFzGA3H95j5uPQp7sShEEo3rYbZ7Qe2SI7ZTVUKCnCLzpM81DjMJVs4g9@DBrO44o1uBr2cIe3ygRA@g3cOFwUbxyGqKRTnEHPaI/oArbryiMpwkCmkpZVclHY9wgaD30xeuz7oS2mwqlQ9hl2KJJ0CkEZcODvWPQOQo2y@uzZM1o9W6qBhDl5WdC3aURHZDlYBJkb9AFk9NphLBUhB9Dh@exTi7/DKUiDxw@qLWsGz56pyhr8ktM6YYzIM6ktGRGks5flLBBQp7FicuKQ9fADXkUZjRg6V6XbQB1hBoukJLRSptSktpdhaHZSLy/3/YhAbNHjCIPLonoKwdCWlehMX4YWmGPE8Rg1kfKrQroohlP08VerMAkiz@rIPXtsAx9Fqsjp4AjInJ4lgx/1WSGo5759Azn4faYxjj9pQt5DsfcwPZmGDMvLiZ4xSpiiu56yEx3y@BEiHkR2qigWtIqRINSI64V8Kk3rPh2hnCAw7U0t1G5jf9SeuAo/uAMXvTVCtI8IeEgG2OZxHu3DeyETQdtYJLKb4prsleNqjHS5G0MtD6pe2f0mZKY99H8P94PfbmQTEpjI5f23ILwDnYv7lod3JRxHJ/8gKxJ/uF64sI@5XjiWnaFdEYwW05U3c/iCB47/I2PUSCE3@dFbTkQ3Vs2RqZFPTZUtffgX31WInG4IvoVSgXeXF6lHKWUVoa3GsUNDwci4sUElsGwRLerdZduxJZc1HOLnvgzSup9IE27OjCEWORXjCeCK7l3JnbkLk3dix5GfSeRdXLIQA60ZMWOAIQ05xBlGFLgwFDGUdi8KqmxV/0IQgexESb/204vZrjN6zXONoGbpsIvIjKkAnTplI9ITgieH114yTqRUi@8vKb@LMEtVwsYidcxnnDy3bSgjKHmy/edqqUYo6myGX8P3FoJlK0HbzFGVNv1VS9rdfVITg0/5Tj3K3j/KPskSDMMbLcmkNWZjVPE2NywrFA3ReWsRzFvh2zHaA7RcgJhRPONEBvHaxyjj02sQtWEfqtGPUcj7bwQcfMKRR66zUf8OEusNxXCiZusaLUG84ZqdBaLDwKF593hdvLdLhxCO/aMzK4nssYOKjhzC7hpJgw3FXUi0Qlr/3cGFm61C9Jtz7nOU3MhMlg226/HH6m7@1mxNKYtg8Xq5pB7mRxqWaDaeoHoX@h1uuioGr3zuRVxAhuQ7OpEhChRFNXyJ6kkaEhGYAdDqXT12aI/YsJakwU6R3C3X6ms9MsjnFRwXAa1cNOrDj5gSffjnqqBEf3yC0Rr49nJ8Xo1eTpAVmeUe8Hye2jFH5YbxIlYrrU3pX1pYtf7lzvMphU19fG73E22XYVTFO1BXPYOsHQwnuaMBLsXIrZhxYt/tswYaqrTA24XOct5uHnGY02Qy/9E7UINi8myxGBByNWBZwfoXuVCG5xZDcRBUUvQa8JJCwMwE5f4WUhCzHQ0UsrSYKQH6aQZ5z1tZUY3ZuVWzMTvTAotL7KYGW3Q/K7lbyoENq6e4luSOaVQZFPDWvTCBvP@MlGqQUudL9b@1TgC@pWOZQ9I0GAVanK8RBZ8jU7Drw5cnFW0E826wGgHQMnROFFphssQzBSKIvaJ6sZFeGNTjBlZ@xqJ7PjUsFcOdcySgxUkXR@9cxnwYuPRri01A0G1SrEX6KMTt2JXvLw2@ok0MgAKlOBtC46PmvhtPVE6VbpnQ36OpNyTtAgIZUTm0g5WzTzZ0OQWOmtc6EetcN04BdoQkRPT/htEwrKleF0lGAUkRWkhaCi2o5okiWf0@j//aYRttU9tkCwsPaf8gRn@FMXo@If@xIxtRt8e2O1vXzKlcwLYS6F6rVQsC2DDK0P3OATXjqXPn3nl3EJoULPKr/w6U5xXT6WVixS6FUNuSUihoK1Gu1Qt3dyLsE5X7ZtUiMUumKY12tcH2axUSpLlm0@9TH6cx4pBjavsy7Der567hNxL4UWu5dOHl2qFXakfdX1ylH@B2bUAglE1O9oMcWtMHOySY7ythARnEuvgOXjsdCmEpRUlEVZCbxsmipeqp4Gw@b5zMQcg8sMnuq8LegSCd2YbmatTDAcPcntFTNpklWg@3IZqNU5oz6pzA2sLXgUL48L/V7/lwUplw5VTJVkRrSCb3fGuOCxWTxZa4nm83K03D5JaGa0Ov2zjrk7/lM07rY74MCNkrw5JJz5cBQxjo0mFOSh7J14DmxanxqkioTViq7qhH@4a@LLnT4606Ms2RmENarYyjbCOlTovMe3QmHJRaaVWIGQ2iT30LTv0Cf1b1SyjNQzM/x/FOeVGEKz/GepEbmR2d0IBXxZkGdYeoZLTLy/nELkTf/YLyae7YerXa03cAUfP1Kws/qDMcuwNG5OjYOZ@AuUcRJ5L840Im5KCVNq7QgXSGlX2mEU1QYWPXgLnqgYscz1sUHQMkckjQ5aTESBhJyXy7GeJ1A5buyFTrMQRJj2BuepTs@YKCskOho9Go9AqKaskNwOc1vncgcvkd5HecLq9iux1854CLMnCDhl4LEHeAaV3QB@o4o2gjozPAd1jjlJzF5RD2IiobqDJRlze68rZ@vJ0akFhLjz5ZJtr06Agutw6EXbjRK17uhbW6xAf5D@HClldXsDtSLVQH3gzr4w@2ldNkR4SYGGTykKxIwNW8Wh3Yd6gOfiQRzvSAAaXRhqHLDyYpIhBq7XZRHAI6hs7WFB1XSExI8mRTbmw5PJmsxR@aSuiMJ36gjK@sxik6Y8gtcS9HP8/QiZYEVpl6ncTgDmssTk32JVzkJy4pmaBrdmcRKxetyc/VWE2Yg2v7dN6@jQIPxlfeuK@mCojHh8C@CPJ7rh3sUumlKsUaYE2uzsYJhdjcklYbAzxnaJky67iA0jea8Tyo8B9hbod9nzJUdY9gdV8HerHINwA95EYCvDuq4R4@wbo6Bd@s5Vyf8CpIEBAZCGxHIEyXYO3VypYM/l9oAsEQNR31sFukI9SiLCjr@BE@s269A4xK2Dor6/uMDkPw8uH/GzQCcELyRoYE3zQI07RxGLLjEuPKZzOvuCgBpzw/X6Br5YhwU3EFr1KT7OfwFAGhv6M@B4zeYLkSMs4mUS4plCciRLXskZMeE6rhSschFz4UdAn9cleCei6N21YrAdWv2gNZvASDzoH7Fh9wibB7AzcoEWSZKEyxlfKqd5H7Al9tmahb0BFe2QODa/wCUix/mI8QoU6dt7clBWkRRSLzKuc0Q7fw5mYBK38cBovm4skfnkpMxOXy5mZHPIt0gViyvIxeRji6sXa6/Q6Y7QvSUaJAfRduWDnbjynF7qbUB65WKgx8a//cpUFyTtThfxKi@yAcDfh@mcG2WYKkXqmESgMOBby3EacUpyI7kRf/SiQk3umirmurBZNTWcsJa0bhdgKTw6wi70TcjJaRZ7Q5xFrC9CKih2YNIRdFXa9auy55B7JlMYMUfBy0RaWdW4Q7EMyDJY6Pc0shgGJIqYJuftQtKfIxQbpfFdIC/gB@1mRv28ogTk7jzKHRTDIzx@HPPCCqjHZKKmQzUilTvKHylk2/stuT01VjxmtQZUP3Y0cnOo2Qy@DRgZexql5U9hJeSYxNSJmAxquHuPqDeeTJIhMWkBfgqLtxSFtmuOVrFcLYkrfJFjD2OvRxxw1Sm/JVxaZ7eHOzow5t18tUeUl7GNwU/GXv882zZ3Vv4b1v@f0vZrHi5/8g8erFNXNcNadtm0SEr9sijg6JovX5vFJeYU8hx8PqEpYhzLE5byWBQ35yx067fSHNErSH9lD7a8oRtSMxNURVIxU1aDe6ymuRfWxu3fD9exwa3AYYlIrzr7ZeCzS0Xs18noy6crWtG3vbUH/gtkPcgYDDDnijjr04j95n7yL09pCNco/miI2AdlBqyCNkgoIKMgj78B4gzMNRG9YJ8FqMDTOn2@SCAfHAI8HQIERynEmtMXBoI53IPsNU8dZ4TkEdak0h6nqgxyYQvIlP/9L2Rd1jN/QP9lfj//RlxG71/F7jzIVzBBOgqEX70TYFV3gj3HoPn7fcQcAb0/eqJrDsOSSrIpyi0Z/OP7I@3F8YnDy5AZWGV/PXOwpBYTGUCDzMbazivloWZCrVSBYIkAs7Q8FlGO@ATPWDWw7eIkIUEnXSxzcohbdrinUdcF6iZWXkHh/fSrg7ycVp7ViC/6Zgae2qD1lc35EDkYMkcMwcNePs0L9rnPl3eXQwIAfXKcSAqdIGHFA1m0O94pT6@@g9wJu1z27MU3/SBaie7ViS6t3Rvt2H9zD1X6LtEiEkIpYiWWsBAORyyR4t0E8Q2pzhplBiM4D34WNwvLtE@yEXpHRxCX8tMaaHcMD@YQ25BeKHa30UCIydEboUiV26KOfNh/ewmP7m6kt1zN74b/zZG@/NygFniuoUfxm47wieHrrOcOkLOubW6a6@nwK1mcuU/Gi/5C6AYR@fAmQAOXZGq0Um6ngUBYurL2E9QqdS2QoFxczgD5TxaD4nqiVwwpyb2Xmip1cOu@Bil0KI8YeNAKgx2o16Xfylx4CImvh0Eh9yQZc6aDO4UKJ@ZOD@Hk@wwGXp@YbQESg1Sbtgx4dzosZ5@G3gjfdQlTxG9nEtE2tuLypX3r0k5oSy1gd/tLKEbnbxOdE4cY/O4ED6gnQmlq9xixUfLQhyGNwUF/AG2w1RM8mh19mqwcXWLT5AcigavzAJBSTUTNhmbCiXwRAp02N@HOVKyqyGcDAij@QQtK@uQjh5GtQ0syEcpnkaUbZdkzfsPebOjQrv6r5a5N1kQjIk10IJJgLR20fzOBvKSbfFGyaNnJ1uALsDXuTIACmdFyRuoIBCxBZVVsjSdWN5QBez0vgD9tqok7TM4hs0tJ3nhMSLOjuNwF0l6pyJEccWBP/g6ExOorT4NN03S7FaiinEAH9w5H3GVCK4OQ8sWLDdMR1W7sEbpFxw27TDZO5zWB7eNuVG3@rEbZaUw7Thv7LnH@IOf87iHEUr@POEzaL08Y/NySAMLxGHzgqdt@qhKQZoAVuggRYcqf7PgxRhl8JgkIZbtmv3lRM50fV1hkI72foidtL/h@Qaym4CfL1QXa5JYZZihwXkwnAJ3j6aFNoFzmgM8/dSygM1U@Gqs@HNvS@M7NM3Jnd0ZXWvb7sQA@MbqXGO67BBI7hWE0T1Nuo3yS0grsk03Tdgs3N@7bzxIxdGJqBV3VRvrdkpBtqRB@jFRkHffeMDtvSpQ2r/iGKwsRJq1hyfKgJgPcHGmx@FpONLOC/NSdMhiJjZiU4gYgsGWvVXvYNnEdFQQxcc2X8bYNl32IiK/VjEOmgDKOYjM@om3owNXW0@CZ5anZ2gncSk2V/313oxSmAV4HRfLQJY7/a7nOXEBh6wkA5KeRwClSpn4uzAcg4Ge6kcOxi5YkNEbvM4DDYFP/8ce98ihs9ZJf5sgGPsqn2a1uo8dOvUx9fBDEdZ9BV5nHQMeEuPlv7VhIScbACgXCVSPe5qJLftX/K/CsCRCtIe1bIdrDyCPmQp9@tatX5sTr@baTWBkf5rk/E7@A6rkma/CaPcWPaDiiojZ3F1qG0MuQgMrmtOv1svL36Dp3pdQz0sjk7ghoJLQ/UCatHsfN6kfeFd8NBGZyNAbSk0@j74NiDI5uDhWukodtunN8zlBwgtw0EuoQsWxuIxuuPWroDOTwbWZ8TERL2hZ7tE0VakJaq4pEBsdGFBuVe0YckMJY3em1ZFnqV0b@uLAa0dL3LFkOLSVjHeR7ertVdJ/j1Ez4zEfcSTDGEiC2Cs2C29nKwnaw37TAZbusi9zJAUN10lGMCY1CSYBGnBrn37LLqVTRTktDSr3j5eQ6b1BM29FI322SbWZOctvGosBOs0fN9fxGywpXKTiRNR7jI2Xx0tG4esJVSsFLu67scTXVSsb4m2zRJvReAbPec0amR5QbpmunjXRQxDg2v0LbdtuyRhVbeeBLjxlmHYT7O/nhv4mKSWFfH78Rfzt6qQ/kW@9KACEg4Dp9tfBiAP8@oqOi5Ywe@rdInbZXP1hh8sAoDoXgReF6FL2nYa7mKfgbjUOGWB6B1kv36i1fV21wvRRfr1XZkA6D579kzxe12NJUlAkXlZOxz4QxzX0WgBl5RgtwAzvgwign4DvRU2ZhKZpnYhTL2z7BPwzfbdwCrjp8w0aB27bLBb4d@R/K@JuaOArvBaA3yTrq8lIbETrdKkVAyrRmy850RoaB6lsnp0lNfAFtJ4HQwRjpVoOyLj94g5xqtyUblEnRWCw5gWE5eapHFlPJlgMGFo5ZqlE5tiqNuLnE4m8o8VFPDukqzgrTRoqC1Iyy72BqQuoia1OrWx6oCIXuR0ZaZl4T@apBP5kUD22QSTwfucyurRJlic54JG7kTupf69qTQAGThk6BmxCUXES6tvaknlSUS/atA3/vPMGJxyMgznwXpyRpIYnzsRme8jXoOVxm/YPoR6mHf0VCGdryPOTkqtRANp4fyNA@2d42MEc3MGOakOwjS4glwD7KD6jTzbJQAi8@bqS1g7Io0jCAf3lVpB/CNqVGpbsbnRMOZsGr0UWGN6IAItWX143yEsZgh7xgotU4T1Pk5Pd0CAUPyuWDjIXS9qMnJyOtHCBK3fPfnjU0RuiSEkoMeTejXHVFfHsF0DBmf4Tp7DeBWUPsaE1Ew5D9XKD97gaBYXr1XT4ECmcUrwzojKnOpDbocevmf3vg5M6P9UURqSsBILVwS@LR7J9RRxLwJ@c@X46g2ft@51xPTxn7fs48P771T3vpfzvo3srHG/@BBV6LfJvyjwyMCyK7EPrtBId2J/zP2gDxM/CMmv7Oba6Vjverijnp/Vy7aPUYwQ1hCG4jIe8Y1qVxgxizsyvOVtlx8a9PeOPlOwMCAQWDL/pi//mA6wN/DAyMkngN21xMwTJxkGoAgfvoWdfzKWe6EOct@Lg5BjJTuR1bwB8nYyja2xsaptxTXaGqBxnMgD7xBYCDvNhT3J7UjlYus6Kt@QnTP2ZBnrBexwzU51IpXNTVBTaPSi/7dWjlgD/BqnUuTh9UUF8XQY66NkE5kG79tmUYJCmeDF1T7@kHZky8vj@p9VcdGU7ccYGxYRSdI5GAi20SoR4zZsB7fZqhA0pG@vrkIr2Q7b9gb7aGSndyiLHGeCr0uakMP0u4set66uPJ3AlSK99ZwprpUQYwP7BhJGI6TUVweGIDpmWmXGB@WV/zyZCgFIab/pCPK2TrgZCmNrw0fSNq0eHYAATKC@@f/I//PEW4A6bm/5h239xouTbi/VKK7hDzKBm@ggfwaJm2Ntji/l77px4sToxkKNEThzTyJkNibxITFfNA7dVxRWEZWplAhfP1YJ291P3RAD6atgZRBNUNuF7K9Vwa3BgBkVlBXR27ei6x9SYUs91gBMpX2rE7e8Dn2qEszF5g73bKpycx/eqxk9mhm1USuFHweoFyS10tWSgm8rXFHVK88e7HqA3PqhPz9w6fcz/SGBNqYrsEgcEiB4Numykh1rYYm88mDr1qTBnzOOg6o2/dgDvDU24hNoPSEemAqzeTHQibSxDsD/jI7OdLQDCYQvAj7FgCapTRXJBxmdVeuHtiqb3pKmqVIya6iaEaeBPYeAlzpYVolD3GKIu0aVbFu1H6YTPXHX0dMBSvcJKb9KR00LHI8IH4kGhy5j3HAECBYwnyUoIRpE3i8T6vVwNb1ZL9b@c/U0PTp78oevDp@qgcaTPzx9Gd14B9@qdweMpm7UoxjVC7yDsSp@Ga1v1jml6CFA0MfVM2CMCDi4DMnLRBEvoh6@jJ4cH3/VenpDUY4wGOFiawucXOA9hI450VodHhxe5GM1B12zgZY6OaEbk1o7xE5Ey/i8nKGezew9fipCYP4KOuwcGR1ABuCShFZxCfmfiv81QpSBHrt4U13Sk8R/mynz6PeWpZHAdl5jJCiM3U79tqp3wP4FxwaVCFNxlQO6Z@Wwb@gAAqNE6qPI29VRo1@76utKUK1Qe1Y/VbArPYMmpfKahcY3RHB72fJ7iwAHSAKNZKnywmyZAEADir2433KioL9u4I8SflmKFCjS1RXiByBZkdQI1hdM0DinZsDVTCWkzANdjQUpSl7KtwBHWVR/t5LTcR7vtVaJoT@3owajOafPqAJM0Ylilg2ncCPmDHi8AhSeozPfpAYVpO21TUiAz8LOwgpxzdgd@906p2NUTYewqz/sz@cOPO85QPLWJBWgVaKP2Uzkd2/mMN2C02MooCxlQWoRuZEzEAWeCbzP1PgZX2kc@he0w72zAnrRJbEw8bVAGvvtZBZfKVa@5@KzJBmG6Ep7m2pJMFLZfM12Y5teFYUW0Ce5ryC3FqQHlMwQYaQC1vUFfBTiQA9RhemtK4ZaD5m@FRfDwn5sI7e8v8m8Vt8Mnz85Rcf0MQNVzXFohqq0apZwF97hGwbejnN8kQCRgD1i3FaPXYFdRDMR9oOEafrXZiu3i9vjXflKwhFeINVC9Yr868jpXQVSeGdhcg34Z245@0XTk@Vyyc6dssVLf9g4sU@vQE7ypN93EmANPOLM514Xz9W0sCgBycbOYpNpH6CA1GmnxHW1esGqQ3J4ip8MdrY0FYx8fuAlUpF3F87u3Bk623RYVSiHhKD6gK7fpeSk76CrStKxUmQXShIZbcEgiYdpidW7vG5fm6@AoI4hmsURRytWejprBV3PWHmyFqZjpcUVvXHJnGSFbq9Wqb6SgloyiZeXV1AvCR@jWkiw/6Ju6htIF599ATCO3MAXNp8g/cV1gKfR6AQPj9mgBrqb5/mba3zKNcmN2rn5oaOPKTXjJAqVZDkXXA7Te0SRU0zOwfMWnPq5ka68qZHYH6C3VqupqTjX68D2Y8D7LGiNvlTDYNTcuMa5az@4xtwa9FQlblIClFnIF9QV@@85lTjFmVdl0sL26nF6XyMg4jKY9xFPWg2sT/D/YZWA246jE3QG64w/vP@63wL1kAgRAMUAtYXrkWjahcuSaGOq5gAt8voBO9Qzxi5SGeNonuopjrfVWQnfKHBhJVPqqBFRa6LqSNONGalNt6py7VTYI@@YOvj3DOo8frx8TVEQvkoSMnQwb9/A8rokai1ZL2YCBuJvYCQLXQK9UlqI1crN0ywN6ZMc3kkBrzsTP5nwlJLJPzsSsCg0N74kPVkyukMB4aUMpkrKqFxA53mDsi2uvAkd3qaRS/JQm5GhthsiI4DeEExBKSqiJ8vmzXkwb4L7qGKC@wrgEtT9r1IbmBFdgR7NTEQOUBJfuGMD4IVqbOpA9UN1MGhDedfmATSwWXjeyfAxLi2n2lHiL1nEUQeWZ0s5Rh1iTAvcKE7XyOe0fD91eGGyTzNOCm21cM55Odri5AYu6jOcY2k5f1eb/T6/cNFhgBPVESoO9@Ab6hydzNdz1gNs4rvbyns8pLRZ@P2ixrlS2DgkyM5hIosQofEcxxLBPND1gaubJuxGykYCdXkjm3rXLwL2gth0B1UIaK5llmsFyc8V/TM1J8IJR@NExwJbL87Ka1Xp7ZU90SET0iIlPPc65VlYmewJpnvPgLtzUXIbJlFpg9xOrW7YWbOnAt8kl77JuTGfeW6Nwm6mhnrw12JeEMyp6OAzKFsUaPqSIdqyvdJOfzY2QlgYpVdZ5S5oJAj8dcxBKbkrOfhhWml56gfO27c5qTgpBFDD8HonaiK/H5lZwrCcWVHMF8TjiU@kT/USmxOAeIY2RGVvfITgoio8UehZZqjb12RqF7sEU/QatXJZc4k8MYNlBidyWF9WfS/BF02WgvBvaN3jkcqBT2@XSE50AJyohhYlKcpmIYNUDXewScQA9xR3FbCFIG39TWGvE3YFOUFqXya2nMfAL1AUw9BdeR3eVJk@0jKyrKkmTdTOvwLsBweh3uTMC7S/I/VV4ZEOjWdiHWcIGxmIIiU58f0l6Fhj3ft3avxy12g6uFx64t7hSzFDVZ88ag4Nfkv6HM168/kcAG44Ut/7HYkmQKSM/NGs299dI5n@50Z6K8fCky08cb0WPYJSbJcx0mx5qY8rwQG@F0E3jFGREAOZlBCwiAEDH6gpqegzGLNB8AL0awH@tbjw9PgUCMVR7yG6Sz0GLEKdyOmYdB91lE4K@79/Ngr5B/sCPjDSXgSQwqHS8TGRF7wBGGDYJNUR9XI7@DZwRuBx@3kLzkIJdeqrWXOjqc7DDamHaqdyKp2T7Q5ZKCQITWe4xlyTaeyEAXc9wC81rC5IiBTy0L6cL@dodQ4lg8bpcuENZebYxDZqirVmnoGWkaDMYdensF2VOZNxYd20J@u7U8EXMvhNiQwsm8PYAH0HC@gS@REGBb3cPGzZ7VZemUS9u6HFMtzUBqlVriJZcA9h6TzDxCd8yzu4SOwwNFk@3Tk64UDQIdJnSHrXMmMHGdgqB3wn@6CQZlKsiOJFMBWhSxXt2SppGD7C8vpZXxqifdv9NgRLVbg1UiGoxiWs@Xd5F/eFA3BgAKtkA5yU4MAtP2UAKsATNCgtyRaeupNORGqGFNKvJFsKa7sOWUZq35igTrDGnpWUZCFfEPUFLqpMGukp1JVb/cCNSjiGUz06j9C5SwS3Qic59COH1iih33PI0d2Fsv5H5tQanrAcpKaAPb1oNHDV1CdyyX2Qy2q4AFLAkU8LSAP0zFi/lsTA1LF5fCnDtJBYjiaURb5efPKG9KFh9BCNwOZ9vzvxL0k7H/Yd6G6QgjHiLWKaUWEmyCqkESJsGF5Cb60gCWUUHaoOq8T5YDfOL2yfXYexp52@p0lDKz/k3WF0ECK1s1VEoEDWVK2AWsJgA2p7MEPH0LjWp0Zd4km6OJdNbFlunEqvVn6c/Hj8sWmFTCk29VdYkhZhPp/3pj/vTX8Ke9Or6QJsnQOHbJ6DZG6nFNCEdiTxOnDH21H8o7O1P0B7dzUcuoKl@w58Dz3SIFEz2@etxYO0BjsIAehsVesS/KRpcpk@nYM3DiwZPvnDUwrp7uHmWwstEKx7upm6P8rOZI3VGKDiTXs0/8k9MG0rDU4DFRyAY1N8LrJOfeDF1zTSxckWQ/bpdAX2D@9/njFCoD8m1xk8boZkaMrQxYV6M1IhYyPg9O6NxtAP0agJVsMbsxPUEIWiqysfQ7PwFNOqGDWh7oB98sNqInsTEyuVS8xJEYozozrPSO/w6GziWzDZmKkQ1BeF5EvU8gtIIaDkVONwQI8Bsy1o4oXEem2hfoEGdpsu58swXi7n8@VyJdEcPmC4UkTXJVMTy4ivk/ngYB/U@sQwxs8tB7sZ0T7EjzEZillHsGOKaMuapSaqFUmFT3HlDeWF8hPtp@LmGuH@LSNy3qox@zYjQ@vVzOfJqCtXY0gZ1wKw1jujiaskQX/XOh1Qqe@mqfYp5RI7w2sA0oVSNe7NT@JomOZeplrthuo2Vc7sjPYqfsukYzwuhAa7YmOyIls66X/k/EP29VG1Nb1vMxSutGPUT@nufOx86qEYkxvD2N7p7oNVjR@RX0A7XY0NlCP6uMS4VtF3mFVz8PhBqgMcHfkzXNE1RmSggWYHCPbqDbLhisJVtmBVt4bU27bipi6av0qceBP8O/3hdRtx3AZjA4p/6yUwrsfh0IxWvdjbe5@85/02DzO8C2l@c7tWk1rUPniL0xl0I0ZFJmPz57PvgsMlW7zAlG2mjNHA72H7uecr@Vgd@FQocOq3XV@fw0Qu7xyWFtsQ9QWheG3Y3NKGtjZ0c5dd2XCahGwtwTo6KVpgjOfroB/MXwdqLtxtIpYKrucAbJxLWERrDGAese47Y2e8RQ3Y1HTGVKeDNTZXw7gwUPXXljI9LOAEsGn7vAVzy8Z52BY4QTHH4RkpLQQJcAY6ETw3RchpE4qkpXlSreDklhkzla3m073BObHOjYRd3Zawvfq82rSz1SZZfYTVRUiGsPboHby5ppXD5y3UqiNlkm@10xEP9qoQigj5IWh6Ea6Pz2L1YzpUg9kDRTw@9saNQy@GE//ns6@pFaOdIuEbpJEyQvDk4Pwpr4XCNgWsX6K9GbFg64B18KavevTGiaagq8BrnqrLeFGNU@d5C/8nsoyqKqVjcMpSVCYx6/CSB0xCBEENdfCBKUtPTCesEPqky7pscA6a2n4X97kx6q7BDhiTigl/znCWiMkUyceY01mwfD4iURDQmU1HLWadM1rLQpTFKYvpE6z1SV9aL1dUHuzidO6YiUA8nztdfOdZSoSGQZeSUp9Vgp6n8dsHPq/zOOZznqeikUaxpPIUIEJ9HtrsZWgzDdtN9GlBCIomPeo5amyJHm8xTYDvzYJ0UCDmw/tSMfCS3l7IWmeIpUwKVShKyxBhmp0yOylFkPolu6LnldDAxjsCPds@ahs3ziR36pDZcllpd95/DTohKkJQFf3twPXyrcWC3tVr1L7aqdhuqIYkBceeOguYXV0y7TyjNKG7qJfxg5R0Cgu00U3gP8fNeJ9cCAQhSSwiswFiwJ4MdCzo9zxdJlQp0GdQ2YWUrjFbJsYWAc8tclGHOuvwpmiRYxRSGzApAjVaoPbEQutREGg/G0yuMQVuG7i5lsHr5585qNOqlpfW3vNCuOhCfMbjXLQKL@QjswgKSh@xHtRI@JzN0WNU1I/7OQWK6Mbm4w8Ufcz3QH3J5c0R15Op/oG4@BKjCYkjOSSg0Z37BlQAznOKwYpflScPwdBVjKyCoPqG1ei4LZb34Z85hcnOZZIja48Nx0EMalU7QqVEnKBSvCs5pX3atpGCttKxzOUsgCQ3A1ZdWGAvnRpstvxDcEUMN@emoU5mI4tvlW4N6N7DtFvIVxbBqTEgYK7G59BKJ/I@K/mmaF1THcnag/YAnNcO2IOtVq9mzeyeP9Aofz1W9JaSXA4LFbCQ389lqtGNZH0bjlCACQRPNSYIBTAuaDQdcPKl/tmNE6D3Qan/eQsj9cwK@k0mwGIHgxYqZmYS49QStnjuY9T3E7nKzZTXr8qezvl6O6Ktj3CUTtuUKtlyhtQRpnXq4VY2Dldk6XHuoVpF43DpHwE4Rx51QI5z54HXpY1MNdJUj/shzzAzVQZZite9V3WEFsQFmIXXNSknn3zPxu5L0VY3KXjiDqlbiR@XHiJuQKhBi3vG10t5XQbJkR@GGHrr9z3uP8ves05DTpTlYa@ZR53jKd44cGyLkdPxu@LvNkkcRYuXoNG/YJZk6SBJwyWrjZW4HbRSmB8fZw8LdVIJvKOPpz6O9ZE8fE/8IdpANdVvcJgIEBOiTgUVZdorrXCfQJ4UkzU51AWVJXAhNqPh8mw8WdMnU3x8iuu3Y2IqKoZV3uNjrYGu2NQ4NcVOYeMw3WhZk1kpO2h0c68oi82Q2YQgUhpShgHhDy8wROfGY/ptoZM7AvRB/28YoIVyk9zcbSin8T46eNODVPR/5dF6Rkgur3qwB0IFgZTQGM@n1RNyTRGABwNUyyQ@eIIrETCJ2qp2z8KkMIuKtcVoIKJ0aZpGsepxFLg9X7ZsyStHe4tmce2zpzUqw3YCPA5@0mi7iwgoHCYWSaN0OcF6OhHpR0tOjU4O8Tc9xt99xsWNiKFCrLxKEDiGj/aw@OTwaTowfq1KA8CJU@8tAoyDxNw5OoM2JPbjPPEbq2XFGIxcqSLxprqbZcu4AzyIyiAfDNcQQfANgj/zaBv3qwLmUsWMM5iAG2QWLMctoxEP0y/z5wiGlecWpriMWeQWzD482gMb37vCJVpRGZC5z6raRaralgcccTbD8w0I4EHTDjtmJoJeslzC6dmOHw3YQCmbA5zroIu7HgsplUS@diCFVWQ5enDj4C4ejIxKk10HF5QIGZiesLAQtBXjgtId8cKBpoJ0wptdvZXxdPjtCadjxZpOtrKmwl4rP/LW4Uy4opNFNEy1acnqntFoe7lc0yyaTV1BNDzHb3gmJa4KwC0KOusq5d6QopHSZjG60YdtrkKLydtBAxX6gbP/LIuifuWK62VkahHI/0PfQP2MzO1QIQ09KfW26ubeUnIN1DfWBmZYEBrLT2ChysqboJQN8xcbxChibr3yPD4gGqd4nDAqzmPpia91aXhOhkbbJ4wEWKuEQnjEYOqUwhABrN2Lj3K9KTl0urSgiW/kUkJvIwOvP5B6GV6k@fcmCeiOZv8MrkBx47oOre9IWuMe5xbIGIAu0tiDem1Os3losnRf2SEsZI2QnI5BHTFAd4VomHoIQZO3jNA38iEETfSSfI8@4LQE9q6mgnv0eZOpfJOJTHL6Qf914D5v@RHowPrPaff3GvVby8qunRh2MNFHCjgti2kp@jRLH@aIuUc7oGu0DEiyrBtMBQxeTvy5AURDN9B4ughu0U2mEU6Xdr4pVEPulKgCkZtbfMDWdlucd4rfP4Aoon19WcKmuRws9WjPfD2ikgOjSsw9g7hdQ3yNBqB0auZv8m6RU7b8Q9JlwjCPRmrdJwTbmBQB58sIxmXkr5ZBEY3x28ZCM0asW1zUl@0l1i62zyp3cos7/jLazbVZxpsE6JgNbUZfGy0m7viWFbe6sVv/N9JfihrfoY03MO9LB6fMU@Ocz1iJtAzgtGKMzjspzlp1Yl0n3ms7W/XN3E@9pAxDo8Pw@ZPZ6VeHT3ETAjmuvrxrnO2vlDTWO42zBfs1PgQ/9FnmRUkBlJlF7trVc7pwR5@cVfaiYBfX8SAF@kbpveS7vn/X9@5ouqOi77IUOux9UUf7T/ON77VN5UjjLc8VR1WFrool4rYzug@oKbNWR1nPKTcKC0IvJ9h4v8MZHuoDLfszPNRHFfMJB7jfo9Mce7nu6t@PlQXdy2ZRMtm0rKRSpPtkjevBy2xqMglKevKRmjUeD8EracwzcHNzLsk2a0W0gCMvmtABhkVmwl7exV1ecf3bQ7jHsHSiL3ElrgfpVzBfz1vz4@PG@ZTUMZaIQVMhjX42/QgMQ/Jj7@iEdLcpsexrArnoPJ0zusoDNaCOajXwzkyT90cdK@zUawiX677JuK/Avxd0yBHBu@9T/RopBRtQZHh@fJobFZdUZdg2Yp13xiikd7Ym0EIO6bbHCzD/EKTmbZra2zU8gg5hILuQ@BlFBMHndxzJkDfzhTtYOIOFC/44RsjRVYXg1fd@FV/mVOqU1YGU2zHehDedg6nlknfi8VZA49S9GCFc3kURlexF2QS2OZk0CGCvhoT7y63IK3auE8Z4L4w/XjcFUv9tNGnuKiWGy9veocdUVQOUgGsmONHRnGTkXKq5cwcDnz@Ggr58KxFz2UwmFbjkNWu1Eu1ttAtvnHnojgPCk3xSEX070mQCw5JvPNhSAnVWQuu@oJPGsmQB85i75w3n8z47AMrnKLosnufPom/4uyTJCw1cDjprYPIOdj6UfpekuQBAgNhTfflmXn35Bnxlv2nMzjE8VQVP/vAUxe5NYl6Eu1D2tavxsjuLN8j2u8zAi7XFTVv3iOMLrf/@GU35M5ryZzTlTxVN2VqgUWXXGFzrJEMTcGCnMeh7si/eJJSSZN4ZXvMWYX/@2oTkYDPKho7qJKW2FCw6unP1E0infHxc@oyPwroYnBrN3iIoyiWh8mfS4v9nQ/WZ9uDkk28oGHQI/gMikGTJW5OWASEccbFK2RT8nw8wTZ5e17k5eHiom4YzVvRqGbhdgKfB5y58dWQYBQVonEyF6zxanR5lUomeVGPDl5B6FlySf591UX42@g61aY6PU8GWApKD0Ml6AjcArCtS5Ht/VhqtbI4rLwLSC2ZXm9KgA5AAFgYhMYEN51ZEaJMiSTVlgVNIMO2Erk/77PRDb/iCR5jZmExNAm@MstMk/0INBZOBezkOEQxKCXxTtiC9/xb237sckseK/6D//u6d0YdPnu9yM@/eUY13STX6BDG8d3UHVz7dXYgKM9dlVyi8@uqcBVy4rAMhK0i6F7CBCQvW72DFmnwg4Vqvlaa8Ksfg8TGhvptWwhLFPjTOmIIGW4B3@wL/c5eoJEbPMJ4rAeIXWXKU8pIZibp1ZIGCfp4Qb@2SjCPZyqSqDNKyq8J6EYVsq3IRpRusfJHuLNYSpyASFHMwMOYS63BsQg@9PcC7NCTrKjA5HUtApQkSBkE4ThSJZuQg@H6xbrz@BuF51BQZQSv9mJsorl8iWuCDRAOBrMYDW7S@guLrUu956ievqViZAHLJ3jwO5p525AjqKia4AKVHeKx@G@Akt17e0C9FSXdCxpSBBgAEx7hlpfidUwMhWck6U68NTk3AjHqrTEVOOqr378IYOqCFkfqSotqiCUGna2Scn1FYnbjw9cGakpWqoS899VCmCDUPXLLhwoQltVck9J4dLyKW0O1ldC/yjItUy1mqB1vfLu1sO/QfySPRnusMxmG06dp3oAwAKcED56zrQkki40W6EUo8TEu8tu11@3qLFAR1DNFoCzh6N95LbslT0PUMzgoPpBwrzaJ8o3iQZIVur1apvpKRajKJl5dXUC@JEPNaL5yevLeNU3Vszp6H5CIUnWq3QYu4CTbGQIJfMsHAVsqxj0htZoxptBgOe2h6vaYK5Wm03BuN2qzN/Ug6067R9G5y6mkyGmHQnhKJiuE/vNIuYbvLpYf4@@UpwnvsuFuU@gTQQekBNwyLM4Cm4sZwWqkBmComKJky8YcsBr@wpgxL1Tk549vZvYzFYgs0etmhqp6lTAEbhL18pyLV5Cv3VXF59WiTpMLyz13AKEM3i1cwamy643ngku5vp3HixuhLlj7wvfleHQv4JSzdgVdaoN7KONTtqK@cJOBTICOXXllCWe/51wKzBPWcvdCjf8ZIttNiVJ@g6z3JoN84vGacA0z7BKqkoZJZ7klxxoOVrP6O2i1pBtL9xgkac@DaK5iGAKojIBASuo66n9Am5wjJBo0lDtFHKqcAcBaknIvIdJzbBDYz5G@Wmo/6BDwAMSCLX8hUnwjupZqbQIJZWaMqCMmLpyobhzql5rsDGHMNeOw1IGt3iEKbAD7JfbaB55jqIbZgoKEbr74c22nAKIGdY8ggnqQeDgPQjmoncxaQ4YTFMnj2SlzEp/n71w6cOaIBPgw@/SUNfqsJ0HQDpoIOUpsAMQhTwrAXCJCIGHJV4anKt4nn2mfcEvWGbVPcE/uy9t4bQAabY9Teyd2pegcFZfzoRD2q7jiCH1ITEc7dO468u0YTtLMrMm5kc@5AeY1ONS7GZW/Y@HF4c8mUlnGF34XfJZuq3kNYKybNw43NmA518xkJmd7ZxKa7vfk6to3cO/6PPoO/BWkIqsCk5vO5uBZP0Is4lvwHVNIp2VQH1@MJQO007VKPbMLgYAPVUZyltSuyrXbMF7Z3J43MU2nGIW4zNMgR/6mb1jiHQ2IrWRQ3zkGlp14NGG/xpyJgUb1ACZ4HG/tR4crYa@pSvfUbsPUagC/UvWVotjPwAUPxU5H8aWaq3Y/52onWZMP91R@e@nFjhrN2MA9Phyux@qUhutMhRMIF6E6w5w6AI@w4A9wMBrVTlXgdqJH41lXEzwfSg5yEjPKnCe1B/9uAFNycWE11OPbA3wol2P/zBXPmlM/ewuooe3yZif2CbD2oW0fOaCaBk0bPWxtTB5/3GX6uI8hI26ijamJ10H3glQNSu4AF0kF/qZhgIBmqB0bjLJXN8OsFh7ok9eopbalqa4xk@XANDsxMGE2EIdQJmE58eP@Wvp8ACJWlqewyEahhATjYyZWQL7YjlTspUW4bUbxCgfOCBJzqlwRKGS4qeysBR2fwK43EcNQ0Eb1eBo1DPZ0BHIugEXiIJ0gOgZIEMO8Z99HpeR1WRhfWEbr/UBNDYmK1gkz1Sg2gIPLCnpWADebw9LU/Dw3PQMol7QwBds7cUcSQHkWp9gYp5YTOwzSTJuyWrQKha0HNwjoT/tzUS@UczrCNPzwcsg4LSuBldUNvLkwu3ZgLCkVl2klJ5LOrNVLu0mef98loTZ8zAgEDXnKHOtGkZZ9@X42/6BUhX21UpAsvh57WtO@nYvU7GO9MkIi6Jr8/ki5JeKLE@3lB7OMsiCGQAlthNwLx8BczkEaP9QMcC2INkeOJdusddPweQA6IEBEDgmgWZLjzJFi0BxBDbBokhALteJC01sXjX0yb0mZgJP9yC7BJE8SSdCS7FPFkEl6IE0H5piBGCUF9M1A4bSfbcCUIo6meubFAlggGper4y4irMXSJ071RxwIiho0cuG10A@B3CFVUjaEBvbMddhonVdgYUdhixfW9fO4yEfVDdh4GtuSMlCDelAT8nDwreZqWR0/XL5NQvS0ei8H4fhm4PPY301723TdczJ0Og59jAv5pQ1oHjqlKXJlVZiU6KUVVqg@kqx38CfA3HM3W1XftDv0HIAJEST6LaTJCtObRaGQSI/o@wooJIlPGNldOYXzfBu0EexEFPEzjARa3m5Y0jo7ZdxEOCtQreFhW@OGfc4QcmrcWwbwVvh0jRFPLhamY4hknMu5Y3ecxyvj0GoQ792CNfoxCMRntB9dqlBWFZFAUI2gYUpwhu8wgh4fwlygvqPG1x06y1EjJj7DqN/Ng7r6Sp0dxddJEpmVmMiTjH6WTp2uCwdtIHzAeBHhGCJ27ZE6WWp2jMzrIuE393/DTR4MVKIGRxAmFnpqZnWNQXFyxJGiccD6WYce8cUgkHPQ0ncgaj@RQPXKgmhs98u4tzd9i6Q/UsAO36gAghNHscfH9EVzFrq4Y3ibO293@oRfkAPVp1a/6Hjk1xzqD06K@JUvPCrn8@lFLHR6OsCGomyei/DJzf5xd4yNQIEpRSzZDyKfuhfDh/VvOkpYrmJcIDX3Zt39b/aj4zxEo9ogOUF2CRdATO03ZKgxAYefjDk0sjs7Ciyzp8qEaYuh0dxaTTcgETZLU0TisTx@J8fB4GrJVr/RQHZ9h0X7jsGjQ4bxzifG5Op49o62Ym5sbSah3WdM@eZ8mTYMqug7Hixp1F7J7K1N5mr3HqPQTIo6x4Bmfs9cvjioxPihvGCedlNB8v@snkrAX1nES5EJGfdocdgY0B@w9O1wPVe9G0FoH09ABZRH3YqDPalyDMqYUbwfsOX302KuCgzPS5R8Yi0e/53X9ntywO0f99GhoV5LS1XTC9u62rYx0/dqRfRTyuXfb97AsAXd@SvV5HQUA7DC4voYtk@/DWTy/uvLj7534e5prcnytxrkBBK3raycmAxE/olXZJ62v/viUAKHV/9GIRJCwlhNf4yExHQgq/eH9G/xBP2/542XQb6rGAMiriUDTPjmbbq6u6Y8mlJHDM2DVJZuSzFzDVxoxxApCtgWYGiODIjoG16AZYt8sul2qHX5IkvJdLOhNrIsHmEw3bu9GhbAOeu6zh16VpyO3zGX3FBTeLLyDDvhq0O7RcOeOjLF7JIadiLItzADsYRRHjD8q2OrrEcAxbJ1gG9u1ABeUuLrKmZeJtNwzmu2TnbDEpLqOEHNzO12DsbJAYNpJixslUXn5yTtjAko5wN8APRZPHVJnsAmNwDs6YRJNCGNTp2uDDKBSG5OsrHpvLwFERI2zrtAvGxBNuWoSdsVQwbS7UJweV8@Riqe45Fwl/VSpp7urHjxo@6Q9UxkiL@aLvwXcUwvNYj@TAFhR@1qgjWG0K73gnC6vnwL5Yq6hZjVwzoPGIZyZfHe5AGt31JJHTXlY90qSVHoJgyNemvLS@YEauTT9bnk7anD/wnsBd/4FLmK8wAkXBridgkHt3j6erm0vqUia6Kgl/zz2kVpEQ6xGbwAaT1by/vVL5Gr74dlzNSnIjdxCmm@TfC7gOWNviwowITTmcckQua6uYFMA7KymBjDdpMjCzrGs7XxARYkqdqVyj@82htxNWA5I9dwmUUiXQmDp5oKc0uw0lU/exbx7E1q8b/V0PQrKc1Gw8hO3c5uQehya7Zu8rk2tkEzXwlFUI9dm5z3oEqutXfvAQGNtCFQaHp2Br1L0KEqbjG4vVKO7FTlSi9AMHT5457Nhsufp/1yyY0G9bJv2OmFXesT2h2SIOGI3qGl6NoH7YDHaInJF2afXtBzSKCtoVNLIPVur2CdSfqty0TUT8o41zmDL435VxoeOP34PdyeIp9cH6IvzVmL5w3wEChBw3t6WFKRFFInMq5zTDINjk6/QU3StmolAA8wfoCmJf7fkGKGgkyT/rpynu3ShfUK3QG0Pjd8BOXzV50sYQH5g17LrewP4qBf@puaXwpnXj0yPzB1IZYvvkofaI8baA3QhcS8ER9YVMpfV2PIyiOUmmXk4GxLhkk34DItNebCGHMTwojql6cvKjQB7USzpB7u@kkqbOX5Wf@ka/c@oXbtB7ZpeO8NrxlODlS0rU5S@xsErbw8FFYJPStIO08UFrOFO2qGNk3smEmqkfVKo13qGuEAaOBHha6EaK0At9IGB9FYDuwYDDLKCa0yYWTAfQIAG@BKJzFoiAx1INSWGdg/rV93YogPPCo2qcnRma/om79eGXP0aqVzCD6elSwkmgZIBjTgmtMW8cTd0K1KHQSJ3EP3SpDScZlkWwTIR1d9OgIHTGiCOSoqJJ1OWx1RFUAe25RYOrHF31i54Q0dYsEx2GYSwgl@t4WIms/sjGsX2oWaf4MTrAI4s5Za8VvQkvjfHLVlrp7g8mDzVCG9vxZQSblVBYIzaistAw0xiUGSlTw7/gs2g4LzhNw/oZL@Mws7LyG1bfvvAaRKoSrH/pGQSlUMp3aa6cILbxLYOepwypaj7TQ2RGvgZBtwwLPK1sAYWbhJlf0SmlIcwvJV1NdTwh8fAOVrcq98hGHvIJqyYC7PGKtkDi4J3OxTn2FSEnDahSFqaJ9UKgAW1mTFT2Wo@3RuZ6suDhsuPztbGatlRwzI4@32ERtYBPAMRo3mIT8V1NqxfwfJ3LJwZB0yoXNKcNE0atxVNEJLxIts9/ky5MZw76VA@J4V5fUp0Z5bpE6zMrR8imH759e/@5V9Gv7z78ad/ffP9F3/@9qfrf3wh2fhL7@DDP7/86stbdb5@rYL/UOd0qoKVOr2DOxX@Q52LhQpu1PmnP6ngF3XOYleF7yClBvEq@lmdV19GKlyqM4QEVHIhMVdnFDgqfKtOQNOcqfgv6vSjQIXXWFfdNWhBnQEJeo3VXGR5pU71c/7wXsUvQe4MOz5R59HZk8OnKh4Dyz@RY8Tkr1T8f6GPMBtR8SWyeFh1SHTVrkpcYIGPBQNsiuT3kQ4/FZXoYcbBdBfTLqY7mA4x3Qapz1sq/E6dT46PoWdXV3jZxyp8AeXHpyr8gzr/@sO/w8V9A0RIHKrzAPn@CDV@@Pu/quhrSJ6rAP4bz4EtBtEHLRANt@wJptZQ@ucf/6qiN5D8N0p/C@m//f1vcEegK@rX/f9U/IzT/wf@4Zz@3/AP4fT/gv8/p/8n/EM5/T/g3nP6v6vY4fR/w5vGmf@K/09o@K8//gT/REz@8O94n75cwzfyL4t3Xzz58adfvvjx2//y9Y/f/Pn38@uf/vWXf/v6x6NvT57Gf/v2b79/d72c//Cn6yd/fvPj0fH3X6no@6dfr99d//L3dz998bev1//59e9@98UXy7/P5j/@6Yu//fLDLyq6Wfz45y/@@sOPPz3R3/gfnsaK7YsvVIPc3vHXX/z4zbkKjo647Isv4FcxgHpPf//T76@fPP2a6aP/@Nsv13/9/eLvv/x@qQT@Mv9Jyta/g3P9n/8f) (sort of).

**EDIT**

By compressing the string, as suggested in the comments, this answer can then be made shorter.

Using the GZIPped version of the string in a file "f" (size 45708 bytes), the code can then be as follows:

`import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.zip.*;
()->{String s="",l;try{BufferedReader b=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("f"))))));while((l=b.readLine())!=null){s+=l;}}catch(Exception e){}String[] d=new String[]{THE SAME DICTIONARY AS THE PREVIOUS CODE - REDACTED HERE TO MAKE ANSWER SHORT ENOUGH};for (int i=0;i<d.length;i+=2){s=s.replace(d[i+1],d[i]);}return s;}`

Comment: FYI - If you zip your string, it's only 47,044 bytes, so I think this would beat my answer.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, 969 + 36208 (size of data file) = 37177 bytes

A mix of encoding and traditional compression.
I store each of the roots (the "letters") and index into an array to find them, then, if it's not N, X or the empty string (which don't have a "chord type" (combination of the quality and other stuff tacked on the end) and are immediately followed by a newline), I use the next byte to index a table of the "chord types".

The data file (named "b") is available on my [GitHub](https://github.com/famous1622/CodeGolfData/blob/master/b).

```
import base64,zlib,io
x,y=eval(zlib.decompress(base64.decodebytes(b"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")))
f=io.BytesIO(zlib.decompress(open("b","rb").read()))
while 1:
 a=x[f.read(1)[0]];print(a if not a or a in"NX"else a+y[f.read(1)[0]])
```

Edit: I decided not to be lazy after all and go Google correct music terms.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work: `IndexError: index out of range` with the provided file

Comment: @GB I use the error out at the end to exit the loop

Comment: Ok, so I assume the output file is smaller than expected because of CR/LF. I can't verify the original because I have no access to dropbox from behind a company proxy.

Comment: @GB yeah, it should be because of the CR/LF, is the end Cb:maj(9) repeated and a final N?

Comment: +1 for better score than general compressing

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 23 + 802213 (size of file we want to reproduce) + 1

Quite a naïve answer IMO

```
lambda s:open(s).read()
```

This function takes as argument the file we want to reproduce and then prints it xD

Scoring as per [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4934/75323) meta answer, linked by @Arnauld

Comment: Just to be clear, the purpose of my comment was actually to dissuade you from doing so. :-)

Comment: @Arnauld it is just a basic benchmark while you guys are trying to figure out the best encodings :)

Comment: Worst Golf Score Ever :P

Comment: @Kaddath Just look up some Lenguage/Unary answers, those score a lot worse. ;) [This ~62 trillion bytes answer of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177076/52210) is actually rather short for Lenguage. Usually it's more like [this 5.71728886e+3431 bytes answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122068/52210), haha. ;p

Comment: [I don't think this counts as a serious contender.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14592/6484)

Comment: @Grimmy should I delete it?

Comment: @Grimmy It's serious all the time there are no other answers

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB, 55935 = 10 + 55924 + 1

Compress the text file as a 55924-byte zip file `c` and then run the code

`unzip('c')`

[We add a byte to the score to account for the extra file.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4933/counting-bytes-for-multi-file-programs/4934#4934)

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3: 93943 = 91,752 + 1990 + 1

This is my messy attempt at a compression.
Sadly still worse than simply zipping the file though XD.

The information density of the file is not as great as it seems and there were several observable redundancies. Because of that I have doubts that there is a reasonable way to predict the data. I am prepared to be wrong though :-).
The code by itself is not golfed that much, since the main portion of the cost is the size of the compressed files. The decompressor is only 1990 bytes long.
The compression itself is done by Two separate huffman trees, implied ":" between them and two one-bit streams that act as a guides. Also there are few simple substitutions in place.

1. First huffman tree codes the first letter
2. Second huffman tree codes the portion that follows the ":"
3. First bit file (a) codes whether the line before the ":" consists of 0-1 or 2 characters
4. Second bit file (u) codes whether the second character before : is "b" or "#"

Lastly, all the files are compressed via zip since on my work computer we don't have anything else. Might try other compressors later on.
[zip-input](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yCkv-08gBQNvOQefBUuLv9PH6TchIW8O/view?usp=sharing)
This archive has to be in programs working directory.

The code itself is tied tightly to the file. It does not cover full format specifications listed by the author of the question. (Also, I have hard-coded the input file size into the decoder - after I missed the proper termination one times too many.)
There is definitely a room for improvements - for example few more substitutions tied to the numbers in brackets.

There might be a missing trailing newline in the output, that I somehow keep missing while trying to debug.

**Huffman tree generator:**

```
import heapq as h
import numpy as np
from bitarray import bitarray

class List:
    def __init__(self, char, freq):
        self.char = char
        self.freq = freq
        self.leftSon = None
        self.rightSon = None

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.freq < other.freq

    def check(self,arr,  prefix):
        if self.char is not None:
            arr.append((self.char, prefix))
        else:
            self.leftSon.check(arr, prefix + "0")
            self.rightSon.check(arr, prefix + "1")

    def encode(self):
        if self.char is None:
            toRet = "0"
            toRet += self.leftSon.encode()
            toRet += self.rightSon.encode()
        else:
            toRet = "1" + np.binary_repr(ord(self.char), 8)
        return toRet


class HuffmanTree:
    def __init__(self, inputList):
        a = []
        for x in inputList:
            h.heappush(a, List(x[0], x[1]))
        while len(a) > 1:
            first = h.heappop(a)
            second = h.heappop(a)
            new = List(None, first.freq + second.freq)
            new.leftSon = first
            new.rightSon = second
            h.heappush(a, new)
        self.root = a[0]
        self.encodeArray = []
        self.root.check(self.encodeArray, "")
        encodeDict = {}
        for x in self.encodeArray:
            encodeDict[x[0]] = x[1]
        self.encodeDict = encodeDict
        print(self.encodeArray)

    def encodeSelf(self):
        head = self.root
        bits = head.encode()
        x = bitarray()
        for b in bits:
            if b == "0":
                x.append(0b0)
            else:
                x.append(0b1)
        return x
```

**The code to generate the support files:**

```
import huffman
from bitarray import bitarray

a = ""
with open("chords.txt") as chr:
    a = chr.read()

def getCounts(l):
    counts = {}
    for x in l:
        if x in counts.keys():
            counts[x] += 1
        else:
            counts[x] = 1
    res = []
    for x in counts.keys():
        res.append((x, counts[x]))
    return res

def stringToBits(string):
    ret = bitarray()
    for x in string:
        if x =="0":
            ret.append(0b0)
        else:
            ret.append(0b1)
    return ret

lines = a.split("\n")
firstPart = []
secondPart = []
for i in lines:
    a = i.split(":")
    firstPart.append(a[0])
    if len(a) > 1:
        secondPart.append(a[1] + "\n")


###First part
Afile = ""
huffFile = ""
sharpFile = ""

firstPartChars = ""
fChar = []
sChar = []
for x in firstPart:
    firstPartChars += x
    if len(x) == 0:
        fChar.append("\n")
        Afile += "0"
    else:
        fChar.append(x[0])
    if len(x) == 1:
        Afile += "0"
    if len(x) == 2:
        Afile += "1"
        sChar.append(x[1])

print([x for x in set(fChar)])
print([x for x in set(sChar)])

fCharCount = getCounts(fChar)
sCharCount = getCounts(sChar)
firstHuff = huffman.HuffmanTree(fCharCount)
for char in fChar:
    code = firstHuff.encodeDict[char]
    huffFile += code

for char in sChar:
    if char == "b":
        sharpFile += "0"
    elif char == "#":
        sharpFile += "1"
    else:
        raise Exception("error in sharp file")

#######
#####Second part
sPartFile = ""
subs = {}
subs["maj"] = "~"
subs["min"] = "&"
subs["sus"] = "^"
subs["aug"] = "%"
subs["dim"] = "$"
subs["hdi"] = "@"
spPart = []
secSubPart = ""
for x in secondPart:
    c = x.replace("maj", "~").replace("min", "&").replace("sus", "^").replace("aug", "%")\
        .replace("dim", "$").replace("hdim", "@")
    spPart.append(c)
    secSubPart += c
secPartCounts = getCounts(secSubPart)
secondHuff = huffman.HuffmanTree(secPartCounts)
for x in secSubPart:
    sPartFile += secondHuff.encodeDict[x]


aBits = stringToBits(Afile)
huffBits = stringToBits(huffFile)
sharpBits = stringToBits(sharpFile)
sPartBits = stringToBits(sPartFile)
print("test")
with open("a", "wb") as t:
    aBits.tofile(t)
with open("h", "wb") as t:
    huffBits.tofile(t)
with open("u", "wb") as t:
    sharpBits.tofile(t)
with open("f", "wb") as t:
    sPartBits.tofile(t)

with open("i", "wb") as t:
    a = firstHuff.encodeSelf()
    a.tofile(t)
with open("j", "wb") as t:
    b = secondHuff.encodeSelf()
    b.tofile(t)
```

**Finally the code itself:**

```
from bitarray import bitarray as b
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile("h.zip", 'r') as z:
    z.extractall(".")

class N:
    def __init__(s):
        s.c = None
        s.l = None
        s.r = None
    def i(s):
        return s.l == None
    def d(s, r):
        if s.i():
            return s.c
        else:
            if r.b() == 0:
                return s.l.d(r)
            else:
                return s.r.d(r)
class R:
    def __init__(s, bits):
        s.d = bits
        s.i = 0

    def b(s):
        t = s.d[s.i]
        s.i += 1
        return t

    def B(s):
        toRet = s.d[s.i:s.i + 8]
        s.i += 8
        return toRet

def rn(r):
    if r.b() == 1:
        n = N()
        n.c = r.B().tostring()
    else:
        left = rn(r)
        right = rn(r)
        n = N()
        n.l = left
        n.r = right
    return n

def bff(i):
    with open(i, "rb") as f:
        c = b()
        c.fromfile(f)
        return c

def huffRead(a):
    c = bff(a)
    r = R(c)
    n = rn(r)
    return n


fh = huffRead("i")
fp = R(bff("h"))
sh = huffRead("j")
sp = R(bff("f"))
af = R(bff("a"))
bp = R(bff("u"))

ft = ""
test = open("test", "w")
i=0
while i < 125784:
    i += 1
    tp = ""
    n = "\n"
    s = "#"
    b = "b"
    t = fh.d(fp)
    spr = True
    if af.b() == 0:
        if t == n:
            tp += t
            spr = False
        elif t == "N" or t == "X":
            tp += t + n
            spr = False
        else:
            tp += t + ":"
    else:
        tp += t
        if bp.b() == 1:
            tp += s + ":"
        else:
            tp += b + ":"
    if spr:
        x = sh.d(sp)
        while x != n:
            tp += x
            x = sh.d(sp)

        tp += x
    tp = tp.replace("~", "maj").replace("&", "min").replace("^", "sus")\
        .replace("%", "aug").replace("$", "dim").replace("@", "hdim")
    ft += tp
print(ft)
```

Answer (score 0):

## bash, 802213 + 5 + 1 = 802219 bytes

```bash
cat<b
```

With a file named `b` containing the contents of `chords.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 39098 bytes

```bash
xz -c -d a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FJrHjoPYFkXn/oqeo5bJhsmTyDlnZiSTc@bn@7mGDiqB7zl7r2VXmqzVf2myFjj6z7/5P//7J/nvev75N/t7kPz339vN8YAfKYpye2ixBaqkKso@f48p64EaDe@bTy@QOcVkzFA6TOZ2Fnd@eBJ8dzteUZAkxFoQLjD1LK8FHSC7nna844mabyqqx4wEcas0EFWmJLZxV0bnMoMDQWdAtAsJmSHVgDPuXF1ZlVasA9C3bDVY4oYvOd8K1MkAq5BaVZInONZNIJIyHlF27pgq52t64sV4wCUlpRbCvi3fhs@qEUUeJ4I4OuC6NBMmrNoxr8NH660mNWsV8xx4RkuxNqGgEj1ZnhzKH4QrP6ruEN/ZHdgOxmIjl2vMyYJMo3FQCwbxE47PElDZh311/tSLZhdqH7zRh135FFLjd1lXYC2/59ps1ZYzxRpfZdIZmgCRsqSSzNNdjNyn0y3ALqeQqY9W6VjktUftyFCk5TGKqOai3knmEMnHXLMfIWQlUJYRkwB0pXKr1sMtltnDwPGuzaPHGwG29K0TkK@xtX1ZwuuMJNIjQS/ddiq@MZte6Yv4NM2bJOFPYwRJgwcN6PqPiSOoSFfh7sh6v@pacxE7cGgrDGCVhHzsipteSflNja7DpWj7iJLn8Vc3zf2Noh0lj@Wh4bbCpWFwzjogd6MRXDWT8C0lLmDkivy2iEZsrAS1wfgOvzwL6K@lc07RyRSqfeOKkDmUKKhlmTuCRHsgH08Ss0yKNUpQMHxr0jr2XH7EBPHyrB4IQKkxvfLWyX4FdKo609ChpnbkodNwEMuMpFB9KpSHPjAo9SwFf5TWV/zYpgmi2vrjolurpVn9g6beJ0NMQYdp9AKFl@vnjqGyi1OkLppivuFOacUVCfU8NRbb7dVi4@2DJsfUoX2vKJlQp6Vz5jV4tMHspPGGEjJR53S479cqc5n7Pt8u9KkriovZiydbCKl7PwetYWntAgYEquhyNZQ7p4pHL9DS8vtdAeHUXXLlWGJeZMySTQl7PZ2@upIKeaI2URZ2F20n9qr3EZhx@EJHnBUHk4ebTfmxq3DMw276lj3vjcct8XjXpERPCGZ9Mhsm0hdIg3PZzzUuraRIn@JHARH28cA8HshAAd5EzhX9Spk0nfxWUhgyQ1WdOm8HPNGvGRVWnEPSoWyVGMFeVxckisrbqETXTkT8VpJT6UiNz/lQWjXgvHtvMjyxqzlqGoa2Dc07DnH5KIdqV9AZ7qXHzUakMk6qvQgIN4ndByY779/@jQb85xBp3aNsrrE/sz9VNKgVqyD8xvNOF8XhWDIzQDZDJXzaFXfVC16VzHxuCPZFXB2yArX9JlrnibxkDhsbhNHTmdCxLCfOvla@pEOVgbrkQt@MQs/IVXm5gYoWC7vX7gduWPgLjQvRC9sfZEfewomUwBsMAXlP@OimvjJZmfPbfRos45h90MO6aOPj/hYL9J1oYGwHy7RPle4i2ITUpP1@7O6Vp/J2aJ3p0FkkzaMGN3MRHt62WGuUaWYi7tBJzlagChYwTb6jBTz01oBt7aQS1b3nssVYVkrx8XTuxQ5WpKEMHci7k20wAVb3zAHmk/FyUjfr/RA3FDIPiYMyeUHJdFNWg@xS8bFFPOGvrJLwVAje7AV9/d8BiNAGBKVSUjRNyRybsTfj2QGGEwilb7mQh@Z8GYfIO5z6zcDfQiCdTcnk13Q89FmEpIogql1xCSRfZzHtH3SkodMN4k0PPqpbGTvYN4qsCaFxCNGF8l@YqZis8vNC79BxyWqZ08lEGlSreMpYgL1jQI3Oe31w5YRF7R6duj3bEwcDyY8I8CzYPlcsaF5ELFejp8dx8jdSnxNbJ3NE28XXwgMWPootbCyCK4khGsHLbkEdZ9EJ/ID1cO8CtDGUn7i0cbqbFJxMbGGoiUqyZ6fusH4fR4URPgtbpIcsTtnlmFcIj6cQcvacV3t/RzH7XHmJDF2yNWaLHhpCQPG0n9QzkkG6Al8XNNU4CJhoF/zgC07HBJTywiuYXZXh@uu27XwASH29rSKU4PxDPStF7vHVXMmCtlzsHlzkZfIAkdmccZKJDbjORu7xu6HQEMiL61w@FNhPGPP4XMetGZn6S7U12@4fWZLurXkHceYuvl9Vq9aTSt6LXuh@9uBRLBUGPlD/Vd97TYYzvOgJ8DnXCE@ku8wLNle66nldhi0Fo/d@h253COhmd2MvJrTLYdpnDu29aItgP/0IACjti2hUpCK2zOgqOkrHNuxJ84nQAynAB1mrV21@4sQxmT5BkPh28f6TZDA2H0RkXnIAuNEWidSHwNBl9TXeVGyDuW6QklRlOUTh@W0WdeviVZlNjL1WhcXoTdzeUGGIIKsTfIp7HUm5WTgZ6sNyiSoQxwkRhy8QwhVg@dbLb0jWK7OAfciqPbpCQuzX6vD3BaI5WI9OgCbNgNylUAgSjtm/MfapGfFSpkwgkjL4/RtVd@gj37LxFNS93vPNIjCWdbXYPuCTB2qq7K/62ZP0g0G3yGZn1@vscoHh5UcobAaIBnAuhgBgX3EWPTIfrXvr536kAXAHCogmvh9lFjQdVjyWWd2/LO6a7hbJkCObQBmGZwqF2gp3IO/jwBS1UTSjjLiyXlYLhata4KdRG1OQ6yCyhBQsGUbZowhjrE06vgxeQW73@HKf2RhjUC0CDTzu4jtomup4gHmZciccm/oESMIMa6KqAnq/46@FHkPe6UWvsAFqgM84I@KLvVjJy4MHDETDT@ulqzgD/W5HnZuy41pagNFtFA/9MFD8NDUkEimW1i6Dfl4utXzYZ1x5K44M@QeCL4YavEMOnnQVgrHWlMRSKe8yr4bNCoxNDq6s1X2HAPrz/vxyGg6Ir0RHfDewWS5@bYTvFwsDK8X/TNirDtkGDegLmBAobsQdtDblPBTPrPgaUZu1HGWAm25fEEdC5tOq6xOxr/w3Pj06CZBR4ZzSnJr6t@6M1/BhmUrQFTHP1p7IOkcA0OvYtQ1alnqiPk1pupIw1qzUZ3WB4qvpzJIQftFApB1naHjxg5fFsYLgL4IGKLy8e0qIXS8gBaQBXWYeDKu66t5Xn4KtgwnkRNy@8LRiWbNY7QIzZ5vMJtB4ILoKGqJHu61pNVO/xjfNxEyf5e6j85tW5z/Y4I2MS6iMzG6x9ue3TANt8KvsB7YkFGvaWEbS6pFg4n1XienhHlWPA9qT1msO6d0pTqwAtiRQBL4O5@5EnMBNQppBQ2u2uhYwZ1F3AqTp1bS57sLdjcsZSg8DlNhSK0l0QFNk9OQlI44LmS4bZ@3bUgU9ekNQahghoOWcJ30@C218Lke/rzYcyZ2YP0rRMee9Ubn9jGFbfVdW9PwlcuRTe@0j8aAMeX3HH0v/KrDc54XLTZqN7xBPd02XFs854I8RmXcRS46DLvf782OIbIi5GLPn7fDnD54VyLq8ahjMEVfa1x2OPYVbZVFHRf0mK4QPjncOZ1Ts/2aVXNVQgpptCXGYMyLEM0sEvBsSN4zus@h6VVNv9xXUAeF8P2@v@2bK@0sdZf@gOHw3tva7uHG1wSU5MlBc08LVeaLvI/ojkO6Pmk7VyPTSRuQNU/va7f3uBYX@165J7yODv/Cd6nfF@@UTNNwGkLdE5nPNZetmyMomrQE4do/FTUD/THsQRwrrK9@vaa@RzZklEL2UJSP1jox7exft47fYREXkzw05GjoUyiTW@TsHszi5pfV9CQoeznXOm3iyvVWpwNXouD6bPbEao9fay4fZZ09HCvrun5JW0rhmRu2DWgkUTLfeAE3Syzwi2DogqFR7o7IsxoB50ymUyN1ANLpq1p8viJ3DdrzUGzHeAZzH4LWxS9iK/Hs/WWQ@eD18mAp@9h0hBszXJAjHnPpG413OjcnEe4AUm9/KWbJf3Bs0bW3yKu3vYDudYZtIYEDQx3At5uu8KZHeH8IqVfyjoanuQce4TICLAPCQ/hRQMeY@OYOoWZBTKjLiV0vJ3b467JLxjlUMguhBnjO2KILMyZr0zkhF0ayaeefiGimlQSlvJtiq@4GIJuWicNWw/mA9oRla@b2Ug@6@8s6jv6TApIW5lZF@sYETulGn3kARzLSC7ESE91vGKSe6Cx80j5Bf6fTYlpkPm1UEv8xDfe55iufO8QKqhagR6zenc2yhjU5Eft03ZcAds76DqcCFi@ADZjV8Zx1Xj@lg6iT66d2JjrguhXlsimQQ25l0aNfrK2AlKf36P2il/jl82noAvWKOHQIjUCIjxl0d3HV2enFH@hcuNzrhrLJXjT591hZSFih3j0Mh5GbbXljto6MabALNBiIkBSZUh4bKAaIWZcGSr8qQ8n0W8Dx7A5/mjQu/af70A5e4nlUvPKkFxpZGOO5tkvfaVWJRMu/yVTN1I/NMmL1IqjI6v07MA6VnhPkIvJvOLxw61tk@Vo2TBlDUaxZC/dQjUdk/7ACNNmyQFw1ib352LiEgy8K2ZuKHlsmCR9GXIeg8KrYWdFCtsrNC2JdWlLrUDD/kB@X5PJqf0DjPouEyj0a3Cng9qeVtlJZvHIfAG@8OCZz2SvI7zyZ4AnA36tJF6BzDIoE@BYDNhTfEh2oAz6YAhiD92QD359FL5sPkC29vzHMv/XhHbo4Kv8qG04Pd7X2eAIt9XG@W1nXLbU4BRImzrTv89uy6pHwFxGZramSY8hJA9vscui@E13dV6eY32rkGjdyfrye/H1yCLo/Dll8nJLY4LAtMLXk2akiyJl@A@mlMjkbd2r1JM1e2t2zewe3pL7Zz1kj4GhLBRcN8uvjwexauKt4ptY9ZzMVVuxxc/EL3gMHfPpbV4cPLuCJjuQetCkepWtDcnAIQC73mUT6m788qF7DzZ7xgy0t5ID/d@PqSttnoHvG91MQuumYiaIboyqEfIVGtqM/0ZFNy3Qf2/m0TAATHixCrL6Uk8pvVLKZyEGee6U/zged7Vh1SuyjhNsORmLAIa33SSrgafzRQpX8Fi9MjehlruxLlCctY@359XJkpIxdGVQ8nw@udW/5JL1vO/yrr3TiGoHZ2ozdz4Ce/ecwWURwEQrnoBQ@wGumcWByoGVj65fSLV/qrHqfdZ44T194ZK/roP432IfaJMW19AEGt/E4Sein611rCsIg9yYKX44ewfi9M7b2PB9p33vLDhfV1n86b@DZaxeJSq5@lpZvv07uIxD26WEu4gJnOa9@@e/UAzjTFuBqT904dg9n15mjbEycplGtSetVNL8qGZyOJW@Lr@eAqjwjiOaLnIdou7IYrhEznslpqhfdch/HR2rV0529gvwiRFRBA/dq2s@oOyoEbdb4exuq2efn8iHVRmZ8/iwH83oTkjK5Y7BeNyum6aUqGh0TZJGtRX0x6jeBnosy3Zlwji8NvgcvFPi/9l9icvbCoUGsm28z20UWSH2Em@20GxIWl4grqFIn@XeC2e7EDIccWaWCrZC2IeTlS4FXje/lMj93EZq88LHDiWRx83uQCDbVwhZuLgPSssaBT3Ev5ufKDujSMkrGLVT5d9K2l6JplTXeclVrQrxDP3mpEXtW@ii6MCOUrZOL3gSLvjfrwlW3JQ1daskBNIzg4HWYyx1unS6jIGkBVPWSsSG6k3gp6/04v/tOVP@qXlFeRSiADB9tb64mzO5Y6nDq9drBEYHSWC4m75UsoPuuzsBp/6PUcnWVAU2o9QcEhQd58xgmAxsps8OtNa55uLgET9l5lzgsAYlAji3RVb18OVT7fWcLwDMoV8eMMKvsgOtwVT4omRn7Hu@NhXFdu8RNp8pm/X4uaJ9KyoHBfl7/sgx0i3DGALNDJdOMvo/hmFKMO8lgq2FHZNFqY3iO1i3knXRX12JX63tUz2@wa373Y73PGy6@olcZZ9I5LWS3Tu5NLVR8y0cDJrHKBS2lGNsK4xebqTq3m9Ot3vtIga/R16RLT0hC7DzL/ekvnqVozBrtfed8X8zJY/dE63xUM1oPjtC/C0Y2qMZrEbjWyHh2DpisJW/gJlHB90oHs0Qx@D@@n7l7kPaITIeDaWOYke7@189Yzkd3OYbkRRjl8hLbeWEc3ArerHu0@v0h0@HPEfCBD31aT8vvzFLyv10b1kr/9w2vnzDStsNk/In8LcVC0UodjAnS3Pc7d@JL4WT0cgmlWNyhDTdnBz1O2Kb1ixeTAYWVh734S8xciNlmXZpIfbZkckmZHsbyVvSvwaRjHJ@cqTG8QYNayddVbflK92Hn/zzz1G282qEmw@wPhv4GgSfMF9EHXBwjkqSUeY9GgVXtln7NHCPvsaMrIRwvy911LTPdUFUsj@YVqg5ewi2pxyrwqrnpEb48XSpTv15GfVbiK/D2WfdGgpV/BSEEj13HZkFI2eln4u/y2lgyHgnPJB0H7Yn262cfAmOGTGAN/tqQukPzqZi@gC/34Is54m2YwLkWm6RAxI/GUzex61s0ZWVrgSj9bMervB8XWpOvxsH/GAjf09OA46vs0ewljefhjjXf645YDf7M3K7KdTLZQpQSZ7Eb8xur53MtWCC@m90XBgPHh7addzFMItzVgwREfjwRhP7uxkVI5Pq@vvgwsFjqGjGHwNwNAr2XHHvsBGM06HCLvWG0u0KluE4t3@gEyI3gHC88U59hlrmVgaByxB7vqsBW@loJiQ/Y2KNH8PFwhVkZ1Fe@KSn/vS9SIdJIwifFm/tLCENYFhIXYumqPHwxyHX2L1KGMo7Uw2y8k/HW@Jf3bp@NZ4cezcOZQK6aM8@AJ94@byFDM90I2tCdtc44wvLHSZmLUjiZTTMCYHLFMNN190LxOKLZXBPh4IZyTgchUmzQZ8gsNbgNbId1dc4gpP1eYLkuTpiXJBpwINlxXH//EtshNCcskCss/zdRikwImL90xXFXsvvd8ar8kFCaM8jVzi@VDAnBDfT@VT6l1kKqm/wncwz77it71RHzId/SUnGT6OYCFsY3cOPnS4t/72DOop5auiMB0Q/0uwHDYxPUnpOAFmtSkLHGph/r7k@wgk0AsRw8@TogKug5zec6iYf9mgC6MFwauhaOYLOYx0Jjiq4dSBkpJJxX4nV34nCG5dbErzVFJ5hNPYD2YW6LZV60mlB7xMX2R3zqvJ/08r1dgq@573W0em33j6AEIH0C2981NuQmP1Yn@u7tkyRRA@Ujp4ZVkM8FB2qyI/nUfA1aYEnCPJNdowNdex@iidvuY2d/lkK6Ev5/wUX3VjkILXTg3ixSCwwA7JS1QnoWIH2jHSBfIpvtP4gA/jmvPIRiX1seQlzp25sohwvhBI4rdpv6LRIOlf6fop8saWk2svKFf/RECJvnASQy/5@HEUMG0EIK7n7hj3YYKsf0uY@zloA16SvgNbntgzO4gXd9cWPBJaCF0vUBwMWy4SRAeTZ3GigMfl7xdmMQd9Afh1n9sFosSkytjYAnfl10DS@UqZDv5WSxiMcDqZ7@2pcGAzQmNxB0@k4u@xWP2/QQ22jkXAo6wV3dmyneWHcLXUutxiWc89l56NWlWGyAs4HLz3mbJp1J0ySftDkwavs4M/xZjIsur1vL9vDoXqChdD/TVuT@EDmbuJUxLeS7SagJeKw6z8KV5b/ZdoM1D5D@/OAiDC2PI/OxP4OCxDvvHswEXYuXgXDf7uRikOpXNtSxJk@harbkf7nOU0wuhC5KLUL@4eDp0kCkFzC8sB6SWN/eeflcPexLedvU7sCfUFmiPwz/DbeFNFlvs8uQVWBa0jhZeK8uvaBDqJ1BFAmkS7eNXFbA0JuTwa4G9gfhpbrjJSNsQSSuMtF0P57lakbojHgQiFjfOorjqamTe6AoxX9gdKkkouGozdwFO7UXhER8Z5VX6fn/zVmgOmw189M1EFitmoPd@d07gYRActL4IrUJswIeNqdyp9c3rJ3iqyqL39GlgTbPe6fCLRwkLazswzdyH/ZCBfh@zc3jqqHhl6BDrmQxTIQ0ORZoT4cUggwGqPtmH@roCXzyYz5nezVcszvcxnF1x0g3giutZfMB5PU38kiyxlH/RA34@a87vQxJID7OV3c5IMmvGWvncQrm8rueJaD1ch/VY6aniCoziJdmLFQcfQiEPnpUHJGDJAhxPzaVxvrXGL94E5Rw0@2dBRpWCQzs3V72Uvb6cxh9Lcx4XhNHMwVr@TzeN@Pv1DR7rCUnCFmoM5yVtzy9l/uoCAhvvuQA2YI3rg71ljKB6mmWcrr5eTsql9iP9Ulx1dFjuzo9WlRC@xC3jRsAsdl15CNcIY2CGALdbfhhg8xDoLSzgdlkwXqzOr7lWH130n2/O/ZcLmywwJcPe9lVUxiJSbwTGz7WliXzwToZrUaFHdhNdGCbr5PKnmoWMQyvgM5SlPcw9G9A77rjXbkRItVvvSa/cVcqHruTk8WtLJ4KQKOjCvckd1/7BUWehL8FeNuOxyMZVTg3EmyEW6CDVbU5vUX@LX9dlOdbtB9Z8dbjjn29WcFRQXAy4ZET9BuT8MRmamnTm4vr189Zv5XRsJKyp7OnkFv4GEDsglpDMbfNSyUrErL33OSHOldCftnZwx3I7QGdMQmNuL7t@c5qqqE152vhOGzOsHRDRoQeTo3zQGJ/8OC1gJxftVTiPx6pPdyZSLDwd@OEjGTq/eZhgks@csK@hEt1cDT7PIUeKC/gT2jrRTwEDk@THyBdnvfGHHdIOcF/rJfK/Hh7QkxiMYNOjqD5vjRLjHQoNaIyoPOlcbVnzu/@Cp759weWMoXL2LzN2tZEtsMtPyawcDYp9teStYbk83prjLcxP1PGu1R@364pjLMrUzfo@qdZQHrrT55qKpbGQCJJM0aNNJ8RcU8LejEmD364df7GIRwr@BKdxj8lo0W8ShreVAqy@YruDSCc91F0PnRmzeEbQyu73DJq4I2aYs37R08vCJMdSlSn8MH19hQv6zAbrG6vwu0GnCW7xu7zno1qV7yHXvj/OH7@r5aW4URVORI87gb1SGvG6wHQ@msxc3ijJFmmUvSy47Gn/EVHichzOTee1GFKiVrPTUrC3O/VkxTS26SSdtf5y262ZkRu67h0xXVDK0YdIP6eClWoUdMCr1ak@mt2iypnfCb5bi@52Gpqz9NoiUiXabJbtAJZObiQZy4nSI7zjLazkXLJ08QBWHJqKhiyAWd2jV5uJd2U/frwTkYDfwnezu8VN1gUIxl5M162vRE7Juvb01cqkQtLdLf0@G9GPebRavr1AGdD9M7nnSV5XNuapH3fttY@ZgvUuW7KXsh5Iad8CrPDGGQwSDHRzCCk@kQGWHSZPArsUDF876XwzNhkgleJpW3Jem261w@DhZXGum6lpEZRd@FZhxemXkBj6VUPfNLmdmea40BfEFb9Mad7eJCdE0UmUqqwg3pdcbvLwvNJ5OZubCbyncGcMdBJWiTg2Hj8nEa0nCQ0VR@H3r02TpBY0dHU@ks5kMhYORRY@A5w/ogPxPZkzUf0iaPhtkBqQBZ0SfCFH05zk@TIN5x3k1CL16j/3juhb7jdIa7dgHBpvHOK/LCLcpm68@YYXZyhV4ztWXjra6WJaURbjkkpJs3c1LKZen8yobYfUk2u1H4P2G@viqN@nBPTitvds63FrtrpDLH@eGTXd@f0rwuqlMdQMCXJuFOkDxLwSyUt/Xpqde@LM8M2jT9INsicEufLBauYDeGfLLbN0w5gPq1@ZI/e1kCL6XGvrVWq/CBnBL/q0oCmhvkHfAnrUhs/V3E9LvF7MeFgP61vF6Ck7tFruszgP4i94yPMjwTrY5iJyMxtJg6@gIW/Kkzbag58NRzmoZO6vmwU2UeJe0jtqXwryUJC1vuzmHE2LA1g65sfqHpNfFd7HKbofiQ4n7YxeZ3FtU/DAbB5S6w6Wi2dIYYRH4lDvZW9M4LzULOdnT8WSA8jVFuIMnzcQEK4ZR7rqzMRNpxlHZlUjv7L3frifwWh@lS1/cbHaglCrPZp3pRbz1S@rUPvkOJNh1Uo7PwIYOkOeBhGNM@Svci5TgDUW@dD9zkSvRTv0H9LGNYrMGgZiIzvegsM5/Rz7R1VOQjbGGis7MBlejDqyuJhM4PehsGUBOKyeR/dTfycwW@9bfc3ytcBoYVSi3btVHZP1O7Mu8qevary5rolh0SpWnaVKrMcf@uCrbdBkbCn4KkkmyMXtJoD20fil5uUlnNRafXkIaiF1OiBqeeD3QpK3ZeIq93yTpOUsCuBZ/O16a7ne9BCOwaGDEInc73N0WCe31uisccj8haPa0PaN41zMoPWnJ8KHFMrJQay6JCBVKyYwAaqnFC7u0hCYCGpI/9kOEwziAA6/pm9SXDTEOFGOcH7B7@4g5c70SLw/CXNyuiuduR8voAbNKUIqXeTqoOfT87SvXrJmhZCtuOxFKWaA5Ro3ZxKBBkhCS6P84nlGZpRF3aF5/S5XTWTVFVxvv5a/kUionr4YvICgLFRBJy2CfYNUTQcDwPlsvlzdZUQTn7EBswMFtJcbYo5ynJHfJrqy6tFzu5E7LHpt5vOtBUHrFTYQTRK0bDsycxpnjMcwncdX76eknhNEQgOzokthvv3XQRYU1qxZFVUkk1FOPoORr2yw@wZpVHC0NUgaoiyp1t@S4FpBEl8qBZwQyGP3ZTfuyzXC96fDV3uEXuN7ksHfoXWeKo5uNxmMXddeoMmLav8ug66kr2l9S9VEYsCNAzR8ljIy@2H7RJ1Tjd37rtnkdD@wbtSvnP8RwzQA5NoG0UIHXwsXLvGIYonIkQhvybzS3QKCOjOwQ0@Wf5@O1AAG/YBkWIUtrrGmrNRU@ymF7eVuJr9bWtTWJXAs/Xt7/2jxTXJIrCkK5TD@iQjBOt56NpEEA5caxpjeeCqPM8jnV0r8FC81EYXHloBeCkU@OPSLr3y26@PwFh6hAZVzQHH341almX11omZikj4A8Y4moI7UnJ8iUUQW3ilew842XSCsO@bJvGx0Bx0yHxWYYyRL3XVroH896/euznQOu89SW4MSUwO2PprkUR2FESO9TROxzZXEGmKVeSQQdjqZ@LzKWs7LSAA1N5kVVnwL3/iRPyixbCSv@tDbYm7mwdMPIXdxwt@TWP@y7oizdiw2AAcxR2Mgy@n2pEHr1/djhAStfZpCVYPwcAKHn6oZ5pWZVpIfcthlO1DXUbr79y/1Y@jNmOqnyMr1@37wyegfz3u7PAQq7vbC284OpydmKrRaxdwl9agvH4TE0yiN@Yl4TEVG2emLRT6tI@16RxAM7TsPSyZYMY78Pmq4sY9voUnX65MxP7kX83WBkvR0tE2WAftriCIN2kviARWepGhFJWKKmh9Vfzvg8vZEAnLnWmDqo/RTHjNAxA0kdn@pD/gOQcBe6uKr04yNtJ@j59VWRFZ7qjpT@sjR7bU4gR8KF/b1gBVL/LnQyz7Q9LNcShr77ryGh7Svr3oqOvGWMMwtNF8XlrSelthAwC2/OpMJQZU92/4AYXCk5EKpKAqWvm2jyRfI683hVyRN4nm7l@nW2K8P/B2lDORxBJSq@g3eGGVokcmTyHdoPNMtsm9L41d/s6fqSZrddew2wi2A05YSwDBNw7d3G7/F1dnvS7t/KqrGMNyEJUzN@Si65YSec09gQyd@vyifwyiW/PrcOWVeZnPqWnkn3OtmNWfjnl3nyD/v8RoCcHxx5wf0ctlndWd10a5D9LCkpnB4@qN/Ko0cqI1628HqVHj@Tt579vH9M3qeVaS0uHMD2dbYrwxKv3A6X72KMuTabfK4eSFUPHbxCOKyr@vHa0LkrGt6C7rmYH9mixg/NyBXJu@fEfz8msEotTd2X572Nk0lQceXJcdI16p1jNeNOYJH7BM/6cpxiQe@IbI4fKEQCJzRumi2am7RJVu3VmkqdvLtfglUIpPHeQFP4XqAvapTfxYtA36aKuQjf97dRKzqkUonY3k6WNy4VZ8WuxcqYGcJuZLapmamyzhrHjRjQLu98Z3SlgN/bPPi5e3H@2Xo9pTkPUzw5Kmphy4zddaiflyXsGdVWVb@2OJstMj9Yi9Od1U9tmH9hr4wJVV8xLB1x5bwS4PdBNrG@Ku5GURRohZeE2ccRnnxGpN@kJOVnIt86yK@KxqL/ngfm4qEkmaMY7fghL1McbulGCvEmV/bebBISi3O6Q7mCBdhHYVf@duNjC6H@KSEVGf0b5i/zgipM5dgA8KkJ/H4heFVn3RPRe1doMMp2TP@AjG6LIRuqILj@M1T0LXo3i0n21CRvQvPMXHSSYokwb5bqJ/mTzLFWcqAoKrn89fnfa0FQ3Lxuhbk0VdJPog5X8WZRqftBR6fuyhhZ@LZBZwjcUe2d1jEy9IYy9BXjlAGluqv940L6tOu2XJ5wvP88TH/nOTLQnIlUbxflX8KfceJ2kdhDQl0al2539po5Y61efHrTenqAV5iN6PFxKyzSojzhUzNhog7VtUruFnPXnbKugkOW1hoDMmXWoedUTfCKRZmgxexSL7h9z1OY1jEK5qzeP0MiawHmqsLifpzW8M96YE43w0VBu@XlyXfqcpIOX5GQyHd2ElDAmcEZIBwiw2b5faLB1FFPBxQCM8K7igf6@zaOFGdpxrQ2VAGzIj1SzuD19nEdUzYLIjnYg8@eKxyWrOxX0uUcyDZqsFWNOOXKb/IWQpJbpEPLtp4uqHNoauAIORoA0d9Ji06sLzePHrjRoneDs3uT3Hb72ugTUagCcOQQb8E7B@uiDjqjI@mBGG02hQW3b@zdKaSuO8hFLVoOT/Bk0zIa/pktdrpQXWP8dmkUf39BlEOmt7WRZEJBAHQco2J1UEwbX8/VvmtbLYOCEGScuCIYX0CbFsSx0uNNnqZOE2SkvK7KM2UiltP3xV7rpWNiVq7uvZ0d@nowLY0FBemvpXwc9iaR87WrHVfihVLcNX0fsAQ13qWl/pjHfBshx8d2qbkts@pQoXSan9ftrdQMnEOXyEk6IW8gt1t1xESaH4SHtYwKC5Qvqsb7E2L/W8XYPy1dAsiAHYyuaZSIKA78JjcGOFqrj/3GsGcMyvcD/vytwi9cEuzj0lYYhwFzAcu3MbqMzrWN2EZTRWSVxMh8HUkhGaJn2bEHsqIWl19XxlUCHa7zsHuC0OO02dRrKj7aPmuA6kPuvy6ZILxk0/l96qA1EzfH69ZA366leG00yS/Ww9bWFtM1CD8eGJMuK8zE@cIWuCFTcHZKALuMfi04tU/2jqv7AdQWgE2s5APMnB7jaH4HFHiMoDyKa6a1C2h5K49rcsI4Olik6lC75rYJyHs77@LCTsNHjlP0KhpP0ODBD5YkD5lLAUdyq@mV6Hztn@dv6Uy9c5YhkXGpwCaTmYqxAfLY@cR842tZKBsnmRgGN0ON0vWxc9Ra@j4erhOQFFwAOz16jj/00hChzHueP5cUwYG4voJ8TitI2HIGMlab/xcbgI4es5fl2/rPlA9IfsOrix@EdW1m7b7bSc9/7wwDDvSxo3bSD57pck2TDRQEljVLTjepN8dNQVUwbp9pFggKrusMi7K0sV7n4CxA75iRKJtdMweRf3nBcj6R3gHyvQ4eiuzycdfuONy9n03ZOBNfrCtg@HnN@M3pRWsjZ7IL0XZSk2XrZQcZQMDktyixyoB6fv69BbZ5cDgxMfDrWM4V6NqbBUYOXHQZ85kbnskmbPIMSsxfBh4jxM9fgCzjdfhbLIzz5eHXOyibf3vS@k/OLRlRF2T9shB0fPu7fTjtFfnNfi8eO2tlaFI6CUXuBhsp6t/D05aYbVWUUb5vc0CmgL7lpDR/L7uMAeyGIvXnxDT4MWBVLgkWXsQsdfkcRGxiUPF4mQ12iym2@d3aECkHNz4iVCsJYcFcr@9iOJmv8LGazVGi0scB4NQDbtkzpj5GO0Lsbe/ifbdNihHfxhb454mIcx8cuQ3G1IbMR@pywhLq8pAOIgVuIEg2V8cKNnju9Hq6JAlJF/f7CrBctPbVVx6De168SjW0iOyw/ClzWQ2PK1hUzRCUebQbOKq7jm/houcRTt43e3BHHFdpEsJZmGTozaqr13M/hqZU@T9WTjImXbyUPoQYRQkhY1n@vLArf5uYI3TXzOdSMG0Lset79eNaWHYNpFMuDbTUJpz/44ZJeCqW5E3kG/LfmwsisKAT@1hFHPmnF6nY8bfLxLI4uzSlz1ZYgSI6dK/eDpd@AR499f3wU8v1gPXwA6n8Mfbv0d7nd@sRSNHpkfnT75glEJT/SBICOpVH99xDd2d936ud0dg7OvapfimliiR93cuCKukc@tChGnermnphgNhS532ZBRyHu06zgqhfhDS18b3aIGZJ3BcA87Mm1Qund1e7Pg0eGkdooAdURcHVpiwl8Qx3w9hNmql/aIKoHTGZvRi4wvRFHUsUjnzA7ncxyFECgtObpG870Ms5KtKMWPAKPg@6u@hzyNXpVX11RNxzHTAqz1XUAIqIQAb5h4qwIspUVnfm6EPFQs4qRwfJDa@QLchGPa8DELu213C9EBmyRsOK3Oda1PMreNGP2wdAcVkQL1CYLJOck3dvCeHH6Uvj8@7Ez6fbmXKiAOSdW4H8qVwVIpt73dglPmHLX/IkZ0OVAwsgjXYWb8VUSeENRQbwpMkmaEiQjix/HS7oodk9cs7QxqeCS4Sqdq9MI5sPZNOwhyzQutpxO/oZUNGHOR8ufE8NjCI@43db6M2w7vBG@tusCu5@wyA2KnZwW4/4ABimNZWvvZn1s49/PkyfXPRBf3OlJv9MMf3eY/uFGalINOTHx0l2Y8LUDTtu2jDEuw9m800saOQJ7rOXFMbrP1LfocHl4gEGVmmJc9lyv5KL9XCHEoJrcCnHxPBcJEdiBubs1R90toy@8cMBzfG8ra@BiqWQ0kUO2wuX5QWCua3IMaYQ0jnSgSaYVUeDGzCipUHF90x60edR7NkI0icA0Co/6iG9@l1TLiXaB1ysVR4I5gup3v1ePWzk@7dIEqJLefu3T5KX5XUzgiMBeuDrHMHRuMVniTcKGPtSoTj@gE2W7ssR1xNfGbZsVqAQYPvq6vU/aOzPc/cWuQnIakBUlTm8TzgbwIEqrBWZ765mUXKCMBcCOcrDBxsLCrf4wWiAayHqqmtU4uYYC/HBpKCZTFHUK5aSXLeaUp8@YUY4AfAwkD8XWm77s7wRpETV51vPn4@X/CHIpOsNnGrO4vbj2Li6/T1Yq0m19uJPoAuvBK4fKe5ma6AZ3@75rrNT/yrXn4Qp3bzz3raVLkjTkUG0WtLNB2JtFNjgIlyFCkx1dd@JN7qiAmiqNj07jEOcKJb7L7yLeTXGlE10pkXVv7uNHWeNXXOIxob2//wZFhya4hLSM@Zo3nD@TO@vF51G7vZuAqAwXhArwtjzSnqegziBtPEM75AyEhYrpu4E1FinWMdIKzoPzePrF/howVvpLFo/IjJ6@UrnnbWCV5UyZ2rOB9tRszhTAxw9md5IL37VFHUMB2mCYQ2U0ZHM72eidTnHDKWiNr1AxcR6PSAQX5fMvbFlXijBK/nBgM@@XZWmaZp6NXdGEgEBJn2pUUhmXoncdFIU0ngztQ3z4qWTSqxP9fjrbX4wdVTf/FML9qeWLm@5zYuW0leGSzOkwjbe8H7KehcWVJgpVjgvEDioIY0lGQGPdBRyuIesczhw54MYDFWcnoJFRPA1516zazSvHEDw36mJVao3i@fq2JgSORxsP7hL2IDfy5OcQMfpn3pIHtStW7Bpb/os2/VM7/ea1VHqNueGm1mHRuRMHi6R6swyA4mAQLHSZ4T84l/XXTsl1sqVCQ2FX7BfNcHMIwIg10QsfbNUmDLkFfaNx2mlntGgd2U@vrRbkGTzOQb3kzPQabjhhy59fMzOwyhchQ4SShdz3OElzjrMypnvKRLElslbiOv97uOvuhzq0874qS57up3qYqfakjVUaDMzY@yKjoIV9iAfovoPaYFbYVyCdk96cuoJbjoHMWbxOe8//KUnLaL3rXMW0OzbgmHrb2@sRlZYifdBpWBZSWJkaBebDf1rlRvUZ2gi7@nK3Q8rDmHhbjDzzvJdPq1jAWOwdsIwDn88F8T7y5aUK3YRsqzXRf54/sAZdEUjP@4yUrzbDh5531eCVEI@RdlBuVNZjzyC7LLf1Vktn8D6d5cEbEa8VbiWfZdWQnVFt4ZSqT5wxKXSLVtxplibge31n@DjBO2gzRvOWcw6FqDs6yk2/gynW/qYkOYt5Ijs9Z4GFuGsXh8H0kZn162OJbsGXkscbWExXnRi5VYj2HHf5fNazabcKr6@v6oKcfBV@YsNETFDGZuRUTU@p12vCgqUE7EdLCzvA2CSxGESvY5AxeElJqdn0ua3A28O6yl8hgdNLTl8XTkwFft07kB/hLaS8h7IjUPBe3JnLo7c1PrNCyLFoMfGNP7yTx1xxt56DXfcRn52l/MGCEDXvtbMAZL1P5l8mNGS7bRx@/EN40skMQ@Li4kMXm8m2m3pwIoE6y@u3JkaVlgrygRn4/kiGC7L@MEhI2Ptw7Rpxngl/xsAcTofTxZ46XnPbiBpz@NiUFKv/EdoDOcsW3gJBP68aXYmy6hY0NSmMNgXWSTvzHPSu94JCW4CV4w8iU28cN@PZMLWstOQ8yAGGy@UWzLv28CS6b8MS6WAR8nCC@Lyrb0h/JIoMaxlgfQ6NQ3y3O7Lcnui7muTzFBJH7lMr9B8AeKaayVpIowxl9UOtcdDYVFICAOgRMPdUDDM4juyxENpXFGRX4QhsUNtsH37F9KZwd2BEwYp1Uw4og2qKrbQASDe2w@PlBphaTtwVN0pCT7pGmi4cOR8xGfysmkcS@1GEkxrM09WCV/hhKNqrPxVjlcTGdnjUBgQAFjHKcILCxfUcj46i@/qesz2srUMkKmoTWUrVywcJ4JUu0I4yvYejH4fdVNEFyjR2RfYu1m5YjkDXXS9O2gGL0N/Yj9QoDNK1wWqkeHmw0na5MydT9LmBoM3qqSlFYqHlMmctNLwopQhvO1xnsWOgd3eifSZH43C2rvmflkn7tnrN9Ryk@qyO56ylnKsB2apyQU6kVaKcr5NgVA6jw3eL2poeEm@EIjek0lDFFow8kowgfhgJfOp/n9vZ@AZs8HhKhuutQV/nlqf1rvMRh4sUxYj4Vw6if9h1K9XPH/FJ23coNAFEV7/QoFOZVkEDkK6Mg5CkT4euNaHozZffeeMyPWrNs53wTVrJzGRewDDpjEc8XyLcLgmVpXyUe5SAhkSh8q/caWI6PMbOKKHReVoGdmQvB5YGa@ywkvV4N8yv@tqlQZ5F7qJfrbqyQV97Mds/6eIUUxb26aR8QfnKzBu4ejZcFqmaW9VkSiINrDVAgJETAxXrGn0igPfpxxpJQREnG74gC2vGKRfD42C8HIjjgbXCOitCCOkgcplln6wgCmInKwLUjKsp4nnccvr15firCo@RGadFXQh465LZmjrMk5fuV4XV9VJRzTHKajhJFtE7SqJaK6exQjCBLu6SE2C@UZAKyLXxy/ykBUEnLa7lQcbifcKfjDobwNePsTMRJaL2wWilNooysnNYA3tsH@M3EYGpKfYkRs7/vCd@Zj5Yc/IpbubxEcD9MU7GuQAreRPBp4uCmX6Gnti/vggAVWhNiRdgSN3W8Q899wgaxvalEOpwy5ATvkIRz4dXYvkdmBY@IGEYe15@qYa/L4cmDZiSKRWqStCDV4o02BMlb50/544DdhdWzlF@pxfNxQe0E4ARBG0nP3F2Y0PTSFBb0LVgV@vI3VT7r7oGpQnQqr1rzZx@9hyGdVx8on49EWLZvz9@iZJ1sl@FS6usMHjxzWszXSmqAWPaHiAFrvliZuzjpYMFZdGqbdm07aMsun94c6MLffRUfndNh3NV78bU/ScZjqW9iNU9JvEtrtJUWQgVns9QC3jq1hD6t83VzyPHTo1PTeHjWlkLTkJ8@oRMHsCTImCyiM9fg/K6O7dlhls@OOiAA/wxc@P@KmTug8EVNKaWI7tkZ5QXq4hcs77asNSx3vi5n4RkC4fdGt1OXQMpozwbv0fnS9mqLozanf5KO/EiIV/VBi2HtJDst73HfyHTJAYvAmtmLbl0782BT0tYd2Zseja0v52XEZdwMX1rnDh3KmC7BLTmqH3@vMnd47uAhWP0gHRPmHuUKlCZ72fPeTJA3W4PoTJsu3ZNsWLRh5kNxFyjQLR@21jAG0DJ6khVLe9d5efv6ufiqeGDqQf0EOzBbmoJm@18bvdHcFjssBid8cJMpAo3lR/g33VW79rxPj4ewuypeF@VhTtR6eqxcwgL4dDvFKzEC3Ge/jQg6tbzgfn6HAhR2Wc/hi2QLdCcckh5J9CxyHfgCXeUuzjc7vVvuQG9uQ3A687sL0wcfGtS1moyrTyQrI7SR1yIwGV1a2EykEnHkJZsIhpTkVdBmv574lrdwzLzW5pRE94CrLwhBWXrT/g4Wf@DVYfAQRenejzkf2XAYlQwXrH1Bqqhl8axLAG@I@PlQZrH3cla106M7XsMWwoRHLBHJsW5lXBBtvhvhoM@v8jrZdslyGK0nzascXPdDrj0c8n0tsiiC3z13TXrkmbDA8tKKa/pv/f61oOn2/HsDqfLGsihzN3QuXblPigXwecf@mx/791SqxAUhy4esXPVKohgA5sw9dMRTs@@P6w3G3WG3R0DsZNSs6Cr1f9YlrBT7aUlWnbxUxHY9x7PsL7ToPBfSttgshIMKPijFiPAqanUVDi@fvr@I3wbRLMx9UPqsUjq9C/FU9pRdPhkznv/rj2LQIACngON9IxS9VHD9xNwE/9jKmazzPHQXnHXGMUSfTgJZ@gOqEOBmLtN9m1TK96lE@w1Ftk1naucKi9aAqx9C3Prv6Lm1PSn/XCKZjltBHgYPm@JFTjNpXUkacCa849eqqcgmjmt1u7XXIUEzEvLECXJ1bnaCKdD9DSCR@@dJWJkoMaJEXCvNnq7X8PIZ6EnXdZ1UW3tr2Fn@zAPMXggzJ4kcvzsW@qZQ0U@SCbJDKzehE8hJ8wWOXF9WVTNJT7y9wirrA88IZfvdFHT9DfiH@oa0EylVjEdkkhrAo/MqXzzGrGkD2EOCEvZmaxT7ktmQIcbLCxBSX40zKS8PfUD4JVBSNAHHOKMGORGVrG8QQavYpf@0u1OkLv9kfQeNafZlYNZvf7TONqEh1yDpTuaGoSjGSlTcRp5dYEVAXgWzV6gRYAWV9K8KTfH1aKl1c5uWzvUyTf1xJPrnv@FvRKsDCQGEYa7RbLL/3gn@DsM/PdXwXXD0Gmp2larWglpgtoqVANQesA4MY3/DpVOq1SlPW9XWlqvu0oxrHKYA56PIWGXjaC4iaGXdP9nUzRySl/YI29z5aw9vbaZDqpQklH3L1NfAnJX@aF6x6STAZHw3fNtrpnCGEP/d92ajmdVkFRDhnmv2HQ7yklRDOlLuv@NbWSw0BG04jJIF0ucx2oeKtCH9pSLySjqBSlLRf4Cpjb097zwjglXf0FLLhPY04VQvUeymCe@EgTpuqcz58zxONhMukEv4GAh4U9kH7AoS9AwSD8DXsqyMb2fAlNB33NG/DhUjeQWhuJB3vq5bx@9d9EIsYa2UT11/1wS/kyq51vOb48yO8HXnRPKGY8iNaYhITkWWbjzJ7x0nG/HvBP1WAirKLQeJ0amBfggXlfH/upRXMFpTwIKDTapBI1HJ7JCDNy4zcb514MArY72UfjsOwfsbmMunEL5tiamkQRRkJ5CVkQhoIUvRV15adAdhpJ0vMpqEbNW2sy4eC7q/2pMLx4yg@9/7OW3IQjYHxbNhYR9YjyWFLF9QIqEYP99meUNINMIUeRhUzwG0fuMkKsWA@tQZ7mfF@DYA0CuaFi7SRfhdVOCCF4EPnQsc2PQVdG0P@VhVg9EIUDDf3u@fgCPyQs/mEQIWDe1/v9mlKW5uv20sVru2UeseLrfXx5KIPXcu5TpQnAVNAHAuixUfenGpNZAIIpffX0grv85UhGmg5lO7cCPGxvtDX7Ne/omhNFIPtxXjHXcsUSHV5TMqsz4cAyc5/IjvenmX3gz78nG/JdZRs3sFpeXffd6v6rdNTMoPZnceZ9Gs@M4nEyS@UGOCpl62zMEYvwQg/P5Q520lCg@osqmeKf29DCzQG9CK@7r@KhXDL91M@nbrst7KeA1q8HmhX1eJKb3oJMmtpv@fiZTnxI@0g@kZj5gmbeu@fqGiozxvtlF9EytLb/WkRqGEXMi9Ya/4@2NuKje@L@o1mHW@opLGFzqpFQWjyinz5cASTK8ck44ANN1JFhzcOS9P/v9e4ZpErXxD5NbETM6nV4LJ1uksVen0mo17LnVkdkkCugS4I94JKXyZRtrAv5z1Z5NKSdsxj6rFxO0koWQggCuvZdeUTfkUCb0SZEXTvoO/L8rjLPPpFh1uJn6aPYf9aiH2eq@AIp8BiP7lPLEG5S0PFt5h8rwGwSZu9RxEbQR/uQBYl6wjGpg7pKeHhqd4BQUDrrPfZAOJ64mN2EwJig6GCm5cf6/kWvuDjj3ThfJxsusKRfK6V1Ft0AjnGT6qb8fD70cfLzq@PpTa0ohkduqZTNiP2t3ibx@GzOjBFOwmVQL@eOuzqaRgy51A2oU3XRlrXP8Pf0bjDRzO/@GqgXmPDwCTe42hR@En1C38UG/2OZ4v74FB5H6z2vmBjeaul8Ce5riFsOFUtm@ZlqzsyTBc24YaEMuxKEsuLX@igWHUQwWMHBx8ujM2eHfR7WDFXF4sI0sx87JXCA3YcD9FM4cBGAgFUmRpib96zcshpf0xtqAfWa0zpSY@FY6KWXp2g6pblgq0q1dga4Cc9bSFC/gf85cabCrLfwphcwuBrJG28Ed4kDSJDSXd4eTIMcL4@TMRMSl67qq@eK1aTBzgUbYFcPojijm5GN66iaXl9kQAGfOAnPrtDf7OOiavO6qEG6qKt1nwphdaIl5jYla1SPd@SDAFdB5IAIWG/p/6d@mebffjOjlK5wOEmr8d3xHgk1lCcXNxIUVQF6BS5dAo@l5eu936BOcV9/s8O8lypVohGFK@0feePY9@TpzBclwHx0rXehVt54bqh4Yc0q8CObvm0/E6@8nk@PVCxSou2L69acNLePDez2XWkMJyohbuQlntPLVGfTBGggeoCogBs7dAjCN@vWOhNWO5enLRXFf2T8tW8dR@hQ16KnY2D2PAsQigbbOwVGTIcIkLlaOjb8wsdRUIuKlmdUCuZjLgK4wCESjRAMi5Ip/xsCbO7cU47SjC@uDShDSMfxOz9hj7E3udSF4cgmyYObvZqjHLqZ8xbvWfnFk7zt8xEuacbhXLz3tWGQEHhaJVJTNIDy@tRg8TyFR0xkBXZW5w6Y8sQvxFVgMJvPgFiSrTVNdcqruXj41LH@10mVr9sKmtHG@JGafQxxisxfMp6wZI9Kg/ILCmz5yZZPlNZ7vfHB@y5esABYTX1yGQTHq2lE353/wEEafrVvmiP/OYI2iolFtkb@LE1x4sdZFggCXyUopn/hdaPBTFAhLWtIIF63yC7HEhjjT5Xq7AkLJP2qU1avCjePpwUAW27WKiIMycPyXcvD6orA/NMco/jMykIKnWakYWRgwVi6vLLhquw/wrSV5lwEu3r9HbrjTeo/CqDlUNTmz30KX/es9j1tY4dM17l9BaHUtvf1KPQG/a9ngFWccsRz4PdpTtLMg8t0x@82zeF5F/Nn9cm29oPmM63KNTwFQM1U7/uLdMR6B4jZi0GiSzcLnQ1TwX4DqMntWWU4ipT9QNCSzupwYmDCEtlAsC5amwx6Mrm88knaYj4IRq/MEYhAxz8cJUxOXJCRfBPitTr7HKyCX2qIav8eld2qtAXOlxNWtmomEDJw4GI93zUrSaJK7lK0l07vzbSjVcnHmp0J2Rkq/XcWMWTRuN35AsPWDmk4yrDrcaNXLH7jt22rxoHJIckbDRPoVWBjEQsugd6wb5YL6qqdXcu@R0UkWh/UgkQ5Uy0zC6n@D7HADMM6OBOGsx/xtrYy0HxsYYOoBanf1gxVFkscpnpnR3zGn9gPMhfgy6KeWFmsWgQM2@sBoz9wWOTerC6Qc6F7@9y8PckvZunEfiD2HJEGSqClJx1eIatJ5bePl5H7XOO6Pm9aGBqH9v3TeObkDwANiw2AFa/oHYgDEqJbkTEL4SMQ2RZHy5B8JS5Ty2U776FZpWdiTR@bT@iadTU2HKj2W@5JBnQ/sTLFk5Uto8jMEtksq/2FiH7p6kzUqr2ir8Yo8xQcadTOjTmeBN45jMr@KvhmBAQ4nc16a09fC9KM9hZ79xzyjQHPq0G61xg1xS9U7F35Q8HDUnhSqVR1Q@WhMZOT/DybNrMSkmv6LzOtIhQKufDd4d5PTie87LX9Mpb@mKTWwva07vKbFOqkbVkEcot@8DF4pkjELxdGDJrXTx80MK1X4xzP0vv/KACPduuHW1YpW3CKI18lVBpG3ZsXp69blC1c5ZqHenbI3/MvUgBhgeo8p3tpTR74a19rOs1hza3ZUhutEHFMM2Y6Q3Q4U9pH1jSAv3ClBHWXfY7Yq/8NMoxaHH2mS5LjemCj0Z4@JFqYISy3UTpq/j5ltwLDdSnYjHJuQWneCKzRcZmtzVgn100HR8fMP53TWMvhsN1j6yLalXVf5vP11S8DVK1xQXtEX4NWluhyCrJnZoSAs1Y8T1VRKkW/aRRXL8Iy82i7/RtmvaHDL9PTfJZ7NOfSUoWm7pZwjn1x2N18dM@s1nY7QY76UqOVe/grW5ugRZykRIJcqIuW5MprGgBD1@5uY0rbj9nF7iJvhnzMoMoCoX1oVwo0Or10CsBkc@V8UMf0KxEuObvZBuswQiENeYbSYoy0OQu6EBj8PrfeQJpBv8cVg3f23Bmy0PfNek7XPwbkA/xmkLizXMY@Ux0ubeIMMxckh9yLDW@D6zwE9PLQywYDI0@lN3RUD2hAo/PTYO@0YG7zprW@iivy6eW/0px952146AVdlOSnwnCvp9nlZ@sbh1edKXLlWmLmilyL5Y3r5Rtv4iUQXbX7PMj9ZEJU65xXPHuDsdeqPcOHVDKzINNpN3u8DxcbkPyUwOJlzeaLXmepydONShZ6umU4hqMX2d@Td61vXN2L5nvrqzvjxSt9MucubzuCFGNS82GzcFGfTKjbm66Gwma1sHktvyd@AqJmQ8tb8yVLLefZ7wT31fsJ/@nyDFednCmQn1fn/VEBxGnXcD3ExmVhijAid8QXUA6Z7C3xiypm1@aysYQb9MRDvt3DUdowJOtKT/MfiPfuxpXPxjk85U37sRt/1@HAHX@p44nW028dSUX/Q5IZJEAmCcQu3i/9Q9SfDCZQiJdxXrBjY3NQKwttUg3lEbcSkbkVSvxkjPyU8lSKfxKg5l/dMwBIzvHAIrj4LjhxZ2W3Ca7q5jHjJykh59qKQR8w9QK7K95LfNOqqD7mV9WfZMPViSnd8BMeIqGzMYOwePGBSZBH2OuQCyy2Y5YnPUhxgE7hD4JtxxYeonHm8l0ylrfcGk@jc@92Cg7IoqEjnWS66vDB4UNEFyyXDQ4thOwP5tRy8TRMBd5UjQ/TPKuT7wT2vFFd/eTtfRJBBg3Kp@qed0V/KPw0Z5xpWadEcuSMrIMuGZksVnx1Af67o0Czvh14YvOXS0p2O4zIq4iHeKjp@HVfEnVZDN7yZuX827pxpqWKe0EgLbApto@Fw3j@0/q/a7OJAIWOjuzOvoDS7mJfNpv06d0kavFVielFsHNLafuLtnh@YoKDV719G1HZ5rF7HWWJx3ufnWwZ56LIBjQyjKwO/ge6oVRMHHbBa7GVJIUIVs3ahWzrLjC19Aeg@o1lh0BSiVDIt6zdFpOs5OgcGUss6ZqwdDMJ3WKv2nNP3563@Uo2n7INSPbBUlW61kStE/E/dhkKFyAl9Z9N@PyCCwexdLAPQP6YDNdZ2bnLdChqIZ0d0oyFpwVlAu@wSMSyFoF6H4X7Gitc78O8/GV7lbCjV8PAPL@Efc@hDkLn0OuIJrmNnH8ezF1hLBd/rBMzBw/P/nMHyRjG9jcFSifeZmMitCmCtZXP4gj1Wf9Krsbu@lbO0HJ62zeDCyWLZmJoYLBndT1je6ztPlz@Mj6OS0m59AUZa5SLI8i0QSe12tLjLO4U3xp75U6@HEbka0fOH3Zv6ELjehbF8jH6JiWEiP@NpvPjxRXzew58LlCAk8900v0OooN8dAoMbg7ZT6hcH5e8lRv6paTQNj8DstJ87ZgB/uEyZiylyepukV3G@gyIektncuCv5dubKLgMoqiT7qwb55uPAAA7AqeeZ0mXxDT@rFKJdiKxPCkKUFPfvhkBVqO5ySLZC9Rch1WyA1zSpb329bHwREb5uPJzzM7fPBtFDVXVuQr4X8Z@FlbALBd9UpETt0lEBVkKyWB6xtPq29XhRWaXX38oFi5iKNVq1OJ2fiXLtWyd6ggkvYXlTUTfzHXb5LH5LfNS6HpPysppgdPXW81p1/K0eCpAJsQ2YOzCL8mDR8a3G8dnE62LDHXypTty9sYiM9p0VuvHbW@6iTt/u@O6Vy5wMVPj7JiAcnrK9rpkuDxFBTsfYG2VHJbiCWqJC/RS25sfWybguHHGUcz6FjgvQhAWbIlE1eDSEwJe0Ii7n/rs2CJsXNpkTza8vZ/lnRo7QbcxRuAENG8eDSzxZjtlvdGkDrM3h78KPSrFejxRuFluTMXL9NYY3gtRv/fLom@0k/Fd1YURy1OkQv9ovH0bQEEmMM7FM7Dp1KJucMk2oWStuXy9@ru0OBvVrkQW7fMB7gRYD3bB4vL8EcQRpVT6F5glgeWUCzmXwL97AF450MYxx/Cbd5s5D6C2F@YcbovQ/FADPOiPWCgVO2wkYbORCKZRw1AQuR/JpOK0tsEdrbKOhCG92YklkVWHBqy6MutlDssGsmFqa/9fdkLc9EGUdJDLX5gmwpdnnYxfgJrst9wUCESNZ3Jt46b3wXWHl5klwKvst93H@sy1t@N4kPrGMCgSvCv8xcnP5plyXUeCC/fryLi62SBbSAFVKdcOV0EV7AGU7KMYY6YptAUrtr4vvO35PNEvqiEu2RnlUu8@DJtjrFU9cso86VYP5DL8@88K0ozvommSi0IdeANZJdd9ieU1xE6BlIIH9NHu@/ABCGeHHUGe1ZzYbJXJOpxgufo/yHTGAquNPGN3AuDKudKcNt30Wfc@aqqKNxyK6MfShbUgFbxDE9bEHMRcbEIvHZ5buxOXp35denTnGI24WjZySIhCjTPdExp6beMyWQqqYrma1IqV1drOfZQdAaEKWSCncHayVeT8nWcJfEZIHiZ1OLs7KF8FbC33suoqlXRmV23c3kxGZ1a4vIbmFuK0FQm8TcFGYaAzdS3bTLrsqe@PMQG6yzDY4vCC@XWw3vwc45McIRgKGIXSUjJ7arTc8iiUw4@ePzVrlBA316qg/rkdtLN6xbuTELeTYrN3zvXz4qYuS9zYRY@UDm9bfcrJWzahpaz@RagMmFdnVwr4W9ddfEa/o439Xqb8A@kK8EC@FCVSJfTc@mCws8F2H784pFzaFJAflej1cfFSDNJEkkE0UndRE5EXpHsZrOm5IMkejBO/gCN0a3MbwIw6P989drIb3JFNK28iJeUDZw6VeJX3mfuE3J9tubFDO0O8Y1ZE3aR@dPynAOQyubwZEARpDxE43ph/USH0CceIRqdbZYw6I59qZa8jDax2Qd6BbxJ9@OcV6kjcwBnGyERArBA2fjZ3@0k6Nmovq9JaADIykck@ryN5SCIaYMNhl2B9qWHvJKYde7y51xKcFlI7ufhSFZ4A8cKKnTt8NMlGJIwAGg8f4Adt5vjgiC4eA9HPiAyBHqfXfehw1FebAtu3L48qT6zZe8BYTxehn5VDZ5ylgBua1RboMLAHyGbqYfgptSKN0BDe7NIg/ImHGUoTef/UDS4fWHrXDAMkOTluf10zfGlZAXmUquW8@v3owwIlqN0ZJGDSQdtfeN@BSi8899oL1cDKZ4d7cXDJadV/6ZXH7cHtAVPIWaSHhXXLgmey9nLeuuOH9ReoYZz@72f@F9rD/fBoNi38mmmElMv6kw0TP7gCH242tm6r5hxYgKhOCBtYxujMqQpbRF7IqaCYTiqQ21VlHTG6Qf38yoAg/BJjdPbNVy6hnOccsPgESIkHx0@79cJW@7F2yeC/Lw3TuTX7zrI2Tz1tyobl5zFYekXx5und99J8TEhcmQ/G@xSmZtcWO6H1Wygp6vQTYf/QteCza/v19jMXy76BZzqEdn@1ttnPsQw4thO5mt@LdNmrE2JNKi1QKjxDkuSMtSbdVLhkwXGMC7j5L16aQYwnpFkdXnEqUfmjd@02ikk@c3o7JIP7KBC64/67K4Pf5P3KGvp@/5WK4F9arTPFEd/bxCCpkIWvoS3X7J@l2wSxsegnwR2GWMsdzPPo6p9RXgA3o6YqQOuQhFoVahEzc0/6O/4lHfL@C75HrHZTybQLrmX9wuNxLZICIQUnZoHweigmelWU14TmIq7xeb3B2wybO7o4VsmgHE99o4Eu0/pRmxB7diwEzf6By3uL5bkN7sjYxK/kNlfoBDsHefGZZ82@T2yN8@AiYy6IgnlQwVEgaa7IGr4wXYb@G5gItiAAyJs6gGpMS9Rbub2A8XWvur@SZoN5Hl4Gq8Z652B/f9@fFXWmjXvtYNuqxHxhX04bU4fM9wu7SCTEEpbohT3M7G@pNUBO7jqQKK@whvpgRZbDD2uiJ2jvsr4k39fhPkqxMbrn7Wk3we9BsTUaiTSgTLi4kCkhlZcLpiFlC8ZwFYEBT94hDJqURpaH6Bf0usk4xcxAz4dOe6axxB/kgwkdWIAQ/zOvKIjcpncdKnhMMz/PnbQ4JX2@sr@Q5aLOPGyfIH4JkDdIlY@H3TO0@DMeI@VEpujzI7Xw@wWedNIZB6dljFvn8upM9jX3@zOlvVxz9f6WUQ0amfZpIFeEWpOBCxf@4ihU@bmd9vEfUG4EpoTHbAyfZdg@kpAIpfMz4PtuHfa8cD6BO6yCk@/oMmy9zZHIdWVVBWAvltJRxMkWFkFULsLaatpDx2ppiVu928VCQJxtpumVllX2PmSrbbGN0Ovrk8Lebm1iS/vevu1gNTpiHonwZuq0yTJqxYXaZzYyzKTUtDE8b5wELLbBlOcRg4pXENUPoWm1kHiRYS@6dardmOVt5PAP0Q/8pY6DI1P/ntWhMLXejaVunwXjvDep2qgByiiRi432a9DzwZST2RPZvDN1dSDsALXvz4LCyooro4N/dbk4/plcqpMoqtRj3cArPsRh9Viuk3Xvn4608jcQPkoQGdMe0qoevyv3q0KlsaU9vUXkXXaE0z8qDo7Pn9/yOhjwhGt6cBzn2pVcaestiUiPOqjQQ/PxGNQfFaK2reVrcYpmAugQy5b1Ml8el09BbciUWr4YFyfVN1VHQQtTAB5NrRwZoXan7VXw0O3gJZtlZOYmL3fti993GlV1E52aiofcWjfWP@V4INJ0KZyfxLblchDKac1Ec@mNL2JV94N1Rha@AbE6k3/SL4kLtquRV84yYKZP1v@PAI1Fmf86T2Xfb1jR71S7d03HsnadvyzFWUfpy15DyklktytCoKFeZ81J@6auiX8YSfgJ5szpUFn/iDl23kCyAOImxde1dl65RyuT67adjM7V2B8IyeKe0PaUuNO4nYI4qxygIues1hXDy8baaTL/4/7Hom9Gdpnw@/uwOJ7@noAscvH4Kyjzxp2Ka0hp6hCrW6KHYfekYZo6LXMSdMxqhuUm9mvAgTqM6IQwY9FvtvF65oE1JRN2NRrJpwOTpHf3OrI9ntLF6xpqjwSITbfJ9rKUnQ8u7BMqHfY/fhVLSn0/FS2@LY@JrdkgJCEIG9VzOIcyCtr2Tyqj@1e5c6007R/okxYH1R5Zqyfpbzq1kx/PwRBeS39QJ/tMmRFXcHlsDcnOA72fbsOnKTU6HGvFrNBYfklvjNAxGO097NiTMEovQnJe7wvJDBQkIN6ZtFEbUHKwn0cG5w7wvjlZgaIZ2aGGd/I2HSmnjvDbzJxgxxzUtQPdd5FdWGxkF3GwaQHNRAE6YL@JkXWpDDvWuwvuVXJcIZQK0vSIvivWQL2ytS0Wb2YJS2YHmm8s1jqTy6v2tiGl@kOYsf3c05XGG1cwMMz1f//KIo@9ZvZGzbhyY0py9b0tPC8bMgtpZWEXwt3LZRdRFyxuHyfajt54fR0wQsPRCeZR5mRAsjMsJTAI9HXwsP0iBt@bVW8RVXGT5CVXA4uvtvt2F6u80OUTzDJ2PLjOavWUtzgvkk9R2zss9cb8UJm6yLbhyXS82VHu8OjJU47x@idA4XQ8/sy96Fcb5n21SczP/7YH3Uy8e/js8Fp@DVvFqWz7gCS9b8roJmOX7/SmeWulKnPoIry22my@ZpEedzTHHADMZnZpXstBQw6UC9AZiLvDnDAJCiJ2fnV5taQURW1izFwzEY0KbbI25rRWmyf8rljjGxIKJOXT8hiQ97sBkp7lZvhI5iUPangVu7J4KJ@9bhW7p3Wfg1zj9rvGaxF21i7qmLs1Th62pggA2LowQFFp5D6wHT5/szD@ApodMx3/aZhrHgAMgwjpVkVJGpG3KQfWxXd8201loymQTyMEX7RWSXVdLMsAapV2b4QJfc@FwX4GPaLTHLS/Ea56rDpxz71HjMo5XwetFBodVHKm/F1ysOHhamRIZKpt1bqVFgBQF3aY3B5z5PfOEhXRqf@eQE/A1PuW3DRhPvF75PWbnnsf/oPJhtd4eXgLg202IouErzSAZM5yg2YlxesL0yAIBAjm5A1xVslpKoX8cm/b8Jfx7KVPSkV9h6ruWd8PrLKQ18FSUALP/QCHIYC08YYwWUmIcIVXYJEtr7H2ns3NZp6F7Oc9RI8HQSUwGq21owLWTuRWK6MTb953J0Px8zjH1PItDnUfjC2nvfMmH5vwcWj1FkZXXwzqNjWQz0pgfuQozMC0hqmZaKaor@Zo4DdzfZt33nXSiSWPM3ncD5sXT6A/Hhgr1SZ69PbZY5La/ebmZ8iWBjw0xr168MtBfUtyFv8zusv12OjmBVcmo/MQH8qZL2tyne3IAPQrZVjGr@1Kj/q6ged38yT@zMR@Oup/PPs/Oq1lOJ5xMBbuVPRe1jkd3BR@CwUgyWKU1UyKh1A1umBmscXBxve5lAXIQ6394m/54OT9lcPydiF87cOvfZfazbgZmikGn8uhXYHYYdi4/wUYpOFy2SAsdI5AJ7wbnh8PCl3oadOzu@z7YqvJZ3fip@CN/lRyyl70S79lLU1@DJ4StR3fFvEs@rV1@toAySvYK1NWKZFkTzmpkZ/v5BAk18Ss6kgkLASYv/fwrm44wpYBXlNqh23BZIs8YNmLJGQ1bsUZ3iAnd/8A4YvXbiEOVezFokaDJUq20SspemgWet9IpyJ@BXqGUU2QiWYF8yrKmzwGFv8BtTLMOOG@WXltIah8M/0WEWpVzzF1Ru0gYZ1TUbII1wP1mpI0ryYJ6jS5BtTOHr5S17nMoImO5oEHF1dLfdA37f4@NtnDIevSFDiN0U9G72A7aFx8VSFHf7EsNLAjjxEbq4pgi@Kf0NsV7TyxfnZTpE6xC@fAxQ0RR0DdD03pK0eT8vH9ud@nlL90atyYs@j9pj@2SXHhkfPGP0wKKwofTiOOTiAyX@1W1eP5jLzZJ2VfIqrrIQqXIRBGgfMl4TC9Ft26cvN8iBvIYXqtZ6@MRZxqzPQN4TdXFwrnJ3nh7h@6WSsyEM6m6BhE8D4GxVEaX3BwELeij8BbkRCmNkVEaFl@CVCjnqW6XyruGemhAn4eUp7gtfvegXizetmkZthtsOZGffAwJnuwlkvFtTpU8qnSEMAQRlbrabCBUtK6UBmJ3aiWAd8/9pe6jS8Wj5SzYWcweSvz0nUxfc6LvPXvP23ZZHIlFRYc0qRF@/p7xvrmH69kyy5BLYj0JEyRzEw@k4KU8sbem2Nr7PA/MUN0heKXFBdaBcoHA4T0G7JovxoY9@JhG@MePyc99z1UHH/nTihtzjARIz/ZzvGTfWO6cBSUnMlMltiovjRavlXUu/I42a@DjdXiRcoAzfEEpE59w1ipFVKaE@tpqfWEFfchn9GZ2s42E7XF77TkpX27U7RqZDu7UUop7tG7HhQwyPbh0PNvW7I1SGvwu3s9zh1xkZ8KVYmDzS0P@M7Vrsh7YisqdTG68kmfVt4wEmEdaQvDbmG5HMN7vv5C95hv5MOo4RusrBKINfRZGMmmauD/XmLPfxMvVRVdCh6wm20n88QinHAYmu22R7a/7@99j2O3A8rrVHH1vxshLiBVd9GOFcVasoen1gnSW13NneROoDpRlSeRQ38kWN6v1FCzsIGEIfHSuT7ha0BZ9I1X1tk3ZjOBVUV/MCdyHgE4elzsqaLtofSFZwq3F5RF7W45toUF6ilq9NghlyzsUy8dPZ28VqkAxlUM7Kqxm8JB5y07JcOjGFFsRKm00CnaoPXVVPMdFzV8a0a8In1ppDpCWwqEbQI50D04cqlYPhCIB/OjJIyHg4xteiqxf8XOxu1tfgtl5y3Qs4Cc46y8fvAOzIaW@N4kvKrqTUe6WZTJo0TI9KzMUaVH@GHTSpdJqIRuPdx3FB3cqXH4/thUttP2Y1RPR2D8wh7Nc/su6qLm1HHQqRmbhi1/nRBBpfY6c3wub@u7TA0A2uBbdb5W3G3NiuDc1gyHt09lALVrq/XwppVgACi60EptfZPtFDb5lgedejwT@32wU4G3yx5FXoa23X8dUTmoer@6RGCtgXxzY2YrYEhGkhGMLn6dsrncYBOP8fhRLfjsCMGvdBDc9KI6LQ8zYU1@Yp2KrKGRhPiGM/WqE5o9h1m3oc0enkyDoq6fTmBZwMHZToU4iyzkdscOGqAkFwgtSQbWBGe7e8hxeYrxPWKliCVaawrTJqtIeOk9939IaC3qiok/niK8y25RSMJJA9cfdfh9qRx34xjlRNXNVQWUlnj/AQ/L64coLTKug9EqzO48byoxtziKT9CsUh8gVrry@YVWGBXuAEkWApEG6TiWy6z/0MQe/PY1EA@dO1o380LxiIDYVYAxJqASyfy@UmxOmHKF9OezN94PFuKmnRhqiKetLM@xHtSFgpcfH7inx4@lPijgXXxGD4RXkFEKs7N9PS3AmlMKicje4NVWoBfayfA0Tdw2ZDfI0iwdJRPBgmbJ9NZxBOiE36bzsmQ9BZ3SNdN4fu1UHmwsZQepl@CUtC8sD9knvsp/xQEmnqRWMhF@x6jKcKNkZ1urZmVHAOrMg522W@qG28Q5fbeSZ9sL083@U/CNsQocXdCW3EPt4ObRUL5u/DWsJhmrYJNvqklVCqW@i7n/jmNCOFpqnv3UeV3TOFeWGpaWvR6E0P0KB3kQHjQN1ukLYVNCZQ9lZYiGL9bbJGE6w4/lcjghsAgV1gyw9paH3W/U9JJR0St1x18IBfvleO80hQfVoHdnet@h8HIvNYspSC9YQHfPpb@hTky6@hgmTtNYCodBj7FOwD54Cd@bviDOMSOs6zzDpiX7gaLNqEAkEzSh0hOEYbM2xoKK@p9aLBOnWXiruaJPvenRZG2Da/6HjAnntK294Wpj6GssxvptcxUryPrAjcqqnzMxekdfE5LumzekqsRm7rfjbZQvJA76LAP7e@eX55e@BkD14oMGDR@ANxQ3xajO79saegl2c7qhYNMM37pTGYFavloGBh/nu4Qt4bh9CE03dLvcrgnvp14k@1tCAzGAMjm4fflk9yEifjILLLda0s/ltXpR6KGC1pcGttStIHixRI4j0XevMnE8/xM4VmdonF0z@Lxcq@JYyfqbk7/YvsW4POIypY4llemzSROfTRxcotu60ec02uVnBi@mdLay1zk0WNP@LFWJR5MsY/m5NemDYJxx@GWaqr45n3LVrHRdxu/OJNlqdTMaB7xit5Q29zUrPkznVcPviFM6L0HNPZ@bm77dsi9Olc3a0dt5/zt7guylpe2JLBtsTq/frEO8QUn89uiBILtDJjbu950atFg1eY0fWyopzb1RbIELjYoK/CoPm01jVF6nEDkRghaLpr9dhua1faFxMQyfsD6KUModnfzEqJ8odj5w2RwDjbEgk/VzGb8x2H571hLNEfFP@u@A6DpYP3wz5Y29FLp7gLfX3sBW26qXPFRct/jnAlv11cfkpUB0MRjsQg/4TeCN7OZNOhMdZk9c0d@ZPZCh4pgLTuk9wpb0QMD1F9n/i1aBgfy3WYASgAhHzNhZuH13/0Zxi1W4Dfb@BhdWGM/WjK2wWlHn1kNIhqljHxxKXgb1xFUwOv6Um0SSoZuzSrjCHxvW5r@t52o2Vk5uesGrnuLfeDVh9qnk@06KAyfDrYj2pz2SoZ/wEId@9aCMlTv44t05igaH@yZSATaig@08aiVJ6K8HKxwutSkBndkgR3/JtGMtbiaQNOv@muQUUSIDrQnNU6pGCkk4re9ThreFd3WZffn0qDUFb8nBGxdX3D8eoooPSVULdFsMed@WahB3E0xpQYWcbQE3W5XQuYrmlV3UhOKfp1JYxhTNXpRUdTAnr5zIRZOHkCcilSX@ZFUNlEGAq5ZAdMPXoSzoPFlG4N9DwPfZxQPZaNXZbuWNPBipS/d5@SDrr9S5YYU23VOSyHTMHm/84D7wrUjTWnGoyGCdvyZsE1QRTXmHdvymca9y019ab9/qsPhL49dtopzahPB@pKZIK0k7HGqgGepUabMUP1jjxL4EMgnJncXhjtw@E5oxLAHz7e93ReyB7LQd2eHd/rKP@bGzRPr0A6/67GzIbRc3mS9w0J9jsRokjaWkIpS5F4VVg4NyD8TjGrk/SG9RCiaHswujmApG6WkF0zS2mdlfEX2NBodQaWRVBHrGpbnb/uBNT7UEAvTE@Sr5tYETr89DkObAdkermPsLiN@gkYhFVHVhl/aFB1BphVUnKhlzHW5DpTJwE2QGeh7yoCiciX7NFD52Ttulr33nyMc61Bc04Ks99WAmAHtt5fiCZS/is380pA0TXuAFGRHP7NxmM3yCfnA/VZbgoi7Z9Gb5iGoIl0ItGMiYII/ce5V7FvKp0orvWjbPKZH/Av8pqKdo6CgcqRE75pTK510WGswmAs2sB9EJYzY7Ajj60CWR2xFD9lMMlwUYwmTe9lZkZ@b5eO0qpYvghISkVYXFhEu6keUVKDeA8gfzuU1t2TeHn/i71bKMtAgD@qAaZCEbLmdKQg1GN/Sj83DEKxkho6GX7KA9QMtVh1OhjJ9GQouRiv0QfglNUkG69fuYtopTTrMKuNiIpKivGRxjtb@c46/vqkOfSpm0J5FH3oFUtyAX7b2UJi9lMrmsgzldvfeMrJtnnykf6STIsUUQA6VavGbTR0VSXXHzY3DTA2J5YVRtLuP4VvP1oDwET0klBueS8Yimv6oG@fD@up4VbZd3sUXjC5pvS0gkZRS3PNidpRVuaM2jaa@Zk5W@NKaiD3f02sIaY4GiSPnOZ0ze/szcBwASN8cBLWwkHKAjw9PCPCiBU4@@Ows6sp0ilKVSGlx1rG15qUNzx16LVwvy8qiYgdMsrPD2r3x4Sv0Id0gCC9FqPD47Q3tv8XdQsOa@k7MP7GlNDBKa87OcItAJQKlWXiMKBDYvEz9ZlMjkjW5/rU@XSkY0BQA5po1s@@JWRf8943LxwR6XLS1HeQ4gwQmDkV9uYuZZ7mnEhU3j2@vx8fruliF/660P2M72Ko/in97H6KsWwORZ0Yt@GbOdwG1CrXLZ1@Xdw9WPCl4/PQOIk9XUzTHKuXmNJGKX9MmfefTkwRYJPW3ojh0S6y2fsDfbvO8vMwzFB5hgTgDrguRKxAEeJDbnTxWDf48jHrifnCatpT1O/1SO6FAh/flf0ZAfZuNhwc5kIV8iUNC1jGJBHFZWFVvNBwP@neOIsl/v0nEDvZV1dtqa@/9q5jQDg/88ZKjr2/x2W9@OBdH9Kf4E0yKHGpwdvwbcfo9ywnPqBhSTTHm7ZMdhODZPqDrJ2Iu2GAcm1Q1gRdnzvoLSig@dz1TUNgrjguCoxkDHiioEp6ChwQntiesIU/jEBe6LAT5uQW3v20NfljIRNoF5CZW5/CdWVb9FRt8TUOiUgMhiR3thIXFShMM/pUUEc8yb2QkPDaaziE5DLnCSRr9QUCge6@RE91CW03eawVr5fQM4YsZRhXWE90ur2evWe/QvprtC9srS9XT45d1Sz96HmVZQq/A@xjMroYnvbFSc4KDjNtDJDsQ6smkyvy@NP8dmKvjfUP@6NqkMm7fD7wQDDpDicJShTgJPYzPMf2ysLyqMHpTIJ@O6dxcV25vxOf3kNj2iNe0/14fnVv1u/EfkbUiV@ZBc7hbBBQ67AQPoPgZ9T1NzB9F563dIBBFwV6/QkFOJSAyEjl25Jyzvt64tXXsNbvv3hkdGTSwUPBsmx9g71Op/VqGHHq9aCaft5OgRKaxMFh3L9iHeBNzQlHtSQ9U@tRsIwFCCV1P7TvYFZl3U4DCmpo7WugJztSDpcd5RCtrQdFF36iCcncoXfDMdy8tSUkk@8QRJF398p0qCd8kej43pbd@ySEr0H66d7n5y6YLt@fPYJzL3VeZkPVxr54qtDxD859jmpDx4nUyXcjm0gl7stnIi/T5GxKFvuztLrM/fTlu0beTNvm@AYscfFzRiijpnIKA0yEKJXSNrGihs8Zfl1d4kkSd1XxRPXgKufdvQ@mVX@rVa2FyEAm@bFApnSGu3xTzUvYBSOAaqgRtDmGNRzsCSqtVCjP2OacvWtPIJbEvoTLraFpG29cXMTzVZLgq3WAL3eE/Nq3DE@VRqYyjYcny9hpTD5NWF3DF/k5iB/fECPINX80s6@0nc3AjS2fsMckBQ2lnBT4/NNKFp7@7QXNL9Bj9G2UZoHlvXs8e8/3eNWNeT5mx2hkcywuDSOE1JvL0ZcqVYTdR4SgUjx4v6b2uQ2F@Cxo0SfHnQPnwHZclSRVSlQrp7eCWOsoxtrp9BnQEgCEk/IOml@eUa5nqu2EsKcXNERE6NkBoXviRvj0sxyZAkcHlCZ8gIA3DuwLn97EJLcYBTU0EeMN0qpZqN/ax3/AK63EMvsybliaFW7fWPOZYvP0Ag4MoIsHNEt@TdRnHI3QMv/AchRuFXrukDM/CpxdbFgMULGO3BQyDl/tDVWpPNj/rpa6gDuyHiNY3K/b3m2dnP@kMlxSsmGEs9znD4@9QkMe/Jp@WvfLZJmr/HbYoZUuhY8NrkHn0271rKi@yKLd@nbKKzKVsvXpEoc7SUrt@gYWGGyDsOy8av7@QdsD7xBsZkpnAx8d1ECISNZ5@fEE51qkAMeryGU0@yIVh9q1cQIeOg43OnfwhcsFNbHYNe0Iq5Ew9E18th7dQoSbLR4fBw7tRsNBhhe51uNzQaQ3uSrsS0@AP7d5QUFUAK@VxzaEO9eTVd1azvJTfJieGab0Js8yV3NUtFOuRtCNTIezLWMxBLyTBtoBMI40ZzAyaShc2KbtcZhHdMaI2JSAVCCvTES9b9G7OAK8280gDNOrqv9Xqhgxy@EVVhzlhGC/fQFyPHg2no@0YnfIvFSTjTY7obzrZpG0xkJt@tx5TIEd/dcy@xJsuNMkCYPEnfqECq5d2T/Soworm9U6f7JuV3xwf7@N4W5s9WIX6iGVukj@K1g/W46rxa/mLxl9Wr3Gur88BSjkcASscoFJmGTuGmik@OL54TFSE5GrxS41x0Q@2uzOXGLPAC27blm7ZppDPw4Aj7cuaOqtNcdkHxEwpLNmcYx7wkILFCZGEdk28PpSeCwA/20UuGowDRlT3ZWJnUez1aw7KdEq8AU85TYox827JlRhxPoukzmiB8jMOJMYWe7hRAxFE5YsNYSHwp6xC9LAzPshMfxKvT7Y667/p/00FCCqZg5QO4QAyaFayuqwauETKe5rQj0NLhakUiYi3tYl@@afX@GSxOZyKsqq6oPhQE9PVG9dDMPrhzi3X71HtAVilLu8WBVRxXZQP5HLq1m@kgQI3HTF2Dk5l91rGS0sSz8gtXx16yw/Nw/ys4tSPCY0xifsQhhRbkpMxVZrj@HUWko20166vAExqvwwJf82YTVsIru4r8GtbCigxHnZEjsuz7PReFbVdcSNYtC6sOjewc65Gj2jsIYO3Yv8SZnQNVFF/Rs4ajxpxK@UTHyFQXscRk0lib1cqI@wExYVGEQrBk72SIZNgH9LSBds7/tkJ3DdpfMDB99cHEUKjpPPWWfGcfhBxTPqJw/NL@bjKSsXgtwGHOZKVUAhgCcQCKteJlbBNmhnvyR@Lzz7MszlNe3vXO0@sXG55h@k5XF/M@4SBMZ9Vr5S0xDALxVtG0tytIC04camFUeudXj@rUkP2K@YF8XnWqx8FDu86onyNvjP6XkHx4t2MfVNwvQ@xRPk6Pp8s@YiLHaV4jheI6HafzZ8WwBTdeAZtFo9O9Mh@w3lBDuTrMSjT6uB9VtAR7eUyq/QeP3BzBuKcvLB1Zr1s7r7Z0qRRqhtGzQP0Zzu3Wqqo3GGziv5GH21vh4PBvthZegwDLtduHkBVRx/5HThy98lpRE1eVlzoT5RnPmU6qVqZP80E@uC@u59N6RZra6IF1tGv3dHDPJ/DNzB7VOYThgCjOzM8rypnWXgWJ99j9sK5WTD9z2d9uBKMqqmMmWDc60G5EKvFEOaX89OpjxeQHS5/dRf3toqm0pDh8@2Yki72KuB9rss5mIhf3C7WQ0T1q@ghYUo5D99vMhEPjrTc0@exZO53T/2F1MoPFoDPBwEfBGUMf@/1h2jad3zprPnzj2z994D1kr7CiMG9@3TvoJ/WXoT6Tz8wWFzCAF5N1nb5uaOZYtzCoE5yBidHQ@JxAi4gty0Dx4FMNiph/HqBii2OyheeewsNdF0jivMYQwiD@emuXNlvAOS6CC3pJLGhSucAmIn0maQTysirUDP7bgTYbg93eq7yko6HFq@QXwnayKyQsq8fL@ATz5YMOWopEGHNwMamg6RyI4P83AAnEfB4Ov@Otfih7ficyEUxXDo@1RflGY8qR4bxrYT6Fjxu@eoXNee6zgiNXg5BGHeL@HvPH9n8Jlb5lr5mwWi1eIxxAlEVllPNfNVN10Dj6xPS4LYTc0tniEWuv3fkePVGH3wYgyVGd8kvFkda@fJw1ATYcmrdlOf1p7rOvdUxufvdKnZcWq2EWf8yAozNRBlJwthTShFFf95PkN/cA78mGVSaP38m/kjxOiGLXebuPCQOFBVL8fsuoCDO0veIFO0zhg8LvpbTrTRqiL2jWKu3l86RA@SZE6/e6FPqEvku@nO9uDSoRb9ULJyRn5lFciBLyq5n3Bb/ZBI1TzeI6@EllnBSfS5g0ISsRUE@X/GAd20hDvbkEfnwSUupcaAu3YialRmF/fbfk/gl8WMn6LHE7VgG/qiJqECEr/2xdfBkzqgZS/r/UeXUeCosSEf5DGCM5@mO/Pk5wvKBhcN@8CLyBsLNHHpEoN5FGiCORtRkmGJTdebFjcWxJBbNWPbmsYKhE8PN78EQBbMq2HtQyerzglbQBdKkZ7WVObXH7f1K6oSrfdUMxNFLDucySA5@7RALf/2qDLL3II@@C20MzUjVnNYLBSLiNyIioiNdrxQpyuIKVCRqAAtJaXHgBV8nX2N6wbZpFAO642UHuji0DSK8P03P9aQ/yXxik28q@BFd6X6TAMshi0iEk5mODRlgMi0l7KRQGoYlDQ57RqgOkuIrMnVeCGepKECr2EOCIMgYUJqbZ@NudUAEqunzoX7KArHSVkWV5CyI6IZ1Z6HJW66fWPbuQjpOuHsXy8/2fQVzlKWqV58ezbcKVYgQske@eHFMOknYj3xYWr0/xGrGLCdfnfJg6Hiq8v1MhQ77FXbL4LI2de6Q@Pry8d8agm80dhhYSa5UwrI2zgoKeEMt52IFUB6H21@SGXP@gzDsOw@/X4BK786Gqf07nUK4QXQueSYwv2ysB6/PTTQJdqleirhqtH6KfC4JTlzxrDJykROAvG63wDZWzPzVJLDjQth4FqZNMk3mdDQV9XgGyvgi43RwITaOmjaH95wpG/epvEDZe4V1QyD/IhGhSh2wWrQLQvkB89nux1hrF8jPAiH6sfmAvy3N/KnDy99PtQYpJE@wIYS8QVuXDlFd6Dv9CFAPcJnQOLqFQ4P7DNUl/UyT8fznmx8ZkU0n2mgIehguir42Qb3iO5gAlgvb9/D0kwr3iKYvfQzO14TCqXSyDlkMNZtk4LWc71N3NrMmN0/DAb77CUaAdH4NrOGbuy7zpdrghxW3Zcf1mfdzJDlCe1nmDKlE5Uv3LjP2yH2d3VGgVPM7R4hFPxPFm/d54bXTsC0IgHeebzMzWa84w7djMKM3QDnBLrsE3bGTI5DAsdKDw0@cRQv9SXboZVK924IhmCa3G@Eh8YO@HkkhaUHSpCNEg4a@0h@3A2PtwN7O6o11sCeakbO0Q4AMQ6lJfj8KrsQfTwaGVBHFq@LMskC/mnje/jiIoXSiArj05LmH@cu8MdK9KZqUybANeRw7qH1GUOHkp6@l/@ReVofCWHNAdMQRpLPI7sPfRUh1g@t@UdRM0pZDq3bhlogvGDFCC97HFC25nZfR/0cKQqtR3RF5nLwREh9LeZPDoU3EZflJXpTulJDR7TwV@8Vd3u2a8TN@hkX251fSO1ZBoo@4/eb64toJGb35rij3@wD/THrt7NfQuX/ZFl4KyBlAj@LvqQGnlHZg9f8x1gATh1b4BfjhFVNMQFoLRk9hBYZJQhR3Ty/SFTtERtBnOZto2H86tFd4@MtE2Rnt5m3xrClO4hyxpc6RBJbyakY20KsNi3vxCeCN9uBTgJMhfRIyx5H6HcyIpnUjHYVvH/mdGnrroQEX9sc8PaZSEsspbPC54guD@Qstxqz5@r1HqqIkGm80kqB@jRpqoI8Ok3fCRve10OWdumA7129quzTiAqIsEvNrr82g5sJiiu6ILajP@k6@DfkqVdAsJXvwVx3o461SsX7rZ8IAdc@rNs6NQTgpwsbfRJqwd4S/G4eW1DoPKe7GtE6B2pWTn/loANl9XbW4x2aqA2rtSKjuyh@Nu1Llsf2wpuh@OAN75bcvFX9EYGuUCiWab9HIigKyEJrWZfVAnJuVwmCE86sUXEr42ms3bFuVsclSqwcJFwAdSYihvWmIbjjn@8S6xwee6HfdD7J7qJOFzQ6TSmc/IbI71Gz6JiW9LtLFiNydaKIcIIO1@nrGgJLqi9QpG/ogoXhO03iFmYdY8gj@QA6iKWU9iLp@vSdkWCUysROfYNvYfgGXoCXgpBtUtC70G863fp9n0e8rLrNEuuehhfdkn4XxX@JlRex7Qv/uoI/B0mbgkszRk1pl4oG7Y9aLKMCywNDlSe/imNIqFHTjHvnGK1cm@X2W/o3HK51Raz2i22J9wAFg2WCbT35tvTWLntSxHh9CFXu4XhQk361/bP6KVm0dzV4sbEa6OwojdW8QpHXg3gWYIQBGgHMWObc8KYe9aPrqYJ8Npg11wIbEXsTx5F@JJH/VHDLCiQ8sTeQo04KqulS7gQpDp5TyURWGeHK7dlCWSMMUG3SGUnJ3I1w6w0oKx8xgscITneVfqOI@G@KnT9pG39aOFm4Y0RbyIFcRUszTwEoCKGVErgCQVVSJISlrWslEmXbIRwiIdkaGOx8SiuEbv6YON3zXqfkmrq@V66LfaQ/HAkjzgzes/l1sh15nygfUGeWAYEGdZIA8IYYfJl3K7PgN@iocz9ZOPvXq1ErH8sumjoH0t6/9DaXew00PabrTfPL2fRtZQ208hyw8MbSyr00ZP@C16pRgbT1n4ktu509q31JZvDQXpm4KoJdd@xT9jwoRHiZ88z0SkZzAGJ@6JyROsogDj/PmUj107qVp/m@GR0HcmDAEOENdTBHQSuQVDasshUJO4eaWwkMk2w2kC7vldhSTnmEpkIJij2nJ0WAlgKebX19zHlNyGKSf17roYfG1KwvW93rzL4xpjI3WElg36dA5SQ3mEvXXNhtBRIMDMSnuEVOb80jnHeIb6cPpuHTMkT58CVHF1dEZ5Pf4@92azT8Ftddgw0q6FV7bc3vtF5j6JYRAxsrVAgjF8d3pMu9N7BR7q@3B@G7gV45iYJXJfjn6gpwz@lFWqbtewZYakoBAZaLr/ikPnxTwfOp6rvrXqjZYD1qwe5A4AcyOsU2qG7Ld0CWlO9nUHxrBMxe@ds7cYMDH0RG9YEGDrRRtuGcLMjwRjQGn3PEY@ayZPbAaPpNf2v28wwq32z3zco1P985P9zzLyZriG@2SZTCtGfYlmMz/p9M@14xOsI7tk/SLk47KSgDyy@9OdnVJSgjkuhanhNx814mjFKAG9gDN/6ZCwa86om516wC7e9GSnVkss50PHegfPOXPLzKmXYeXWkCeXoq75dRbX2Gubbp@Kvl7rpweKLIxl7ebHUNrNVzW7CeTwsgrz2PJE3XDZ99VzbFcb7Fz/LEBnVpMwYFop47BJTGmSw@1olQwMGBaGu69kprsjd0Cfa6AsqACzPbtl4UR0VMYdj/XkkxSKtFNWTRNV7TJxmY9Ls3w1vpIQnbtMS2Pa5Yj2pzf4PhD0tZClFsPdhHtUvVWyZd6GAQS42HqzjQM4pfZnIPSxUcqwfV8KuUsWj5lV6mngna292CwKRMtvrssy6oc9dj401jipouqhDAvfwoC1medzv/VFoslUNaPMeppcZ40EKT9gKFRxMkezCtLY63cCunRLiz5PPiW358hgFT7@RV3qj2Le7WHZs09wlFEGK0o6XUCNE/fCgIHLBtWm2eFX7VDSs/kqlbyH/q9/LT2dyEZO@CPG5MHgtgi86tBgA9eml4eNgYSPyGpPwr8Eaf/2wCev5TlrVgSZ@y28pPj2Wudjqhng2x6I4o8YsNWaWhq7bTNjdawrIbcxq8tMDcyjX@UcQQ8mKw/rupAzYMTGDwXHFkDNsKsWr7dLkPjgZ/4vGl5lSpMo8USXUo5jjavPQviJt5faPQuhqhubmRF89AnJJawNzDWvdYMf85p50vVue8zEYNYa/WvMmqnNhf4o3XpcdVChSuAOuFhlwco/XKox2CQyONHzwIOsFIiUmPO2ad@o8nlNl@s6/1bOwxgNUmevkUKvLnGnb5QO7mnQpIm/8GxxDrn0NNfHoGTsEhVvzL1ocDHKxJ4gIJbh0ZvSP6QJbrWQYMYex5fKPI@IVIOrbruj7a9Ce4GirEKQ6pTt6l6v36sCfPD9Qxl5GCQJLGU9ZvC@kDBcAke7hUZZmb3QMKKSVLjN@OuPQVOhO@vGLOn5VJWWawLbdcu@/pa1logF/Qjtnsi3CFzrMRwUO8xz@Y3egeivPs2vnMCAX0CqTwprb/aYQ/XqIx0PCEY1H6wq17uGvXDl16Bl9cdaG/ZgcCTSp4j//90y6s87XJLhfTHQ7BWtGXMCIpnO4j7/53jESIHoRid1K@d/owzdEh@dsrXMvhO1JZb6RHrzEslGHI/g@F@XxZp7a9GheuHP1F454x970uUg4QdaYHUcCEzF0K1kGVqWKeNZXTWfqUwhn94pr08BmZxdkGDSunysgpuRNR7EOJ5pGh/n9rhOsme0h/Iq/SBMqYAW/FTdWI6csPmaAew3vhrzbVe1He9ThO9Qm@g1vF1sQ8ZoOYwIce7eisY@btLX1hoiRFCD4rzd@sz2swdfb7pGIarc4mErSrELxGcFgwgdXIUE@ip9afoZc3LhX3CE7WyWQy3jNbP4UUJuqwe6jaB5Q/jNPoO4msl@PEsQJldqgVdZq/fUzoggYhp79dOAixN7n8IBxi0o8meS5QcTNwUjfMGKcozLjEWF7ThLbCbZ@nKq2eg4us@AOqUw814Ibc0BOIPGKVc5H3opsR9s3uMjZMMYoiUJmsFIe9pAuZRA5Is2Y6VBCSpld6nqKUGgsS6GqZGkBMA9QrZ4CpEPL9oUVPQaARomAtwbT7nmuXWhhrblFV1bdf8sCvIiGdQrX5IaTXmgw2OYcxQ8p2tmFAIcv7CwPZW7TirbvQyVI4hU9Zdc27OhOVm8eT24FjufjlrE/g8iLy5Y7PNlqcLr3Yka4jLp5@tV4q9IwDhJW4NbzgwAxrZ09QY3hbvz6pjcngviXyvOQ52qgwLTLu/fWW6qlaVXdu/t7KxiJqlg6/Fh1TUwO9MUF48HxuXWqkJVJkC4jcVaQcKZr7pKVdWmW9k8X3Dbdq9E8r/BuD7k5fm29tM5UynYZHeM5MjKWfXxibuLykoS7w0PAgmfg/gAcgYfpFvUx8l0JpW9T@m7G1FgmBkA7g/m/ZGkhAvsQfxS3H9chJG/fiY9D8Ktb6u8TuFeX6KzCx9OlDFMIKTZejoMaWGG2vfS53KAb0772prJOSuvz@NQho2dT1KB0dGGO87UHBbpyXthdWTph0HExFffKiccZVQV0PfmJ4TcmxT8Mc1u9Bl7gaGYA4Kz67CjaCuiBYWxpjteOmhjXFiV/1h3lf5mU/GddVqRC3gxzi3YPPKcMfHFqbIZbwNpAszB8x5ppsQEv9ita9zGAJilI6J9DEMFE6YkMsJqaW/IjflLQkIU@/WyocrNsFe9ewn/pz9@8zyGgIx3n87NnJHPDVDnFSroFsefEhSsbUIBqNLvpPv6At3xyvenq/E9tXN8vp0a6TutKu5XSRRDk99bOd32EN@0KkTEkF6srJRBtZKSIGdSiGsBEZFxmW5WJEj7MEr3VmtcJ9B4uXmW2a6ihmZcIk9F1wbEoZWR@l4k5PqbErB@fYx3l5sxX2Q1lP6JFDoN65UqXEL9a0SL/WDXzJT613NybhWADwYrD61nH6DfC/5Fo3Qiz6x3SLhWAfyklF5pNypoO4RVhQXlwH3G//gMEz9jvOV03wlYrPJMqz/QIScHOkXxlaZ@2/REYmrG7Bl2qcE5S4QGf9ttAKfFQisa1sCDckFsCESi9R3cwC@KvkUSA2k2Qr7CRsCVySWwt1cviGEwU8gh9zSDvlLompQPYlAAps5oBgGbkqWG6v7cpz@LJTx2cIWfOUNGwabH87Kw3xp8itVhbcwzc2yI9BH/isSjw36PMlkRaTVrmbhmbbn6kPaktK3Fr3knQOShSe93/rL9wjBEeBfjARzZ1DTVmGD9E4eAXjMbu27U9qThGueYrOjPXuO52HtfCG0H5qUx0hEaBcxjifvc2BjXnsFwuCGTSD2hIcwks19psSwkMXPH8@UJoaYKkF2aqd9CuBrqcc4pwyw7oeurTUTHzXXWd33DB4GXL@KlT7Y/Rlfjult6TcEghMiPbR6DrD38mNZc7hz4nFtkJBEYZBaTqmNQvyr2rduM6WGIj4Snk08RDj7@uCCJSgj@31w8ofdHsUP90@qXbI1SIjWdWqKIjfgz18OTDFXLVgS/bBTs8evx/3ycApwE@3uhP75nfbSlWV73CplGxGgYJcemRDNh5JjfSBqPlPa15xZuE3es0h@vU88YhOp7mk02EmUxtnv9/s4@0oWVB3WL7SkgHt4rrii4ZqaOvh3c5Dk3X4hf0a@yR0AjInWrsqklmLhVGQulvpzuhGdWDoS3XBb2VLih/gETOxVIqkxXyaG1QmihZAi7lzYIh@T3PhYqoROy2XHEE8xLDCERg4vd1zyqzCI23gf@PO0C2F@sFX5vwe8@/JszrQRZrbaGjL5cRA@0OYzHros5fc4A/SBJfFQuSRs8YPjyi6Zyjuc01YmUmyywuX7rASFFUX7eeSL8@n3oSeNALJM43Wr@gOb4kh7uD9HZC@GaaD8PBnJcrf3@8I/3aHyFyBq2GAHY86C3Pu2vH46lZn3X4dbPk5VmkssYU70vZSr6ooCO3bnvWv9iS5c2UtOBMVz0ObIUIynrFFGILnRA8ZeaL3HN0zevR93GvBqQpMhWyVySrrNI@@o6MCoWalwZ2B4o9nYx6nmioTLdauJFxOvGKBCETrT790KAKsKvCMUpNT4akL5VadyGq7pvfq4aeZvRU3qEFG@hVp9PRR6ZjpMcMQoMMtAwUFxl@95b@yAMe@YERDNZq0Mc@wB4Yggl18VMKf4W36P3M3BV9ml9VEvSGHr7U@QK3GL0yR3zA8KZIwhulR@aBOwg63xvmYVtRaKphP9mHnu43P5a4Z31LRzUel6kZQ/YVPogTHBHdEI2VyxtoQdXUqcRgxm5fFjEQ9VTHg1EeMmEAsJmwkeCtKxT3iWpVf60QMpUKot2e2pCaQGoX88NIXERCTAyQCZe0osv1CH9p2gyeembHdA7fA0T5MNVqDXZ/40ub4@Vam81oqjT3zAZ6XoaSe0nN1wUEkCkUO0rCa2vKMwpGewiJJksPMLbrVAmOlSPD8XD2va@il0Ym7vMSnl8jW7rNyh/PZxYCsKzfZ9yN3JHCb8lYCfcZvdFZ2KoaqnrePTHM@SZS@qH/d93qoQOVofSA8cN2E6ZMxeYbzfe7h/R0VHc4H6pRz@URy63@2UCH3fL6UgxZcwq4xPXikXDgUdT6n6@AmcEBfV87e0qW3dqHJd7etdPC5PsKVrZ9/mm3Ml9IsV9Gv3nI8KUvatx2e0xAp5p7RvVNVXpoPiDfsbyaSTgh0o@dHu0SWcCabv17W6vcx1dCcRcYfTz7Iz@L4RSmpU9eZUpG18A0m/@wIjWkGeLGfMllDi3YCGWs61p6Q49g@JM7WB8Jeki8v9MeYC3j4NvAIolyv/9/pROh6q1hIaqzWDFOOOaI2YHcliwHYDYe0646W8oFsHb@iaSk8A2A/3mhRP4aqkRRDs6DcQreGISr0lZ0b3ez3GHMVmEZAICPdCB5WM6SsX2zvj5CzUEEecX6sNHXjlanzI5SUUNSqOP4uUpf0xRbrKg8VRDa@b1yxrFwEeHLIZgCSO24rM4EgklRA34s@6GQYeTSX18aJMg2kMMYFX9aEmhQyrGdMpViCF0eWqUo5kV7dIXW1npItTFvkE5Vqa1h4g3e/hyfc3W6Ss2sukH/fc3sSMNJJSezV1Fqiyp5P7Z@QgDQtMFGX3GaBCZzHsb@@4bUpE2C2tkHivEmxGh7Gn@1aIrFTFxpvDCeoG953i8fTli/gB9HSNNJE42csmux37UwGv2Xy36yiJA6/SE21eo8qPzg54fXRFT3KTmNkb@8zm1308@StzQLUqL/HcQA8B3pmFF0pDvJklylMb@q3uBITKA96c6TrIYavYs/h50Q1Zi62PrxD8Zj/Dujj/z8zdHpTMDOkVVwZHo27dwuYWrPRs8b@zw@x5z67O682vzsiW2H3VQIyMEuETUoxMq2U@CS9BZqhJnzw2fSAFyR1lX0qysSFjZPbnwzD/n88Yup5LqIidBheBdASkOvSRmYabYPWtYlGn@1ZmgbhvqiS357pthvK7Gw01tc2XIjgAuVy7gBTMzoeuNcT7ySZXM24f4mfq51RNd9UDBMYI8XCtOkBNOX2Fb34z7bGIc6IOWddyBUo4Xl6IC8usvoPo0K1RMOPfTBsSvhRN3PFmHF4htSw7tQ4o/dawL2rvFpwitlnL03dDzYFs3Sv6fJlgMNjX4A1O31DoG9BO7NuSnZp3J/sQURbBtW/mjNVgX0xxUQq7AVyWcwAeopsdY5MaVeGBaI/n9Y5QvE7aXm1QlRQ1naHQW4lj3Y8giTn@nELpK812gGYfFAGI8TdZ6hMw@Uy@gSuckjf@xAgVhei8vGOQOmviowMvMdZ4EFI6Co8LXdKwrFPc6tZUybBsZ58y40jxhPoG2Vc9tGLB2rLLxHvmLoa/i2U2H1uxnOZN/RhaeU1AdRLfpw042tQhSDdC591vvBYVByfE0JGstbl5KCOh6v5B0TEdoN7ZhF6fSzMwkGnQV6rYU6EfvODVxGZTbT6oqnMkM8/QvndbmJ/qGa0nWMgHmKJ625Muw1TLTB6rTn@UWZIaXIrNetvBDyeC6cDN79U3rx0oueMB2HBUsmAALmlm@3JbJs5C8YWzaqW6fqTRevPbQchDFLeRlAM0sn81SbDfzq6@D6KcqdZ7svf60oWtpm5MNvj4c7889OYjZhuktSfjbikiNvU7F4@0xXHqI@Ftsfk40MJ1poGy3EXGzh33jxlFlPH9vnKgaLXw6YX5J4Ndc0ltC5UWYby/Yd3jBMvZ1qpSYt6hEZ6PPTTPXkQxFfblAkr9Peu95QRFeOM5p8PLosdPrc@7UYZcY5u/WnHAPZT96NLARymJ8iQcyBEI9EgZPsdXIXeGD7jd24x1uMNQzdS29kDiw3nlL85unYLVMBc9tJrWNBnTFHVRJDpddqw7MRGumqD7ofx3e66ozJWuUvuB/uzbR@z9WihZp0j178oygfhakHg63@SPDKSRyD9FAcXhI5T4oWpkSGdRrS4U2n73zStrB/t9iFijQxv8mqokI3ABn6fYXW7BfZiieNF5BwJHjrwhqKFg6SBvVGIsSF830V2Mj8IVn6Kznfd4XO8E75eM2bP4W51k1SxPqKOxvAPRwkByUcavY0zC@XuDKKpxQE67k2TqcfnJJVD0r/czkGKivG0vqXQZVXhDkJYLw7DM68CPd4Cbq0HQD4q7VqXr@zU98@tqXnrFhzXsuFfmQ/LTCgHvJkH0J8eTD@4mlt0upA1QbKhxzXuWuMyNBJhpR7yz8MAG7Lm@r/BlZhmC0toplevcaDVPFCZ4tNMoC1zcgUKcYrBTcIPOx6NjERREfT7KroOZvUjsDkEJUtxfUrpWW262V9hZqvez5XH9fiaAkxUxYLxaL@nsJDjnZjTdk2TGElpzeNODMiifbYCaMEKHVHLOCvh5HPaMmKTg2v1S1dofiW6QhNs1V/3axQXtq62MK2kG3mZLFyniFRatbVV9/rAvI549SozPGauhwKvKDvftNmW6J7i2VyLzWkHHehHJjgZUqZrpwnFsjnjN98MRpBo2dj1pW8HyogvTqBbFMuVuHNov9b4Rj21hb3UuHFAyrZeeynP1ebdeE8WqH5Q@ChOj89t29TLz6CsNuvcBgO1NhiIcDB/dmqc7vHUUE@s3IZctZB54QSjRR97Fl0/muV/OneVH2tgQGO0kAyBo4LY6SFoBkNGVtPAOe@FJB0sOuejH6rlvnyn7qYFs3yFj9JjlO1STSr2SGYNCQL/eO3p7ko@VznrJBaohHebcuQjb5/qcd8tayHd6w7pKrQrHwkWMm6L6oFZLMZ/@Xe3VIq/8C@wCN9QYY8VGax7nS7vjS3dsleOO5T2vEp2X9DtWWs3ksgM7vQ/I7@1eNKOzcpD84UFrx6m3gpZy8TCtjYLNfGonhLXZaD/EYyHDXmfp@mWd@w5PjS1ITtiswVU3jAFZ6H7aZXrzhuqkpBXiZ6vPKgnVlum@qppR4cwtrGQQTiZOCO7LC0THv@F7qHLD5tSh//bvBvNJmWf5bx/fRxN8vgH62aRv4fDBbB/AvK6Sbrw2jByzlmUT2ev1eFjl3NwAbJg@sAHZDw2@ITq/HIXsatPEUvW77d5eysZBmP1EMREm26De2jGfozH58uvKdTENZGycYMZ09nSAY785HUnZMGrtR9hSDy2uC6BEYANWBeiQHDx92gU22r9GqP0pZtDWindhxutWb201gFw3oIG3nFJqUpfaKsH9tY/5EX2C4ikngk7bzznF7m5UIlxvpXxyomcvFXncWnSaCWhXaupLyn5DQVd3SEdP3JHXl9Xm4AvKqjpM5J6Km57sRGEFk/wDnj4GGQDykyXsZOioXL8uGb4Z28S5CE8JX5Hm/GSG77MYCtGdZk@B3gZHLP8/pOtobbppQ8A0u8l5ugnx9mNkAMQUIy0mqa2Hx3W/K2cKErJUI@d1Hlm0lEjyMRdarmO3CHJqiJJZpOrDXQ/2vP0g1Qc6uYdfpKPoN/aoE95YcIvm@iLvADWdqed@ceRZr9WBZo6Q7WQmKwBfrpzf8kQx9TquskMEAxeZP4FtW@/TmQG34J3QeDipkUJMYP3nlX4eTzF6fVZby15LszkhPO1wn1XDMcSeQ9C/0NB4yXDkY@u4ViGy1ltG791bTDyvlvOupzBPq5MPko@fAd9nlJIP@RuQV9/rUwWtZMOI1gZ3rHxfgP4J/Ta1xOhTjVIat0k94NnukcNQLPkFDen4C9alZMtzIM0x@mwnLyx1srzcTquXoEY94DYiBxvaVfxdCl5gxCXBJaqegEeHHw0awq858K7KOtTh3COroIHWujiY5g56YEmw90H1cgjHHnvTa/JqJ1jtCmQ0nwGAb2SO6I8JrmaPL02HplfIH/l@TPEGHZCxzaaEwt7orHzOySHm6xN9wNd7V96dG02gZrQRkz1JXO/mp6qGtQK6EJgaEFbNS@E0/iwO1usVZedc/ScAMzp/6PFLWnkymrK2@4@ju4ur6D7lpNdhKFFb9r8GFW/twmTu6YBPYt8P7E9@WgMrzgN1b3HYQvao/GjnZBz8Oym/TyHEOehE8mPC@bgD3qOYQx28TUtCRfsnp@jiJm@VPjOjFzSgCGFiugSrvgyMY8cc1RWX8j9AvGrJZX4764Lwyi5fWb6qoJmNtQrFEvFtrwCsSW@ViadAz@rIYONHkOPHaH9Ux82xLfGIykG/KsmigAObO/rhpfAV058Vla@waYrrPEA3HlXRyqo8ShgbRO4JCoDcKjkmfiZ8Y5C@u3iPuXAWkwTRa8egextbuFXFV4VB8wmjWmFfybaxFfJY4yCEi2Z/0UOhqZkvH9Xn9IKlMbeCjjQF/eD7nLhwPJJUHAwb5sD22SyKfYc03yDfUEtG5nVMXIC5c5WiEafos3R7g6ql/0EONIUThrf8Kcp0DG5gWC5YE4qLVzoS8MxDxjX9@RPuGymgo/@umPP6bWrIeJrH6v7HXtjjARxsJgIHn30JbIFNu1li42nfHEvg5pWtP5ceT@Y7ARI7nsN5VPjPsAmfVL6glz5ATkz@AkZ0Uf18L1jdQd/8bVzp10gmd9EAlSIYeic2laD3fT2D1kCEfocTWyeZpo3q0kZ43zg3eHrt9HLTjuSXRl6YdxMkdq@ebZx/ffBHczqCEHfbcD1ELUkn2qr0jh7PKUGcl3GXU3ytxWKXOL4aJZToyzWM8FywCiyOAwsAwRDBhhVSWuMRWEKQevHgqNLsrjoAkBSv7HGHEW7gUVcR2g6ZPLxLxrvW//eSmZeLpiOWJFUMvWsQ7b/nuNLaw7RBtNd9S09PkCxVhMys1X1GxQQ0VMPmvX7DmH74gqa/qZm2G2Bbg@p6/cQIx59UlJgzLYQwAvw55oI0AvZfeKhbeHwjfBNBWYFozTJYLLLeexPb0HjThCKjd9wOOKwbwrI65gPIjdiQ0@SbFJLrKYO3FpZjp8K/v3D7CbbpvUEWHbJlj1q42p6A/qg70FOVcsLu59zk3907cc0tiYu/Al/bG2qjdYnh@jTwKSvyf45DHoHC1FSMqqTQjkMzh111F8J@H8QhN1Upx3kc2Gu6e3CZGaStox4evLJi7wDYhANfxNWA0Z1S3fLq4gZF4CytElWNYU/uTN@@qCYzP9RF71maQGp56l2wDKe3wqrlNy5hQH4RG/uVyhGxVmfPJ2Q7Z5xri3de1c704bSt/cHbJxkPOe9YLafEY6cL99iE0E8KsnlXGJ9/FAwbcN/lXmXFEQQ2KfnM@Z@0jlijCBkigNXMVAf4zT7EjVvtYegBPjjEcJQatja8HjXvOU8v@Mc3wqi@NwTzseM1jcLpfdmQ0KshKDTtM0i3Wak7wFqyu562RguRBzyF9eTOutSxThJfRCTsBW3ln0DK4jf4WCFyid/f@DLJsGdx7saQn0GPtlK4gWbkuPREp9t@v3hyBTRqrm98b98RM7PFeH62ACR98mcU0oK/iaw7ET5qvLt/0RC/gFqMwHBh1FB6Qygm3Gb5aSg5Vz8C3pLv5LlA1hF@QciXcBrAcT4zms/v0c3x/uqGAXjUIREBNb7ayvSgnIQ5@n6DXUKdPtlHi08JlYPn7HsUd4p0tHeceM3PWOXViAa49pzr@3OUJ8iPsOk0NaMnCd3M1yKyuUie3yWmvx9mex9ChhY9MgBGrvnMeXYrEQuQquIWicfB7Bgr@cnprryL6DAzxIfmwsvOrcvwxX7J29CWfpkIGJefhbmzfP5eUZptba80jAzFBmvtd7zeJ18xv1DzWRiKEnp7bMQV@1asqS09hsa/d858XgmgQZ@YZAISYVQsLPpmptg5ab9CiIBXlW82mNYo8o1TiZa1gikd82aNgVVjWVbydI@KQAnDiZdPTnsNiQ1m1HGXrE77yxp6NNQHq45vCEHGXfh7bHIeq@YNoPl2vC3yIH0xlzWAof0KegAfYWLqYx0LCjTOi9UDmM23aRUxAVgY4T0y606xNc8eNe@V3QwPFI6FRzIvbZK4Kjq6plQRnV@Fxelxz6jGUeUqP0H4SS@2uXIspamumgVE13Hj5EvPz/pFoxSM7u0wKQUEXO1EiqPjHXqZ9ab2ZE8rQqpc3H0TPavL14XR66d5PadehN7AV9RHvlV9kEDaIkMM/Yrv6Vuwwl0UtlFexIwS3I0bMGIVglPmICp9DAlbpoYerEoQv5k506/tJJIYQLog8dHQSPBEBic9Q6PlHeoDV0xYYdx7FjH5J8PTfefF3aMiaw6QQpR5nTFkRDqwxdqSMetfE@mF7Wl93mFXxO9ha57NkSAK4RdZndtOZNQCsZoqBIFdtae1s6fvsIkPNjnnmmmYW4eeGRRrMDkq9vJcQCP1sM4XbmGSN98ukyqZcKbLmSlj3KkU7wKRxvfaeQyD81EXWKzMk0f5ENhBvX3t8VSugdv0gPIXtBxYEU@0vnPer0pZVQzJx6f0cWq0aENqqDkYjDf2XsUk7QPlIQLxuWYLp@LZ582si75yVZlYnRNqL5XQ/Fof3tvQNZiCiIgq1uH4rDTfdqbLA5LyotRU8NyUVmK86NVAuFpbf4iwSUx2tALt3pznOuxWN6/DQ2r3qwXtOrHJYaKlGT/0xyeoph2ir/@GTP1tE6PbE4dro7ODMEOAzmgGzvSkH1yvyYYCuH8@hH2@9rtaf/3OgjZdUYc3q9DXDawsBgzWMMUfI2g9wUuhQDjsWWY9cBG9@QncJYG/7PlE/pgmmdhNb46sxZekugsKV0lpf4xshCEabUajhGh5E4pmyI79qADPWy0h5q37qQDKUU9MvklAAdZ4I829ENjp3sbNk8jXd9k7AxYYaMVhQSiETUX6@INKVJsuUaumMoFiARTiQz7rKyqwb6bAeII@Vbz6ab6Hkx3MTU3vs9rgv9YorgMDE2xPFN3EJfpO/xG2BnCSrbzzprTQ@P3WoeQLwSyY27jUNgFlwhghMEb1Fn4tRlLnfj@yZCgvHv@YfjPJ0o01@UEdMJJtVFAfh4i9jYqySsAE8SvvIifx1vRX@egQeA4DeF1yAWl@TGw5aoDXY9k7eKXvRRSpXCeLvKJa3I67jMxKOqHlBrif4wOJ1khlmrPxpPfRYiPjHyAZ@E07sURROmVVpp1cAWsIvd9LgxjZu/zANUMDCS@yNUY6CF3kXdBcH4g9d7yZjc7vEEyjgwvY2efcTpGKCQHA4Tdsk1ALugfZlDm6L2CfTvpghspEskhkI090jugmMckMy8aJAKEwTe3gm4genb@OzhvZVSWKojlTIcAKE7wAEEY44V0mvPd@9J/7ewyr99mrqus0WWbOSqZVBbpP6@AT@KHlly2HjGGoxHxTIMONuOExcSH17WnXqlMt3z1jTT9um0LNloHAgh3pEec1nucPdaJve2sB/HOQqJAsed3@frQIaBM0cxBQWKMdVEVf@D4P2B8fV9rvqiXWhmbQxRO89DItKfMcwt4aOPQT287hK35opN1ZWVhCzF4oap3W9bca7/PRLGmD5YrfpMgCTXptDf3jjznVbRLSjQ4FrVauceWkvlUvwcQTljiDHT5imzR82fj6kDK/t/1jlQkI2OKpkIlXtzd8UQ1MacXiFmL9actimRNXZ3FVr9I2DH/vujQDjnNfG70lN0@EsyZxEy1J5VSuLnNwAA6Gy3DbobbGadrleBSKzJ3JN8hMeW6Kr6D1HzTiKls00ltFx6xbpVpJtH9tE3pTqHO0t5wga2aaMKDTVIPoafmlsjcYYs1J8o8L@tavN5uefXx6psi8@aa@RIU3hlheTF5gAUvVF6yiKWte2DDH4tC/A48DJORYPdsLunBtOyevLMV85rVof1p0yjI3PfyVkETa6N2pBv2EN0nXsT43K@PcZKWpteftN67KUa/HHnAJD27V9EIM96tUaASFLMnFWFNi8KdHC/NDt2mc7hFfU8pPX8Jh4rjReMGHDRliraQ969Qule4LErTAPTrbC7wph@Rf2wcRdXabYwsdg8SSL/PUXQtO3kw/OaNJqCwro7ZVXvs8Or4SM9rdWzbOxP4cbOfiApoJYWKNYsclBcX3/rZvnRbLyh6YopltrB/tuNI/e6MW6qqqyj1heN1/f0V8xLtBCxfdYLzMEl@P6nFADis5M/NpPv36KIrvwNp9hqrdIuwweMDuD/IsMH/QS6k31kkDTzeL5I9n4kOSaLTXxGyBDCfZSSMzkOiC3BuvsuZ9Dt1dpm9mbNXENYpVMsIdc@4NOLGeiAv99SdJzAzZBEjIzFcdUahnMm7HJ8jQigLpVCBhGYlOzB7Fvp/QnON9CJeXrCIz5Dfu5mLQ2wNXzkVxvr7draOWt4qPo9LbZriBwuXScd4vkif0bU4DPtVhd38//AhE68DbON04pEp2MstvdmNmowiKyaPAzKwb6qaZ9u/9P4kPBbHsuRHkbBX/xOCxt6IlAEjAXiR1OohEymXnvOCp6RMw3um1wwSpwJrF8KkhzpFcw8t2Gw6YlZK6645PhK6QXA1EZZQIvyz9OQNVVDvJg@NlOhPqDE5snnV1sJFCKKCwb2GNoFWg42mTgAwnHLFsaOxJe6lG2NnbMx2SsaSuxa96bCvgzonY1OgX7f8OlOX3cpm0niYwsfR@rw3fDHGTU0z3YrHKcBl5ItEu3uTRVTCGZgt8v0UChbX9IXq/AIcV7MNISjuamb04hr7h502MeORTSlbLVBXVxPVt01oPwdOtZPmUED6fK8YPIrwp2pmNBP30PlE5@gKpnkTdvBrjt0y8bKnaShEP1ibvvoHe8fF4vqKmrvI7gy7@xrqhGV05qDMab7pWwvhlYGWGShFlXb8fkKOPlXlgsc3WEWmeURHxZwahlbV395Xa6aN1/nLdF872IgqvUabLJmoszYyP1xshDJ7AH7GIlcr8eAATom1iLW4nTJAl6U7MEVUii3ZJRyKHxYfUkHoacNSc1aTBQpZQfuwlg4wBP1509@njLulcuXvGMwkBBwOd9EirTaXhpCGMjQ9@ta0rdC/9ZDx@xqMe7yGXKEtClp@/HG0P3tfM5xIxEH4xn7kiFkOcBXoBgdsNRqP8vVurbPi7ZrdsBhttF5yW/B2EfgyFo1LzVqAR6kih@ZR2JVIVhMtnyklihya1wPKX2ojPwQRSMdoGIQxfbmTI7nnVz9h2Q5K@hWL8lbajyGApn/xX9IWjyhvYdxsDh/o94Dn2b0kC/m4@Zj5YnsDIQE2WIDO@X7@n@y8CIU0a6@jTVoBxsfaSWuFYj0ZLJS4o10kCtq6f8ZCrRI2/l5aYRG1zgq7zygjJ0A4c3j25iCAFl7tn5VsuES2CXjRSyua1YOeRBu0kKlDB@5SkqdZFqK81xGg/Kj5@Khxz02p4AAYX1hYEgM/ieLnkGz8OhmHeY@2QL@4sifNg2IrkOUjnx/h@smOW@AhaOOb/Y0V@8e/ffw)

General compressing tool, also make them able to find source