# The most common substring

Tags: code-golf, string

The purpose of this task is to write a program or function to find the most common substring within a given string, of the specified length.

### Inputs

1. A string, `s`, of any length and characters that are valid as inputs for your language.
2. A number, `n`, indicating the length of substring to find. Guaranteed to be equal to or less than the length of the string.

### Output

The most common (case-sensitive) substring of `s` of length `n`. In the case of a tie, any of the options may be output.

### Win Criteria

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so lowest bytes wins; usual exceptions etc. apply.

### Examples

`Hello, World!`, `1` > `l` (appears 3 times)
`Hello! Cheerio!`, `2` > `o!` (appears twice)
`The Cat sat on the mat`, `2` > `at` (appears three times)
`The Cat sat on the mat`, `3` > `at`  or `he`  (both with trailing spaces. Both appear twice - note case-sensitivity so `The` and `the` are different substrings)
`Mississippi`, `4` > `issi` (appears twice, note that the two occurrences overlap each other)

### Some more examples, all using the same input string<sup>*</sup>

```
Bb:maj/2
F:maj/5
Bb:maj/2
G:9/3
Bb:maj7
F:maj/3
G:min7
C:sus4(b7,9)
C:sus4(b7,9)
C:sus4(b7,9)
F:maj
F:maj
```

(note the trailing newline)

1 > `\r\n`(appears 12 times, counting `\r\n` as a single character - my choice, your code may differ on this - otherwise either `\r` or `\n` appear the same number of times). `:` also appears 12 times
2 > `:m` (appears 8 times)
3 > `:ma` or `maj` (appears 7 times)
4 > `:maj` (appears 7 times)
5 > `F:maj` or `\r\nF:ma` or `:maj/` (appears 4 times)
14 > `\r\nC:sus4(b7,9)\r\n` (appears 3 times)

<sub>(* input is taken from [How predictable is popular music?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/198425/how-predictable-is-popular-music/). The result of this task might be used, for example, to find the most efficient way to apply a substitution in order to compress the string)</sub>

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks for the `n=5` spot. regarding your second point, each line in the test case ends with a newline - there are 12 lines in the test case, so 11 newlines. Or am I missing something? Or maybe the formatting is messing things up?

Comment: ...but, `:` does appear 12 times (not sure how you got 8?) - so that's actually the largest. I've added a trailing newline to the test case, so now we have `\r\n` and `:` tying.

Comment: Ah oops, not sure how I got 8 instead of 12 indeed.. Mainly wanted to say `:` occurs one more than `\n`, but with a trailing newline they indeed both occur an equal amount of times.

Comment: Is it acceptable to return the highest occurring substring with its count? (C.f. [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199718/75323))

Comment: @RGS sure, why not?

Comment: More interesting is requiring the solution run faster than $O(|s|^2)$. See rolling hashes and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597025/most-common-substring-of-length-x

Comment: @qwr feel free to submit an answer using that technique, it would be interesting to see even if it didn't win the code-golf competition

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ŒIù.M
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6CTPwzv1fP//D8lIVXBOLFEoBuL8PIUSIDc3sYTLCAA) or [verify the smaller test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWXC/6OTig/v1PP9r/M/OtpQR8kjNScnX0chPL8oJ0VRKVZHIdoIKqio4JyRmlqUmQ8XDslIVXBOLFEoBuL8PIUSIDc3sQQsa4xX1kRHyTezuBiECgoylWJjAQ) or [verify the larger test case](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/X90kmdZpb2SwqO2SQpK9i6V/w/v1PP9r/NfSUnJKckqNzFL34jLDUybcsEF3K0s9Y2hXHOotDFQNDczz5zL2aq4tNhEI8lcx1ITDwesC0IC7eKKNtQx0jHWMdEx1TE0iQUA) (which is a bit slow).

**Explanation:**

```python
Œ      # Push all substrings of the (implicit) input-string
 Iù    # Only keep substrings of a length equal to the second input-integer
   .M  # Only keep the most frequent item of the remaining substrings
       # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 10):

## Python 3.8, <s>[75](https://tio.run/##Jc7BasMwEATQX5nmEok4hrSXEsgH9N5bmoMsry1RZWW0a7v@ele0p4VhHrPTpiHz2/tU9gG3rz25Z9c7SMNXyUWpN8ZI6/PMapbrTe7xGk/8sM1ih1wQERnF8UgmERuxZz5drLX38@WxTyVWNZjDZ4gCCTmmHh1B8pOq84UkdomQMo@YInlCHqD0o7UCDU6hI9VAFN4JVesrFRRyKW31JFocawPHPQL57wZRQQsxgpP/Hd2mLPhAH3s@KrqsYS3wuRTyGnls2xbdrMgBK6XUIJEeqyXC@vdBoDokc1JEeTk0eLV2/wU)</s> <s>[68](https://tio.run/##Jc/BTsMwDAbgV/nZZalWKgEXNGkPsDs34JCmbmOROlXsduvTjwhOln75028vu8Usb@9LeYy4fD2Sn/vBQ1s5z/7unNMu5FXMbeeLfvKZT/LdtFsz5gIGC4qXiVwicdo8y@mlaZrHUriK0R0@Iis0Zk4DeoLmmaoJhZT7REhZJixMgZBHGN2trsCiN9hENVBD8ErVhkoVhXxKex2JNi/WwsuASOGnBRtoI0H0@t9j@5IVVww8yNHQZ4u3gpBLoWAsU9d16FdDjrhRSi0S2bFaItz@LohUi3RNBtanQ4vX@tkv)</s> <s>[97](https://tio.run/##XcoxDsIwDEDRq1idbBFYYECRepLQIUADjlonitsKTh/SFelPXy9/l3eS8zWXGqC/1cnP96cHNWJn/0FEpy7aeJAhpAIRWKB4eY04jYJKNJweaZUFN9urY8sNktlox/yPj0JENRduPmDHqnudgUvbPw)</s> 63 bytes

```
lambda s,n:max(l:=[s[j:j+n]for j in range(len(s))],key=l.count)
```

You can [try it online](https://tio.run/##FcJBCsMgEADAryw57RLppT0UwZekOdhUW41ZxTWQvN7QYcrZfpnvz1K7B/PqyW7vjwVRrDd7YNJmkinqOPLsc4UIgaFa/jpMjlGIZrW606Tbkndu1EsN3NDjEET@BwUPon4B)! Increased byte count because, as @xnor kindly pointed out, Python's `str.count` doesn't count overlapping substrings... But then @xnor's reformulation of what I was doing allowed to slice a third of the bytes!

### How:

```
l:=[s[j:j+n]for j in range(len(s))]
```

This creates a list of all the substrings in `s` of size `n`, plus the suffixes of size `n-1`, `n-2`, ..., `1`. Then we find the `max` on that list, with the numerical value being used to sort given by

```
l.count
```

That means that if `a` and `b` are from `l`, `a > b` if `a` shows up more times in `l` than `b`. This means the shorter suffixes are never the result of the `max` because they only show up once, and even if the correct-sized substrings only show up once, they are first in `l` so they come out instead of the short suffixes. This allows me to save some bytes in the `range` used, given that I don't have to prevent `i+n` from being larger than `len(s)`.

<s># Python, <s>[83](https://tio.run/##LY89bsMwDIWv8uolFuIYSLsF6AG6d0szyDJtEVEoQ2SS@vSu0HYiSPB7P8tqMcvbNuH9a0v@Nowe2slJczEa21bPfOK9XKZcwGBB8TJTm0hadQfZH53rrrS@/6N20j7ku1hrzp0Px8u2FK5bs2uwx9Q2n5EVGjOnEQNB842qaiikPCRCyjJjYQqEPMHo2@oLLHqDzVQPagheqbKhoopCPqW1jkQPL9bBy4hI4dqBDfQgQfT652PrkhUfGHmUnWHIFp8FIZdCwVjmvu8x3A054kkpdUhku8oS4fmbIFI10nsysL40HV5dLVWrue0H)</s> 64 bytes</s>

```
lambda s,n:max((s[i:i+n]for i in range(len(s)-n+1)),key=s.count)
```

Thanks to @mypetlion I saved a LOT of bytes :D

You can [try it online](https://tio.run/##NY/BbsMwDEN/hculCZoF2HYrsL/YbdvBsZnaqGMHltI2X5@5KHYRIIGk@JZNfU4f@4TPnz2aeXQG0qfTbO5tK9/hFI7pd8oFASGhmHRmG5la6V7T8a3r@gu3TxlsXpN2@1JC0rY5NDhiapsvHwTi8xodRkLyzJpiC10Y44aY0xlLoCXyBOVdqwTqjdbBehCFNcLqtdUqKDSx@gojryZpD5McPO2lR1DwygRv3POPbkuWZ9hjH7PbwFjDbC6FVunwwJo5DAPGVZE9boyxR6Qeam0St/8qhbJGRZCXpsd7V@kqY7f/AQ) with my very own incredible test case!

Comment: Replace `sorted(...)[-1]` with `max(...)` to save 7 bytes.

Comment: Replace `lambda t:s.count(t)` with `s.count` to save 12 bytes.

Comment: Incredible! You shaved 19 bytes already!!

Comment: [fixes typos](https://tio.run/##NY89bsMwDIWv8urFFuIaaLsFyAGyd2s7yBJtCZEpQ6ST@PSugKILhwd@72fdNWT@OCZcvo9kl9FbSM/nxT67Tr7iOZ74Z8oFEZFRLM/UJeJOzCuf3ozpb7RfZHB5YzXHWiJr17QNTpi65jNEgYS8JY@RIHmh6uIK@TimHSnzjDWSI@QJSk@tL9BgtR6qgiicFaqsq6igkE2VK5Tobll7WPYI5G49ooLuxAhW/nJ0X7PgCh89t4oxV8sCl0shp5HnYRgwbooc8KCUeiTStrJEePw3KCRbUkR5aXq8mzqqTjPHLw)

Comment: [makes sense, too](https://tio.run/##NY@xbsMwDER/5erFNqIaaLsFyAdk79Z2kCXaEiJThkgn8de7AoouNxD3jnfrriHzxzHh8n0ku4zeQgyfF/vsOvmK53jinykXRERGsTxTl4g76V/59Nb35kb7RQaXN9b@WEtk7Zq2wQlT13yGKJCQt@QxEiQvVFNcIR/HtCNlnrFGcoQ8Qemp1QINVqtQPYjCWaHKuooKCtlUuUKJ7pbVwLJHIHcziAq6EyNY//dH9zULrvDRc6sYc40scLkUchp5HoYB46bIAQ9KySCRtrUtER7/DQrJlhRRXhqD976OqtP64xc)

Comment: [or if you prefer this](https://tio.run/##NY/BbsMwDEN/hculCZoF2HYrsL/YbdvBsZnaqGMHltI2X5@5KHYRIIGk@JZNfU4f@4TPnz2aeXQG0qfTbO5tK9/hFI7pd8oFASGhmHRmG5la6V7T8a3r@gu3TxlsXpN2@1JC0rY5NDhiapsvHwTi8xodRkLyzJpiC10Y44aY0xlLoCXyBOVdqwTqjdbBehCFNcLqtdUqKDSx@gojryZpD5McPO2lR1DwygRv3POPbkuWZ9hjH7PbwFjDbC6FVunwwJo5DAPGVZE9boyxR6Qeam0St/8qhbJGRZCXpsd7V@kqY7f/AQ)

Comment: @S.S.Anne [gives credit, too](https://tio.run/##NVA9T8MwEP0rjyxN1BAJ2Cp16MhcNmBw7Et8qnuO7Evb/PrgCFhuuHufNy3qo7ytA45fazDX3hnkVg5X86jr/MkH3sv3EBMYLEhGRqoDSZ2bZ9m/NE17oeWYOxtn0WadEovW1a7CHkNdfXjOyD7OwaEn5HilomITOe7DghBlxMRkCXGA0kMLBOqNlkFlkRXWZCpcW6gZiUwovESBbka0hREHT/bSghV0I4E37tdHlylmvMOxk52ij0UywcaUyCrL2HUd7p6tx50SbYbyf6WSdsG5O3c4idCG7GdF3KAhtAiku9KLqAj8ZU2U56Dg/FS1eG1K/fKEZv0B)

Comment: It looks like this unfortunately doesn't get the `"Mississippi", 4` test case right, due to how Python counts substrings.

Comment: @xnor [defining my own `str.count`](https://tio.run/##PcxBCsIwEIXhvacYupqhcSG6kEBOUrOItIkD7bRkStDTx6ggvM3Pg2977Y9Vztct1wjuVuew3McAasQu4YmICdUU63Rgy714MoXimoGBBXKQNOE8CSodhYgOyf2BYn9HkBGLa8C3C3nqmzmcrG9U3TLLjhE7Vv2sM3Ahqm8) is a possible fix but it is extremely long :/ do you have any hints for better ideas?

Comment: @RGS My best thought is to generate the list of substrings and do `max(l,l.count)` on it.

Comment: @xnor that is incredible, as it allowed me to golf even further than my initial answer :O

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 8 bytes

```
s₎ᶠọtᵒth
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v/hRU9/DbQse7u4tebh1UknG///RSr6ZxcUgVFCQqaSjYBL7PwoA)

#### Explanation

```
  ᶠ        Find all…
s          …substrings of <1st element of input>…
 ₎         …of length <2nd element of input>
   ọ       Get the list of each substring with its number of occurrence
    tᵒ     Order by the number of occurrence
      t    Take the last one
       h   Output the substring itself
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>49</s> 46 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to SirBogman*

```perl6
{$^n;bag($^a~~m:ov/.**{$n}/X~$).max(*{*}).key}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WiUuzzopMV1DJS6xri7XKr9MX09Lq1olr1Y/ok5FUy83sUJDq1qrVlMvO7Wy9n9xYqVCmkKNSrxCWn4Rl4a6b2ZxMQgVFGSq6yiYaOoAxUIyUhWcE0sUioE4P0@hBMjNTSwBShtr6vwHAA)

#### Explanation

```perl6
{                                            }  # Anonymous block
 $^n;  # Declare argument
         $^a~~m   /       /  # Regex match input string
               :ov           # Also return overlapping matches
                   .**{$n}   # Match n-character strings
                           X~$   # Stringify matches
     bag(                     )  # Convert to Bag (multiset)
                               .max(*{*})  # Find Pair string=>count with max value
                                         .key  # Get key (string)
```

Comment: [46 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WiUuzzopMV1DJS6xri7XKr9MX09Lq1olr1Y/ok5FUy83sUJDq1qrVlMvO7Wy9n9xYqVCmkKNSrxCWn4Rl4a6b2ZxMQgVFGSq6yiYaOoAxUIyUhWcE0sUioE4P0@hBMjNTSwBShtr6vwHAA) `/.**{$n}/` works. Not sure why `/.**$n/` doesn't.

Comment: @SirBogman Cool, this sure would have helped me a few times. `/$n/` is supposed to interpolate literal text (like `\Q...\E` in Perl 5), so I can see why `.**$n` doesn't work.

Comment: I don't fully understand what `.max(*{*})` is doing. It seems like both of those whatever parameters are Pairs?

Comment: @SirBogman Only the first `*` is a whatever parameter. The second `*` is simply to get a [full slice](https://docs.perl6.org/language/subscripts#Slices) of the Pair, returning a list containing its only value. So `*{*}` is effectively the same as `*.values`.

Comment: Cool. Those whatevers are very flexible.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>85 83</s>  80 bytes

Takes input as `(string)(length)`.

```javascript
s=>n=>[...s].map(o=m=(x,i)=>(o[k=s.substr(i,n)]=-~o[k])<m|!k[n-1]?0:m=o[O=k])&&O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZFfa8IwFMXf@ymuPtgEYrraitgtHUz2h8HmwwZ7qAWjthptk9LUscHYV@9SHSpsD14SOPfc/EIOWfN3ruelKKquVIukTlmtWShZGFFKdUxzXiDFcoY@iMAsRCraME31dqarEgkiccy638aM8VX@1dpEsuvG1xdBzlQ0ZsbtdMb1XEmtsoRmaolS1H5IskwReFNltmi1MXIxhkM5DtiZbf2HtGC0SpJSqAbqHaEGUa0/zOsqgRGvQJutJFSmzXn1izYMr85nvAMDNqgSbDP5Qz8JrZtVFMIg/mms/SuboW1ZGhhMb2ZBztdOb1JO5N1O9ht5at8HQ8c7moPjUW8/zoXcmaNAb7WPZgMyxOf0u0sOYnppRS6BHgGPgE@gT8D1Y5qq8pbPV0gCC@E06ePL@Jma7xdyKdJPE1xjJLGp@gc)

Answer (score 5):

## Java 10, <s>212</s> <s>211</s> <s>196</s> <s>195</s> <s>146</s> 143 bytes

```java
s->n->{String r="",t;for(int m=0,c,j,i=s.length();i-->n;)for(c=0,j=-1;(j=s.indexOf(t=s.substring(i-n,i),j+1))>=0;)if(++c>m){m=c;r=t;}return r;}
```

-15 bytes by outputting the substrings with their count, [which is allowed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/199696/the-most-common-substring/199718#comment474884_199696).
-1 byte thanks to *@ceilingcat*.
-52 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jVNNb6MwEL3nV0x9soWhIUlVNSwcNlJ391D10JX20PTgEJOYhQHZprtVxG/PGgKKqm2rSnwM85793oyHXDwLP9/@PqaFMAbuhMLDBMBYYVUKuUODxqoiyBpMraowuB2CLw9WK9zxDzk/0Mqd1BxO5CSBDGI4Gj9BPzmckqBjQriNskpThRbKeMpTnnMVm6CQuLN7yiLluyUR6zipw/PYDyOaO4bCrfx7n1HrYtNsTL8lVT5yxXjuhYwl8TRiKqOelyYlO5RxGunYRq2WttEIOmqP0cSVXDebwpU8VP5cqS2Urhv05PLxCQTrOgNgpbE05OS7LIqKw69KF9sLwqIzOBvAC1jtpdSq@g/@uZewEhaMuysE6z5LYV@x5p9iLTi5U8Z0V12rEXp4MVaWQdXYoHbubYGU@CTQspbCeZ9OGetrhuFg@r3cyZCvm2Up8svZGm/74GqN59S35c3lfExcj5R5B5QKXWK1NI1Z0M01v2Eff/VLhxd513PnqjNdiFRSskbCydo92VDlODFqifIPuOjx6RDyGZ/zBb/i4aJlPe3tdmBMPOWRJRAvC0RdFy@9HBtidRJpJ@efoR@JvumdKI5DDWaYizdUjEdA4BY6MXwtZkYlHJXa4z8)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->n->{         // Method with String and Integer parameters and String return-type
  String r="",  //  Result-String, starting empty
         t;     //  Temp-String
  for(int m=0,  //  Largest count, starting at 0
          c,    //  Temp count integer
          j,    //  Temp index integer
          i     //  Index-integer `i`
      =s.length();i-->n;)
                //  Loop `i` in the range (input-length, n]:
    for(c=0,    //   Reset the temp-count to 0
        j=-1;   //   And the temp-index integer to -1
        (j=s.indexOf(t=s.substring(i-n,i)
                //   Set String `t` to a substring of the input-String in the range [i-n,i)
           j+1))//   Set the temp-index `j` to the index of String `t` in the input-String,
                //   only looking at the trailing portion after index `j+1`
        >=0;)   //   And continue looping as long as long as that substring is found
      if(++c>m){//    If the temp-count + 1 is larger than the current largest count:
        m=c;    //     Set this current largest count to this temp-count + 1
        r=t;}   //     And the result-String to this temp-String
  return r;}    //  After the nested loops, return the result-String
```

Comment: 146 bytes: `S->n->{String R="",x;for(int M=0,I=0,m,i;I<S.length()-n;I++)for(m=0,i=-1;(i=S.indexOf(x=S.substring(I,I+n),i+1))>=0;)if(++m>M){M=m;R=x;}return R;}` (no imports, and Java 8, not 10)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Thanks! That's a much better approach. I had the feeling it was possible without the Map and/or stream, but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: I also tried with `.split("\\Q"+substring+"\\E")`, without success because of the overlapping test case in `Mississippi`

Comment: 143 bytes: `s->n->{String r="",t;for(int m=0,c,j,i=s.length();i-->n;)for(c=0,j=-1;(j=s.indexOf(t=s.substring(i-n,i),j+1))>=0;)if(++c>m){m=c;r=t;}return r;}` (just changing the iteration manner)

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>133</del> 126 bytes

```php
for(;$k<=strlen($i=$argv[1])-$j=$argv[2];)$s[]=substr($i,$k++,$j);$c=array_count_values($s);asort($c);echo array_key_last($c);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYrBCsMgEAV/xcMelKSH5GqkHxKCbMXWRhuDq4F8vbWkh/dghtndXqf73v4ZE5fgJ0U5BbtxeCvA9DrmYRE3WP8wLlIAzYui8mhhq3rwXdfDKiQYhSnhqU0sW9YHhmKJAwmJFFPmYIS0xkV2Vd6eOiBdvtaanWUGM6O2uLEffjDX8Qs)

Annoyingly `asort()` <del>and `end()`</del> can't be chained into one expression.

-7 bytes thanks to @manatwork

Comment: PHP 7.3 has [`array_key_last()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-last.php) to reduce it to [126 characters](https://tio.run/##LYrBCsMgEAV/xcMelKSH5GqkHxKCbMXWRhuDq4F8vbWkh/dghtndXqf73v4ZE5fgJ0U5BbtxeCvA9DrmYRE3WP8wLlIAzYui8mhhq3rwXdfDKiQYhSnhqU0sW9YHhmKJAwmJFFPmYIS0xkV2Vd6eOiBdvtaanWUGM6O2uLEffjDX8Qs "PHP – Try It Online").

Comment: I really should learn all my `array` functions.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 92 bytes

```javascript
s=>n=>s.map(F=t=>([F[w=(w+t).slice(-n)]=-~F[w],w]),w="").sort(([a],[b])=>a-b)[s.length-1][1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVFNa@MwEL37V0x7KBKRHfJRQgPyoYHsXva2sAfXbGRnEqsokpGUuHvZv54d293uUmjBlpg3b9488Z7VRYXa6zam1u3xepDXIHMr85CdVMu2MsqcFduik6ybRJ4Fo2tkqeWlTH8TXIqu5KKTt7fUcz4yVqhSFFXJZa7SihchM2iPsUlnZTErr7WzwRnMjDuy3Vc0xgn44bzZ3wiYQQ4GmGpbVD7AAqI@YeDJQLuBTYPotSPinIgEvDFjR6Z48r1B2KgIgX5nIVJ5UnGkE/SP3njEv@IfDS3GIeeBEFa52ECn6YheaaPtEUKragwZPPatUXo0AilYFxFqFTANaIOO@qLjLwgO@m3K7oc1yiPs9eGAHi3tP1chehImT990CP3XtlrAkoz0xbvninFJbMhkrxY7B66uz57UyBe4C3qjWkBVN0AW0fMdRRrrhk1ZNuEC2NN@wkm8r@CJTY98iDz02XtsDT3vI6pgP4USlagpZS8PrMiyTJWcTSrO7@4858n/ORczMRcLsRT3YrYshyUvMh@ndo/V@qSep/NkO9z3yRvwZf0wXbyWq9f2gtCTtqtksw7nsGTVSjzwT4phajx35O@Fc379Aw)

Takes `s` as a list of characters in `(s)(n)` syntax.

Comment: `=>a-b)[s.length-1]` to `=>b-a)[0]` to sort in reverse order and save some bytes.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen That could fail if there are no repeating substrings. Try `f([..."123456"])(2)`.

Comment: Ah, you're indeed right. My bad.

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>97</s>, <s>96</s>, 92 bytes

```cs
s=>n=>s.Skip(n-1).Select((_,i)=>s.Substring(i,n)).GroupBy(x=>x).OrderBy(g=>g.Count()).Last()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY3BbsIwDIbve4rAyZFCJNhuW3JYJQYa0w5M4jh1xRSLzqniVIKn70LZbr1MsvXb/j/blcwqoX7ZcfUkKRLXZqiJk1m/xNC1efTnqJt679VBuV6cZ@fFbk/UAs/m2m6xwSoBfBrSg9N93VaADGtth4PPFzg7f9b2Pe4x5q52vrZF6DhBZjalZO0f73aREm6IEQ4wXWHTBKN2ITb7yVRDfvaKFz1GTVRxRIwUrtxilPs4oirKpCRnYJVy@12m/@P3o/gbiVyjbSkzD79M/wM)

Explanation:

```cs
s.Skip(n-1).Select((_,i)=>s.Substring(i,n)) //select every substring of size n
    .GroupBy(x=>x)                          //group by value
        .OrderBy(g=>g.Count())              //order by increasing recurrence
            .Last()                         //return the last one
```

Comment: -1 byte by using a currying lambda `(s,n)=>` to `s=>n=>`: [Try it online](https://tio.run/##lYvBagIxEIbvfYroaQLZgG1vNjm4YAu19GDBo6zruA6ukyWTBX36bdSjXoQZ5v/4v6mlqIWGec/1h6RI3JhrJk7mxt6rnXKDOM/Oi10eqAMuJtouscU6AawN6WvTb24fQIa1tp8x9N3sDCfnT9r@xi3GTI3zjS1Dzwmys6gkX/uN52H6soqUcEGMsIPxF7ZtMGoVYrsdjTVMtH5kjFS5R4wULs7rnfO3R1VWSUnewCplPFbpOfXtTv0hkct0HeX@PffDPw).

Comment: I'm pretty sure returning a Grouping is not acceptable.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate check the comments section

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 28 bytes

```
ＮθＦ⊕⁻Ｌηθ⊞υ✂ηι⁺θιＵＭυ⟦№υιι⟧⊟⌈υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYy7CgMhFET7/QrLK5gu3ZZbLcQgpAwpjDHxgq9Vb8jfG4UpDsOZMU4Xk7TvfY@Z2pXC0xY4@Lq8U2GwR1NssLHZF0iMVOFi46c5cFywg3POFFUHJNjNo7HgBEPBlB/iMXAI6yJ13lIIOr6md98SxTYJxwU@hqAKjkalDFL/MFAAmsPez4vEWmdyxn76@j8) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs the lexicographically largest substring with the highest count. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input the desired substring length.

```
Ｆ⊕⁻Ｌηθ⊞υ✂ηι⁺θι
```

Extract all substrings of that length and push them to a list.

```
ＵＭυ⟦№υιι⟧
```

Replace each substring with a tuple of its count and the substring..

```
⊟⌈υ
```

Print the substring with the highest count.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-g`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ãV ü ñÊÌ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWc&code=41Yg/CDxysw&input=IlRoZSBDYXQgc2F0IG9uIHRoZSBtYXQiCjM)

Comment: Is there any specific reason you use your own interpreter instead of the ethproductions one or the TIO one?

Comment: @S.S.Anne I don't know about Shaggy, but I use it because it has a lot of features that make golfing in Japt a lot easier, like the autogolf button

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 30 bytes

```
#&@@Commonest[##~Partition~1]&
```

Takes an array of characters, returns an array of characters.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2ar8V9ZzcHBOT83Nz8vtbgkWlm5LiCxqCSzJDM/r84wVu2/pjVXQFFmXomCg0JatHNGYlFicklqUXE0F5eSU5JVbmKWvhGXG5g25YILuFtZ6htDueZQaWOgaG5mnjmXs1VxabGJRpK5jqUmHg5YF4RU4uKK1eHiMgVS/wE)

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 36 bytes

```
#&@@Commonest[##~StringPartition~1]&
```

Takes a string, returns a string.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2ar8V9ZzcHBOT83Nz8vtbgkWlm5LrikKDMvPSCxqCSzJDM/r84wVu2/pjVXAFC0RMFBIS2ai0vJKckqNzFL34jLDUybcsEF3K0s9Y2hXHOotDFQNDczz5zL2aq4tNhEI8lcx1ITDwesC0Iq6XBxmXJxxf4HAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 89 bytes

```sh
local -A m
repeat $#1 ((++m[${1:$[i++]:$2}]))
for k v (${(kv)m})((v>M))&&r=$k&&M=$v
<<<$r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVFdT8IwFH2/v@KCdW0zDWFACAszURL1hfjCG/IwoHOTdZ1tmYlkv30WnPBGc9t77zn9ODn9MWmTMM6aXG3iHO8fUYIWpYgtkps@Mub7ckkO/ZAsM99fhSSoV5xDojTusEJGDmxXcVlzxqqHOeeepyOy87x5RCqYTqdENxxgkyq9NRF9Wocy/uwF8HzKIzgDL@GkN2jbcUsPHCqzYgyz0OzNkK3HdxN@pTmdalcKJ40GC2RAjZLCplnxgVlhhRbGupriAOiryHOF30rn2w7Ffgt0cJYKrTPlsADoIhW4cY4YN1WB1rUytlcpd/U8M@YYZZlRHAL5M8G98V8F5@rCji77hsDxAACldqIT7C6cbMQQb42L9@Jtb8u9DbGL7g@@fG5qJAUkSMwxH71HGrnhnKih@QU)

```sh
local -A m                    # associative array, "local" is shorter than "typeset"
repeat $#1 {                  # looping for the length of the string will cause the
                              # program to use shorter, invalid strings as
                              # the bash-style slice gets cut short
    ((++m[${1:$[i++]:$2}]))   # increment the map at the key with substring
}                             # starting at $[i++] with length $2
for k v (${(kv)m}) {          # loop over the associative array's keys/values
    ((v>M)) && r=$k && M=$v   # find the max value M, save the key as r.
}                             # looping forward ensures we avoid our invalid subtrings
<<<$r                         # print $r
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C++ (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <sup><s>201</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>151</s></sup> 150 bytes

```cpp
#import<map>
using S=std::string;S f(S s,int n){std::map<S,int>m;S t,r;for(int i=0,x=0;i<=s.size()-n;r=x<++m[t=s.substr(i++,n)]?x=m[t],t:r);return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVBNT8MwDL33V5hyadV0Gh@nJS2HXbhwKhIHtkNo0y1Sm1SJiyam/vaRZIMxEFYi2@89O3bqYcjrjqvN4XAt@0EbZD0fymi0Um2gKiw2i4VF4zJaQZtUYIlUCCrdB8qJWeWRsnc8EkNbbRKvkMWc7Io5laywMys/RJLmippix7Ksf0UPjm@ucyKzjKh0/bArHLwmuDApNQJHo8DQyY2l6m5sBDCpnVzwvozO2LuoUZsy8i/2XKokjfYROAvTHVkW4oHLU3RcJwxdAgqLFgo4Vnnbx4@i6zSBF2265iomcDOR3@wVLLdCGKk9f3vBP0lr/RkG6bj7C@55K2DJEay7WgG6tOf4p8W/srspqCYanPtqSPiIOmyxCKuk323CrrUeERiDeBXH3nvNrJXGfqEEzrgVtVaNxyHPSziVtMm5iPzQpacOKxXTaDp8Ag)

## Ungolfed

```cpp
#include<map>
#include<string>
std::string f(const std::string& s,int n) {
    std::map<std::string,int> m;
    for(int i=0;i<=s.size()-n;++i) {
        m[s.substr(i,n)]++;
    }
    int x=0;
    std::string r;
    for(auto a:m) {
         if(x<a.second) {
             x=a.second;
             r=a.first;
         }
    }
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Excel (Ver. 1911), 60 Bytes

```
B2 'Input: String
B3 'Input: Sub-string Length
C2 =-COUNTIF(D2#,D2#)
D2 =MID(B2,SEQUENCE(LEN(B2)),B3)
E2 =SORT(C2#:D2)
F2 'Output
```

#### Test Sample

Note: Newlines do exist in cells, but default formatting doesn't show them. Also only 10 of the 105 rows are shown to keep the image a decent size.

[image: Test sample]

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

I have a feeling there may be an elusive 5-byter out there.

```
ṡċ@Þ`Ṫ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzoVHuh0Oz0t4uHPV////1X0zi4tBqKAgU/2/CQA)**

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 72 bytes

```powershell
param($s,$n)(0..($s.Length-$n)|%{$s|% s*g $_ $n}|group|sort C*|% N*)[-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVLfT8IwEH7vX3EuxW6kgDAIssSESII@qC@a@GAMDqkws19pSzRh/O147QZiMnXZ2rvvvvt2d22efQipViKOd/QNLmCzy0MZJi5VnKaee9Zuo9m@EelSr1qIFI0NVUUDVHMJdAY03RZLma3zQmVSw6SJobum99TqPu@2hFAtlL7XMkqXqD12yOU8SML3To9M7T74Bq6CUcev3GEV9hFNonRIJoFaq747H/KR94djs6rVGRMydgngw112Gyll3jyPGIc@B2Y8NHteRTkqlUOXw9hlAePOS@p46NfTeqgTJKhyXhv2S5UkZJxhSQyFhrXEvtVBxm@EgVWalhxL7djaDGLq69d3gbpIOh6RaWc/k2s89IzDYybjxQmzTbMYd/8n4wQmKyFklBmO6bg0DqSHlYBJqEHhl6Wg0U1CXXGt4f/PLUeFKLaHqBkV/sGDAhqwsdlUacnxvq0TXMVnLl61WKCpo0QovFx0VtKkUOtYI3CK99kk2Rwbc6hbhVtRetDwgn2SQ8h29wU)

Unrolled:

```powershell
param($s,$n)
(
    0..($s.Length-$n)|%{
        $s|% substring $_ $n
    }|group|sort Count|% Name
)[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 58 bytes

```ruby
->s,n{a=(0..s.size).map{|i|s[i,n]};a.max_by{|e|a.count e}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYvdCoJAEIXv9ymG6CJhWvMPybKLgrrqCUxirZU2cJMmIXN9drOQLoPDnHO@4dyrrO7y@NBNV4S6EfFkxjlxUi9p8UKUjVGGEoU6bReiB89jVjdGGsFPt0o/QLZtRxDDeMnvUpxZ4iC4CB6CjxAgOH7KpThdGjDaQAl5Qgg6hZZ98miviD4q1ahfpN06iwpxtV22/XrAfmAXzW1vqOHw9npaKB2yTUQV@ZMsxLn1p3xXw30D)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-lp`, 47 bytes

```perl
++$k{$_}>$k{$\}&&($\=$_)for<>=~/(?=(.{$_}))/g}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19bWyW7WiW@1g5ExdSqqWmoxNiqxGum5RfZ2NnW6WvY22rogRRoauqn11b//2/C5ZtZXAxCBQWZ//ILSjLz84r/6/qa6hkYGvzXzSkAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-h`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ãV
ñ@è¶X
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=41YK8UDotlg&input=IlRoZSBDYXQgc2F0IG9uIHRoZSBtYXQiCjM)

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://golang.org/), 131 bytes

```go
func f(s string,l int)(p string){x,i:=0,0
m:=map[string]int{}
for;i<=len(s)-l;i++{t:=s[i:i+l]
m[t]++
if m[t]>x{x=m[t]
p=t}}
return}
```

Takes as input a `string` and an `int` representing the string and the length of the substring respectively.

Some newlines can be replaced by semicolons if people prefer one-liners.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVFNa8QgEL37K6Y5JcQu249Ttvayl14KPRR6CKGINVmpUdFZSAn@9lQ33bK9VXQYfW/GeTODXRwXn3yQMHJlCFGjsx6h6Ecslv5oBPRlgIBemYFqUAar0v3cq3miqmFbuiVjw0bu2vW9S6w5kt76nXpgWpoyVNd6p@p6xoaFVjWq1h0ZW@zqmqgesvc4zRPLDnEMYyRe4tGbuOCXk4AyoOBB5o@PAmEmAHAuK/tTroxEQk4lZylltbLOoQEaBm33m@kEpjUXT1JrS@HNev1xVVC4ifQvdgX7g5Re2YzeXqCvBwl7jhDSsQbwkLuI/yXdXZCeVQh5O6cScr8iSU6yqY3wTgFFFuC5GeSFprOKNK7NS2oGalOioGloKDYhR22mqtqt2eLyDQ)