# Scroll Word's font size selector

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, subsequence

Word's <kbd>**A**<sup>▲</sup></kbd> and <kbd>**ᴀ**<sup>▼</sup></kbd> buttons change the font size according to these rules:

1. The starting font size is 11.
2. If <kbd>**ᴀ**<sup>▼</sup></kbd> is pressed when the font size is 1, the size stays 1.
3. The font size changes with 1 point in the range 1 – 12.
4. The font size changes with 2 points in the range 12 – 28.
5. The choices are 28, 36, 48, 72, and 80 in the range 28 – 80.
6. The font size changes with 10 points in the range 80 – 1630.
7. The font size changes with 8 points in the range 1630 – 1638.
8. If <kbd>**A**<sup>▲</sup></kbd> is pressed when the font size is 1638, the size stays 1638.

#### Task

In as few bytes as possible, determine the resulting font size when given a set of button presses in any reasonable format.

#### Examples

`[3,-1,2]`, meaning <kbd>**A**<sup>▲</sup></kbd><kbd>**A**<sup>▲</sup></kbd><kbd>**A**<sup>▲</sup></kbd><kbd>**ᴀ**<sup>▼</sup></kbd><kbd>**A**<sup>▲</sup></kbd><kbd>**A**<sup>▲</sup></kbd>: The result is 18.

Some possible formats are `'^^^v^^'`, `[1 1 1 -1 1 1]`, `[True,True,True,False,True,True]`, `["+","+","+","-","+","+"]`, `"‘‘‘’‘‘"`, `"⛄️⛄️⛄️⛄️⛄️"`, `111011`, `"CaB"`, etc...

`[2]`: 14

`[-1]`:10

`[13]`:80

`[-11,1]`: 2

`[11,-1]`: 36

`[170,-1]`: 1630

`[2000,-2,100]`: 1638

Comment: Do we have to take the set of button presses in that exact format? For example, would some or all of these be fine as well: `"^vvv^v^^^v"`, `[-1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1]`, `[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]`?

Comment: @orlp Yes. Originally I wrote them in, but I found the formats silly. I'll put them in right now.

Comment: How about "" or "⛄️⛄️⛄️⛄️⛄️"

Comment: @NickT That's fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>49</s> <s>47</s> 45 bytes

```
11: 9:E10+'$*H'o8:163 10*1638v11ihl180h&Ys0))
```

Input format is `[1 1 -1 1 1 -1 -1 -1]` or `[2 -1 2 -3]`, with optional commas.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@29oaKVgaeVqaKCtrqLloZ5vYWVoZqxgaKAFpCzKDA0zM3IMLQwy1CKLDTQ1//@PNjSOBQA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#S/hvaGilYGnlamigra6i5aGeb2FlaGasYGigBaQsygwNMzNyDC0MMtQiiw00Nf@7hPyPNorlitY1BBKGxmCWoQKYY6gAETQ3gDCMDAyALCOgUQaxAA).

#### Explanation

```
11:         % Push [1 2 ... 11]
9:          % Push [1 2 ... 9]
E10+        % Times 2, plus 10: gives [12 14 ... 28]
'$*H'       % Push this string
o           % Convert to double: gives ASCII codes, that is, [36 48 72]
8:163       % Push [8 9 ... 163]
10*         % Times 10: gives [80 90 ... 1630]
1638        % Push 1638
v           % Concatenate everything into a column vector
11          % Push 11
ih          % Input array and concatenate with 11
l180h       % Push [1 180]
&Ys         % Cumulative sum with limits 1 and 180
0)          % Get last value
)           % Index into column vector of font sizes. Implicitly display
```

Comment: Finally a golfing language. I was beginning to wonder...

Comment: @Adám We need an answer in APL :)

Comment: @APL is not a golfing language. 8×6=48, not 68

Comment: @APL is not a mentionable user, neither a user at all.

Answer (score 46):

## Word VBA, <sub><s>199</s> <s>147</s> <s>126</s> <s>116</s> <s>102</s> <s>100</s> <s>87</s></sub> 85  Bytes

*Why emulate when you can do?!*

Declared function in the `ThisDocument` module that takes input `n` in the form of `Array(true,true,false,true)` and **outputs to the Word font size selector** **<kbd>:P</kbd>**

**Golfed:**

```vb
Sub a(n):Set f=Content.Font:For Each i In n
If i Then f.Grow Else f.Shrink
Next:End Sub
```

**Ungolfed:**

```vb
Sub a(n)
    Set f=ThisDocument.Content.Font
    For Each i In n
        If i Then 
            f.Grow 
        Else 
            f.Shrink
        End if 
    Next
    ''  Implicitly output font size to MS Word Font Size Selector 
End Sub
```

### .GIF of usage

[image: I'm a .GIF!]

### Thanks

-21 thanks to @Adám (removed `Selection.WholeStory:` call)

-10 thanks to @Adám (assume clean environment; remove `f.size=11:` call)

-14 thanks to @Adám (cheeky output word font size selector)

-2 thanks to @Adám (bool ParamArray)

-13 for changing `ParamArray n()` to `n` and expecting input as Boolean Array

-2 for moving from a code module to the `ThisDocument` module

### Old Version 114 Bytes

Takes input `n` as a ParamArray, in the form of `true,true,false,true` and outputs word vbe immediates window

```vb
Sub a(ParamArray n()):Set f=Selection.Font:For Each i In n
If i Then f.Grow Else f.Shrink
Next:Debug.?f.Size:End Sub
```

### Older version, 199 Bytes

Takes input in the form of `170,-4,6,-1` (accepts numbers larger than 1 in magnitude)

```vb
Sub a(ParamArray n()):Selection.WholeStory:Set f=Selection.Font:f.Size=12:For Each i In n
If i>1 Then
For j=i To 0 Step -1:f.Grow:Next
Else
For j=i To 0:f.Shrink:Next:End If:Next:Debug.?f.Size:End Sub
```

Comment: +1 (I'd give more if I could). Why do you `Set f=.Size = 12`?

Comment: Also, do you need to select the whole story? isn't the current selection enough?

Comment: @Adám Thanks :) the `f.size=12` should, now that I look at it actually be `f.size = 11` and is there so that the sub may be run more than once, as this actually changes the size of the font every time that is is run. Also, you are completely correct in not needing the `wholestory` call

Comment: No need to allow multiple runs. You may assume a clean environment.

Comment: Btw, I change the OP title so that there is no implication that actual emulation must be done. Real use is fine too!

Comment: A function (not complete program) is allowed per PPCG default rules. Couldn't you `Return f.Size` instead of printing it?

Comment: @Adám in VBA because a function requires `Function a`...`a=n:End Function` (26 bytes) calls, it is actually more byte efficient (in most cases) to use a subroutine and print the output `Sub a`...`Debug.?n:End Sub` (21 Bytes)

Comment: Actually, just [use Word's font size selector as output method!](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7139/43319)

Comment: Couldn't n be an array of Booleans, so you can write `If i Then`?

Comment: Does Word VBA support `With`? That'd probably be slightly shorter than `Set` for avoiding the need to repeat `Selection.Font`, if it works.

Comment: @ais523 word vba does support `with` however it requires a `end with` call that means for code golf it is often, as in this case, more byte-efficient to use a `set` call

Answer (score 12):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>103</s> 101 bytes

Takes input as an array of `-1` / `1`.

```js
a=>a.map(k=>[1,12,28,36,48,72,80,1630,1638].map((v,i)=>n+=n>v&&k*[1,1,6,4,12,-16,2,-2,-8][i]),n=11)|n
```

#### Test

```js
let f =

a=>a.map(k=>[1,12,28,36,48,72,80,1630,1638].map((v,i)=>n+=n>v&&k*[1,1,6,4,12,-16,2,-2,-8][i]),n=11)|n

console.log(f([]));
console.log(f([1]));
console.log(f([-1]));
console.log(f([1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]));
console.log(f(Array(2000).fill(1)));
```

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to ETHproductions*

Comment: A tip: whenever you have `a&&(b=c)`, you can save a byte with `a?b=c:0`. Here though, I think you can even save two with `n+=n>v&&k*[...][i]`

Answer (score 9):

## Python 2, <strike>111</strike> 107 bytes

```
i=10;r=range
for d in input():i+=d*(0<i+d<179)
print(r(1,12)+r(12,29,2)+[36,48,72]+r(80,1631,10)+[1638])[i]
```

Requires input to be in the `[-1, 1, 1, -1, ...]` format. It works with the examples for some bytes extra:

```
for d in input():i=min(max(0,i+d),179)
```

Comment: You can save 3 bytes by using ` if 0<i<179:i+=d` inside the for loop. Costs you a linefeed and a space indent otherwise would be 5.

Comment: Or `i+=[0,d][0<i<179]` might work

Comment: @NonlinearFruit Works but comes in at the same byte count for me (108). Looks much cooler and golfier than an `if` statement tho.

Comment: Both suggestions are incorrect. It would mean that if we hit `0` or `179` we're stuck there forever.

Comment: @orlp Good point. Missed that one.

Answer (score 6):

## Octave, <del>93</del> <del>89</del> 87 bytes

The input array can have integers larger than 1 or smaller than -1 to represent multiplicity of action

```
L=11;for k=input(''),L=min(max(L+k,1),180);end;[1:11 [6:14 18 24 36 40:5:815 819]*2](L)
```

Thanks to Adám, Changed language to Octave only to be able to use direct indexing into an array.

Saved 2 bytes thanks to rahnema1.

### Test

On [Ideone](http://ideone.com/tYVO9O)

Comment: Save 3 bytes by removing the first statement, and changing the last to `[1:12,14:2:28,36,48,72,80:10:1630,1638](L)`.

Comment: @Adám Good idea, but then it only works in Octave

Comment: @LuisMendo, thanks, fixed it.

Comment: @LuisMendo So? Change the language to Octave only.

Comment: @Adám Yes, that was my point. I wasn't pointing it out as a drawback

Comment: `[1:11 [6:14 18 24 36 40:5:815 819]*2]` some bytes can be saved!

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 106 bytes

I managed to shave a couple of bytes off the python solution (and it took a while of shaving).

```
->n{[*1..12,*(14..28).step(2),36,48,72,*(80..1630).step(10),1638][n.inject(11){|a,b|[0,179,a+b].sort[1]}]}
```

It's an anonymous function that takes the input in the form of `[1, -1, 1, 1, ...]`. It seems to deal quite well with input in the form `[170,-12]` as well, but I can't guarantee it will work 100% of the time, so I'll play it safe and say it works with `[1, -1, 1, 1, ...]`.

### Tricks I used:

- `[0,179,a+b].sort[1]`: This clamps `a+b` to be between 0 and 179, which are the valid indexes of the font-size array.
- Using the splat operator on ranges converts them into arrays, so the available font sizes is generated from `[*1..12,*(14..28).step(2),36,48,72,*(80..1630).step(10),1638]`. Which is a flat array containing the values from each of the flattened elements:

  - `1..12` is a range from 1 to 12 (inclusive). The splat operator turns it into the values `1, 2, 3, ..., 11, 12`.
  - `(14..28).step(2)` is an enumerator for the given range, where each step goes up by 2. The splat operator turns it into the values `14, 16, 18, ..., 26, 28`.
  - The individual values (`36, 48, 72, 1638`) are all concatenated in their position into the great font-size array.
- I used the `inject`(/`reduce`) method, which uses each element of the input array, while reducing them down into a 'memo' variable (as ruby puts it). I initialise this to 11, and the body of each inject iteration is to set this memo variable to the result of adding the current element of the input to the current memo value, and then clamping it between 0 and 180.

All hail the splat operator!

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 116 bytes

first generates the size index (from 1 to 180 inclusive),
then maps that to the point size and prints the result.

```
for($s=11;$d=$argv[++$i];$s=min($s+$d,180)?:1);echo$s>12?$s>20?$s>23?$s*10-160-2*($s>179):24+(12<<$s-21):$s*2-12:$s;
```

takes `+N` and `-1` from command line arguments.
(`-N` is also accepted; just take care that the size does not hop below zero!)

Run with `-nr`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>123</s> 106 bytes

```perl
@a=(1..12,map$_*2,7..14,18,24,36,map$_*5,8..163,163.8);$i=10;$\=$a[$i=($"=$i+$_)<0?0:$">179?179:$"]for@F}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYhBCsIwEAC/ImUPrW5CNm3aaI3tyZsvUCk5KATUhOpN/LprDh4GZiZd5pthHr0rSUrSePcJpqXGLleDZFE3WLf/bdDm3daYkbbqIThSPZwc@GP2EgoHYQVTtVWD2kCxo249ZLKer3Ee9583syBa0DemV4iPJ4uDkYoUC59@)

Input format:

```perl
32 -32 12 4 -2
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>157</s> 154 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to ceilingcat.

Takes a string of `+` (step up) and non-`+` (step down). Returns the final font size.

```c
n,d;f(char*s){for(n=11;*s;n=n>28&n<81?index("\34$0HP",n-d)[2*d-1]:n-d+((n>1&n<29)+(n>12&n<29)+(n>80&n<1639)*8+(n>80&n<1631)*2)*(2*d-1))n+=d=*s++==43;s=n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVFNb@IwED2TXzG1Nht/BdkhoqFZ02uPewe0Qo6hqDCgOF1VqvjtrB0@itT1IZp5z@/5zcTma2tPJ5RNvaL2ddlyzz5X@5ai0brmvkaD06L6ib8q/bzBxn1QMh@VP9TLbyIxb9is4E2uF0@hFpTiVIerxYSJWBZfdaVCrcejCePVfa8ZLxinvQljKExjuBfCmHJUe4P18fR3v2lg3WcD7iVssAP3cXC2cw1LPpNBBFrn37cdGFhRz@pkkAwObcBXlKQW0rKBWfgsYE7SIfepn5M5EnlVPZibITxD9pDBE2SQXXl5YyWMlQwRfNduHYaXYBqQoCHD4ZAEFSHh8WOSnMPu3v607uBpDIgSetC@9plb1723CDu3866jdrnd7i1FEKAlaBbvSsCzV1TvlhukvbA38bNSTcaLfs41JUKIXIgwj67i7D0Su/LS5bFRN@ruBKK6EvnXiXjx/X70GY3P6/WX/YZtkNRH5jqtflQSMpExdsnnZfjP6r@yPPV3ykKpi/TOTX1zg2AXBz2e/gE)

Comment: @ceilingcat Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 98 bytes

```sh
a=({1..12} {14..28..2} 36 48 72 {8..163}0 1638)
r=11
for i;((r+=i,r=(r>$#a)?$#a:(r?r:1)))
<<<$a[r]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7dCsIwDIXv@xQBe9Go@8k2ZpmrexBRmOB0Fyp0uxDLnr2GOdEl5JDk45C8uqtvFCpfG@UoDCkZwFEWhonmGiDNIdOwScDxTHk6xMCqUVhDJJqHhXarlF2Zdm2Nsju5qLFiKZStbEGIKMqylPXeHjwKcWov/bnrp1s6HvC3km5qo2gZERPRAEFAMCYPcuLwjQXc6ieoz0N/fHSNnFHMJJDHuZed7Z2dOIfjMYaJfwM)

Iterate through the arguments, clamping our index between `1` and `$#a` (length of `$a`).