# Draw a graph of \$y=(-n)^x\$

Tags: code-golf, math, graphical-output, complex-numbers, trigonometry

### Challenge

Given an input of an integer, \$n\$ (where \$0<n<50\$), output the graph of \$y=\mathrm{Re}((-n)^x)\$ from \$x = -3\$ to \$x = 3\$ inclusive.

Where \$\mathrm{Re}(p)\$ is the real part of the complex number \$p\$.

Note that \$\mathrm{Re}((-n)^x) = n^x \cos{(\pi x)}\$

### Output

The output may be in any form you wish (e.g. an image or a window etc.). ASCII art is disallowed.

The graph does not need to have axes (to allow languages without built-in graphing functions to compete).

If an image is output, it each side must be longer than 500 pixels. Similarly, the plot must fill the image as best it can.

The minimum interval between plots is 0.05.

Vector graphics are allowed.

### Examples

For an input of `2`:

[image]

For an input of `1`:

[image]

---

***You must put your corresponding outputs in your answer (n = 1 and n = 2).***

### Winning

The shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: *`ASCII art is disallowed.`* (ಥ﹏ಥ)

Comment: Can the axes be on the left and bottom edges of the graph? instead of at the centre?

Comment: "The axes do not have numbers" but the examples have numbers on the axes

Comment: @Kritixi As long as the domain of the graph is from -3 to 3, yes

Comment: @Kritixi You'll just have to ignore those since I couldn't find a graphing service without numbers

Comment: "If an image is output, it each side must be longer than 500 pixels." Are vector graphics allowed?

Comment: @MartinEnder Yes, I suppose so

Comment: Should "The axes do not have numbers" read "The axes do not *have to* have numbers"?

Comment: @JonathanAllen Yes, sorry, it was a typo

Comment: @BetaDecay Can I suggest making the axes optional to give languages that do not have builtin plot functions a chance?

Comment: @Kritixi Axes are now optional

Comment: Why am I not surprised to see MATLAB, MATL and Mathematica as some of the first answers. :)

Comment: Where is C++? :'(

Comment: Your examples are smaller than 500 pixels in both directions.

Comment: "The output may be in any format you wish" and "ASCII art is disallowed" contradict each other.

Comment: @immibis Not really, when the question tag is [tag:graphical-output]

Comment: +1 for banning ascii art >:]

Comment: -1 for banning ascii art

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## MATL, <s>22 18</s> 16 bytes

Thanks @LuisMendo for additional -2 bytes!

```
I_.01I3$:i_y^&XG


I_                       push 3 and negate         
  .01                    push 0.01
     I                   push 3  
      3$:                generate the list [-3,-2.99,-2.98,...,3]                        
         i_y^            calculate (-input)^(list)                 
             $XG         plot the first list against the real part of the second list
```

[Try it on matl.io](https://matl.io/?code=I_.01I3%24%3Ai_y%5E%26XG&inputs=2&version=19.9.0)

Answer (score 24):

## TI-Basic, <s>26</s> 21 bytes

```
~3→Xmin
3→Xmax
Prompt N
DrawF N^Xcos(πX
```

Output for N=2:

[image: TI84SE GRAPH OUTPUT]

Comment: Code screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jct97.png

Comment: I count 47 characters in your code, not 26.

Comment: @KonradRudolph See: [TI-Basic scoring guidelines.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4764/44713)

Comment: "If an image is output, it each side must be longer than 500 pixels."  Doesn't seem like the built in graphing capability will work here.

Comment: @user5090812 "The output may be in any form you wish (e.g. an image or a window etc.)" - I'm outputting by the graph window, not an image, so this restriction doesn't apply.

Comment: Who would've thought that a graphing calculator could graph things!

Comment: You can save 4 bytes with [DrawF](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/drawf), eg. `DrawF N^Xcos(πX`

Comment: @pizzapants184 You're absolutely right, I should have thought of that! Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

## Bash + Gnuplot, <s>56</s> 45 bytes

*(-11 bytes thanks to Noiralef!)*

```
gnuplot -e "se t png;p[-3:3]real((-$1)**x)">A
```

Saves the resulting graph as a `png` image named `A` in the current working directory.

#### Example Outputs

For **n = 1**:

[image]

For **n = 2**:

[image]

Comment: +1 for using a langage I use everyday. (no "garbled binary nonsense" as with golf-langages ^^). This can be re-used in everyday situations.

Comment: You can save 11 bytes by using abbreviations: `gnuplot -e "se t png;p[-3:3]real((-2)**x)">A`

Comment: @Noiralef Thanks! :)

Answer (score 14):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) with [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/), <s>103</s> 72 bytes

-12 bytes thanks to DSM (a module is installed alongside `matplotlib` called `pylab` with the necessary functionality "making Python in a repl more like Matlab" - odd, but true!)
-18 more as a result (pylab has many numpy functions too!)
-1 byte thanks to Ajasja (replacing `arange(-60,61)/20+0j` with `arange(121)/20-3+0j`)

```python
from pylab import*
def f(n):x=arange(121)/20-3+0j;plot(x,(-n)**x);show()
```

**n=2,1**

[image: n=2]
[image: n=1]

Comment: Can you get rid of `from matplotlib.pyplot import*` if you start ipython with the --pylab --matplotlib flag?

Comment: Have you got iPython; does it work? I suspect it would be acceptable if it does, but would need to ask myself. I don't have iPython and have never had the need to use it.

Comment: yup, works with --pylab (tested with python 2)

Comment: There is nothing non-standard in any config file making the display work, right? If not I'd say post it as a separate answer on this occasion since it's a clever use of a change of language IMO. EDIT: I see you have golfed it there too :)

Comment: Yes, I remembered `%pylab` gives you numpy as well and if you're in a notebook you don't need a show at the end:)

Comment: Wouldn't `from pylab import*` also give you `plot` and `show`?

Comment: @DSM, so it would, I had no idea about the existence of that as a separate module - thanks.

Comment: That's probably a good sign, it's too stateful an interface and so it's out of favour these days. :-)

Comment: Oh wow, yes that is flat; `len(dir(pylab))=961` here!

Comment: I'm not completely sure if there is a difference between this and Ajasja's answer anymore...

Comment: @BetaDecay yes they have certainly merged - the presence of the `pylab` module here did most of that really. I don't think there is reason to delete though.

Answer (score 12):

### Mathematica, 41 bytes

```
Plot[Re[(-#)^x],{x,-3,3},PlotRange->All]&
```

Output looks exactly as shown in the challenge except for the font of the numbers (which I suspect was created with Wolfram Alpha).

Answer (score 12):

### R, 29 bytes

```
curve(Re((0i-scan())^x),-3,3)
```

`n` is provided through stdin.
Result for n=1:
[image]

And for n=2:

[image]

Comment: Why not use a variable `n` like the other answers and shave off five characters from your answer? Anyway, crazy answer. I always forget about `curve`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks. Actually most other answers don't predefine `n`. The matlab, matl, TI-Basic and mathematica answers take input as stdin (as far as I understand them), while the python and VBA answers create a function. Even if it's allowed, it's just a matter of personal taste: I just don't like predefining variables as a way of input.

Comment: Sorry correction: the matlab answers define functions as well.

Comment: Well. This *is* a code golf …

Comment: I didn't want to be pedantic or anything but actually as a community we consider that using a predefined variable is [not considered a valid input method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8731/6741) unless stated explicitely otherwise in the question.

Comment: Fair enough but these are merely the *default* rules. This question seems to explicitly permit it. At any rate most of the other answers just use a variable and make the comparison this harder. My point is, this is, hands down, the shortest solution in a non golf language (minus the weird TI Basic counting rules which are essentially cheating).

Comment: Yes you're right and this is why i didn't downvote your answer despite it using that form of input, but allow me to respect the rules i believe in. In addition, as explained in my previous comment, i think your assumption that "most of the other answers just use a variable" is wrong: apart from yours (and maybe the postscript) I don't see any. The others use anonymous functions or, like me, a prompt.

Answer (score 11):

## MATLAB, <s>35</s> 30 bytes

```
x=-3:.01:3;@(n)plot(x,(-n).^x)
```

This defines an anyonmous function. The output is via a new window with a resizable vector graphic output. MATLAB's `plot` automatically ignores the imaginary part of the y-coordinates as long as your provide corresponding x-coordinates.The following output is for `n=3`.

[image]

Comment: Would `@(n)fplot(@(x)(-n).^x,[-3,3])` work for 29 bytes?

Answer (score 10):

## R, 30 bytes

```
plot(Re((0i-n)^seq(-3,3,.05)))
```

#### `n` = 1

[image]

#### `n` = 2

[image]

Comment: Oooh pretty circles

Comment: @BetaDecay R’s default rendering is ugly. The rationale for the default is that unfilled circles don’t hide overplotted points as much as filled circles/dots would.

Comment: I don't think it's ugly. It looks really cool.

Comment: The x axis is labelled incorrectly. I think you need `x=seq(-3,3,.05);plot(x,Re((0i-n)^x))`

Comment: @user2390246 Given that the axes are completely optional, I don’t think it matters. *If* the axis labelling matters, other answers also have issues due to scaling (e.g. the 30-char MATLAB answer).

Comment: OK fair point (though both MATLAB answers look fine to me...)

Answer (score 10):

## Excel VBA, <s>168</s> <s>160</s> <s>147</s> 138 Bytes (cells as pixels at 100x scale)

<sup>Saved 8 bytes thanks to KyleKanos</sup>
<sup>Saved 22 bytes thanks to Taylor Scott</sup>

```
Sub g(n)
For i=0To 1
For x=-3To 3Step.01
y=n^x*Cos([Pi()]*x)
m=IIf(y<m,y,m)
If i Then Cells(500*(1-y/m)+1,(x+3)*100+1)="#
Next x,i
End Sub
```

Formatted, it looks like this:

```
Sub g(n)
    For i = 0 To 1
    For x = -3 To 3 Step 0.01
        y = n ^ x * Cos([Pi()] * x)
        m = IIf(y < m, y, m)
        If i Then Cells(500 * (1 - y / m) + 1, (x + 3) * 100 + 1) = "#"
    Next x, i
End Sub
```

Fun Fact: VBA does not have a built-in `pi` variable so we have to evaluate it as a worksheet function where it *does* exist.

**n=1**                                                                         **n=2**
[image: n=1]     [image: n=2]

---

I started with a chart version at 193 bytes but it *did* get prettier results.

```
Sub c(n)
For x=-3To 3Step 0.05
r=r+1
Cells(r,1)=n^x*Cos(Atn(1)*4*x)
Next
With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlLine).Chart
.SetSourceData Range("A1:A121")
.Axes(xlCategory).Delete
End With
End Sub
```

**n=1**
[image: n=1]
**n=2**
[image: n=2]

Comment: Is it not shorter to use `(-n)^x` instead of hardcoding pi?

Comment: @BetaDecay It would be if Excel could handle negative numbers raised to negative non-integers  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Isn't it shorter to use `atn(1)*4` for pi?

Comment: @KyleKanos Indeed it is, thanks. I didn't find that identity in my constants lookup table and, as an engineer, that's where I'm legally obligated to stop.

Comment: in your chart version, you can drop the `cells(r+1,...)` call below the `r=r+1` call and change it to `cells(r,...)` for -2; also in your current version, do you think that it would be within the scope of the rules to just add an `X` into the relevant cell rather than coloring it black?

Comment: You can get this down to 138 bytes w/ `Sub g(n)
For i=0To 1
For x=-3To 3Step.01
y=n^x*Cos([Pi()]*x)
m=IIf(y<m,y,m)
If i Then Cells(500*(1-y/m)+1,(x+3)*100+1)="#
Next x,i
End Sub`

Comment: @TaylorScott That's three new tricks, thanks. That's more valuable than the 7 bytes they saved me this time.

Comment: @EngineerToast there are always new tricks to learn about in VBA - like the `[{1,2,3}]` array declaration notation for Excel VBA :)

Comment: Also you can leave the string unterminated - it will autofomat to a closed string, and there is no need to check if `i=1`, as `1` is a truthy value and `0` is falsy

Answer (score 6):

## MATLAB, <s>35</s> 33 bytes

*Thanks fo @flawr for removing 2 bytes!*

```
@(n)ezplot(@(x)real((-n)^x),-3:3)
```

This defines an anonymous function. To call it with input `2`, use `ans(2)` (or assign the function to a variable such as `f` and then use `f(2)`).

Output is vector graphics (resizable window). The sampling interval on the *x* axis is determined automatically by the `ezplot` function, but it seems to be more than enough.

A warning is produced in STDERR because the function passed to `ezplot` (`@(x)real((-n)^x)`) is not vectorized, but the graph is generated.

Example for `n = 2`:

[image]

Comment: `ezplot = la-z-plot` :D (I keep forgetting about this one...)

Comment: Huh. Never knew that you could pass the domain to `ezplot` like that. Sadly, the same cannot be said for `fplot`, so no byte can be saved there.

Comment: @sanchises I didn't know either :-) It was flawr's idea

Answer (score 5):

## [Jupyter notebook](https://jupyter.org/) and Python 3; 53 bytes

```
%pylab
def f(n):x=arange(121)/20-3+0j;plot(x,(-n)**x)
```

Three bytes saved thanks to @Jonathan Allan.

[image: n=1]
[image: n=2]

Comment: Two minor bits: if I read the specs right, you need a minimum of 0.05 (not 0.1) between (effective) points, and we're supposed to be inclusive of 3.

Comment: You can use `x=arange(-60,61)/20` to fix the issues highlighted by DSM at a cost of 2 bytes. If you add `0j` to the `arange` it can be used to change over to `plot(x,(-n)**x)` saving 4.

Comment: @DSM Ops, fixed.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks.

Comment: Ah I saved you 2 in total, you just saved me 1 by changing to `arange(121)`!

Comment: I'm not completely sure if there is a difference between this and Jonathan Allen's answer anymore...

Comment: @BetaDecay Well, his was first but this one is still shorter. The only remaining difference left is in the use of magic ipython commands...

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>37</s> 36 bytes

Thanks to my colleague Marshall for guidance. -2 thanks to FrownyFrog.

Anonymous tacit prefix function.

```
-(]plot@;9 o.^)i:@3j120[load@'plot'
```

[image: Plot window]

```
-(]plot@;9 o.^)i:@3j120[load@'plot'
                        load@'plot'       NB. load plotting library
               i:@3j120                   NB. -3...3 in 120 steps
-                                         NB. negate argument
 (           ^)                           NB. raise the negated value to those exponents
 (       9 o. )                           NB. real part
 (]     ;     )                           NB. pair with the exponents
 ( plot@      )                           NB. plot it
```

Comment: I think `20%~i:@60` can be `i:@3j120`.

Comment: @FrownyFrog Correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/) 0.6 with Plots.jl, 46 bytes

```
using Plots
~n=plot(real((0im-n).^(-3:.05:3)))
```

[image: GR plot]

This needed a Julia representation!

Not much to golf here though, except (ab)using operator overloading to save bytes on function defintion, and using `0im-n` to make the input number complex where I might usually have used `Complex(n)`. That's necessary because in Julia, for [type stability](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introducing_Julia/Types#Type_stability) reasons, the `^` operator returns Complex results only when the input is Complex itself. So here we make it a complex number by adding `0im` ie. 0i.

One cool thing about the Plots.jl package is that it automatically chooses the backend to use based on what plotting packages you have installed and where you're running the `plot` command from. The above plot was created with the [GR](https://github.com/jheinen/GR.jl) backend, but if I didn't have that installed (or if I explicitly ran a `plotly()` command like I did for this), it would have used the more interactive Plotly backend and output this (which looks a tiny bit nicer IMO):

[image: Plotly plot]

There's even a [UnicodePlots](https://github.com/Evizero/UnicodePlots.jl) backend, to print a plot in the terminal (or save to a text file) using Unicode characters and color codes. SE keeps messing up the plot alignment if I try to directly paste it though, so here's a terminal screenshot:

[image: UnicodePlots plot]

PS: The alternate formula, \$ Re((−n)^x)=n^xcos(πx) \$, comes out to the same length:

```
using Plots
~n=plot(n.^(x=-3:.05:3).*cospi(x))
```

Comment: Dang, that's some clever (ab)use of the Braille characters.

Comment: [45 bytes](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v7Q4My9dISAnv6SYq8JW19hKz8DUypirLs@2ACim4aCXnF9ckKlRoZkXV6H5/z8A "Julia 1.0 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## Desmos, <s>12</s> <s>10</s> 9 bytes

-2 thanks to @Steffan
-1 thanks to @LeoDog896

```
n^xcosxπ
```

How has nobody used Desmos yet?

Comment: You can do `n^xcosx\pi` for 10 bytes

Comment: Huh, it appears you can. I didn't realize you could say just `cos` rather than `\cos`.

Comment: You can also use the pi symbol itself, which is 2 bytes but replaces the 3 bytes taken up by `\pi`: `n^xcosxπ`

Answer (score 3):

## Encapsulated PostScript; 232 bytes

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 500 500
%%EndComments
/n 1 def .02 setlinewidth /f{dup dup n exch exp exch 180 mul cos mul 3 div}def
250 250 translate 80 80 scale newpath -3 f moveto -3 .05 3{f lineto}for stroke
%%EOF
```

Now since this is a vector image itself...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ooh that is nice

Answer (score 3):

## [TikZ](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=en) + [PGFPlots](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots?lang=en), 175 bytes

```
\documentclass{standalone}\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}\begin{document}\typein[\n]{}\tikz{\begin{axis}\addplot[domain=-3:3,samples=120]{\n^x*cos(180*x)};\end{axis}}\end{document}
```

Compile with, *e.g.*, `latexmk -cd -f -pdf in.tex` for a pdf output. During compilation, the user is prompted for `n`.

Sample outputs (converted to png) for n = 1 and n = 2:

[image: n = 1]
[image: n = 2]

Answer (score 2):

## [Math.JS Grapher](http://a-ta.co/grapher), 20 Bytes

```
r(n)=f(x)=re((-n)^x)
```

By sheer fluke, this graphing utility is TC (For the most part, Infinite loops just crash it.), and by nature, it's primary output is graphs.

### How it works

`r(n)=` assigns a function `r` which takes the argument `n` to the expression `f(x)=re((-n)^x)`. `re((-n)^x)` is pretty much letter for letter the challenge description. But this assigns the function `f(x)` to this, which the grapher implicitly outputs as a line graph.

### How to test it

You can use [this](http://a-ta.co/grapher) site, punch that function in there, then call it with `r(input)`.

### Output

[image: Output]

Answer (score 2):

## Excel VBA, 133 bytes

Immediate window script that takes input from `[A1]` and outputs a `Chart` object to the `Sheet1` object.

```vb
[B:B]="=ROW()/20-3.05":[C:C]="=A$1^B1*Cos(Pi()*B1)":Set c=Sheet1.Shapes.AddChart(4).Chart:c.SetSourceData[C1:C121]:c.Axes(1).Delete
```

### Ungolfed

Full `Sub`routine  version. I/O is unchanged.

```vb
Sub b()
    [B:B] = "=ROW()/20-3.05"                ''  Define `x`-axis
    [C:C] = "=A$1^B1*Cos(Pi()*B1)"          ''  Define `y`-axis in terms of input from A1
    Set c = Sheet1.Shapes.AddChart(4).Chart ''  Add line plot to Sheet1 (xlLine)
    c.SetSourceData [C1:C121]               ''  Set `y` source to match `x` in [-3,3]
    c.Axes(1).Delete                        ''  Remove erroneous axes (xlCategory)
End Sub
```

### Output

Where input, \$n=1\$

[image: Output plot n=1]

Where input, \$n=3\$

[image: Output plot n=3]

Answer (score 2):

## Dyalog APL, 41 bytes

```
⎕SE.UCMD∊'chart x(9○(-'⍞')*x←3-20÷⍨⍳121)'
```

#### How it works:

```
⎕SE.UCMD∊'chart x(9○(-'⍞')*x←3-20÷⍨⍳121)' ⍝ Main function
⎕SE.UCMD∊                                 ⍝ User Command (called from the session object)
         'chart                           ⍝ Plot a chart with arguments:
                 (           3-20÷⍨⍳121)' ⍝ Yields the list [-3, -2.95, -2.9,..., 2.9, 2.95, 3]
                           x←             ⍝ Assign that list to x
                          *               ⍝ and use it as exponent
                    (-'⍞')                ⍝ with (-input) as base
                  9○                      ⍝ discard the complex part; this generates Re((-n)^x)
                x                         ⍝ And x.
```

The user command `]chart`, in this case, takes two vector arguments, `x` and `y` and plots the graphs:

For \$n=1\$:
[image: n=1]

For \$n=2\$:
[image: n=2]

Answer (score 1):

## Google Sheets, 65

- Input N is in A1

Graphing:

- `=SPARKLINE(ArrayFormula(IMREAL(IMPOWER(-A1,.05*SEQUENCE(121,1,-60`
  or
- `=SPARKLINE(ArrayFormula(IMREAL(IMPOWER(-A1,SEQUENCE(121,1,-60)/20`

Resize row and column of graph to 500x500.

I tried to use the COS() formula, but the best I can do is 66 characters with a named range. Problems that I came across:

- X is generated by the SEQUENCE(), which is then used twice. You would naturally think to cache this, but every time you cache into a column, to use it again, you have to either name a range, or use a FILTER. Named Range is obviously better, but it does cost 1 character to make it fair.
- Attempting to scalar multiply a SEQUENCE() forces us into an ArrayFormula (or MMULT() at best), and we cannot use a non-integer step for SEQUENCE(). This means that the most optimal way to use it is to give it to the SPARKLINE formula.
- This also means that our scalar multiply/divide has to occur each time we use the range.

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 82 bytes

```
INPUT N
FOR I=0TO 399X=I/66.5-3GPSET I,120-POW(N,X-3*SGN(N-1))*COS(PI()*X)*120NEXT
```

Graph fills the entire screen, even when N is less than 1.

When N is greater than 1, you can scale Y to be between -1 and 1 by dividing it by `n^3`. I'm already doing `n^x`, and `n^x / n^3` can be simplified to `n^(x-3)`. However, when N is less than 1, I have to divide Y by `n^-3` instead. This is equivalent to `n^(x+3)`.

I can use `n^(x-3*sign(n-1))` to use `-3` if `n>1`, and `+3` if `n<1`

Images coming soon