# Tips for golfing in Visual Basic

Tags: code-golf, tips, basic

### This page is not for [Visual Basic .NET Tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/155840/61846) or [VBA tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5175/61846)

Visual Basic (VB or VB6) is an object-oriented and event-driven dialect of [basic](/questions/tagged/basic) that was developed and released by Microsoft in 1991. The last release of Visual Basic came as Visual Basic 6.0 in 1998, and the language was declared a legacy language in 2008. Visual Basic .NET replaced Visual Basic in 2002.

All answers on this site that are written in Visual Basic are assumed to be written for Visual Basic 6.0 unless otherwise stated.

> Some helpful links
>
> - [MSDN Visual Basic 6.0 Resource Center](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms788229.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
> - [Visual Basic Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic)

You may compile and execute Visual Basic code using Visual Studio Community.

There is no online resource for compiling VB code.

Comment: IDK VB, but isn't this just https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5175/tips-for-golfing-in-vba?rq=1

Comment: @Pavel The short answer is no, there are several differences between VB and VBA, including, but not limited to the availability of the certain packages, data types, non-variant arrays, threading and proper graphics in VB that are not available to VBA and version specific tweaks available to VBA - such as the `Cells` command in Excel VBA. You can find out more about the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/993300/7099906 "Difference between Visual Basic 6.0 and VBA - Stack Overflow")

Comment: consider using the normal [tips] format from other tips questions as the main part of your question (applies also to the other recent tip question)

Comment: @Uriel you mention a [tips] format but as far as I can see there are several that are currently in use on the site, could you please be a bit more specific about exactly what format you are referring to?

Comment: like the one on https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python. I think that is the one I've seen the most. Language info usually goes into the showcase question, not the tips.

Answer (score 1):

## Use `DefXXX` statements when declaring multiple variables

The statement

```vb
DefDbl A-D
```

Defines all variables that start with `A` through `D` as being of the type `Double`, which means this can shorten cases such as

```vb
Dim A As Double
Dim B As Double
Dim C As Double
Dim D As Double
```

Similar commands exist for the following types

```vb
DefBool     ''  Boolean
DefByte     ''  byte
DefCur      ''  Currency
DefDate     ''  Date
DefDbl      ''  Double
DefDec      ''  Decimal
DefInt      ''  Integer
DefLng      ''  Long
DefObj      ''  Object
DefSng      ''  Single
DefStr      ''  String
DefVar      ''  Variant
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use `Console.Write` over `Console.WriteLine`

There is quite a large amount of overhead code necessary to get a snippet of code to execute in VB, and by default this overhead is configured to take up quite a large amount of bytes - for instance

```vb
Module M
Sub Main
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!")
End Sub
End Module
```

May be golfed down by 4 bytes by the `Console.Write(...)` command over `Console.WriteLine(...)`.

```vb
Module M
Sub Main
Console.Write("Hello, World!")
End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Tips question are usually required not to offer whitespace and name shortening tips, as they apply for all languages and go under the generic tip question. I don't think this answer should appear here.

Comment: @Uriel - you are completely correct, I've modified the response; please continue to let me know anything I can do to improve this resource.

Comment: I still don't think that existence of `Write` method is worth an answer, but that's debatable. anyway, please refrain from long codes. You could make just fine with only the central line - it just clutters pages