# Tips for golfing in VB.net

Tags: code-golf, tips

Any general tips for golfing in VB.net?

This, similar to Pascal, is a very rarely used language, thus having very few resources online

Visual Basic.NET (VB.NET) is a multi-paradigm, managed, type-safe, object-oriented computer programming language. Along with C# and F#, it is one of the main languages targeting the .NET Framework. VB.NET can be viewed as an evolution of Microsoft's Visual Basic 6 (VB6) but implemented on the Microsoft.NET Framework.

(Quoted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net)

Please post each tip as a separate answer

Comment: To prevent stacking of answers (better to post all you can in one answer instead of multiple)

Comment: But that means that different tips can't be voted on separately. If you're doing that, might as well have one big Community Wiki answer.

Comment: In every other language for golfing, every single person has posted all their tips in one post, if not, all you see is one guys name over and over again

Comment: isn't this already a thing? [vb.net link](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155840/tips-for-golfing-in-visual-basic-net)

Answer (score 2):

If there is no parameters, you can remove the '()' when you call a function.

```
Console.ReadLine().Split()
Console.ReadLine.Split
```

Comment: can you post your answers on the [original question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155840/tips-for-golfing-in-visual-basic-net)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to test booleans, you can test integers, it's true if not 0.

```
if(a<>0,do this,do that)
if(a,do this, do that)
```