# Increment The Time

Tags: code-golf, string, number, date

Every digital clock contains a small creature that has to advance the time every minute <sup>[citation needed]</sup>. Due to the popularty of digital clocks and the popularity of catching them in the wild, they are nearly extinct in nature which is why in this challenge we try to automate this task:

Given your string of a given time in the 24h format, the task is to advance this time by one minute.

### Details

- Both the input and output must be strings.
- The time is given as a five character string.
- Both the hour and the minutes are given as a two digit number: if the number is below 10, there will be a leading zero.
- The two numbers are separated by a colon.

### Examples

```
Input    Output
00:00    00:01
00:02    00:03
05:55    05:56
09:59    10:00
12:49    12:50
20:05    20:06
23:59    00:00
```

Comment: Congratulations on finding a challenge in which Excel beats Jelly!

Comment: *[citation needed]* 

Comment: Ref: Pratchett. In [Discworld](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Discworld#Thud!_(2005)), imps usually do that sort of thing. *“Good Morning, Insert Name Here! I am the Dis-Organizer Mark Five, the Gooseberry™. How may I—”*

Answer (score 62):

## Microsoft Excel, 9 bytes

```
=A1+"0:1"
```

Input is in cell `A1`.
Tested on my Mac (Excel for Mac version 16.53) and online at Office.com.

[image]

Comment: Great tool for the job :) To be a little nitpicky: If you input truly a string as required by the challenge (eg. `'23:59`), you get a number in the cell with the formula.

Comment: Thanks.  I just tried ```'23:59``` on my Excel for Mac 16.53 and somehow it still works (```00:00``` output)...  Edit: it seems to work on Office.com, too...

Comment: @pajonk https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVFFr.png

Comment: @pajonk (after some trial-and-error) - It seems to depend on the order that the cells are created.  I entered ```23:59``` into ```A1``` first, and then typed-in the 9-byte ```=A1+"0:1"```.  After that, other inputs - including explicit strings like ```'12:30``` - produce the correct output.  This seems to be because Excel automatically applied a custom date-like format to the formula cell (my cell ```A2```).  This doesn't necessarily happen if the cells are filled-in in a different order.  Not sure whether (or how) this should be reflected somewhere in the byte-count...

Comment: Yes, I agree that it depends on the formatting of `A2`, which is automatically applied based on `A1`. Anyway, if the string->string I/O requirement is strict, I think `TEXT` function should be used here. Without it, it's just pretty formatted number. Otherwise counting clicks to reach required formatting [may be tricky](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10211/55372).

Comment: Also works in LibreOffice, but not in Google Sheets 

Answer (score 11):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + [coreutils date](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/date-invocation.html), 17

```bash
date -d$1+min +%R
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYlLCoAwDAX3OUUWupJCrGbRegtvUE1AwQ/YgsevVvAtZmDeFOKS72XdFC8NgkljmkPUAfCdnJ@iJjQGq//MEpKikapt9vXAph6znIdmIk8EhRaIPTOQ8@ygtb53YN/OYLtSHg)

This assumes everything is in UTC (such as how TIO appears to be set up).  If this is not OK, then 4 bytes must be added:

---

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + [coreutils date](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/date-invocation.html), 21

```bash
date -ud$1UTC+min +%R
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvhfnpGZk6pQlJqYolCSWlySnFicas2lAAQp@WCqOLVEQVdXQQUm@T8lsSRVQbc0RcUwNMRZOzczT0FbNeh/Sn5e6n8DAysDAy4QacRlYGplasplYGllasllaGRlYsllBBQ35TIyBokAAA)

Answer (score 11):

## x86-16 machine code, <del>61</del> <del>55</del> 54 bytes

```
00000000: be82 008b fe8b d6ad 86c4 9346 56ad 86c4  ...........FV...
00000010: 4037 0430 3d30 367c 1293 4037 0430 3d34  @7.0=06|..@7.0=4
00000020: 327c 03b8 3030 86c4 abb0 305f 86c4 abb8  2|..00....0_....
00000030: 2409 aacd 21c3                           $...!.
```

Listing:

```
BE 0082     MOV  SI, 82H            ; SI point to DOS command line tail 
8B FE       MOV  DI, SI             ; save pointer to beginning of string for later 
8B D6       MOV  DX, SI             ; save pointer to beginning of string for output 
AD          LODSW                   ; load hours digits into AX 
86 C4       XCHG AL, AH             ; endian convert 
93          XCHG AX, BX             ; save hours in BX 
46          INC  SI                 ; skip colon 
56          PUSH SI                 ; save string offset to minutes 
AD          LODSW                   ; load minutes digits into AX  
86 C4       XCHG AL, AH             ; endian convert 
40          INC  AX                 ; add one minute 
37          AAA                     ; BCD Adjust After Addition! 
04 30       ADD  AL, '0'            ; ASCII fix low digit 
3D 3630     CMP  AX, '60'           ; is minutes wrap around? 
7C 13       JL   NO_CARRY_HOUR      ; if not, skip hours 
93          XCHG AX, BX             ; move hours into AX 
40          INC  AX                 ; increment hours 
37          AAA                     ; BCD Adjust After Addition! 
04 30       ADD  AL, '0'            ; ASCII fix low digit 
3D 3234     CMP  AX, '24'           ; rolled over to 24 hours? 
7C 03       JL   NO_CARRY_DAY       ; if not, skip to convert 
B8 3030     MOV  AX, '00'           ; reset hours to '00' 
        NO_CARRY_DAY: 
86 C4       XCHG AL, AH             ; endian convert 
AB          STOSW                   ; write hours string 
B0 30       MOV  AL, '0'            ; reset minutes to '00' 
        NO_CARRY_HOUR: 
5F          POP  DI                 ; minutes string offset to DI 
86 C4       XCHG AL, AH             ; endian convert 
AB          STOSW                   ; write minutes to output string 
B8 0924     MOV  AX, 0924H          ; AL = '$', AH = write string function 
AA          STOSB                   ; write DOS string terminator to end of string 
CD 21       INT  21H                ; write output to console 
C3          RET                     ; return to DOS
```

Thought it would be a more straightforward use of BCD operations, though it gave me a use for the `AAA` instruction so there's that.

Standalone DOS executable. Input via command line, output to console.

[image]

#### OR...

**21 bytes** if I could take I/O as a packed BCD hex word (`12:59` == `0x1259`), and get to use `AAA`'s bastard step-sibling `DAA`!

```
40          INC  AX             ; increment the time 
27          DAA                 ; decimal adjust packed BCD 
3C 60       CMP  AL, 60H        ; did minutes reach 60? 
7C 0E       JL   DONE           ; if not, do nothing else 
32 C0       XOR  AL, AL         ; otherwise, reset minutes to 0 
86 E0       XCHG AH, AL         ; swap hours and minutes in AL 
40          INC  AX             ; increment the hours 
27          DAA                 ; decimal adjust packed BCD 
3C 24       CMP  AL, 24H        ; did hours reach 24? 
86 E0       XCHG AH, AL         ; real quick, swap hours and minutes back 
7C 02       JL   DONE           ; if less than 24, do nothing else 
32 E4       XOR  AH, AH         ; otherwise, reset hour to 0 
        DONE: 
C3          RET
```

Comment: I'm impressed. Apparently BCD still has a use, if only in code golf.

Comment: @rosuav _"`AAA` and `DAA` are extremely useful x86 instructions." -no one ever_

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 68 bytes

```python
def f(s):v=int(s[:2])*60-~int(s[3:]);print'%02d:%02d'%(v/60%24,v%60)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcxBCsIwEAXQvafoJiQjitNpE@iIJ5Hu2tKAxGBjxI1XjxndzOP/DxPfab0HKmWal2YxG3C@@JDMdmUaYe/w@PnHjkc4x0cNWiFNLEcrk08OFfWHrBxCea3@Njct108@xGcyAEUjMqLe/STRsrXiwHaotsS9SHWXnjrpvw)

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>65</s> 64 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to @Matthew Willcockson*

```python
lambda s:f"{(v:=int(s[:2])*60-~int(s[3:]))//60%24:02}:{v%60:02}"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYpRC4IwFEbf9ytEELYgvN65kRf8JeWDUUNB19BlhNRfXxu9fJzvcNzbDw8rT24Jpr2EqZ@vtz5byeQ736gdrefrmbATBw3H7/9K6oQoSw0F1gT4oX0rNCTKw2sYp3tWUeaWFBs@Wvf0XAgRICbA0iIDRUoxaEg1rEKqG4bRK4Yymh8)

Comment: What's amazing is a more normal script version is less than 50 characters longer: `import datetime as d,sys;f="%H:%M";print((d.datetime.strptime(sys.argv[1],f)+d.timedelta(minutes=1)).strftime(f))`

Comment: Also, with Python 3 a single character can be shaved off with f-strings: `lambda s:f"{(v:=int(s[:2])*60-~int(s[3:]))//60%24:02}:{v%60:02}"`

Comment: @MatthewWillcockson Thanks, I somehow missed that!

Comment: @MatthewWillcockson if you're so inclined, you can golf the "more normal" version down such that it's only 34 bytes longer https://tio.run/##NY0xC8IwFIT39yseASFRKbE1YAMdBRenOnapNNFAk4b0Ofjra1NwOY7ju7v4pfcUqktMy6vplrH3z6FH0nzoyZDzppgpxWw4Ha04ZDeYkXruXfiQmZuTEJmxG2MF2DR5/LfR@Tgl2oNt2O6md3e2PK7to8UGGWMdSKml3LQEqbRSIGutajiV@lxDueYKyionKw5gp4TrJ6ELuO0UcxwdjS6YmQuNMblA/MUzI8TyAw

Answer (score 9):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 35 bytes

```php
<?=date("H:i",strtotime($argn)+60);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt42JbEkVUPJwypTSae4pKgkvyQzN1VDJbEoPU9T28xA0/r/fwMDKwODf/kFJZn5ecX/dd0A)

Comment: Nice answer! On older PHP you can save 1 byte using a bit flipped string (`~"H:i"`) as a default constant instead of `"H:i"` but it's probably not worth the hassle!

Comment: Could you elaborate on that, @DomHastings? Can't figure out how that'd work.

Comment: Of course! I probably didn't explain it very well! But basically `~"..."` bitflips the string [see this example](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vyCjQEG3SEG9oCgzr0RDyVFJ01q9pqIiRUE3iQtVrg5F8v9/AA) from [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218530/9365), and the resulting high-byte string can be used as a bare word constant to save 1 byte on the quotes. But it does add extra faff to the answer! Hope that helps!

Answer (score 9):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 216 bytes

```
,++++++++>,>>,>+>,++++>,+<<<[-<<-<-<+>>>>>>->-<<<]>>>[<<-]<<[>>----------<+[<-]<[->------<<<+<+[++++++[>-]>[<<[>>-]>>[<----<-->>->>]<]<<------>]>[<----------<+>>->]]<]<<<[->+>+>>+>>+>+<<<<<<<]>--------.>.>>.>>----.>.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU5BCgJBDHtQt3tQPLiUfKT0oIIgCx4E3z8mM7O2hbZpEnr/3F7v5/ext7bYDCxgsY3FIiI9wpmGHg7uUZySePFO7B9hKTB9YqQasWGe8JJKipK@M9xligp6DRFq3g5PEaoT5GzMUXov@jcHd8UK1ZxbO523y/UH)

The character `:` is the ASCII character after `9`, so the program uses the one provided to it in the input to check if digits need to be carried, allowing it to avoid creating any large constants.

```
[
Read in the string and set up for the comparisons later. Increment minutes.
Subtract ':' from all characters and copy it elsewhere.
Layout:        Cell #  -1  0 1 2 3 4 5 6
        Cell contents  ':' A B _ _ 1 C D
The central 0 and 1 cells allow all of the conditionals to land near each other,
reducing the amount of travel needed in the worst case.
]
,++++++++>,>>,>+>,++++>,+
<<<[-<<-<-<+>>>>>>->-<<<]
# If minutes are 10: Carry
>>>[<<-]<<[
    >>----------<+
    # If tenminutes are 6: Carry
    [<-]<[
        ->------<<<+<+
        # If hours are not 10: Check for 24:00 rollover
        [
            ++++++
            [>-]>[
                <<[>>-]>>[
                    <----<--
                >>->>]
            <]
            <<------
        # If hours are 10: Carry
        >]>[
            <----------<+
        >>->]
    ]
<]
# Undo modifications from the start and print
<<<[->+>+>>+>>+>+<<<<<<<]
>--------.>.>>.>>----.>.
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice answer!

Answer (score 8):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), <s>83</s> 49 bytes

```java
i->java.time.LocalTime.parse(i).plusMinutes(1)+""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZA/T8MwEMX3fopTpkSobgpioBXslehUNsRwda7hgmNH8TkSQvnswSnpH0a4xfLzPb3fc4UdzqviY9AGvYctsoWv2QziLBag39GWhHtDwFaoPaCm41vTcodypcIm2mCanbRsS8CiQ6vphWuCdNIkXrL1cbP/iWnC3rAGLyjx6BwXUI8Uk@P1DbAtfXaimsg8SWjOwga8M0HYWXg8i5ft0pkDFaBdQQPPn6rYWY0g6tlpNCOfarD1lHKmGhP8lm0Q8ukyu0mSYX0J3n16oVq5ICr@gBVj01OwumqbJst8ledJNjX9k/X2bnX/8D9r/iu1n/XDNw)

Huge cut-off thanks to Olivier Grégoire

Comment: [49 bytes](https://tio.run/##nZA/T8MwEMX3fopTpkSobgpioBXslehUNsRwda7hgmNH8TkSQvnswSnpH0a4xfLzPb3fc4UdzqviY9AGvYctsoWv2QziLBag39GWhHtDwFaoPaCm41vTcodypcIm2mCanbRsS8CiQ6vphWuCdNIkXrL1cbP/iWnC3rAGLyjx6BwXUI8Uk@P1DbAtfXaimsg8SWjOwga8M0HYWXg8i5ft0pkDFaBdQQPPn6rYWY0g6tlpNCOfarD1lHKmGhP8lm0Q8ukyu0mSYX0J3n16oVq5ICr@gBVj01OwumqbJst8ledJNjX9k/X2bnX/8D9r/iu1n/XDNw) by just using `LocalTime` rather than `LocalDateTime`

Answer (score 7):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 12 bytes

```
YOl13L/+15XO
```

Beaten by Excel... :-D

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P9I/x9DYR1/b0DTC//9/dQNTK1NTdQA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8D/SP8fQ2Edf29A0wv@/S8h/dQMDKwMDdS4wbQSiTa1MTUG0pZWpJZA2NLIyAdFGQHmQuJExSBwA).

#### Explanation

```
YO     % Implicit input. Convert to date number. The integer part represents date,
       % the fractional part represents time of day
l      % Push 1
13L    % Push 1440 (predefined literal)
/      % Divide. Gives 1/1440, which is 1 minute expressed as fraction of a day
+      % Add
15XO   % Convert to date string with format 15, which is 'HH:MM'
       % Implicit display
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>20</s>  19 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly)

```
ØDṗ2ḣ“ð<‘Œpj€”:ðṙiḢ
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of characters and yields a list of characters.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATYAyf9qZWxsef//w5hE4bmXMuG4o@KAnMOwPOKAmMWScGrigqzigJ06w7DhuZlp4bii////MjM6NTk)**

#### How?

Surprisingly tricky to get anything below 22 in Jelly, no time-based functionality while parsing, evaluating and then adding leading zeros where needed is expensive, so I went with constructing all strings as a list and getting the next string cyclically.

```
ØDṗ2ḣ“ð<‘Œpj€”:ðṙiḢ - Link: characters, S
ØD                  - digit characters -> "0123456789"
  ṗ2                - Cartesian power 2 -> ["00",...,"99"]
     “ð<‘           - list of code-page indices -> [24, 60]
    ḣ               - head to -> [["00",..."23"],["00",...,"59"]]
         Œp         - Cartesan product -> [["00","00"],...,["23","59"]]
           j€”:     - join each with colons -> ["00:00",...,"23:59"]
               ð    - start a new dyadic chain, f(Times, S)
                 i  - first 1-indexed index of S in Times
                ṙ   - rotate Times left by that
                  Ḣ - head
```

Answer (score 6):

**Powershell**, **82** or **153** bytes

`get-date ((get-date ($Time=read-host "Enter the time")).addminutes(1)) -uformat %R`

Or, if you want to show the input as well as the output;

```
do {$Time=read-host "Enter the time"
    write-host -nonewline $time `t 
    get-date ((get-date $Time).addminutes(1)) -uformat %R
    } while ($Time)
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first answer! Make sure to check out our [tips for golfing in Powershell](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/191/tips-for-golfing-in-powershell) to see if there are any ways for you to shorten your answer.

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 32 bytes

```
T`_d`d0`.9?(:59)?$
T`d`0`(24)?:6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcohDoAwDEZh33NAshnyU1aS1UxygXlKMgQGQbh/GeaJL@853@s@fAybebW9WYNNuQSVHMtA1ZrBAqdYdHUHFKC/TBAVIeR@0syaMnF3IV66fA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
T`_d`d0`.9?(:59)?$
```

Increment all the digits in `09:59`, `19:59`, `X:59`, `:X9` or just the last digit if nothing else matches. Incrementing `9` automatically rolls over to `0`.

```
T`d`0`(24)?:6
```

Zero out `24:60` and the seconds of `X:60` (X will already have been incremented above so it is correct).

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (Chrome / Edge / Node), 50 bytes

Very hackish.

```javascript
s=>(new Date(+new Date([1,s])+6e4)+s).slice(16,21)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc9BC8IgGMbxe59CdlJcm7opTFinvkV0EHOxEI0c9fFtRluR3Z7D7@XPe1F3FfRtvE5b508mDn0M/Q468wB7NRmI13WgZTgiLEyLcEBVsKM2kIqSURS1d8FbU1l/hgMsCJGEFAiBugZp080fwL5AkwEuOV/AvEUGOsm7N6Ap9wsok@0KmOQZYPPVkkg7S7Dmk3h9FJ8)

#### Commented

```javascript
s =>              // s = "HH:MM"
  ( new Date(     // generate a date:
      +new Date(  //   generate a timestamp corresponding to:
        [1, s]    //     "1,HH:MM" which is interpreted as
                  //     Mon Jan 01 2001 HH:MM:00
      )           //   end of Date()
      + 6e4       //   add 60000 milliseconds (1 minute)
    )             // end of Date()
    + s           // coerce to a string
  ).slice(16, 21) // extract the updated "HH:MM"
```

Answer (score 5):

## [C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/), <s>64</s> <s>62</s> 55 bytes

-7 bytes thanks to asherber

```csharp
(x)=>$"{System.DateTime.Parse(x).AddMinutes(1):HH:mm}";
```

[dotnetfiddle!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZHEdxy)

### Old version (62 Bytes)

```csharp
(x)=>System.DateTime.Parse(x).AddMinutes(1).ToString("HH:mm");
```

Comment: Save a few bytes with string interpolation.  `(x)=>$"{System.DateTime.Parse(x).AddMinutes(1):HH:mm}";`

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>100</s> 95 bytes

```python
from datetime import*
f='%H:%M'
t=lambda s:(datetime.strptime(s,f)+timedelta(0,60)).strftime(f)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYpBCsMgEADvvsJL0G1C2VJaiJB7Ln2ERZcKMYrupa@3sVB6G2Ymv/mV9mtrVFKUzrLnEL0MMafCJ0GLGlYzPJTgZbPx6aysRv@2c@WSO@g6EYydnN/YapzuCNAzfTNByyXsrFkrRIMXBSD@Zja3@TDtAw)

-5 thanks to @pandubear

Python is terrible at this...

Comment: Ah, you are correct. Reverted

Comment: You can save 5 characters by changing `timedelta(minutes=1)` to `timedelta(0,60)`!

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-pl`, 40 bytes

```ruby
$_="#{Time.gm(1,1,~/:/,$`,$')+60}"[11,5]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/XyXeVkm5OiQzN1UvPVfDUMdQp07fSl9HJUFHRV1T28ygVina0FDHNPb/fwMDKwMDLhBpxGVgamVqymVgaWVqyWVoZGViyWUEFDflMjIGivzLLyjJzM8r/q9bkAMA)

`~/:/` matches the colon in the input (yielding its index, `2`), setting the pre- and post-match regexes `` $` `` and `$'` to the hour and minute, respectively.

---

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-plaF:`, 35 bytes

*Suggested by @dingledooper*

```ruby
$_="#{Time.gm(1,1,1,*$F)+60}"[11,5]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/XyXeVkm5OiQzN1UvPVfDUAcEtVTcNLXNDGqVog0NdUxj//83MLAyMOACkUZcBqZWpqZcBpZWppZchkZWJpZcRkBxUy4jY6DIv/yCksz8vOL/ugU5iW5WAA)

The array `$F` is formed by automatically splitting the input at the colon.

---

Both versions perform the following operations:

- convert input to a `Time` object,
- add 60 seconds,
- convert to a string of the form `0001-01-dd hh:mm:00 UTC`, where for the 40 byte version `dd` is either `02` or `03` (the latter only when the input is `23:59`); for the 35 byte version it is `01`,
- extract the 11th to 15th characters.

It's somewhat noteworthy that `Time#gm` internally coerces string arguments to integers.

Comment: For more flag abuse, you might be able to do `$_="#{Time.gm(1,1,1,*$F)+60}"[11,5]`+`-plaF:`

Comment: @dingledooper Thanks! Using `-F:` felt a bit too cheaty but I've added it as an alternative.

Comment: This combo is perhaps even more cheaty: `$_="#{Time.parse($_)+60}"[11,5]` + `-plrrss` :P

Comment: @dingledooper Gotta love a monkey patch. We haven't even got to `-e` yet ;)

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>71</s> 69 bytes

Thanks to dingledooper for the -2.

The only sneaky things were to reuse the input parameter and cache the format string.

```c
i,z;f(s){sscanf(s,z="%02d:%02d",&i,&s);printf(z,(i+s/60)%24,++s%60);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZDBboMwDIbvPIWViTYp2ZbSgtRk9Amq3XbqeqChDEsMJtLuAOLZWcLSLYf8jv37i2X9@KH1NCHvVUkNG4zReWMj3mckFHEh3UX4AvnCMPXVYXMtac8pRuY5FSyMtzyKTGhDNU4P2Oj6VlzgxVyLGs9P1T4IbAd85tjQ7xYLBkMAoKu8g5U5nrKBCCGFIHzW2Gkik8TpTiY7q@tYbp3Gtu7y8WbOv74dDiO3rPmsuj/W2rM2npU6hv/DshLhWan3Cc9SluVGRRXYqGw7iplQYI54UoBR9Ds5gF8BCQ1keyB8djA11@ze/h93I1BTtbe6gPNFwjI0S/be2Lbu7hyDcfoB)

Comment: One other sneaky thing you can do is to reuse the input format string, with `i,z;f(s){sscanf(s,z="%02d:%02d",&i,&s);printf(z,(i+s/60)%24,++s%60);}` ;)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
23Ý59ÝâT‰J':ýDIk>è
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fyPjwXFPLw3MPLwp51LDBS93q8F4Xz2y7wytAUlamlgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkv1/I@PDc00tD889vCjkUcMGL3Wrw3tdKrPtDq/4r/PfwMDKwIALRBpxGZhamZpyGVhamVpyGRpZmVhyGQHFTbmMjIEiAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
23Ý                 # Push a list in the range [0,23]
   59Ý              # Push a list in the range [0,59]
      â             # Get the cartesian product of these two lists
       T‰J          # Format each integer to a string with potentially leading 0:
       T‰           #  Take the divmod-10: [n//10,n%10]
         J          #  And join these pairs of digits together
          ':ý      '# Join each inner pair together with ":" delimiter
             D      # Duplicate this list
              Ik    # Get the index of the input in this duplicated list
                >   # Increase it by 1
                 è  # And use it to index into the list
                    # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: Wow. Much better than my clunky one

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>46</s> 43 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to [Jonathan Carroll](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/26763/jonathan-carroll)*

Or **[R](https://www.r-project.org/)>=4.1, 36 bytes** by replacing the word `function` with `\`.

```r
function(t)format(strptime(t,h<-"%R")+60,h)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jRDMtvyg3sUSjuKSooCQzN1WjRCfDRldJNUhJU9vMQCdD83@ahpKBgZWBgZKmsgIQgNiGXFBBIyRBY7CgqZWpKUwQyDYDC1pamVpCBQ1BRoEEDY2sTOCCRlamYEEjoCxMO4gN1m5kjNAOdsl/AA)

---

Without datetime functions:

#### [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>89</s> 85 bytes

```r
function(t,`[`=substr,m=el(t[4,5]:0+1)%%60)sprintf("%02d:%02d",el(t[1,2]:0+!m)%%24,m)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7LCsMgEEX3/YrWIih1MU5iIAN@SSiEPgKBmpRovt@qJG1nMVyO5w4ucbBxWKd7GOdJBNV3vfXrzYdFOft8idDVylwJLlpy3oD072WcwiAYB3xQXkwVTSvM2sklD2vlZEwSAAEweT6myVkfNoh/sCrQkDE7TLkpsCXTblDnUxlqpPoLkUyBmF73es6ljtWvXn4SPw)

Comment: R4.1 function syntax really helps with golfing, but also `%R` is equivalent to `%H:%M`... `\(t)format(strptime(t,h<-"%R")+60,h)` for 36.

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 40 bytes

```php
fn($s)=>date('H:i',strtotime("$s+1min"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc9PD4IgGMfxu6/iGWMT1h8Bo03MurVeRJdWOjkILHj9kXoJ7frbh30fXO/i6eJ6l@EOGoidIdjT5vx6hJbkN6XzrQ/vYIMeWoKw3/BBG0RprLOsffYWcEcQY4oxRGEP6G5QDUUB08SXQvyLMhFSSbkS43RMRKVktRR8Cv8EF@qwFkLJRIjxwaoyTUlFlH@V@XtxvvdjXdDW@Li7fgE)

PHP relative date formatting at its finest, trying to compress it to the max. Should take in account the DST following the locale

Comment: [36 bytes](https://tio.run/##Zc9NDoIwEAXgfU8xaUiA@ENbLAmD6M54CDdGSmAhbaTnt1I2Fti@@SZvxnTGna@mMyRqoQbXDkk0pvWleVqVxHfs4/1oP1bb/q38ZFew1FWEqFenIWoTyhgyRlM4An0MtIIsAx/xpRBbkQdCopQrMUVFIEqU5VJwX/wXXOBpLQTKQIhpYdXio6BF5JuW@T033/vVxvZ6GN3h9gM) or [35 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt42JbEkVUPJwypTSae4pKgkvyQzN1VDJbEoPU9T28xA0/r/fwMDKwPjf/kFJZn5ecX/dd0A)

Comment: @Shaggy That's a significant improve compared to my answer, if you want to post as your own, be sure I'll upvote it!

Answer (score 3):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 24 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
╟r■gæ├M<Þmò♀+░m╞':u_l=)§
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///R1PlFj6YtSD@87NGUOb42h@flHt70aGaD9qNpE3MfTZ2nblUan2OreWj5//9KBgZWBgZKXGDaCESbWpmagmhLK1NLIG1oZGUCoo2A8iBxI2OQOAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
╟r                       # Push a list in the range [0,60)
  ■                      # Take the cartesian product with itself
   g                     # Filter this list of pairs by,
    æ                    # using the following four characters as inner code-block:
     ├  Þ                #  Where the first value of the pair
      M<                 #  Is smaller than 24
         m               # Then map each remaining pair to,
          ò              # using the following eight characters as inner code-block:
           ♀+            #  Add 100 to both integers
             ░           #  Convert both to a string
              m╞         #  Remove the first character (the "1") from both strings
                ':u     '#  Join this pair with ":" delimiter
                   _     # After the map, duplicate the list of all possible times
                    l=   # Get the index of the string-input in this duplicated list
                      )  # Increase it by 1
                       § # And use it to (0-based modulair) index into the list
                         # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 3):

## SQL Server, 36 bytes

```
select left(dateadd(n,1,a),5) from t
```

[Try it online (using all of the input values given in the question).](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/236eac/2)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!

Comment: Your post has an extra space before the 5 that's not there in the actual code.

Comment: Thanks, @Neil, I fixed it. Doesn't lower my score, though, unfortunately  - the score was based on the correct version that didn't have the extra  space.

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 33 bytes

```
%{'{0:HH:mm}'-f((Date $_)+'0:1')}
```

Input comes from the pipeline.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvbmBgZWCgrqMAZhiBGaZWpqZghqWVqSWIYWhkZQJmGAHVgKWMjEFSNf9Vq9WrDaw8PKxyc2vVddM0NFwSS1IVVOI1tdUNrAzVNWv//wcA)

Try it in a PS console (Windows or Core):

```
 '00:00', '00:02', '05:55', '09:59', '12:49', '20:05', '23:59'|%{'{0:HH:mm}'-f((Date $_)+'0:1')}
```

### Explanation

**%** is an Alias for the Cmdlet "ForEach-Object", which accepts input from the pipeline and processes each incoming object inside the ScriptBlock {...}
**'{0:HH:mm}'** is the output string; {0:HH:mm} is a placeholder for the first argument of the following **-f** format operator. It contains formatting information to print a DateTime object in 24 hour format.
**-f** is the format operator, which will replace the placeholder with the actual time. Using -f is shorter than calling the .ToString('HH:mm') method.
**((Date $_)+'0:1')** does the heavy lifting: It first turns the current string coming in from the pipeline ($_) into a DateTime object by passing it to the Cmdlet **Get-Date**. The 'Get-' is implicit in PS, so leaving it out saves 4 bytes (Disclaimer: **never** use that in a regular script; it slows things down, because PS will search the path for a matching command as well - each time it's called!).
Now that there's a DateTime object on the left side, and PS sees an Add operation, it interpretes the '0:1' as timespan of 1 minute (try `[TimeSpan]'0:1'` in a PS console); this is shorter than using the DateTime's object AddMinutes() method.
The result of the addition is then inserted into the string, output is implicit.

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 52 bytes

```scala
java.time.LocalTime.parse(_).plusMinutes(1).toString
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7LCoMwEADvfsXiyVyCiU2hAQveW3po7yXVUBQfwUQplH57qvVRcxuY3dnVqSiFbR6FTA0kWXap5TmvOyNBvoysMw2JUvD2AHpRQsXhatq8fkJ8XMkWohfY5JXEp2bI3UZSotUyuCOsyk5PRR0QhE0zrVmhtWxNUAV@GPIw9BHEMfyY@MhzLd3YyLWMM7bYgfeuPXB2mC2ZrmwsoXy3WsqZa@kwv5RHdss0@pfn/72P/QI)

Straightforward approach: parse string as time information via built-in functionality, add one minute to it, output as string

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 56 bytes

```
[ ":"without hhmm>duration 1 minutes time+ duration>hm ]
```

This doesn't run on TIO because the `calendar.parser` vocabulary postdates Factor build 1525 (the one TIO uses) by just a bit. Here's a screenshot of running it in build 1889, the official 0.98 stable release:

[image: A screenshot of running the above code in the Factor Listener]

### Explanation

It's a quotation that takes a string from the data stack as input and leaves a string on the data stack as output. Assuming `"23:59"` is on top of the data stack when this quotation is called...

| Snippet | Comment | Data stack (the bottom is the top) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ``` ":"without ``` | Remove the colon | ``` "2359" ``` |
| ``` hhmm>duration ``` | Parse a 4-digit string into a duration with hours and minutes | ``` T{ duration f 0 0 0 23 59 0 } ``` |
| ``` 1 minutes ``` | Create a duration of one minute | ``` T{ duration f 0 0 0 23 59 0 } T{ duration f 0 0 0 0 1 0 } ``` |
| ``` time+ ``` | Add two durations and/or timestamps | ``` T{ duration f 0 0 0 23 60 0 } ``` |
| ``` duration>hm ``` | Convert a duration or timestamp to a HH:MM string | ``` "00:00" ``` |

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 83 bytes

```
@set/ps=
@set/am=6%s::=*60+1%-99,h=m/60%%24+100,m=m%%60+100
@echo %h:~-2%:%m:~-2%
```

Takes input on STDIN. Explanation:

```
@set/ps=
```

Read in the time.

```
@set/am=6%s::=*60+1%-99,h=m/60%%24+100,m=m%%60+100
```

Batch parses leading `0`s as octal, so to allow hours and minutes to be `08` or `09`, `6` is prefixed to the hours and `1` to the minutes. Additionally, the `:` is changed to `*60+` and the resulting string evaluated. The `6` prefix does not change the overall result because `600` hours is exactly `25` days, while the `1` adds `100` minutes so `99` minutes are subtracted to obtain the desired total number of minutes. The total minutes are then divided back into hours and minutes, but with 100 added so that the last two digits can be extracted.

```
@echo %h:~-2%:%m:~-2%
```

Print the last two digits to get the real hours and minutes again.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 13 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Ð6e4°ÐNi1¹¤¯5
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=0DZlNLDQTmkxuaSvNQ&input=IjAwOjAwIg)

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <sup><s>43</s></sup> 42 bytes

```julia
using Dates
~t="$(Time(t)+Minute(1))"[1:5]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYyxCgIxEAX7/YoQLBIE2US3uMCJha2dnVhcEWQlhsNswOp@PcbD5jEMw3vWxJP7tFYL54c6TxILLDLqjbnyKxqx2wvnKtE4a/XNBbq3nkhRoypzYjFaa0AMiOt6QApEgEOgAZwPhwF89wR@/zO9tgCnnZrfnCVl8z87qmUl274)

Answer (score 2):

## [QBasic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QBasic), <s>132</s> 129 bytes

```basic
INPUT t$
i=6
1i=i-1+f
x=ASC(MID$(t$,i))-47
f=i=4
x=x<10+f*4AND x
MID$(t$,i,1)=CHR$(x+48)
IF x=0GOTO 1
IF"24"<t$THEN t$="00:00
?t$
```

[Try it here!](https://archive.org/details/msdos_qbasic_megapack)

#### Explanation

```basic
' Read the input time into t$
INPUT t$
' i is the index of the current digit, starting one digit to the right of the string
i = 6
' Label 1 is the start of the loop
1
' Subtract 1 from i, and subtract an additional 1 if f is set (see below)
i = i - 1 + f
' x is the current digit plus 1
x = ASC(MID$(t$, i)) - 47
' f is true (-1) only when i = 4
f = (i = 4)
' If x = 10, or if f is true and x = 6, set x to 0; otherwise, leave it unchanged
x = x < (10 + f * 4) AND x
' Write that digit back into the string t$ at the current position
MID$(t$, i, 1) = CHR$(x + 48)
' Loop if this digit wrapped around to 0
IF x = 0 THEN GOTO 1
' Special case: when t$ is 24:00, wrap around to 00:00
IF "24" < t$ THEN t$ = "00:00"
' Print the final result
PRINT t$
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 63 bytes

```c
f(*s){strptime(s,"%R",s);*s=84;mktime(s);strftime(s,8,"%R",s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBNboMwEIX3nGJkCcUmRHJIiAgWPUS3lAUhcWKVP9kkUYW4eqlt3Kj15o3ePH8zdrWp6rK9zjPHgSKjGmQ/iOaCVYj8dxQqwgKVJXvWfC42YTrCXSR5haZZtAM0pWjxoxNnAqMHUN1KCYHKi2xElKaUotBqZDRO49joMY2PWrdRujca6b7xo5316RRqkD2BfIG2DrRzoIMBuAEaFFMHOrgcNSCmQWZJwTxd8U5ikVEGKhcFA7FeLzsD9FKnOEa@guwNUGgThNmefdHpzvOEFoujf6Pqv7D2/gW5cVz9B4jVrbvXZzhdUlj5akU@Wj3AXpa/lydvmr8rXpdXNW@ePw)

Thanks to @AZTECCO for the "%R" format!!

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 66 bytes

```julia
using Dates;f="HH:MM";g(s)=Dates.format(DateTime(s,f)+Minute(1),f)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY6xDsIgFEVn/YoX0uERq6EoQ2nq5NClmz9AIjSYFk2BxL9HYDv3njvcd1yt6n4pRW/dAg8VtB/MSKZJzjMZFvR0rOXFfPZNBSzhaTeNvjX0NFsXg8aO5pDyAjxYB0gYk4yRFirwCkIKUaGXoi/QcXmrwPOmKn4tih4P3926sDokjYfzHRosP2g22r0g/QE)

Using libraries because why not and it's still shorter than Python.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 101 bytes

I was hoping this would be shorter, but I am posting it despite the length because I think it's an interesting way to compute the answer.

This function modifies the input string so the output is the input. I'm not too familiar with the C golfing rules on this but since it's so long I'm neglecting that issue.

This function treats the input as individual characters, where each column has a 'max' value (the first 5 characters in `u`) and a 'reset' value (last 5 characters in `u`). First the last character of the input string is incremented, then from right to left each character is compared to the max. If any character is greater than its max, it is set to the 'reset' value of that column and the column to the left is incremented.

As described so far, this function will reset after 29:59. To make it reset after 23:59 I used `short *a` to check the first two characters at once to see if they equal `"24"` and if they do, set them to `"00"`.

Also note that I had to modify the test code in order to copy input strings into writable memory.

Improvements are welcome, I think I'm out of ideas on this one.

Thanks to att for -22 bytes, a bugfix, and some awesome golfing!

```c
c;f(char*x){for(x[c=4]++;~c;)x[--c]+=x[c]>"29:59"[c]&&(x[c]=c-2?48:58);*x<49&&x[1]==52?*x=x[1]=48:0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZHNbsIwDMfvfQqrE9Cm7ZaGFkFD4AXQbjuxHoqBEal8qC1TJ@henSWhbJwmTVqkyI7t/PxPjMEb4uWJWOVmX1Qk48jXDm6ygtTuab0vnHqOIko9j38iz0Tt1vMgwNQTKp5ObDZK4pGt3G5XV6YCAzaNhkk8dDnJAqF22O8P2JQmIWUD3li/8f8Cd66C3fra4Hx2SK3uhamIVLqxyNPlv1rV42jU7Rq2iNn0p09CeXN5kDvMj8sVjMtqmcvF42ZiWXJXwTaTO@d9L5cunCwArQRIOU/FyaY0odT2jWXaxkkca2tk@HbIkkhbpvI6zvom/vwymzW@YplFim9W2LL6LWugGW0PxYppyxq0dbRlccXSUkHyViEBROOLbZbne3RiVx/190lBOZRzmXKQnnd9FMChUIC1YxtJnRLEBGzflJmLAGVV4OHDQfTvgmow2LqHY1XenW44Pd9jvoTFKoFep@y5rzvFLW6IxmouXw)

Comment: [114 bytes](https://tio.run/##TZHfboMgFMbvfYoTl7b@XVCrSWV0L9DsblfOC3usK4nVRnRxadyrO7BsKQl8h4/DjwOg/4k4z@Lcdr1TUDwXnTMwM9yl8Y6QlBCTIq2sxR/tW9V21pgh2@auS3@QFmy0x8z3MXeZ9PP9IIf1WuXkTMZunNvUKXwmexBFSfhK0oCECZ3mJ95gPZQneBF9WfPj83lvGLzp4VLwxvpqeWnDzQBQR4MjspzdzHtF3qKh0jiNY6WqXKlBmG6VhnJd@WG0@G/vh8PkSdbSnO6fFWhWpFmJYugzJCsmmpXoPKJZVLJUqcCprtABxCVml6KuW7RiW03Ve3FGKIiM5xS4694vBXDtJKCyzJUAtgfTWzKWPQCi7/D6bSF6D6b8BNThdejFw0yTwJK/ONQlHE8pbFZiY380ktv9ISZjmn8B) and a bugfix (e.g. `"05">"24"` is true)

Comment: [103 bytes](https://tio.run/##rZHNbsIwDMfvfQqrE9Cm7ZaGFkFD4AXQbjuxHoqBEal8qC1TJ@henSWhbJwmTVqkyI7t/PxPjMEb4uWJWOVmX1Qk48jXDm6ygtTuab0vnHqOIko9j38iz0Tt1vMgwNQTKp5ObDZK4pGt3G5XV6YCAzaNhkk8dDnJAqF22O8P2JQmIWUD3li/8f8Cd66C3fra4Hx2SK3uhamIVLqxyNPlv1rV42jU7Rq2iNn0p09CeXN5kDvMj8sVjMtqmcvF42ZiWXJXwTaTO@d9L5cunCwArQRIOU/FyaY0odT2jWXaxkkca2tk@HbIkkhbpvI6zvom/vwymzW@YplFim9W2LL6LWugGW0PxYppyxq0dbRlccXSUkHyViEBROOLbZbne3RiVx/190lBOZRzmXKQnnd9FMChUIC1YxtJnRLEBGzflJmLAGVV4OHDQfTvgmow2LqHY1XenW44Pd9jvoTFKoFep@y5rzvFLW6IxmouXw) with a couple alternatives, but getting rid of `short*` yields 101...

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 85 bytes

```
func[s][p: func[t][pad/left/with t 2 #"0"]s:(load s)+ 0:1 rejoin[p s/1 % 24":"p s/2]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rc5NCoMwEAXgvad4pBRaXBhTs3CO0W3IIjUJtYhKktLj2ygNndU38OYnOLvdnYXSlafNv@dBRa1WwsGUaWwzOZ@az5ieSBA4Mc50pMu0GIt4rcGpRXCvZZzViti0OEN0jNjeCK03vwRnhn1YVcjFOCfO2d@iWJKUxT3J/udWUFcscr5kxO3I5CfDOOftCck84JHy0S8)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 26 bytes

```
':¡`©59%(d+24%®>60%‚т‰J':ý
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATIAzf9vc2FiaWX//yc6wqFgwqk1OSUoZCsyNCXCrj42MCXigJrRguKAsEonOsO9//8yMzo1OQ)

I am sorry.

-1 byte fix thanks to Kevin Cruijsen!!

Comment: You're missing a trailing `':ý`, since the output must be a string in a similar format as well. You can remove the `ï` for -1; golf the `D`, `.À+`, and `s` to `©`, `+`, and `®` for -2; and the `т+€¦` to `т‰J` for another -1. (PS: We posted our 05AB1E answers almost simultaneously.)

Comment: @KevinCruijsen thanks for the 0 byte fix!!!

Comment: -1 actually. ;) You forgot to remove the `ï`. Integers/strings are interchangeable in 05AB1E, so explicit casting is almost never necessary (unless you're sorting, or unless [there is a bug](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/issues/173)).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen oh yes! Coercion is nice

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 25 bytes

```
24ʁ60ʁẊƛƛS2↳ð0V;\:j;:?ḟ›i
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=24%CA%8160%CA%81%E1%BA%8A%C6%9B%C6%9BS2%E2%86%B3%C3%B00V%3B%5C%3Aj%3B%3A%3F%E1%B8%9F%E2%80%BAi&inputs=%2723%3A59%27&header=&footer=)

What a mess. Handling 0-padding, *and* some slightly cursed vectorising, was a pain.

```
24ʁ                       # 0...23
   60ʁ                    # 0...59
      Ẋ                   # Cartesian product
       ƛ           ;      # Map...
        ƛ      ;          # Map...
         S                # Stringify
          2↳              # pad left to length 2 (with spaces, we really need zfill)
            ð0V           # Replace spaces with zeroes
                \:j       # Join by colons
                     ?ḟ   # Find input in this
                       ›  # Increment
                    :   i # Index into this
```

Comment: I have an idea for the 0 padding, add each by 100 then cut the head. You can implement in vyxal

Answer (score 1):

## [Twue](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Twue/), 123 bytes

```
a::>*
:59$::=$:00
23$:::=00:
0$::=1
1$::=2
2$::=3
3$::=4
4$::=5
5$::=6
6$::=7
7$::=8
8$::=9
9$::=$0
^_::=!_^
!_::~_
::=
^a$
```

[Try it on the website!](https://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Twue/?code=a%3A%3A%3E*%0A%3A59%24%3A%3A%3D%24%3A00%0A23%24%3A%3A%3A%3D00%3A%0A0%24%3A%3A%3D1%0A1%24%3A%3A%3D2%0A2%24%3A%3A%3D3%0A3%24%3A%3A%3D4%0A4%24%3A%3A%3D5%0A5%24%3A%3A%3D6%0A6%24%3A%3A%3D7%0A7%24%3A%3A%3D8%0A8%24%3A%3A%3D9%0A9%24%3A%3A%3D%240%0A%5E_%3A%3A%3D!_%5E%0A!_%3A%3A%7E_%0A%3A%3A%3D%0A%5Ea%24,input=05%3A59)

Works by taking input through `a`, having two replacement rules governing roll-over (`:59` -> `:00` and add 1, `23$:` -> `00:`). Then, we have a rule for incrementing, rolling over only when we increment a `9`. After that, we output everything.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 130 bytes

```hs
import Text.Printf
f(a:b:c:d)|[m,h]<-map read[d,a:[b]]::[Int]=[mod(m+1)60,mod(h+m`div`59)24]
g s|[m,h]<-f s=printf"%0.2d:%0.2d"h m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nc3NCoJAFIbhvVdxEAJFjXFyAg96AUFBULthyLHxjxoTnaJF925ltjk8i5fv1HK4FNfrODa6u/UGjsXTLPd905rSKh2JOZ5RuS@u/VokgZYd9IVUXPkSeS4EIt@0RqRc35SjvdBdE//L2tOZah4Zi10aCauC4T9RwpB20769IEuqcLp2DXrUsmkhhc@T3Qm6uzmYftsCr8C8TBJwC8AmBAmx/T/pTIaMzYyRxT@GFKOZ9NPOAV19AyHGNw)

Haskell is missing, hope to see a better one because I feel like mine is a bit messy

- `f` reads the input string and increments the values properly
- `g` prints/converts back values using C-like formatting of Text.Printf

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-F:`, <s>67</s> 64 bytes

*<s>63</s> 60 bytes for code; +4 bytes for -F switch*
*-3 bytes thanks to [erlik](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38911/erlik)*

```perl
@F=++$F[0],0if++$F[1]>59;$F[0]*="@F"<24;printf"%02d:%02d",@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/9/BzVZbW8Ut2iBWxyAzDcw0jLUztbQGi2nZKjm4KdkYmVgXFGXmlaQpqRoYpViBCCUdB7f//42MrUwt/@UXlGTm5xX/13WzAgA)

Ungolfed version:

```perl
if (++$F[1] > 59) {
    @F = (++$F[0], 0);
}
$F[0] *= "@F" < 24;
printf("%02d:%02d", @F);
```

Comment: You can make it 3 chars shorter by replacing the second statement with $F[0]*="@F"<24

Answer (score 1):

##### [Slim Sharp](https://github.com/jcoehoorn/SlimSharp) 46 Bytes

```
P(T.Parse(t).AddMinutes(1).ToString("HH:mm"));
```

[Try it Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/taYhm2)

###### How it Works

```
P(                               // Write the contents to the console.
  T.Parse(t)                     // Parse the input as a date time object.
            .ToString(           // Output the date time object as a string.
                      "HH:mm"    // Format the output in 24 hour time with hours and minutes only.
                             )); // End statement.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Zsh builtins (no date utils), 66 bytes

Reinventing the wheel... [Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##LYtBDoMgEEX3nIIFJBA3wwgmTkJ6EOOqleiCtqmuNJydgrr5L2/m/32dc1D6yNGLQYnDUJsao2UHI/v@lvcWuAR8UQ1@N4AwNSp6D48iWku0IxcxT8/5wxILHIAACk1Hrq/uyLmbp/cXDZKtxNKvf2yvO9qyz38)

```bash
m=$[(${1:3}+1)%60]
printf %02d:%02d $[(${1:0:2}+(m==0?1:0))%24] $m
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 47 bytes

```
StringTake[ToString@DatePlus[#,1/1440],-{8,4}]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P7ikKDMvPSQxOzU6JB/CcXBJLEkNyCktjlbWMdQ3NDExiNXRrbbQMamNVfsfAFRR4qCVpu9QrWRgYGVgoKQDpo1AtKmVqSmItrQytQTShkZWJiDaCCgPEjcyBonX/gcA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 66 bytes

```python
lambda t:f'{(int(t[:2])+((m:=(int(t[3:])+1)%60)<1))%24:02}:{m:02}'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY5BCoMwFET3/xRBEPMplBhNqZ@67Al0V7uwtKEBjUGzKdKzp0a6mYHHYxj38e/JFmc3B113YejHx7NnnnS2cmM99zeSdzxwPlL9BwVtIMf0JPCSI6ayJCG/tI6xstBem7ZhNUuSpAMhSIg9JQhFSoGoSFWQSyorkBtXIItINh1ATzPzr8UzY9m@c1zcYPxg7GvhSMzN8YLm0UEMPw)

A slightly different approach to [@dingledooper's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236025/106393) (and 2 bytes longer ), but the same basic idea.

Comment: You can save two bytes on parentheses by using `-~` to increment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY1BCoMwFET3OUUQxITS8o2m1E9d9gS6qy4sNTSgMWg2Rdqrp8ZuZuDxmLFv95pMdrGzV2Xjh258PDvqUCUr08Yxd0fR8gNjI5bH759k2PL4DPyach6LHEF8cB1DJb6@VXVFSxpFUUMAEGBPQUCilAQKlAVJBeYFERuXRGSBbDohapqp6xdHtaH7zmmxg3aDNv3COFI7h3/FgsO5/wE)

Answer (score 1):

## **[PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 45 bytes**

`(Get-date $x).AddMinutes(1).ToString("HH:mm")`

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/f9fwz21RDclsSRVwcDAysBQU88xJcU3M6@0JLVYA8gLyQ8uKcrMS9dQ8vCwys1V0vz/38jYytQSAA)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Visual Basic,   49 bytes (format command)

```
Dim ins$, out$

ins = "20:21"
out = Format$(DateAdd("n", 1, TimeValue(ins)), "hh:mm")
```

Uses internal time functions.

Comment: Welcome to Code golf, and nice first answer! Here, we usually require that answers be golfed, which you can do by removing whitespace and shortening variable names - also check out our [Tips for golfing in Visual Basic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155838/tips-for-golfing-in-visual-basic) page. You could add a [TIO](https://tio.run/#) link so others can test your code online.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 86 bytes

Little late on this one, but haven't done code golf in a long time and was bored :)

**EDIT: -8 bytes**

```python
lambda s:'%02d:%02d'%([x:=int(s[:2]),[x+1,0][x>22]][(y:=int(s[3:])+1)>59],[y,0][y>59])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPqfZhvzPycxNyklUaHYSl3VwCjFCkSoq2pEV1jZZuaVaBRHWxnFaupEV2gb6hjERlfYGRnFxkZrVMJkja1iNbUNNe1MLWN1oitBSipBbM3/ygolqcUlxVwFRSCFaRpKhgZWJsZKmppIIsZWppYoIkZQkf8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 88 bytes

```python
def f(s):h,m=int(s[:2]),int(s[-2:]);m=(m+1)%60;m or(h:=(h+1)%24);return f'{h:02}:{m:02}'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdBBD4IgGAbgu7@CDg1YteGnuPoc/6F769AWjg6oAzq01m83xWUuO8HHHt530D6Caeps37quu@qKVMxzNFurbnVg/oRw5ttxuwM889IqZjcpXxeitKRxzKBiZjiAnJdOh7urSUWfBgW88GmHhcbgoPUQ3bqYNlmfJBfvtQsRVIwKgUJQzolSJA4p/SNgLrKFkCjlJPqhWIgDysNHpLHyR6SA@VcAyoWA/trUMgyLFshmLePDkmT8AXrs6YryrnsD)

Very straightforward solution here. Nowhere near competitive and nothing novel, but I enjoyed this! I learned a new trick along the way:

`m or(h:=(h+1)%24)` is equivalent to `if m<1:h=(h+1)%24` and the same length, but allows the whole function to be collapsed into one line with semicolons, saving four characters. Without that, this would be four lines.

```python
def f(s):
 h,m=int(s[:2]),int(s[-2:]);m=(m+1)%60
 if m<1:h=(h+1)%24
 return f'{h:02}:{m:02}'
```

Other fun equivalences I learned today:

`m=(m+1)%60` is the same length as
`m+=1;m%=60`

`return f'{h:02}:{m:02}'` is the same length as
`return'%02d:%02d'%(h,m)`

Comment: Another fun thing: `-~m` is equivalent to `m+1`, except it doesn't need the parentheses. Also, `s[-2:]` can be `s[3:]`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdBBC4MgGAbge7/CHcKEBmYz1hf9h91Hh8EMd7BC3WHE9tedGWuxdtIXHr@Xz@FhZd/lx0E7dxUtahNDQKaqvnU2MWdgDUnnaw4NqVS9f6m4oJVCvU4k@ChjdiCVFvauO9TiUQJlTxjVdOAw0woxTR10GLRYE0UXY4S2AbQJphQoxYSgukYhZPiPYGuRbwQHzhfhQ7ERJfDyI7JQ@SMyBoevYMA3gvlnS8sUNi0sX7XMi0XR/AP45OkOE@fe)

Answer (score 0):

In Go you can do this 153 bytes

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    t,_ := time.Parse(`15:04`, os.Args[1])  
    fmt.Print(t.Add(time.Minute).Format(`15:04`))
}
```

[Try it online](https://play.golang.org/p/QaiiZ6lofOl)

Comment: Welcome to the site.  I'm a little confused as to how you are counting bytes here.  The first block is ~174 bytes and the second block is 78 bytes, so I'm not sure what code you are counting.  I also don't think either of these take any input? They seem to do the operation on in the first case a fixed string and in the second case it seems to expect the input in a variable named `i`.  You can see a variety of ways you can take input [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/).

Comment: I was counting just by selecting code, and seeing whatever Sublime gave me. About input output, also wasn't  sure how to deliver data. I fixed my answer to take input from cmd line.

Comment: Hm. I have no idea what sublime is doing. Maybe it isn't counting whitespace or something? You can use TIO to get an accurate score [link](https://tio.run/##NYyxCsIwFEX39xWPTgmUkIAuAYcubkJ3ERvatARJUpLXSfz2WKPe6cI95y6xlNWMD7NY9MYFAOfXmAgZ4J5m9tR8GzlvfzXmBjjAvIWxSozjsy7U3lGf8IOK3qRs2aCOWh6GFmMWXVryVd04YoX3a9EnF4iR6KaJVeviwkaWi3NM3tBf5xxepRQptVRv). We also have a [tips question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/41862) where you can get tips on golfing in go. I can already see that there are some ways that you could shorten this so try looking at that and playing around with whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

## [K](https://code.kx.com/q/basics/exposed-infrastructure/), 9 bytes

```
-3!1+-5!x
```

## [Q](https://code.kx.com/q/), 14 bytes:

```
string 1+"U"$x
```

### Explanation

Q is evaluated from right to left:

```
         "U"$x          // Cast input x into the minutes types
       1+               // Add one (automatically casted into minutes)
string                  // Cast to string
```

For this specific input string, the casting part can also be written as

```
parse x
```

Resulting in a quite readable 16 bytes:

```
string 1+parse x
```

Replacing `string` and `parse` with the K [internal function](https://code.kx.com/q/basics/internal/) equivalents (`-3!` and `-5!` respectively) we get:

```
-3!1+-5!x
```

[image: q/kdb+ CLI]

Comment: Minor caveat: input `23:59` will yield `24:00` output, not `00:00`. This can be fixed adding `mod`:  `-3!1440 mod 1+-5!x` (+9 bytes).

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>118 114 113</s> 112 bytes

**New version**

```
i=input();t=[-1]*59+[59];h=[0]*24+[-23];a=int(i[:2]);b=int(i[3:]);print(f'{a+h[a+int(t[b]/30)]:02}:{b-t[b]:02}')
```

**Old version:**

```
i=input();t=(1,0)*59+(-59,1);h=[0]*24+[-23];a=int(i[:2]);b=int(i[3:]);print(f'{a+h[a+t[b*2+1]]:02}:{b+t[b*2]:02}')
```

**Older version:**

```
i=input();t=[(1,0)]*59+[(-59,1)];h=[0]*23+[-24];a=int(i[:2]);b=int(i[3:]);print(f'{a+h[a]+t[b][1]:02}:{b+t[b][0]:02}')
```

[Try it here!](https://tio.run/##LcpBCsMgEIXh4yRGpGZsoBnxJMMsdFF0k0qYLkLo2W2E7N73@Osh@bO5V91bK6Fs9Suj8hLIzDwtq6ZlZZ8DWZ7gqcmAYx@vTsZCCKx8uuHwQt073sMZdaaoO4QSP5xVjBZ@eCbTj74H1RoAAvwB)

**Cleaner version**

```
i=input()
t=[1]*59+[-59]
h=[0]*24+[-23]
a=int(i[:2])
b=int(i[3:])
print(f'{a+h[a+int(t[b]/-30)]:02}:{b+t[b]:02}')
```

A somewhat dumb but interesting approach I tried, I am pretty sure I can probably shorten this somewhere by 15-20~ Bytes, I will have to check it again later. The method uses two lookup arrays to figure out what to do with the date. Its worse than the other answers, but I thought its interesting enough to leave in after golfing it a bit. I am not really good at this yet haha.

Some thoughts that would be interesting to discuss, I see a few places where I can see an improvement being possible, but not sure how:

1. In the part (`a=int(i[:2]);b=int(i[3:]);` this saves a number of bytes since I use a and b alot, but its still a very... ugly solution for the lack of a better word, I looked into `a,b=map(int,i.split(":"))` which looks neater but unfortunately has the exact same size. I am still looking for a better solution here though.
2. I really hate how the lists/tuples are initialized, must be a better way..

Edit: I legitimately have no idea how I came up with this madness, but some weird maths helped me remove an extra byte, somehow haha...

I am certain I can push this further later..

Dang, just as I posted this I thought of a simple change with the signs that did save me another byte.

Answer (score 0):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang) (v2.0-alpha), 70 bytes

```
;=t+1+*+0=iP60Gi 3 2O++G=x+'0'%/t 60 24-Lx 2 2':'(G=x+'0'%t 60-Lx 2 2)
```

[Try it online!](https://knight-lang.netlify.app/v2#WyI7PXQrMSsqKzA9aVA2MEdpIDMgMk8rK0c9eCsnMCclL3QgNjAgMjQtTHggMiAyJzonKEc9eCsnMCcldCA2MC1MeCAyIDIpXG4iLCIyMzo1OSJd)

Comment: you don't need the parens (btw you can use the minify button to remove al the excess whitespace and parens and stuff)

Comment: i was gonna suggest `+0` => `E` but i guess that's not part of the spec anymore

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 106 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBRS8MwFIXf@ysuZbAEZmg7O1i0giCyBweC@iQi2ZrWjDYtSTqQ0t9ek9gKsofAubkn37k3@sgqNoq6bZSBEzszYkTNyWdwcVU0qmaGPDDDX2396EvDVRA0hxM/GtgzIaEfc15AgTR9MUrIEmf9mVVQZhfvSFM8eyFRuNvRug7xzVNjx3Eu0jKlOdKrEpO26vReyM5wjWI8zYFKPIwBgEurbTBiqtQU7pVi3@@/0R@YwpsUBjLorRPADaJt5U0ojCIaReEKvEi8SGmaerGl6daJOKHXXiTW41vJ2rXwH1D9B8YzcD0DN54zZ1lgGs3AzWyOLNAT7XKABNxegSZC5uLINZ6mn@K47iq3kv1iJDCeWq1d2FQS6XDRu/sBsjtYTGakv5quyuHAKSwXvXL9JZ52GAJ3hmD8AQ)

```scala
def f(s:String)={val g=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");LocalTime.parse(s,g).plusMinutes(1).format(g)}
```

Ungolfed vesion. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZHRa8IwEMbf@1ccRTAFV2pdBcMcDMbwYcJg@jTGiJq6SJuWJHUM6d/eXWI6Ed@@u/vuy/1avWUF6zpR1pUycGBHFhtR8vgruGnllSqZiZ@Z4SusX1xpuAqCanPgWwNLJiScAoAdzyEnmsK7UULuo17A3I0BjqyAvN/H7k1mXOVvTkgSLha0LMPof9EegzuvFZ5ul@KaKc2JHl0iL2bJf1Znv2Ooi0YvhWwM12R8dnmHxyNXGW3gaUpEI0ztkelJKfb7cQb6RLS1FOYKTGPlTCRMEpok4QicSJ3IaJY5MaPZzIpxSu@dSNHjRunEji4M6jpw3AdO@sCpy@nfwsAs6QOnvTnBQJeIgEAEPNyBjoXciS3Xkb/eP8d1U1gk/IVERJEf1QhsCkl0ODjZfgvzRxh4M9HfVVPsYMMpDAcnZefDyDO07ku2Qdf9AQ)

```scala
import java.time._
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

object Main {
  def f(s: String): String = {
    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm")
    val time = LocalTime.parse(s, formatter)
    val newTime = time.plusMinutes(1)
    newTime.format(formatter)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val s = Array("00:00", "00:02", "05:55", "09:59", "12:49", "20:05", "23:59")
    val r = Array("00:01", "00:03", "05:56", "10:00", "12:50", "20:06", "00:00")

    for (i <- s.indices) {
      val result = f(s(i))
      println(s"${s(i)} => $result (should be: '${r(i)}')")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 21 bytes

```
24ʀ60ʀẊƛᵛ2Þ0':j]:?Ḟꜝi
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyJUIiwiIiwiMjTKgDYwyoDhuorGm+G1mzLDnjAnOmpdOj/huJ7qnJ1pIiwiIiwiMjM6NTkiLCIzLjQuMSJd)

Same as Vyxal 2, might be golfable with modular arithmetic tricks but I doubt it

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 95 bytes

```go
import."time"
func f(s string)string{F:="15:04"
t,_:=Parse(F,s)
return t.Add(Minute).Format(F)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VZDBSsQwEIbxmqcYAwsJxNLWrbiBCgvam7JobypL6bZL0aYlnYJS-iReFsGX8E30aUzT7MFLMnzJP_PP__G5bw7fbZa_ZPsC6qxShFR122j0aFkj_eqxPLv82R4ZVnVBSdmrHErWQYe6Uns-X0MiYxpE0l9SgmIr402mu4IlouNEF9hrBeitdzt2W6keC-4lja4zZAkf5zG_JzW-twWkU98-RxigUq2A4q11k2Ak8_DJKeMwECw67EDG8PicDmSgvi99nwqwRUBH4Vh4ZOeORTKKLDPFhWMrGa0mFtgmlgWhXM4slJFjoXm22qlw2vDcaf2j1ljdGM_4qhiN4xge0vV9CqainJSNhq3AybfOlEl-XmMgWW5hydAzq3NSlSazaf_TGDKbiO1ZMrroIL4Cc7JFx5-UGW0lYvomZhE3cY3_TcDN3TU4Ey71w2G-_wA)