# Isogram checker

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem

## Challenge :

Given a word, check whether or not it is an isogram.

---

## What :

An isogram is a word consisting only of letters with no duplicates (case insensitive). The empty string is an isogram.

---

## Examples :

```
"Dermatoglyphics"     ---> true
"ab"                  ---> true
"aba"                 ---> false
"moOse"               ---> false
"abc1"                ---> false
""                    ---> true
```

---

## Input :

You may accept input in any reasonable format

The input will only contain letters and/or numbers, no spaces (`[a-zA-Z0-9]`)

---

## Output :

- `true` or any truthy value if the input is an isogram
- `false` or any falsy value otherwise

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code in bytes in each language wins.

Comment: Suggested test case: `sad2`

Comment: Your definition of isogram includes two different contradictory statements.  Which is it?

Comment: @WhatWizard Neither. Wikipedia says nothing about digits.

Comment: @Adám Then why include the definition? I also don't see any other definition of the term used so what are we supposed to do?

Comment: Suggested rewording of ***entire*** post: *Given a word consisting of ASCII letters and digits (`[0-9A-Za-z]+`), determine whether it has any digits or case-insensitive duplicates.*

Comment: @Adám : Hi. I am going to update the post. Wait one second. Thanks

Comment: I would recommend that you start using the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) so that these issues can be caught prior to posting the challenge.

Comment: @MuhammadSalman This is very sloppy, please remove ". Any" from the end of you quote and give some more examples (`sad2das` would fail even without the `2` so it doesn't show anything).

Comment: The "What" and the "Notes" seem to contradict one another: "Implement a function that determines whether a string _that contains only letters_ is an isogram" (emphasis added) and "There may be numbers and those will and must return false" say opposite things. I have voted to close as unclear for the moment, but will happily retract it once that is cleared up!

Comment: Do output truthy and falsy values need to be consistent, or can they be different depending on the input?

Comment: @LuisMendo : I would rather prefer if they were consistent , though second one also works.

Comment: @Giuseppe : I updated both. Take a look

Comment: @AsoneTuhid : updated. Thanks , is this better?

Comment: @MuhammadSalman You should probably decide on a single way to handle digits, I suggest "return false if the word contains any digits" as that's what most of the answers assume. Please use the sandbox next time.

Comment: @AsoneTuhid : Oh well. I guess that works too. Updated

Comment: @AsoneTuhid : Added

Comment: @MuhammadSalman Can you add a test for mixed case in there too, where the repeated letters have different case, e.g. "Aab" - my initial solutions didn't cope with this and returned true instead of false.

Comment: Trivia: The Google Universal Analytics script contains a minified function whose seven parameters are named `i`, `s`, `o`, `g`, `r`, `a`, and `m`.

Comment: @Neil : I am quite well aware of that and its purpose as well.

Comment: @Neil : Although thanks

Comment: Sorry, I had no idea until I stumbled across it earlier today.

Answer (score 9):

## Python <s>2/</s>3, <s>36</s> <s>52</s> 48 bytes

```
lambda s:len(s)==len({*s.lower()}-{*str(56**7)})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYKic1T6NY09YWRFdrFevl5JenFmlo1uoCOSVFGqZmWlrmmrWa/wuKMvNKNNI01F1Si3ITS/LTcyoLMjKTi9U1NbngcolJiSj83Hz/4lQUkeLEFCOgwP//AA)

I take advantage of the fact that `set` contains only unique elements.  By invoking the `__len__` method of each, I can determine whether `s` also contains only unique elements (ignoring case).

EDIT: Updated to satisfy the previously-overlooked requirement to return False for numeric inputs. The set of all digits is encoded as `set(str(56**7))`.

EDIT 2: Following [this user suggestion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/50719/79945), I now take advantage of unpacking the arguments to set comprehension.  This formally breaks compatibility with Python 2.

Comment: welcome to PPCG! This also is supposed to return `false` when `s` contains a digit character.

Comment: is using `\`56**7\`` (as in the other python answer) instead of `str()` shorter? I'm not familiar with python but that seems to be the main difference between your two answers.

Comment: @Giuseppe python3 don't have `\`\``, a python2-only version would save 4 bytes (3 on this + 1 on division instead equals)

Comment: @Rod exactly right.  Funnily enough, the `56**7` was inspired by your own encoding of the digits 0-9 below, but saves on yours by 1 byte.

Comment: Perhaps you can add a Python 2 version? 46 Bytes: `lambda s:len(s)==len(set(s.lower())-{\`56**7\`})`

Comment: @SunnyPatel That does not actually work, unfortunately; you actually need to call `set` on `\`56**7\``.

Comment: Well I be damned. I didn't check the test case with a number. xD

Comment: Saves one byte: You can use `7/17` (`0.4117647058823529`) instead of `56**7`. It also includes a `.`, but since you're taking the difference from the input it doesn't matter since the input never contains a `.`.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
lDáÙQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/x@XwwsMzA///d0ktyk0syU/PqSzIyEwuBgA)

**Explanation**

```
l        # convert input to lower-case
 D       # duplicate
  á      # keep only letters
   Ù      # remove duplicates
    Q     # compare for equality
```

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 41 bytes

```r
!grepl("(.).*\\1|\\d",tolower(scan(,"")))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DccxCoAwDADAvb@wUyIi6Bvc/UCXaIMKrZGkIIJ/r8ItpzUdi5I@kLnsEg1rsylfCTz02LchDG8I0XdFktysYCud0HmPiNUo/hwt5LLMxu7f6CbWTEW29Fz7sVr9AA)

Regex approach. `!grepl(regex,scan(,""),F)` didn't work so I guess capturing doesn't match case-insensitively in R? I'm bad at regex in general, though, so I won't be surprised if I'm just doing it wrong...

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 58 bytes

```r
!anyDuplicated(c(el(strsplit(tolower(scan(,"")),"")),0:9))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcgxCoAwDEDRs9gpAQdXnb1IbAMWYitJRHr6WhA@b/jaJR9K2uBiP2sy7BOVtj@35EjOCSKwgLnaOA5epb6sYJEKzCEg/izbitiN0qh/)

Appends the digits `0:9` to the (lowercased) list of characters and tests if there are any duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>25 23</s> 21 bytes

-2 bytes on both thanks to Giuseppe

```ruby
->s{/(.).*\1|\d/i!~s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664Wl9DT1NPK8awJiZFP1Oxrrj2f4FCWrSSS2pRbmJJfnpOZUFGZnKxUqyCskJJUWkqF1g2MSkRKIIMlBXSEnOKodK5@f7FqSgKUKQTDdE0o0obJuKQ/g8A)

---

-2 bytes thanks to Kirill L.

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-n`, <s>21 19 18</s> 16 bytes

```ruby
p !/(.).*\1|\d/i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0BBUV9DT1NPK8awJiZFP/P/f5fUotzEkvz0nMqCjMzk4n/5BSWZ@XnF/3XzAA)

Comment: @Giuseppe I didn't think that would work, thanks

Comment: I think, in the second version, you don't even need `$_` - just throwing in a regex without anything else implicitly matches it against `$_`: [16 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0BBUV9DT1NPK8awJiZFP/P/f5fUotzEkvz0nMqCjMzk4n/5BSWZ@XnF/3XzAA)

Comment: @KirillL. thanks, I never saw `!/.../` before, can't even find it on [ruby-doc.org](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Regexp.html)

Comment: Not surprising, I also learned about it here after getting advice from some Perl guy :)

Comment: @KirillL. not surprising either, ruby weirdness is generally inherited from perl

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 4 bytes

```
ḷo⊆Ạ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pf/ahtw6Ompkcdy5VKikpTlfRqQMy0xJziVKXa04vK/z/csT3/UVfbw10L/v@PVnJJLcpNLMlPz6ksyMhMLlbSUUpMAhOJQDI33x@oC8RLNgRSSrEA)

The predicate will succeed if the input is an isogram and fail if it is not, outputting the lowercase Latin alphabet if it does succeed. Since Brachylog's `⊆` built-in predicate doesn't exactly match the ordinary relationship between a subset and superset, I had to spend a byte on sorting the lowercased input, but saved a byte on not having to explicitly check for duplicates in it. (If it didn't need to fail with numbers, we could just use `ḷ≠`.)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <strike>29</strike> 25 bytes

```javascript
s=>!/(.).*\1|\d/i.test(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAr1QnjTI8h516hhex1QxzxZUg6O82c5nHkC0h1znhAc2pRmrrFya4GLX89LEEUYEqI94sJsIIIqJnjg07lNtU9PHNZ7AkBz51zkQCvrYf)

Thanks for the update on answer to *@BMO* , *@l4m2* , *@KevinCruijssen*

-4 bytes thanks to *@KevinCruijssen*

Comment: `s=>!/(.).*\1|[^a-z]/i.test(s)`?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen : I didn't see the updated version

Comment: I'm pretty sure `[^a-z]` can be replaced with `\d`

Comment: @KevinCruijssen : Thanks. updated

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
§=f√ü_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9By27RHHbMO74n///9/cWKKEQA)

#### Explanation

```
§=f√ü_  -- takes a string as argument, eg: "sAad2"
§       -- fork the argument..
  f√    -- | filter out non-letters: "sad"
    ü_  -- | deduplicate by lower-case: "sAd2"
 =      -- ..and compare: 0
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) 2.0, <s>12</s> 11 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to Nit*

```
v
f\l â eUq
```

[Test it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=dgpmXGwg4iBlVXE=&input=ImFiYzEi)

Comment: Uh, why did you change the version to a longer one? Also, I think the last version of Japt is 1.4.4...

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer The original didn't account for numbers automatically returning false.

Comment: Ah, so you used an alpha version because it's actually shorter.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Right. The regex would've cost +2 in vanilla Japt. https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=diBmIiVsIiDiIMqlVWw=&input=ImExIg==

Comment: Matched with vanilla Japt, not using regex makes it equal length: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162672/16484

Comment: 11 bytes: https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=dgpmXGwg4iBlVXE=&input=InNhZDIi

Comment: @Nit Thanks! Good use of `e`

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 16 bytes

```
Ci`(.).*\1|\d
^0
```

Returns `1` as Truthy and `0` as Falsey values.
Thanks *@Neil* for discovering and fixing a bug in my initial code.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8N85M0FDT1NPK8awJiaFK87g/3@X1KLcxJL89JzKgozM5GKuxCQgSuTKzfcvTgWykg25HJ1AYolJScnJhkbGAA)

**Explanation:**

```
C             Check if the input matches part of the following regex:
 i`            Case insensitivity enabled
               Check if part of the input matches either:
  (.)           A character `C`
     .*         followed by zero or more characters
       \1       followed by the same character `C` again
         |     Or
          \d    A digit
^0             Invert Truthy/Falsey, basically replacing every 0 with a 1,
               and every other value with a 1
```

Comment: Why is yours opposite ?

Comment: @MuhammadSalman Two reasons: reversing the matches would cost more bytes. And I'm not too skilled with Retina so I'm not sure how to reverse the matches to begin with.. xD

Comment: reason 1). Ah ok. reason 2). LOL

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 12 bytes

```js
;v
oC ¬â eUq
```

Explanation:

```js
;v
;         // Set alternative default vars, where C is the lowercase alphabet
 v        // Make the implicit input lowercase and reassign it
oC ¬â eUq
oC        // Remove all items from the input that are not in the alphabet
   ¬â     // Split into chars and select unique array items
      eUq // Check if the result is equal to the input split into chars
```

[Try it here.](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=O3YKb0MgrOIgZVVx&input=IkRlcm1hdG9nbHlwaGljcyI=)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 9 bytes

```
kt2Y2X&X=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P7vEKNIoQi3C9v9/9cTEpBR1AA)

```
k   % Lowercase implicit input
t   % Duplicate that
2Y2 % Push lowercase alphabet
X&  % Intersection of alphabet and duplicate lowercase input
X=  % Check for exact equality.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 46 bytes

```python
lambda s:s.isalpha()*len(s)==len({*s.lower()})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY2xCsMgFEX3fsVrFjUEaekWcOveD2g7vKSmEYyKTygh@O3WkDvcw13ODWuavbuVSb2KxWX4IFBP0hDaMCMXrdWOk1Bq59aStP6nIxdZlMlHIDAOnuyu44LJf@0aZjMS64DhcDTuWPyD9LHH60727k9QE6JxibNmy00PW2aySquJUwdTvYWzgosQpfwB)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 91 bytes

```powershell
param($b)($a=[char[]]$b.ToUpper()|group|sort c*)[0].Count-eq$a[-1].count-and$b-notmatch'\d'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hcc7DgIhEADQq1iQACYQtbfyClqxFMMnUuwy48DGZu8@Jr7uEX4rj1bXVYSAYTMqWaPgHnIDDjGq5J/4Iqps7PFm3OkYyPOUzzZcon/g3qerHwXBXaPP/0IvKrmOc4OZm16KFhE9oNz0Dw)

Naive solution, but I can't come up with a better algorithm. Takes input `$b`, converts it `ToUpper`case, casts it as a `char`-array. Pipes that array into `Group-Object` which constructs a object that has name/count pairs for each input letter. We then `sort` that based on the `c`ount and take the `0`th one thereof. We check that its `.Count` is `-eq`ual to the `.Count` of the last `[-1]` pair. If so, then the counts are all equal, otherwise we have a different amount of letters.

We then `-and` that with checking whether the input `-notmatch`es against `\d` to rule out any digits in the input. That Boolean result is left on the pipeline and output is implicit.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
ŒufØA⁼QƲ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opNK0wzMcHzXuCTy26f///y6pRbmJJfnpOZUFGZnJxQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>57</s> 56 bytes

```python
x=input().lower()
print len(set(x)-set(`763**4`))/len(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzLCsMgFET3fsUlGzXQFtIXBLLrvp/QWHPbCEZFb6n5emugi5mzOMyElWbvuqL9hEPTNCUPxoUPCbm3/otRSBaicQQWnUhIIsvdhvF6ObbtaZTysJksSx2zl4/wAOOAA2/PPQOKa48ZNWz/DDBrDNQHlVLhN4yLIv@2a5iNTpxx9VS1F39PWJnU1P1Rw38)

First it turn then input into a set, removing the duplicates, then remove the digits (encoded in `` `763**4` ``), then check if the length is the same as the original input

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>61</s> 39 bytes

```java
s->!s.matches("(?i).*((.).*\\2|\\d).*")
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jY7BboMwDIbvfQqPUzKp0dYrWqdNu64XjmMHE1IICwnCoVK18ezULVynItmWLX@//Td4wm1T/kzaIRF8ovW/GwDro@mPqA0criNAEYIz6EGLLPbWV0Ay5cXIyUERo9VwAA8vMNF2/0CqxahrQyIRr1aqRyEU1zzf/eV5yV0ip3QWd0PhWLzcOAVbQss2lkdf3yhnC9mZomlVGKLqeBOdF15pkXyYnn@Fyp272mpK5M3Z/zwWKxC8y7ThicyKS/r5LvT2vsLTAoybcboA)

```java
s->  // Method with String parameter and boolean return-type
  !s.matches("(?i).*((.).*\\2|\\d).*")
     //  Return whether the input does not match the regex
```

Regex explanation:

[`String#matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) implicitly adds `^...$`.

```
^(?i).*((.).*\2|\d).*$
 (?i)                      Enable case insensitivity
^    .*                    Zero or more leading characters
       (       |  )        Followed by either:
        (.)                 Any character `C`
           .*               with zero or more characters in between
             \2             followed by that same character `C` again
               |           Or:
                \d          Any digit
                   .*$     Followed by zero or more trailing characters
```

Answer (score 1):

### Visual Basic for Applications (32 bit), 102 bytes

```vb
s=LCase(InputBox(u)):j=1:For i=1To Len(s):k=Mid(s,i,1):j=j*0^Instr(i+1,s,k)*(k Like"[a-z]"):Next:?j<>0
```

Used the fact that in VBA `0^x` yields 1 if x is zero and 0 otherwise. Run in immediate (debug) window.

Edit: as pointed out by Taylor in the comments this only works in 32 bit installs of MS Office.

Comment: If you restrict your language to Excel VBA, then you can swap this over to `s=LCase([A1]):j=1:For i=1To Len(s):k=Mid(s,i,1):j=j*0^InStr(i+1,s,k)*(k Like"[a-z]"):Next:?j<>0` for 95 bytes by taking input from `[A1]`. Also, it is worth noting that because [Exponentiation in VBA is weird](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143645/61846) that this solution is restricted to 32 bit installs of office.

Comment: Also, you can make your answer look better and more readable by using proper capitalization (see above) and adding a `<!-- language-all: lang-vb -->` flag to your answer to add syntax highlighting

Comment: @TaylorScott thanks! Added syntax highlighting and noted de 32 bit restriction. About the Excel input, I'd rather keep the solution application-invariant whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 12 bytes

Anonymous tacit function.

```apl
(∪≡~∘⎕D)819⌶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wSNRx2rHnUurHvUMeNR31QXTQtDy0c924ByCuouqUW5iSX56TmVBRmZycXqXECxxCQolQimc/P9i1OhIsmGYIY6AA)

`819⌶` lowercase

`(`…`)` apply the following tacit function on that:

`~∘⎕D` remove **D**igits from the argument

`∪≡` are the unique elements of the argument identical to that?

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 22 bytes

```perl6
{!(.uc~~/(.).*$0|\d/)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJZq@79aUUOvNLmuTl9DT1NPS8WgJiZFX7P2vzVXcSJIgYZSYmKSkiaC64jKTUxKNkTmZ2SmFuWn51QWlCYXK2n@BwA)

No matches for some character then later the same character. Implicit function as a code block, match implicitly on $_, invert book with `!`. Added `|\d` (ta Adam) but also needed `.uc~~`, which needed parentheses...

#### Alternative with Bags, 23 bytes

```perl6
{.uc.ords.Bag⊆65..97}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJZq@79arzRZL78opVjPKTH9UVebmamenqV57X9rruJEkAoNpcTEJCVNBNcRlZuYlGyIzM/ITC3KT8@pLChNLlbS/A8A)

This one normalises case then makes a bag (set with incidence counts). Subset or equal only true if all members are members of the comparison Bag, and all incidence counts are less than or equal to those in the comparison Bag. So any repeats or digits would make the comparison false.

Comment: Fails on `abc1`.

Comment: Ah, wrote this answer before the numbers spec was added.

Comment: Can;t you just add `|\d`?

Comment: @Adám: Sort of. Realised it also didn't detect repeated letters if the cases of those letters was different, so needed to normalise case and add parens as well.

Comment: Can't you use `(?i)` to make the regex case insensitive?

Comment: Seem to have hit a bug in that regard: https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/1749

Comment: [19 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJZq@79aUV9DT1NPS8WgJiZFvzZfrTT5vzVXcSJIVkMpMTFJSRPBdUTlJiYlGyLzMzJTi/LTcyoLSpOLlTT/AwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>87</s> <s>85</s> 83 bytes

- Saved <s>two</s> four bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat).

```c
f(s,p,b,P)char*s,*p;{for(b=s;*s;++s)for(p=b*=*s>64;b&&p<s;b=(*s^*p++)&95?b:0);s=b;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7RS8MwEMaf3V9xPVmXpBmsoAMX41D2rg97EhGarN0Kaxt6BdGxv72mnbIOFrgc3/347js73Vrbthkj6aSRb9zuklqQFE4dsqpmRpMSpKKIeCedNkILeprfKROG7pGU0UzQp3BRxMOH@6VZzLgibdSxvd2kWV6msGbU1BLqlDi4Oi@bjGHG4APH5EtYDhrGG1h2vx@VKKE3xPOp7/u07PxcwgQmEoIg@5N@31mC1t0AloAIC0BgAUeuRkWSl4wfRjdrhqu0LpKm2u6/3S635GNi3oPEIAzfACR4CWYnUFSvlOIVkBgb4zXHZcJ/Ro9m3oSDDc8D8WJX5zt/3r8G7CQ8Ora/)

Comment: @ceilingcat Fine suggestion, thanks.

Comment: @ceilingcat Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 29 bytes

```julia
s->!ismatch(r"\d|(.).*\1"i,s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@59m@79Y104xszg3sSQ5Q6NIKSalRkNPU08rxlApU6dY839uYoFGQVFmXklO3qOOGWk6ChpKLqlFQNX56TmVBRmZycVKOsoKIKCrq2unUFJUmsqllJgEE0QBKCoSsSkBq0hLzCkGKsnN9y9OxVSErCQxKdkQizHISpRAAjiUgJ2iqcn1HwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) with `-n -M5.010`, 17 bytes

```perl
say!/\d|(.).*\1/i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJRPyalRkNPU08rxlA/8/9/l9Si3MSS/PScyoKMzORirsQkIErkys33L04FspINubj@5ReUZObnFf/Xzfuv62uqZ2BoAAA)

Perl 5 port of my [Julia answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167479/8774).

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell, 32 bytes

```powershell
param($s)$s-notmatch'\d|(.).*\1'
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
v
¶r\L â
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=dgq2clxMIOI&input=IkFiYyI)

```
v\n¶r\L â     :Implicit input of string U
v             :Lowercase
 \n           :Reassign to U
   ¶          :Is equal to?
    r         :Remove
     \L       :  Regex /[^a-z]/gi
        â     :Deduplicate
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 32 bytes

```sh
c=${#${(uL)${(s::)1}}};((c<$#1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9P9lWpVpZpVqj1EcTSBZbWWka1tbWWmtoJNuoKBtqav5PTc7IV1CxV1AxrOXiSlMoLE8tKqmEMECsIiDTJbUoN7EkPz2nsiAjM7kYKJKYBCYSgWRuvn9xKpiXbAiklJT@AwA). Isogram/truthy returns `1`, otherwise `0`

Answer (score 0):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://github.com/ngn/k), 18 bytes

```
{(a^,/$!10)~?a:_x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqlojMU5HX0XR0ECzzj7RKr6i9n@JVbVKdGVdkVWaQoV1Qn62tUZCWmJmjnWFdaV1kWZsLVdJtJJLalFuYkl@ek5lQUZmcrGStWEsSDgxSUkBGcCFE1HErQ3Awrn5/sWpShjCiUnJhkqYqlFNBpv9HwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>25</s> <s>20</s> 22 bytes

```apl
''≡'(.).*\1|\d'⎕S'&'⍠1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wR19UedC9U19DT1tGIMa2JS1B/1TQ1WV1N/1LvAEKhCQT0xKVGdC0i7pBblJpbkp@dUFmRkJheDxXLz/YtTwazixBSjlESIaHExhA4udUpxLfJNDMl3z4ks8Mh0BosmJiUbqgMA)

Returns 1 for true, else 0.

Saved 5 bytes thanks to @H.PWiz

Fixed, and saved another byte thanks to @Adám

#### How?

```apl
''≡'(.).*\1|\d'⎕S'&'⍠1 ⍝ Tacit fn
                    ⍠1 ⍝ Ignore case
               ⎕S'&'   ⍝ Search and return the match(es)
   '(.).*\1|\d'        ⍝ For this regex
''≡                    ⍝ And compare to the empty string
```

Comment: Fails on `abc1`.

Comment: Isn't `\w` → `.` valid?

Comment: If you mean `(.).*\1`, no. It also fails for `abc1` :/

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by "it also fails"?

Comment: If you  [Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wR19UedC9U19DT1tGIM1R/1TQ1WV1N/1LvAECitoJ6YlKjOBaRdUotyE0vy03MqCzIyk4vBYrn5/sWpYFZxYopRSiJEtLgYQgeXOqW4FvkmhuS750QWeGQ6g0UTk5IN1QE) you can see it returns 1 for `abc1`, when it should return 0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76272/discussion-between-adam-and-j-salle).

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 11 bytes

```
qelA,s+_L|=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7BSgNBDIbv@xQ/40HQUqh3BaGXgtSDQk/FZmcz25HZme5M2rKoffU1XRHCH0LC98V@UjfyDXb9DpmpKaAQkBze3perNeoBDTs6Bpljw2hSvBWcKQpkTwKXMgjCRVCTCOdhVimsJJwZJXjL8KI0B0loWfS4SPaxVdchc@Eo14HgjtGKTxEUG0VzhNU/rqw/z/9ai0@qmZzzqr9szdhzeJ6V@4@X78fRPDy5r8vP@m40S84dSWrDcNh7W0xlqJ6CNLv0Wnia7EKb@QU)

## Explanation

The basic idea is to append each digit then check for duplicates. Since the append ensures that each digit is already present once, any further presence of digits will be a duplicate, causing it to return false.

```
q      e# read the input:            | "MOoSE1"
el     e# convert to lowercase:      | "moose1"
A      e# push 10:                   | "moose1" 10
,      e# range [0,N):               | "moose1" [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
s      e# string representation:     | "moose1" "0123456789"
+      e# concatenate:               | "moose10123456789"
_      e# duplicate:                 | "moose10123456789" "moose10123456789"
L|     e# union with the empty list: | "moose10123456789" "mose1023456789"
       e# (this gets rid of duplicates)
=      e# Equal to original:         | 0
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 76 bytes

```
func[s][a: charset[#"a"-#"z"#"A"-#"Z"]parse s[any[copy c a ahead not to c]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcmxDsIgEIDhvU9xOWYTXbuZ@ASOkhvO45AmFgjggC@P6WLa7f/yF3Xjrs7S5OfhP1FsJcszSOBStVmDjCeDXzR43eKBlLcD1XLsVlLuIMDAQdlBTA1aAiGikcsSG3jAm5aVW3q9ew6LVJz@h58H8E5rOlc9XLnsiOMH)

Answer (score 0):

### C#, 82 bytes

```
bool f(string s)=>!!(s.GroupBy(c=>c).Any(c=>c.Count()>1|(!Char.IsLetter(c.Key))));
```

edit: added test for char

edit: using GroupBy to shorten it by 5 byte

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I think you're missing the requirement that you also need to check that the input contains no digits.

Answer (score 0):

## Smalltalk, 57 bytes

Method to be defined in class String:

```
s^(self select:#isLetter)asUppercase asSet size=self size
```

This is most likely self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 114 bytes

```
proc I w {lmap c [set L [split $w ""]] {if {[regexp -all -nocase $c $w]>1|![string is alp $c]} {return 0}}
expr 1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5BCsIwEEX3PcV36LZgL@DKTUHwACGLGGINpE1IUqrEnD2m4sLOZuD/N7yJ0pTivJUYsCKZSThIsKAiLnU5oyPaFUScI@k7EvNqVE@HThiDbrZSBIVWVoif@veBhej1PEIHCONqwTOSV3HxM445N/XUo8/lK6rChs7KTyLa0bzcQ8tADYkb4X@2RNA@mew1KNozsqcdQ1XtlhjAhu29/CvKBw)

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 121 bytes

```
proc I w {lmap c [set L [split $w ""]] {if {[llength [lsearch -al -noc $L $c]]>1|![string is alp $c]} {return 0}}
expr 1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9BCoMwEEX3nuJ3cCvUC3TVjSD0AMFFGlINjDEkEVusZ09ju6l/M/D4zJuJilNyflJosGDlUTooiKAj2jwcm4hyAVHXYTUPrIJZ2z4OEBy09GpAJRmVzRvKFqXqukv9PokQvbE9TIBkt@MNq9dx9hbnbSv003nUW/r6sregq/ajjFPPLzcYFaggeSf8ZyeSjmScbkHTsaNqOnQoq90cA0STX8mH/JI@)

Still too long for my taste!

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 17 bytes

```
.Am&!t/rz0d}dGrz0
```

[**Test suite**](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.Am%26%21t%2Frz0d%7DdGrz0&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=Dermatoglyphics%0Aab%0Aaba%0AmoOse%0Aabc1%0A&debug=0)

Explanation:

```
.Am&!t/rz0d}dGrz0 # Code
  m           rz0 # Map the following over the lowercase input:
      /rz0d       #  Count occurrences of d in lowercase input
     t            #   minus 1
    !             #    inverted (0 -> True)
   &              #     and
           }dG    #      d is in the lowercase alphabet
.A                # Print whether all values are truthy
```

Python 3 translation:

```
z=input()
print(all(map(lambda d:not z.lower().count(d)-1and d in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",z.lower())))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, 82 bytes

An Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from range `[A1]` and outputs to the VBE immediate window.

```vb
[B1:B26]="=Len(A$1)-Len(Substitute(Lower(A$1),Char(Row()+95),""""))":?[Max(B:B)]<2
```

Answer (score 0):

### PHP, 137 Bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYzLbsIwEEX3@Qoz6sKWoEq2DY8Nez6goGiwJnUkxzZ@gCLEt6choCjtZjRzzz3jlOvXOzfMOhkZG2tYzT@CuDc1l7FzVKF2Cp@RuJNUlqP32FVX1InC@0imuSTi0iYTK6nQBx6ij1bbG/lRFWKx@c6XxUns8q@ifJAO9Ho3FDWZsfRCj/6ZM8j25FuM9kd3TjUysNWWQZnVHP4BYKLM3g6ex9ZQwjPMY5zsYZ@R1uaBJtbaQ6A/nixmoixm7AhHmBiIT2AZlP0v)

**Code, using ctype_alpha**

```
function f($s){if(ctype_alpha($s)){echo(count(array_unique(count_chars
(strtolower($s))))>2)?0:1;}
else{echo(strlen($s))?0:1;}}
```

**Explanation**

(I am absolutely sure this can be shortened)

```
function f($s){
 if(ctype_alpha($s)){     #ctype_alpha check if the string contains only letters
  echo
   (array_values(array_unique(count_chars(strtolower($s))))!= 
      [0,1])?0:1;
   #count_chars, retuns an array with the times each letter is appear in the string
   #array_unique, returns an array with only the unique values
   #the array values will be [0,1] if no letter repeated
 }else{
    #here the empty string gets controlled, and if the string contained numbers
  echo(strlen($s))?0:1;
 }
}
```

**Yes, i will try to reduce the bytes count :D**

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 20 bytes

```perl
$_=!/\d/*!/(.).*\1/i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lZRPyZFX0tRX0NPU08rxlA/8///xKTklLT0f/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDf7rFgAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 35 bytes

```cs
s=>s.ToDictionary(c=>c<65?c/0:c%32)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU1NSwMxEL3vrxiCwi5o/UIPtlkRexS8CB6sh3SYbQPbRDJTZVny29dsQj3M13vz3kO@RLbTM4r1bsUSrNu10IGeWLe8ePdrmykThhp1i6uH@ye8un7E87vbZlpWVZF8foEQC4MGR7/pGisAtaZwMOJ3/fC9t8jqYgbN9jRNWQ7@jemE4U3ZUo/JvfOBDO6h/jEhJ4B1JanJEVvvewjEx15StIQjLRMqYcgsQFfPz80MRkAjyaoQ/5rO9JxFMdWLd@x7WnwEK/RqHdVnaqPG2SNuFOgWxiKMKnnG6Q8)

Tests for success by [presence or absence of an exception](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/11908#11908).

When a character is a number, a divide-by-zero exception is thrown. Uppercase and lowercase letters normalized. A duplicate key exception will be thrown if the same character is used more than once.

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 112 bytes

Here's my (super long) take on this:

```cs
c=>{var k=c.ToLower().ToCharArray();return!Enumerable.SequenceEqual(k.Distinct(),k)|!c.Any(m=>char.IsDigit(m));}
```

It checks if the distinct version of the string is the same as the regular version, and if it is so, return false. Also return false if there is a digit in the string

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9Na8MwDIbP869wc7Khy2HXLIXSdh/QwaCDHsYOrqKlXhybyk5K6fLbO@2DMcqEQX6lV9ZjiJcQCE9dtL6Wq0NM2Bbir8pnwTmEZIOP@S16JAtnjqX1u0KAMzHKRwo1mVYexUVMJlmQfbCVfDDWq5iIp55fpKE6arbIs/g19LLkdhZNVZmYjbOag1MT9m@f8g6dC@tArmLBpitOmRgK8cp/MbBVvSHZSOtlr49ixuTBYb4mm5BZUTW6@KdacZ0bYhDiYhA/9Dedh@tvrvEmBDepyhOUk@PXhhLyp7AMeySl@TbbGpoSmYPSBWHqyI8WvmuRzIYXrXDXoQdc7DrjVJPPbUzWQ1J63Oj3EeRTf1BtOQF@Jb@Pc1vbpFomGk58PgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 43 bytes

```python
t=input().lower()
print len(set(t))==len(t)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYy9CgMhEITr@BRio9sEkiYQsMhPn0cIntncCXer6Ibknt7oNd/MB8OkladIx@rjC63WurINlD5sYD/HL2YDIuVALGckU5ANA1jbhaG2vXjHLJ8ykMyORjQnOIsd/tDL/ljVHfPiOI7zmqbgixLKDRtc4xIfBTfzhxa9XYarv6k/)

Expects a quote-delimited string from STDIN as input.

Converts the input to lowercase to make comparisons case-insensitive, then compares the number of unique values to the total number of

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) `-Do=1<<*s%32`, <s>53+12</s> 47+12 = 59 bytes

```c
i;f(char*s){for(i=o;i&o&&*s/58;i^=o)s++;s=!*s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYvBCoJAFEX3fUUJysyYhEkQjLNz3w9EML0cfaA@mecmxF9virbl7nLuOZA1ACGgdgJa6xXL2ZEXaEhjQkmi@HA6a7wZkpymms1OsV5Cb3EQcjtvRo/D5EQUP65DtP@Mqva9najpnmOLwJGU@ley9zVu/x89XbheayBfqb50CS9wnW04ZBWZvCwVx8XxDQ)

---

Uses the bits of `i` to store whether a letter has been encountered.

```c
#define o 1<<*s%32  //byte corresponding to letter *s
i;f(char*s){
    for(i=o;        //mark first character
        i&o&&*s/58; //until character duplicate (i&o) or end of string or number (*s/58)
        i^=o)       //toggle the character
        s++;        //step through string
    s=!*s;          //return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### [MBASIC](https://archive.org/details/BASIC-80_MBASIC_Reference_Manual), 202 bytes

```
1 DIM A(26):INPUT S$:FOR I=1 TO LEN(S$):P=ASC(MID$(S$,I,1))
2 IF P>96 THEN P=P-96
3 IF P>64 THEN P=P-64
4 IF P>26 THEN 7
5 A(P)=A(P)+1:NEXT:FOR I=1 TO 26:IF A(I)>1 THEN 7
6 NEXT:PRINT"true":END
7 PRINT"false"
```

It's ugly but it works. Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0):

**Swift, 106 bytes**

```
func j(s:String){var a:Set<Character>=[];for c in s{if c<"0"||c>"9"{a.insert(c)}};print(s.count==a.count)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc2xDsIgEIDhVyFMsDQOLrali75Bx8bhcoEWo9AcV42hPDtq3P7p@9PLOz7W6raA4qZSOzL5MOv8BBLQjpb78wIEyJYGM107F0mg8EGk7J3AXh7kvuMgTzJD40OyxAp1Kd36dVilBuMW2Bj4hy71d5EXSw/gON/f6@IxSV0/)

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
⇩:ǍU=
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwi4oepOseNVT0iLCIiLCJEZXJtYXRvZ2x5cGhpY3NcbmFiXG5hYmFcbm1vMHNlXG5hYmMxXG5cIlwiIl0=)

### Explained

```
⇩:ǍU=
⇩     # input to lowercase
 :    # dup
  ǍU  # remove non-letters and uniquify
    = # are the top two stack items equal?
```

Comment: https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLih6nHjcOedSIsIiIsIiJd   4 bytes with the is unique builtin

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), <s>30</s> 22 bytes

```
{32|}%..26,{97+}%--.|=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPkfreSSWpSbWJKfnlNZkJGZXKykoJSYBCYSgWRuvn9xKpiXbAikgKg4McVQKbb6f7WxUU2tqp6ekZlOtaW5dq2qrq5eje3/WtU8rf8A)

Link includes test cases.

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 13 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 10.7 bytes

```
UDgAzsAqkZUJ=
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhZrQ13SHauKHQuzo0K9bCFiUKkF611Si3ITS_LTcyoLMjKTiyHCAA)

##### Explanation

```python
UDgAzsAqkZUJ=  # Implicit input
UD             # Convert to lowercase and duplicate
  g     k      # Filter for characters which:
     sAq       #  are in
   Az          #  the lowercase alphabet
               #  (i.e. letters only)
         ZU    # Uniquify
           J   # Join by ""
            =  # Are they equal?
```